# Let's burn down the close queue!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

> ***Stage 2 completed:** The initial phase of the burndown was completed on 2014-03-03 10:48:49; the second phase completed on 2014-03-08 at 19:41. Detailed statistics on how these played out can be found on [Phase 1 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue/223605#223605) and [Phase 2 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue/224663#224663).*
>
> *There remains much work to be done! You can find reasonably up-to-date tag filters [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue/223498#223498). We'll be examining the results of the initial burndown to optimize the system for faster, easier reviews in the near future. For details on overall progress, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208311/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue*

So, this happened: [Fuzzy the number of questions in the close review queue, a dopamine for the shutterers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut)

Now, only questions with [at least 4 votes or flags or at least one Do Not Close review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223605) are listed in [the close review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/). If you're thinking, "that's crazy!" THEN YOU'RE RIGHT! This *dramatically* reduces the utility of the queue. But, we've had [one or two complaints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=close+review+queue+size) about the size of the backlog, so it's time we took care of it.

## [So let's take care of it!](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/)

[image: Kill it with fire]
[image: Kill it with MOAR fire!]

Most of the questions listed now are either really terrible or perfectly fine, so they're pretty easy to review:

- Is it a duplicate? **click Close**
- Looks like crap? **click Close**
- Doesn't look like crap? **click Leave Open**
- Can't make up your mind? **click Skip**

If everyone reading this did a dozen reviews, we'd have the queue empty in a day... but since a fair number of you probably *can't* review posts in the close queue, it'll take a bit longer. Hopefully not *too* much longer...

If you can't help - or just don't want to - that's cool; this backlog has been almost three years in the making; it's not so crucial that we deal with it *now*.

If you *can* help and *want* to help, **[then you might want to start here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251490/1523648)** - it's a list of the top 250 tags according to how many review items are associated with them, and a link directly to a filtered review queue. Pick a tag you know something about, and see how long it takes you to get to...

[image: There are no items for you to review, matching the filter]

The faster we get through this, the faster we get to go back to the non-crazy (or at least, slightly less-fuzzy) close queue.

**[View our progress so far here!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223605)**

Comment: I feel fuzzy...

Comment: Can you please include a gif of a woman blasting fire too? It's not all males on SO :p

Comment: "one or two complaints" - 112 results. Not incorrect - it's all ones and twos. :)

Comment: @Mysticial In binary it's all 0's and 1's. So it's even more correct. :P

Comment: Couldn't you lower the rep threshold? At least temporarily? The community thinks it's a problem, and I want to help. Only got 1,343 rep, tho. Maybe for us low-reps, we can only see some subset of the queue that is more obvious than the rest.

Comment: @bjb568 Don't worry, the close queue will still have thousands of questions in it when you get to 3k rep.

Comment: One definite thing is that this would encourage _robo-like_ reviewing.

Comment: I will be monitoring for robots, @dev.

Comment: I just ran into a review that had only 3 close votes.  Is it expected?

Comment: Yes, @dev - some will have a combination of flags and votes, others will have a combination of flags/votes and Do Not Close reviews.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, we now have gender parity in flame throwing.

Comment: Maybe we really need to up the number of close vote reviews someone can do (based on rep and/or audit pass rate). I just reached my 40 limit in ~20 minutes.

Comment: `status-completed-from-my-end`

Comment: I think all events on StackOverflow should be "until crispy"! :-D

Comment: There should be button like "No effort taken", as many questions could be simply resolved by searching SO or Google or by reading docs.

Comment: Lower the rep requirement to 2k and i'll help :)

Comment: Also a bug report [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4089500), post has a single close vote still am seeing that in the review que

Comment: Wow, I just got to cast the final vote on something like 8 questions in a row - this feels so addictively *good*, I could go on for hours :). Thanks for finally implementing this, it's so much more rewarding than the old way.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I though I recognised that from somewhere ;)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian omg....I can't ask for any better :D aigooo!!!

Comment: If this is an event... we should get rewards =/

Comment: @PeterM There is. It's that arrow-shaped button just below the question score. But that consideration has no direct bearing on whether to close — often it means closing as a duplicate but you still need to locate the duplicate (or confirm the duplicate that someone else found).

Comment: This should be [meta-tag:featured]! Once I get over 3k rep, I’ll help.

Comment: This is depressing me... I clicked on my favorite tag and so far of the first 10 reviews, I've voted to leave them all open. I take my time when reviewing, and this is making me feel that the people who add stuff to the close vote queue are disappointingly stupid. All they're doing it wasting my time.

Comment: I think my biggest issue is people who are using the close reasons incorrectly. "Not enough research" -> must be off topic, "Too easy" -> must be off topic. "Not enough code in question" -> must be unclear. This is not correct. Close reasons should be used on questions they adequately fit. If you start closing questions for incorrect reasons then it devalues the close vote system, and each vote has less of an impact to users. They start to say "don't worry, that close vote was probably just because someone didn't like xyz" instead of "I need to fix my question because of abc"

Comment: @Rachel - One thing I noticed is that quite a few of the questions with 4 close votes were for the old close reasons. e.g. "minimal understanding". Now those reasons are gone from the close dialogue but the previously cast votes still remain. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: @MartinSmith Nope, the majority of the ones I am going through are either Off-Topic or Duplicate, with the occasional Unclear or Too-Broad. And of those, the vast majority of the Off-Topic ones seem to be ones that a user has deemed to lack research, or is too easy. That is not my definition of "Off Topic", so am voting to Leave Open a lot...

Comment: BTW I see the Close Review number is now 10.4k. But what was it when you initially posted this 13 hours ago? Has the event had much effect?

Comment: Up-vote my SO answers 42 times and I'll work the close review queue 20x a day!

Comment: @Tanner - Yes I realise that. My question is what effect it has had so far. What was the close vote number immediately after the change?

Comment: @MartinSmith ah ok, from the last few hour or so it's definitely going down which is a nice change.

Comment: What if I prefer my `close queue` to be `medium-rare`?  Never been a fan of overcooked close queues.

Comment: There are a few thousand more questions on the back burner, @mattblang ;-)

Comment: @MartinSmith You can view some stats [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). Currently 10,130 need review, and 9,398 have been reviewed today. So its definitely gone down some (I think having this meta post featured on the main page is helping).

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of questions here that don't need to be closed, @Rachel. That's why we've rejected all of those naive "solutions" to the backlog involving auto-close, more close votes, more close vote *weight*, etc. To be fair, right now the queue contains a roughly-equal mix of the *good* and the *ugly*, so depending on where you're looking you can probably hit 90% for either Close or DNC reviews.

Comment: Down to 9.8k!  Yay!

Comment: Also, don't forget - you can close more than 40 per day, if you send the extra 20 or so (assuming you 'vote to close' 30 out of 40) to 'new window' and close them from the question screen, and 'skip' in the queue. :)

Comment: The sad thing: i want to help but i can't help. Oh i hate my reputation. (:

Comment: Go answer some questions then, @Marco ;-)

Comment: I can't help but being mystified about this.  With the queue now only having questions that have 4 close votes, the only possible way it can be *burned down* is to close all those questions.  It is almost inevitable that *somebody* is going to add the missing vote, given the call-to-arms.  It takes only one of many users looking at this.  So lets cut this short, stop wasting everybody's time and boredom and just instantly close them all.  Exact same outcome, instant burn-down.

Comment: What does that prove, other than what I predicted would happen?  Tell me that a single DoNotClose removes a question from the queue like a single Close does and I can make *some* sense of it.

Comment: For roughly 10% of the current queue, that's true @Uphill. For 2/3rds of the queue, it's 2 DNC reviews. About 1/3rd of the queue (as of right now) can be eliminated with a single close vote per task. Like I said, a mixed bag: this is mostly stuff that fell through the cracks over the past year. If it was clear cut, we'd have just cleared it out months ago.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Adgx9wt63NY

Comment: @Shog9 is this all your doing? Or are other team members helped to formulate this final war against the close queue? Better if we know who to send flowers and chocolates to... ;)

Comment: Heh. heh.... wow.

Comment: I've found the recent push to "fix" the queue really damaging.  Folks are flagging questions to be closed without any idea as to what is a good question, and what isn't.  **Very** often now I see questions closed with no real cause.  I think that there are too many folks with these abilities on the site, and it has gotten out of control.  Maybe this is actually why the queue is so big... so many people are voting just because they can.  What a mess this has become, and the "fix" doesn't seem to be helping content quality any.

Comment: @Brad Could you please compile a list of these questions, and then start a new question on meta about this?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I will do that as I come across them over the next couple days.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my comment will get lost in this long list, but here goes. A lot of the CLOSE votes on Android come from ppl who don't participate in Android Qs or As. C# ppl, PHP ppl etc. A lot of the CLOSE votes don't show an understanding of the OS - I find this to be a horrible problem with the community here, and as such I find myself often voting to reopen questions. Cool, that probably says more about me than about the rest of us... so its just IMHO

Comment: Is there a function to comment on the reviews of the posts? I think I've looked but I still haven't found what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Brad I would upvote that comment 100 times if I could. You are spot on.

Comment: Can you please include a gif of a guy with brown hair blasting fire too? It's not all gingers on SO :p

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'll go chip in my dozen right now. I suppose for the time being "Close Votes" should be interpreted as having a double meaning (questions that are close to being voted to be closed).

Comment: Excellent work, have my 50 votes.

Comment: I'll just humbly say - IMO we're fighting the wrong battle here, we can't win. SO is facing the 'too big for its own good', it's only going to get worse. There're two ways to deal with it a) adjust the 'algorithm', rules of the game (math-wise speaking you can't win this way) - or b) introduce automated-help to reduce the clutter, i.e. make Q and A matching smarter, stuff like that (again probably some rules change will be required). Instead of wasting time we should focus on making the s/w smarter.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier As an Android person here, I'm not seeing what you are... in fact, I'm seeing the opposite. A lot of bad questions are being closed, and not many good questions are being closed. Would you mind providing some examples of this?

Comment: [tag:featured] maybe?

Comment: @hichris123 if there was a handy way to report these issues I would do so. I know of no way to do that, other than to vote to reopen. I cannot think of examples now. Perhaps @ brad can help or @ lowerclassoverflowian. Or if there is a useful way to report these things, pls let me know. Thx for the interest at least tho.

Comment: @hichris123 with all due respect to the closers who have WAY MORE rep than u or me, here is one example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider with a good answer provided as well.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do questions with 2 or 3 votes keep popping up in the queue?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier - That was closed in 2011 so clearly not as a result of this campaign. I'm not an Android person myself but part 3 of that question looks far too general (and could probably just be removed as it appears to have been ignored  by the two answers anyway). The OP should ask a specific question about coding for a particular task not a general request for code examples. Probably parts 1 and 2 could be made more specific as well without invalidating the existing answers. Editing the question would push it into the reopen queue.

Comment: @MartinSmith thx for reply but we are not meant to edit questions in a way that it changes the question. Or has that rule been changed or relaxed? It would be nice to be able to do that, although a dangerous privilege to give, and difficult to temper. So is it an option to edit someone else's question that has been closed?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier - It's fine to edit a question into shape such that it conforms to community guidelines and can be reopened. Of course you need to make sure it maintains the gist of the original and the answers still basically match the edited question though. So it needs someone with domain knowledge to do it.

Comment: Why are questions with an accepted answer in the queue? Are they really eligible for culling from SO? A vast swathe could be cut by removing them.

Comment: I think there is at least one good case for closing a question with an accepted answer - a duplicate of an older question with a better answer set.

Comment: @AndrewMorton just because someone answers a question that the OP accepts does not mean that the post should not be closed.  Too many people answer any question no matter if it is on or off-topic, or provide "opinions" to opinion based questions that still should be closed, or provide a link to a tool on tool request questions.

Comment: Agree with @AaronBertrand here. I finished my quota of 40 and now have to wait for the next 6 hours. I have another 1 hour in my hand and probably would be sleeping in the next 6 hours! Wish I could help you guys more...

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan and psubsee2003 Thank you for those reasons. It may reduce the number of times I click "Skip".

Comment: I'd really like to, but what can you do? You fail single review test and you have to wait 7 days...

Comment: Here are your last three failed audits, @aksu: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4189086) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4091480) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3933615) - figure out what went wrong there before you worry about reviewing anything else, please.

Comment: 2 of those were failed before my 2 day ban. Do i get 30 day ban after 7 days when i fail again?

Comment: No, because you're gonna figure out how you missed those blatantly-bad posts before then and won't fail such tests in the future, @aksu ;-)

Comment: What should be done with clear but zero effort questions? For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133615/how-to-find-substring-without-string-methods-using-char-arrays Should it be closed, and if so for what reason?

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I'm sorry, we're not all beards here, can we get a picture of a guy without a beard as well?

Comment: The number of reviews I could do today dropped to 20 :( I want to do more!

Comment: That should be possible before the day is out, @Szymon

Comment: There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[java] [javascript] [jquery]" yuppi :D:D!!!

Comment: I think it may be beneficial to release items back into the queue in blocks of 5-10K. Dumping 55K items into the queue runs the risk of dampening the effect of the threshold.

Comment: 54 items on the queue this morning... consider it crispy!

Comment: Empty queue. Well done gentlemen.

Comment: @zessx - Bit premature. Still 7 items left! (Edit: Now it's empty)

Comment: Only 1 item now!

Comment: Now it's officially empty :p

Comment: @Shog9 The queue is back to 13k but I haven't got 20 votes more :( Guess I'll have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: Yep full again sorry but what happened?

Comment: @JimmyKane - The close vote queue that was reduced to 0 was just a subset of the actual close vote queue. Now presumably another subset has been released.

Comment: @MartinSmith wow. ok that is probably the cause. Grrr. But how many are in total? Looks like waves from a tower defence game.

Comment: @JimmyKane before the subset feature was added the close vote queue was around 120K, so I assume that it's now around 100K. Just like tower defence the waves will probably become harder to burn. :p

Comment: Moving forwards: perhaps it would be useful if the review queue included all questions with any *recent* close votes (even just one) as well as those with a certain number of close votes?  The idea is that this might keep the backlog of hidden tasks from building up too much between burnfests.

Comment: I think what would substantially help the site get the close queue closed would be to lower the barrier to entry. Lower from 3K to 2K (or 2,500 even) and you get a ton more users who can help keep the queue lower? Theres so much chatter on here about this issue, sorry if i missed this suggestion. I really can't imagine a 2-2.5K reputation user would not yet understand the communities needs. Large issue, broaden your base. Thanks!

Comment: Shog, would you mind sharing updated details of reviewers breakdown, [like one you posted few months ago here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209409/165773)? I would like to learn if this effort caused any trends in reviewers involvement

Comment: Close vote are winning the battle :(

Comment: **This hasn't worked at all**. For my niche tags, encryption and cryptography, questions are simply not closed anymore. OK, they are not in the queue, but they keep mucking up the system and coming up in searches. Besides that, the queue is still way out of bounds.

Answer (score 145):

### Questions in the close review queue by tag (top 250 tags)

The number next to the tag indicates how many *tasks* remain in the queue. Each task may require one or more Close or Do Not Close reviews before it is removed.

- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=javascript&burn=1) ×**1577**
- [php](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=php&burn=1) ×**1406**
- [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jquery&burn=1) ×**923**
- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=html&burn=1) ×**800**
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=java&burn=1) ×**778**
- [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mysql&burn=1) ×**656**
- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=css&burn=1) ×**567**
- [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=c%2B%2B&burn=1) ×**272**
- [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=arrays&burn=1) ×**242**
- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ios&burn=1) ×**209**
- [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sql&burn=1) ×**199**
- [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=objective-c&burn=1) ×**187**
- [c](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=c&burn=1) ×**184**
- [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=linux&burn=1) ×**182**
- [database](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=database&burn=1) ×**174**
- [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ajax&burn=1) ×**160**
- [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=wordpress&burn=1) ×**156**
- [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=xml&burn=1) ×**152**
- [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=html5&burn=1) ×**150**
- [json](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=json&burn=1) ×**150**
- [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=vb.net&burn=1) ×**110**
- [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=asp.net&burn=1) ×**102**
- [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=networking&burn=1) ×**99**
- [string](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=string&burn=1) ×**89**
- [forms](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=forms&burn=1) ×**89**
- [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=apache&burn=1) ×**88**
- [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=algorithm&burn=1) ×**81**
- [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sql-server&burn=1) ×**81**
- [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=unix&burn=1) ×**81**
- [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=css3&burn=1) ×**80**
- [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=.htaccess&burn=1) ×**76**
- [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mongodb&burn=1) ×**76**
- [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=iphone&burn=1) ×**76**
- [email](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=email&burn=1) ×**75**
- [security](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=security&burn=1) ×**73**
- [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=osx&burn=1) ×**71**
- [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=performance&burn=1) ×**67**
- [function](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=function&burn=1) ×**67**
- [image](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=image&burn=1) ×**66**
- [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=node.js&burn=1) ×**65**
- [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-maps&burn=1) ×**64**
- [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=if-statement&burn=1) ×**61**
- [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=.net&burn=1) ×**58**
- [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=oop&burn=1) ×**57**
- [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=swing&burn=1) ×**57**
- [object](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=object&burn=1) ×**56**
- [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=bash&burn=1) ×**55**
- [variables](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=variables&burn=1) ×**55**
- [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=windows&burn=1) ×**55**
- [class](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=class&burn=1) ×**54**
- [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=magento&burn=1) ×**54**
- [cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cuda&burn=1) ×**53**
- [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=eclipse&burn=1) ×**53**
- [file](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=file&burn=1) ×**53**
- [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=angularjs&burn=1) ×**52**
- [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ubuntu&burn=1) ×**52**
- [web](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=web&burn=1) ×**51**
- [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=xslt&burn=1) ×**51**
- [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=batch-file&burn=1) ×**51**
- [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=perl&burn=1) ×**50**
- [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=shell&burn=1) ×**49**
- [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sql-server-2008&burn=1) ×**49**
- [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-maps-api-3&burn=1) ×**48**
- [api](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=api&burn=1) ×**47**
- [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sorting&burn=1) ×**47**
- [jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jsp&burn=1) ×**47**
- [internet-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=internet-explorer&burn=1) ×**46**
- [url](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=url&burn=1) ×**45**
- [table](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=table&burn=1) ×**44**
- [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=xcode&burn=1) ×**44**
- [web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=web-services&burn=1) ×**44**
- [google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-chrome&burn=1) ×**44**
- [http](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=http&burn=1) ×**43**
- [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=multithreading&burn=1) ×**43**
- [mod-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mod-rewrite&burn=1) ×**41**
- [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jsf&burn=1) ×**41**
- [git](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=git&burn=1) ×**41**
- [encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=encryption&burn=1) ×**41**
- [visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=visual-c%2B%2B&burn=1) ×**41**
- [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=flash&burn=1) ×**39**
- [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=loops&burn=1) ×**39**
- [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=spring&burn=1) ×**38**
- [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ssh&burn=1) ×**38**
- [search](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=search&burn=1) ×**37**
- [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=user-interface&burn=1) ×**36**
- [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=xpath&burn=1) ×**35**
- [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ssl&burn=1) ×**35**
- [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sockets&burn=1) ×**35**
- [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=redirect&burn=1) ×**35**
- [list](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=list&burn=1) ×**35**
- [math](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=math&burn=1) ×**35**
- [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=dom&burn=1) ×**35**
- [date](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=date&burn=1) ×**35**
- [for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=for-loop&burn=1) ×**34**
- [join](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=join&burn=1) ×**34**
- [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=regex&burn=1) ×**34**
- [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=python-2.7&burn=1) ×**34**
- [pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=pdf&burn=1) ×**34**
- [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=parsing&burn=1) ×**34**
- [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=python-3.x&burn=1) ×**33**
- [jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jquery-ui&burn=1) ×**33**
- [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=dns&burn=1) ×**33**
- [visual-studio-2010](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=visual-studio-2010&burn=1) ×**33**
- [twitter-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=twitter-bootstrap&burn=1) ×**33**
- [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=tsql&burn=1) ×**32**
- [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=audio&burn=1) ×**32**
- [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ruby-on-rails&burn=1) ×**32**
- [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-apps-script&burn=1) ×**31**
- [firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=firefox&burn=1) ×**30**
- [azure](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=azure&burn=1) ×**30**
- [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=asp.net-mvc&burn=1) ×**30**
- [codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=codeigniter&burn=1) ×**30**
- [pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=pointers&burn=1) ×**30**
- [postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=postgresql&burn=1) ×**30**
- [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jquery-mobile&burn=1) ×**29**
- [tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=tcp&burn=1) ×**29**
- [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=validation&burn=1) ×**29**
- [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=java-ee&burn=1) ×**28**
- [ip](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ip&burn=1) ×**28**
- [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ms-access&burn=1) ×**28**
- [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=amazon-web-services&burn=1) ×**28**
- [div](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=div&burn=1) ×**28**
- [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-app-engine&burn=1) ×**27**
- [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=actionscript-3&burn=1) ×**27**
- [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=browser&burn=1) ×**27**
- [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=c%23-4.0&burn=1) ×**27**
- [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=debugging&burn=1) ×**26**
- [csv](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=csv&burn=1) ×**26**
- [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mobile&burn=1) ×**26**
- [pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=pdo&burn=1) ×**26**
- [video](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=video&burn=1) ×**26**
- [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=vim&burn=1) ×**26**
- [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=web-applications&burn=1) ×**26**
- [plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=plugins&burn=1) ×**25**
- [memory](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=memory&burn=1) ×**25**
- [mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mysqli&burn=1) ×**25**
- [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=opengl&burn=1) ×**25**
- [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cocoa-touch&burn=1) ×**25**
- [button](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=button&burn=1) ×**25**
- [asp.net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=asp.net-mvc-4&burn=1) ×**24**
- [centos](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=centos&burn=1) ×**24**
- [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=iframe&burn=1) ×**24**
- [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=matlab&burn=1) ×**24**
- [jquery-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=jquery-ajax&burn=1) ×**24**
- [rest](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=rest&burn=1) ×**24**
- [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=wpf&burn=1) ×**24**
- [virtual-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=virtual-machine&burn=1) ×**24**
- [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=syntax&burn=1) ×**24**
- [windows-phone-8](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=windows-phone-8&burn=1) ×**23**
- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=python&burn=1) ×**23**
- [entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=entity-framework&burn=1) ×**23**
- [database-design](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=database-design&burn=1) ×**23**
- [cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cakephp&burn=1) ×**23**
- [blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=blackberry&burn=1) ×**23**
- [backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=backbone.js&burn=1) ×**22**
- [input](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=input&burn=1) ×**22**
- [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google-chrome-extension&burn=1) ×**22**
- [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=post&burn=1) ×**22**
- [stored-procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=stored-procedures&burn=1) ×**22**
- [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=methods&burn=1) ×**22**
- [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=testing&burn=1) ×**22**
- [text](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=text&burn=1) ×**22**
- [winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=winforms&burn=1) ×**21**
- [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ipad&burn=1) ×**21**
- [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sass&burn=1) ×**21**
- [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=scala&burn=1) ×**21**
- [session](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=session&burn=1) ×**21**
- [grails](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=grails&burn=1) ×**21**
- [graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=graphics&burn=1) ×**21**
- [hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=hibernate&burn=1) ×**21**
- [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=drupal&burn=1) ×**21**
- [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=assembly&burn=1) ×**21**
- [datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=datetime&burn=1) ×**21**
- [data](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=data&burn=1) ×**20**
- [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=command-line&burn=1) ×**20**
- [flex](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=flex&burn=1) ×**20**
- [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=inheritance&burn=1) ×**20**
- [ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ftp&burn=1) ×**20**
- [select](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=select&burn=1) ×**20**
- [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=scheme&burn=1) ×**20**
- [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=qt&burn=1) ×**20**
- [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=machine-learning&burn=1) ×**20**
- [website](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=website&burn=1) ×**20**
- [time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=time&burn=1) ×**19**
- [vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=vbscript&burn=1) ×**19**
- [operating-system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=operating-system&burn=1) ×**19**
- [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=recursion&burn=1) ×**19**
- [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=hash&burn=1) ×**19**
- [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=facebook&burn=1) ×**19**
- [data-structures](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=data-structures&burn=1) ×**19**
- [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cookies&burn=1) ×**19**
- [debian](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=debian&burn=1) ×**18**
- [cocos2d-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cocos2d-iphone&burn=1) ×**18**
- [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=c%23&burn=1) ×**18**
- [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=exception&burn=1) ×**18**
- [django](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=django&burn=1) ×**18**
- [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=design-patterns&burn=1) ×**18**
- [hardware](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=hardware&burn=1) ×**18**
- [header](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=header&burn=1) ×**18**
- [get](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=get&burn=1) ×**18**
- [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=maven&burn=1) ×**18**
- [tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=tomcat&burn=1) ×**18**
- [wordpress-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=wordpress-plugin&burn=1) ×**18**
- [templates](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=templates&burn=1) ×**17**
- [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=terminal&burn=1) ×**17**
- [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=svg&burn=1) ×**17**
- [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=svn&burn=1) ×**17**
- [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=vector&burn=1) ×**17**
- [visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=visual-studio&burn=1) ×**17**
- [map](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=map&burn=1) ×**17**
- [oracle11g](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=oracle11g&burn=1) ×**17**
- [optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=optimization&burn=1) ×**17**
- [joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=joomla&burn=1) ×**17**
- [ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=ios7&burn=1) ×**17**
- [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=logic&burn=1) ×**17**
- [login](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=login&burn=1) ×**17**
- [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=responsive-design&burn=1) ×**17**
- [phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=phpmyadmin&burn=1) ×**17**
- [sql-server-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sql-server-2005&burn=1) ×**17**
- [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=gcc&burn=1) ×**17**
- [graph](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=graph&burn=1) ×**17**
- [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=hadoop&burn=1) ×**17**
- [hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=hyperlink&burn=1) ×**17**
- [design](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=design&burn=1) ×**17**
- [cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cloud&burn=1) ×**17**
- [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cmd&burn=1) ×**17**
- [cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=cryptography&burn=1) ×**17**
- [content-management-system](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=content-management-system&burn=1) ×**16**
- [core-data](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=core-data&burn=1) ×**16**
- [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=compiler&burn=1) ×**16**
- [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=caching&burn=1) ×**16**
- [asp.net-mvc-3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=asp.net-mvc-3&burn=1) ×**16**
- [architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=architecture&burn=1) ×**16**
- [amazon-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=amazon-ec2&burn=1) ×**16**
- [fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=fonts&burn=1) ×**16**
- [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=foreach&burn=1) ×**16**
- [iis](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=iis&burn=1) ×**16**
- [frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=frameworks&burn=1) ×**16**
- [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=sqlite&burn=1) ×**16**
- [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=powershell&burn=1) ×**16**
- [printing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=printing&burn=1) ×**16**
- [random](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=random&burn=1) ×**16**
- [lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=lucene&burn=1) ×**16**
- [nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=nginx&burn=1) ×**16**
- [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=memory-management&burn=1) ×**16**
- [usb](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=usb&burn=1) ×**16**
- [windows-8](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=windows-8&burn=1) ×**16**
- [wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=wcf&burn=1) ×**16**
- [unit-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=unit-testing&burn=1) ×**15**
- [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=unicode&burn=1) ×**15**

Comment: How in the hell is `android` so high on the list? I turn my back for a couple of days...

Comment: Sorry, Mr. @BilltheLizard, I haven't been reviewing lately like I had been. Anyways, 40 down. 20 hours to go before another 40 bite the dust.

Comment: What's `&burn=1` meant to mean in the URL?

Comment: Nothing at all, @Qantas - that's just there in case I need it later.

Comment: What happens to questions I vote to leave open.

Comment: Go JavaScript!!

Comment: @gideon, they return to an open status and it is no longer closed for answering.

Comment: @chris really ? Even if it had 3 close votes? I saw a question with answers that was probably misunderstood when posted. And then after 3 close votes it turned out to be a good post. So I voted leave open. So it should be open ?

Comment: If these links are provided by default, close queue wont have grown so huge

Comment: @Shog9 the link for C# does not work. It always filters to `c`. Also changing it manually to `filter-tags=c%23&burn=1' seems not to apply filter

Comment: please sort by alphabatic ! :)

Comment: How come I see android is lagging behind? It does mean that we all have improved android tag! Keep it up

Comment: the link for C# does not work. it works the first time, but when you move to the next one, it goes to `c` and `php` sometimes...

Comment: @Shog9 Another vote for the broken C# queue: when I click the link I get a C# question, but when I cast my vote I'm given a C question.

Comment: FYI people: if you're given a question that doesn't have a tag you filter on, it's *probably* an audit.

Comment: @gideon, nevermind. Perhaps I misunderstood this queue. I guess if it gets three close votes and you submit one for keeping it open, it goes into closed anyway? Is this a majority rules kinda deal or does it just take one "leave it open" vote in the series of votes for it to get knocked out of the queue?

Comment: Is there a way to get a dynamic version of this list showing up to date numbers?

Comment: Please tell me you didn't enter all that by hand.

Comment: What do these numbers mean? When I check the review for matlab it seems like none of the questions have 4 close votes. Hence this listing may not be very representative.

Comment: I suspect that it will show you 3 and 2 close vote questions once the ones with 4 are done for the filter you set. Could someone update the post so we see the current status?

Comment: [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=opencv&burn=1) was burned down! ;)

Comment: @Dennis It is also counting close flags, which are not shown. If four people flag a post for closing, it could show up with no actual votes. Also, from my understanding of the original announcement, if there were Do Not Close votes before the queue became fuzzy, that question will stay in the queue until handled no matter how few votes/flags it has.

Comment: I'll try to keep it updated a bit more often while I'm awake, @atticae

Comment: How much reputation do u need to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions @D.Singh

Comment: Damn it. Still 2500 to go :(

Comment: Ha, I see my specialty tag: "css-selectors ×12" I'll take a look.

Comment: I took care of the `[git]` tag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard android is no more...

Comment: Don't try to beat the PHP tag. You can't. It's *impossible*.

Comment: Woo!  No more Java!  I'm likin' this progress.

Comment: Nothing exists currently, @oberlies - I have updated this list though, as a poor substitute for the moment.

Answer (score 95):

## Final results: initial burndown

Here are the statistics for reviews done as part of the burn-down campaign (reviews between 2014-02-28 02:41:26 and 2014-03-03 10:48:49):

### Initial state of the tasks reviewed

- 15,796 tasks
- 5,263 tasks with 4 close votes (0 or more Do Not Close reviews)
- 1,126 tasks with 2 Do Not Close reviews (1 or more votes or flags)
- 843 tasks with 1 flag and 1 DNC review
- 3,121 tasks with 1 vote and 1 DNC review

### Outcome

- 34,211 reviews completed
- 15,395 tasks completed
- 10,507 tasks completed by closing the question
- 4,646 tasks completed by not closing the question
- 242 tasks completed by editing the question

#### Of tasks with 4 close votes

```
 Completed: Close Completed: DoNotClose Completed: Edit 
 ---------------- --------------------- --------------- 
 4900             135                   14
```

#### Of tasks with 2 Do Not Close reviews

```
Completed: Close Completed: DoNotClose Completed: Edit
---------------- --------------------- ---------------
287              818                   11
```

#### Of tasks with 1 flag and 1 DNC review

```
Completed: Close Completed: DoNotClose Completed: Edit 
---------------- --------------------- --------------- 
284              522                   21
```

#### Of tasks with 1 vote and 1 DNC review

```
Completed: Close Completed: DoNotClose Completed: Edit
---------------- --------------------- ---------------
1233             1776                  68
```

### Reviews by tag (top 30 tags)

```
Name          Reviews 
------------- ------- 
c#            2679    
javascript    2472    
php           2350    
java          2309    
python        2150    
ruby          1891    
sql           1875    
c             1688    
c++           1516    
html          1484    
jquery        1289    
css           1229    
mysql         1130    
regex         1070    
ios           1059    
android       1025    
ruby-on-rails 1006    
asp.net       823     
sql-server    753     
objective-c   741     
linux         675     
excel         661     
arrays        639     
oracle        618     
xml           594     
.net          561     
algorithm     519     
node.js       503     
matlab        466     
database      454
```

### People

1,238 different users participated during the burndown, completing at least one review and averaging 27 reviews per reviewer. 1,402 users visited the queue via links from the tag filters listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue/223498#223498), with 444 performing at least one review and completed a total of 9,026 reviews while filtering by a specific tag.

### Aftermath

The burndown campaign resulted in a *massive* spike in reviews performed and users involved. With the initial campaign (and surrounding promotion) completed, activity has declined but so far remains above what *was* normal:

Reviews per day:
[image]

Tasks completed per day:
[image]

Active reviewers per day:
[image]

Comment: We're seeing the impact of this in the moderator flags queue. The number of "multiple closed questions from this user" flags has shot up overnight.

Comment: This is fantastic. I have barely used the CV queue for the last few weeks (after having done over 3k total reviews in that queue since it's been around). But this temporary change, and the really encouraging update on the numbers, have really put the wind back in my sails, as far as this queue goes. Thanks for taking action - and for keeping us in the loop on our progress!

Comment: This really shows that the community wants to clean up, all we need is some motivational boost. An achievable goal and visible progress through reports like this will do exactly that. Keep it going!

Comment: I'm waiting for the surge of terror when you lower the threshold and it spikes back up to 50K again.

Comment: Yeah, well... It'll be a much less crufty 50K at least, @Troyen.

Comment: For perspective, how many tasks would have been queued yesterday under the non-fuzzy queue - to compare against the number of reviews that were done?

Comment: About 1800, @Troyen.

Comment: Could you please make the Top-10-diagram proportional to the reviews per day?

Comment: It's fun to see that the last 2 days, there were less close votes and  more DoNotClose votes. Seems like people pay more attention during this event.

Comment: @WouterJ: you sure? Could be just a few robo-reviewers skewing the results (more for "leave open" than "close")...

Comment: It's bizarre, but i see way more big groups of 5-second reviews ending in closure than in DNC, @qant. (It should go without saying, but if you do 40 reviews in 5 minutes I'm going to be looking really hard at your account)

Comment: @Shog9, how many of current review tasks have a lot of "skips"?   E.g. are they less claer cut then is often the case?   There seems a to be a lot of quesions I would have closed as "not clear", but that have an answer acepted from the questioner, so someone must have been able to do mind reading.

Comment: 1729 for Java. Yay Ramanujan!

Comment: @Shog9 out of curiosity, how many new questions have attracted close votes but have not yet been added to the queue since they don't have 4 votes?  It seems we are obviously making a dent, but I'm curious how many new posts are not getting enough attention from close voters

Comment: There've been 4,862 questions that've attracted their first close vote or flag since this change was made, and an additional 874 that've attracted 4 votes/flags and made it into the queue, @psubsee2003. Obviously we're more than breaking even here, but this still isn't sustainable IMHO.

Comment: The amound of reviewers is back to its normal level and the amount of reviews is almost back. Are we going to get to zero?

Comment: Trying to get housework done, so I might not update the stats again today @Wouter - but even with the partial day shown above, you can see that the # of reviewers is still higher than a normal peak weekday and many times that of a normal Sunday. We're under 2K left in the queue - I expect we'll be able to wrap it up tomorrow.

Comment: @Shog9 - frankly, I wasn't even aware of ability to filter by tag. I just blasted through 100% of [tag:perl] part of the backlog thanks to your prior answer with per-tag links - thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to find skipped reviews for users with less than 10k? It'd be good if there was some way to do so.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced it's that good for users with >=10K, @Qantas - do you have a purpose that isn't met by just hitting your browser's back button?

Comment: @Shog9: some that's far back I've probably been not sure at the time, but might have changed my mind about.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how the rate of completed tasks/queued tasks has changed now that the threshold is down to 2.  Anecdotally, seems to be going down, but at a much slower pace than the 3 or 4 thresholds.

Comment: When you finally hit zero again, are you going to leave it at +2 so people "don't get discouraged" or drop it down to +1 to unhide all the other questions?

Comment: Hopefully neither, @Troyen - there are some better ideas floating around here on Meta that I'd like to try once we've exhausted this brute-force method.

Comment: @Shog9, (please) which queries did you use to make these graphs? As AskUbuntu is above 1k at the moment, I was wondering about doing some similar graphs...

Comment: Some of these are really hard to get accurate using public data, @Wilf. If you post a request on meta.AU, I can try and collect some info for you.

Answer (score 63):

Never thought that I'll ever see it

[image]

Comment: enjoy while it lasts

Comment: A big day in SO !! Feeling good :)

Comment: @m0sa Nope, back to fire again http://i.stack.imgur.com/6X5GD.jpg

Comment: just keep the pace up

Comment: 7k. It's the smallest it has been in the last 7 days. anybody got statistics?

Answer (score 28):

### Stage 2 completed

[image: 0 need review]

#### Outcome

With the bulk of the reviews that can be completed by a handful of reviewers gone, stats are starting to go back to normal:

```
Reviews Completed 
---------------- 
39153            

TasksCompleted Close DoNotClose Edit 
-------------- ----- ---------- ---- 
17019          15483 1323       213
```

Reviews per day:
[image]

Tasks completed per day:
[image]

Active reviewers per day:
[image]

Stage 3:

[image: 30.2K items to review]

Comment: What's the total unfuzzy number left to do?

Comment: Somewhere around 100K, @Martin.

Comment: Thanks. And what was it at the start of the fuzzying process? Have significant inroads been made?

Comment: @Shog9 when you provide more detail, it would be nice to know how many of the 100K are less than 10 days old (meaning how many have we added since the fuzzying process started.

Comment: @Shog9 any chance of an update with another week gone. Is the total number still dropping?

Answer (score 22):

A couple of months back a small group of users decided to [get organized to attack the Close Vote Queue as a group effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208634/so-close-vote-reviewers-next-meetup-wed-feb-19-400pm-est). Since then we have weekly meetups of an hour where we burn through the close vote queue.

As this now has become a real community effort you're welcome to join the regulars in the [SO Close Vote reviewers chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). You can just leave a message about what you've found, how it went or whine a little about the `<cough>`high`</cough>` quality of the questions.

Don't let it become a huge pile once more with only a couple of users handling that queue. By keeping in touch you get the feeling you're not struggling on your own.

Comment: I do hope that room addresses Reopening too... Closing is only one side of Close Vote Queue :)

Comment: @Rachel we are very flexible, if we stumble across gems that need to stay open we're happy to deliver that service as well :-)

Answer (score 18):

For users with >10k reputation, I also recommend to go to:

https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=

> Most votes > "sort by close reason"

Over there it shows the questions that are about to be closed because they just need one extra vote.

Answer (score 16):

I commented but got rid of that comment and thought to push this as an answer, that showing the questions with 4 close votes is cool though it's hazardous at the same time...

Most of the time users review blindly, to gain badges, yes, I do keep a constant check on random profiles and they just close vote the questions blindly. It often happens *(Not in the review que)* but say a user asked a question, that *Game name X is not supported in my computer, what should I do?*

In the above case, one user close votes as *general computing hardware and software* and others just go along with the blue box..

So coming to the point, last vote does matter, yes, obviously if the post has got a score of 4 close votes, the question must be bad for sure, but users don't see if the question is then edited, so I shouldn't cast a close vote, so showing only the 4s will instantly closevote a question which I feel is bad as posts don't reopen that quickly.

---

Coming to the second part of this, questions with 3 or 2 close votes won't be shown in the que, result? They will start losing vote each week, resulting in more amount of crap questions on the website.

---

**Now comes my suggestion to solve this in a different way...**

I wanted to throw a question few days back, which suggested to chop down the close vote per question limit, so instead of 5 it should be 3<sup>[1]</sup>, which would suffice.

This way we don't have show posts which have 4 close votes, also, questions will be closed instantly most of the time because they generally end up with 2-3 close votes.

Not only this, to help this make more concise, we can show the questions related to the tags users participate, say top 10 tags *(Excluding synonyms)* ...

If that's less than say 50-100 *(Which I don't think so)*, then we can show the questions related to other tags as well... This will not only make the close voting faster, but users having the knowledge of the respective field can judge the questions well and then decide to *close* or *skip* compared to the users who can't and vote blindly *(Yeah, we have a skip button but they don't use it)* as they are not so knowledgeable in that field.

---

<sup>1. If you think that's too less to decide whether the question should be closed voted or not, than the privileges of 3000 Reputation CAN BE considered increasing to 5000, as hardly few care, rest are hungry for review badges</sup>

Comment: After implementation of your suggestion  which is `3 close votes suffice`, after few days a new idea comes with `1 close vote  is suffice` where a mad guy can close any question for no reason.  Just crazy :)

Comment: Now if it was 3 reviews that all siad close, with no reviews saying "leave open"

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ No one said 1 close vote, won't make sense, that's why we have mods...

Comment: I don't understand your example.  The question you posted *should* be closed as "general computing hardware and software" so what makes you think that people closing it that way are doing so blindly?

Comment: @HarryJohnston no, what I meant was even questions which are not fit for superuser are sometimes closed as, the question should be asked on super user, in the example, which was real infact, because I read the question few days back, op asked two games aren't supported, it should be closed as totally off topic, was not meant to be asked on superuser as well, but because one user closed with that reason, other users will see the blue count icon and will go ahead and close with the same reason without really thinking that its not meant for superuser as well

Comment: I don't think it's sensible for people on Stack Overflow to be trying to decide whether a question is appropriate for another forum or not.  Now that close votes no longer cause automatic migration, I think closing as off-topic is appropriate, even if the same question might nonetheless have been closed for another reason if it had been posted in the correct forum.  Note that the description just says "*may* be able to get help on super user", it isn't a promise. :-)  But perhaps this should be more broadly discussed as a separate meta-question?

Comment: The important point as applies to this meta-question is that people (me for one) are voting questions of that sort as "general computing hardware and software" *not* because someone else already voted that way, but because we think that's the right vote.  We might be wrong, but we're not just following the leader.

Comment: That seems dangerous to allow 3 votes to close. At least on Android we have a lot of really good, valid questions being close-voted by C# ppl and other "experts". I do not believe that helps the community, for someone with little knowledge of an area to be given so much power to decide what is a good question. Dropping to 3 means the close queue goes down, but not really for the right reasons.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Than it's what I said *Blind Voting*, don't vote if you are not aware of that field, thus I suggested that relevant tag posts should be shown in the review que, also, I specified that we can increase the reputation limit of casting votes ...

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for pointing that out, will revert back

Comment: "I don't agree with this person's vote." != "This is blind voting."

Answer (score 8):

Might be an illusion, but thrilling nevertheless. Thanks to everyone for your ideas and effort, regardless of the real size of the queue.

> [image]

Comment: I was going for the "last" CV :-) but it looks like [@ShadowWizard's the winner](http://imgur.com/TSMaeKs).

Comment: @acheong87 pure luck! ;)

Answer (score 6):

If the site operates on reputation and has determined that folks with a certain amount of it can cast close votes and the reputation is a signifier of the person's "trust" on the site, why not just purge all the posts with whatever threshold you determine, 4 - 5 whatever. Isn't that essentially what this is anyway? Just say, hey, these have x many votes, the queue has grown to a ridiculous size, so just delete them.

The problem with this call to action post is - it's likely misleading. My cup may be 1/2 full but the more time I spend on the site, the more it's clear there's too much user freedom (generally never my view) for the rep amount. I can only imagine the number of posts closed since this change that have been only to participate and go on a closing spree. Why not create another badge - *"Burner - participated in the great burn of the close queue"*. I doubt there's a whole lot of consideration going into it. So why go through the theatrics? The queue's apparently been an issue for a while, and many of these posts have been laying there a long time. Does it really take a meta post for people to care about it's monstrous size?

Reputation does not imply equality. There are a great number of even tempered and helpful high-reputation users, there are also a lot of people with just enough rep to be dangerous. I can attest by the inconsistencies of the suggested edit queue that some users need to get on the same page. A user moderated site should not imply chaos.

Here's my simple plan:

First, raise the rep on close votes and their reviews. That alone will reduce the size going forward and if it's raised high enough it will likely improve the validity of the post's presence in the queue and theoretically get the required votes quicker.

Next, it's fairly obvious users like voting to close while the post is fresh, but they have little love for the queue. Well, force them to participate in the queue. If you want to cast a close vote on a "fresh" post (time table to be determined) then you'll have to handle one of these posts that are in need of review. That's a 2 for 1 special.

Finally, implement a dynamic system based on reputation. How many 20 or 50k users equal a moderator. In other words, if Jon Skeet votes to close your C# post, let it be closed then. Just kidding on that, but you get the point. This would amount to a post with only votes coming from minimum rep users to require the full threshold, while another may only need two or three from *very well* respected users.

I know it's not perfect but something should be done to actually change the system, not temporarily finagle it as a means to an end.

Comment: Uh... `raise the rep on close votes and their reviews` = more crap staying on the site... all it does is make it *look* as if there isn't as many bad posts that need to be closed... but there still would be.

Comment: @hichris123: I don't share your view, but what's your alternative - lower it so many more posts that *shouldn't* be closed do get closed. It's not as if *every* vote is a valid one.

Comment: Meh, true, however do you really think raising the rep limit makes less good posts get closed? I think that would just make less bad stuff get closed, and more bad stuff stay open, personally. And we do have Reopen & Leave Open votes...

Comment: @hichris123: I want to. The truth is we are all individuals doing our own thing, so I can only speculate. If it doesn't then I *do* think something is inherently wrong with the rep system, but it's what we've got. As another answerer put it, those mechanisms might just be what's causing posts to linger and another example of the inconsistencies. The close votes shouldn't *really* be based on opinion. They should be based on criteria, I think those lines get blurred. Not sure if that's fixable.

Comment: I used C# as a stand-in for "very active tag with craploads of high-rep users in it", which I'm pretty sure is what you were going for as well. And no disrespect, but if you don't think knowledge of the subject is *immensely* useful when reviewing questions in it for closure, then wait until you get the opportunity to do so - I guarantee you will change your mind in a day. I can probably burn through half a dozen JS or WinAPI questions in the time it takes me to evaluate a single Ruby or SQL question, and the evidence so far is that this is common - hence the big list of tag filters above.

Comment: @Shog9: That's my fault, I wasn't going for that but I can surely see why you did after re-reading it. I meant that a user who's read/answered over 28k posts could probably discern, fairly, if a post should be closed, C# was the icing on Jon's cake. But you point out that I'm mistaken on what's required to arrive at a decision to close, and at this point I can only take your word for it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a permanent version of this would be in order:

- If there are no close votes, and the question has been in the queue for a month, drop it.
- If there is 1-3 votes, hold off on dropping it for 2 months.
- Older than 2 months since last close vote? It needs 4 close votes to sustain it.

Number of course could be tweaked, but just trying to put something out there.

Comment: I like this idea but probably not those numbers

Answer (score 3):

I have a radical suggestion.

Automatic time-based closing.

1. A user posts a close-worthy question.
2. For great justice, a close-vote is cast against it.
3. The timer begins.

Every question that has a close-vote cast against it has `5 - n` weeks to live, where `n` is the close-vote count.

With the same mechanics as normal voting, someone can cast a stay-open-vote. The timer stops when the close/stay-open voting sums to zero (*much as if no close votes had been cast to begin with*)

The timer restarts anytime there are more close-votes than stay-open-votes cast against the question.

**To summarize**

> Every question with at least 1 close-vote will be closed automatically, every subsequent close-vote will merely hasten that inevitability. Every stay-open-vote will prolong the lifetime of that question.

**The result**

In about a month, the queue is empty.

Comment: When a question gets a close vote and doesn't get additional close votes then that's a sign that the question *shouldn't* be closed, not that it should be closed.  That's why close votes age and disappear if the question isn't closed after a period of time.

Comment: I said it was radical ;-)

Comment: And I'm saying it's a bad idea.

Comment: I understand completely. It's a far more draconian approach, but it'd definitely help keep the site clean.

Comment: It would mean closing questions that shouldn't be closed.  That causes a lot of problems.  We want to be closing exactly the questions that should be closed.  Making the queue go away by simply not taking the proper action on the items in it isn't fixing the problem, it's just sweeping the dust under the rug.  It's important to fix the actual problem, not the metric of the problem.

Comment: That's fair. It does defer the responsibility to time, rather than reason. However the proposed system offers the ability to keep close-cast question open; the queue'd still exist, but the intent would change: It'd be the "stay-open queue".

Comment: And given that there is objective evidence that items in the queue aren't reviewed as quickly as they come in, you end up with a certain percentage of items being closed purely by chance, simply because they happened to not be shown to anyone, rather than because they should be closed.  Sure, it doesn't happen to *every* post, but it still happens to a large enough percentage to be a problem.

Comment: I do not like your idea, if I may say so. It assumes that questions that are false positives in the queue (i.e. that should not be closed really) are taken care of _first_. But obviously you can't tell the good questions from the bad ones before someone looked at them.

Comment: Well, despite the negative response, I'm going down with the ship on this one.