# Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[This recent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251842/712603) posits that due to a hypothetical decline in "interesting" questions, a large number of high-reputation users have been decreasing their activity on the site, especially in the number of questions they answer. I found that hypothesis and analysis interesting enough to be addressed outside the context of [its question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/712603) (which was focused primarily on other issues).

My questions are:

- Is it true that most high-reputation users have been decreasing their answering activity recently?
- If so, why is it occurring? (Input from high-reputation users whose activity has slowed would be very useful)

Other considerations are:

- Is it a problem? (Perhaps it is simply a case of SO becoming more "democratic", with lower reputation users and "newer blood" filling the gap).
- If so, how can it be slowed or stopped?

To be clear, I do not necessarily agree with the original post that this decrease in high-rep user activity comes from a decline in question quality, nor that such a decline in quality necessarily exists. I could imagine several alternative hypotheses, as have others:

- Most users increase their activity over time before hitting a peak and decreasing (as suggested by Gaël Laurans [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252161#comment7154_251842))
- An increase in low-rep answerers has decreased the need for high-rep answerers (as suggested by podiluska [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late/252161#comment4964_251842))
- That some users may be motivated by reaching the top level of privilege (20K rep), and are less motivated to answer after reaching it
- That high-reputation users have become not less active, but rather *more selective*, editing or voting to close low-quality questions rather than answering them (an analysis of their commenting, editing and reviewing behavior might help confirm this)
- That high-reputation users earn a steady "income" from old posts, and it is therefore no longer necessary to answer to gain rep (as suggested by Martijn Pieters [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions-and-if-so-why#comment9664_252757))

Comment: I'm only at 37k now, so not one of the really high-rep users, but personally I find that the last of your 8 bullet points is spot on at least for me personally. I'm much less interested in answering as I am in seeing interesting answers that I can learn from. I also am more selective about what questions I answer. Nowadays I mostly try to answer stuff that I personally find interesting, rather than what I think would give me the most reputation (interestingly these two goals are pretty much uncombinable for my main field of interest).

Comment: I also don't think this is a problem. The good questions still tend to get very good answers, whether by high- or low-rep users, and I don't really care about bad questions.

Comment: You can only answer so many question about how to properly do a `group by` before you get burned out.

Comment: Yes, because the quality of "new" questions is going in the toilet. Almost everything I see sucks or is a duplicate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: As an interesting sidenote, [your answering activity](http://imgur.com/c75ldFk) shows only a mild decrease over the past two years (indeed, according to my test it's not statistically significant)

Comment: @David sure, now go further back. And [when was my last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand?tab=answers&sort=newest)? At some point you learn to just draw a line in the sand and say, that's enough, this community doesn't need my help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Ahh, you've found a notable problem with my methodology (that 0s are skipped). And the analysis was indeed focused on the hypothesis of a "recent" (last two years) trend

Comment: As a high-rep user on another site, I can also confirm the last bullet point.  Over the past few months there has been an influx of weird minutiae questions that I've mostly just been ignoring.

Comment: I'm personally bored from the tag I've been participating the most (Delphi). There's a lot of repetitive questions. Askers usually listen only the highest rep users ignoring the others (but they are under certain pressure sometimes). No motivation to reach a new privilege is also a bit demotivating for me. But I'm glad it happened, since I've started to invest my time into living :) [I'm not a high rep user though]

Comment: @NiklasB. "I'm only at 37k"... it does not compute... is there life after 20k?

Comment: @brasofilo I guess what I wanted to say is that I'm barely in the top-1000, and I'm not sure about which range of users David is talking about, but I guess it includes me.

Comment: @NiklasB. I always thought 10k was the entrance to high-rep, but I guess in SO terms, this is just Junior's High Rep :)

Comment: I'm personally kind of curious what the trend is for those of us much closer to 3k (like me). I personally hit a pretty big wall after I hit 3.6k or so (I've gained less than 300 rep in the last 6 months). Except for the "reaching 20k" bullet-point, I'd say the bullet points could apply to us too.

Comment: I frequently get near to the daily rep limit from upvotes on my *old* questions and answers. Spending time on new questions would give me no benefit.

Comment: I spend pretty much all my time now (which has not decreased) *looking* for things to answer. Unfortunately, that often just turns up nill and I end up just burning through my close/downvotes then going away in disgust.

Comment: If you count me as a high-rep user, then yes, it's spot-on for me too.  I've been answering much fewer questions precisely because I don't see many that interest me anymore. (Over the last few years the questions I found interesting changed from "programming" into "computer science", which SO has fewer of.) Instead I've been *asking* more and more questions, and at some point I'll have asked more than I'll have answered...

Comment: @DennisMeng: I'd say it'd apply to almost anyone with high activity at some point in time, take a look at my reputation graph.

Comment: I think Its Right

Comment: I don't think 20k is a milestone too many people shoot for. I shot for 1500 because at that point i got all the accesses i needed and i thought i would need in the future. I helped out till 2k and then i dropped off. But my motivation wasn't points it was mostly wanting to progress the field of firefox-addon. But points did give me a goal to work towards. So my inactivity right now is because of that.

Comment: The UI is built to make it super-easy to ask questions, not find answers. Now that we have all the most common questions the UI needs reworking to streamline getting the answer; not asking the question.  If it is easier for a noob to find the answer than to ask then the average quality will improve.

Comment: @JohnMee maybe true, but I personally just use google to find an answer, which works well for me. If there is a good match on stackoverflow it will be visible in google. for some noob-questions I just copy & paste the question title as-is into google and get a perfect answer. for me, the research workflow is (most of the time) 1) google, 2) read a book, 3) ask a friend, 4) ask on SO. that's why I ask so few questions.

Comment: Why is this important?  Reputation does not mean knowledge.  I think that the number of high quality questions that go unanswered is more important; but that is difficult to measure.  Who cares who answers them?

Comment: @LIUFA J have rarely seen a case of this happening, so the *all* quantifier is not really justified. Also note that hard does not necessarily mean interesting.

Comment: This is one of the most interesting posts I've read on meta in quite a while.

Comment: The high rep folks can be really hit and miss. Sometimes they help, sometimes they chastise or make fun of people. Maybe it has something to do with wading through "don't use mysql_* functions..." comments on EVERY piece of code that uses them (aren't we supposed to stay on topic?) I see people belittled for too much code, too little code. I see people rip people apart for not providing code (even though that isn't listed as a deal breaker on the "how to ask a question" page). Maybe they're just burned out on the negativity?

Comment: Sorry to be redundant, but to echo some of the above: I’ve also stopped answering as much because the ratio of horrible questions to half-decent ones has increased. On the other hand, it’s my job to close them… oh, and of course, the fact that [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late?cb=1) and its accepted answer got so many upvotes. And the state of suggested edits. Oops, got off track.

Comment: The quality of questions is very low. So either you can not answer them at all, or you can. But if you do, people accuse you of 'rep-whoring'. So I try to balance it. Sometimes I answer, sometimes I downvote, and sometimes both.

Comment: Most of the good "general" questions have been asked/answered.  New questions tend to be "help me now" questions, which are less interesting.

Comment: I can't avoid the feeling that people with high reputation usually answer more questions...

Comment: @ZerO: Answering fewer questions *over time* (that is, fewer than they used to)

Comment: For me personally, my quantity of answers relates to learning. (I don't have an ultra-high rep, but I do answer quite a few questions).  I increased my SO activity about a year ago to learn a particular topic.  I learned by researching and answering questions about that topic.  Today I'm answering fewer questions in that topic because I'm satisfied with my general understanding of that topic.  I'm now moving onto another topic which I again hope to learn by researching and answering questions.

Comment: I suspect that almost all active users "fatigue" over time and respond to fewer questions.  Adding to this is the fact that the question about the Red Light feature of the Green Hornet language, which seemed so interesting a year or two ago, has been asked almost daily for the past 6 months and is getting pretty wearisome.  I think these changes are inevitable.

Comment: @ZerO: A bunch have (previously, at least).  But you can only get so far by posting a lot of crappy answers.  :)  The bigger factor is quality -- answers that are more correct, clearer, and/or more comprehensive get you more rep per answer, so you don't have to post as much.  And the answers you do post often take longer to write, so you end up either writing fewer of them or spending every waking hour on SO.  :)

Comment: @TLama "I'm not a high-rep user" Sure you are. Your reputation puts you in the top half of the top 1% of all users. If that's not "high rep", then, to quote Scalia somewhat lightheartedly, words no longer have meaning.

Comment: Maybe this might help. The number of participants are 38. But, it might be of interest to you. https://docs.google.com/forms/d/10iQ0ZzPdNNh0j2t61W7Tg36O987ia66cygBIrJIJCSY/viewanalytics

Comment: Half a decade later, essentially nothing that's discussed on this page has meaningfully changed. That seems like a sign of a problem _in itself_.

Comment: I certainly hope that SMEs are answering fewer and fewer questions.  With their continued contribution, they will be invariably and increasingly aware that the same questions get asked over and over.  If they are continuing to be helpful contributors, there should be a natural transition from answer-poster to question-hammerer.  The goal of this site is to help researchers. We do this by removing noise and bloat.  Closing duplicates to redirect readers to a canonical and getting all of the best advice on the canonical is how this mission is accomplished.

Answer (score 370):

**TL; DR**

- The number of answers provided by users who currently have >20K reputation has decreased by about 25% since January 2012.
- About half of those users have slowed or increased their answering since January 2012 to a statistically significant extent.
- Of those, 84% have been slowing their answering activity, while only 16% have been increasing it.

---

In the interest of expanding on [Hans Passant's analysis here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251842/712603). I looked at the number of answers per month from January 2012-March 2014 (testing the trend of a *recent* decline in contributions), from all users who currently have a reputation >= 20K, using [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186926). You can find a reproducible version of this analysis (including the R code) [here](http://dgrtwo.github.io/pages/tumblr/are_users_quitting.html).

First, we can ask: as a whole, are >20K rep users contributing fewer answers than they used to?

[image]

The answer is a definitive *yes*: answers contributed by these high-rep users decreased by about 25% from January 2012 to March 2014. Furthermore, the sharpest decline (of more than 20%) was in the last year.

Now we might ask whether this is trend is split across all users equally: is this a general but gradual malaise among all high-reputation users, or is there a special class of "quitters" that could be "blamed" for the decrease? Furthermore, are there many high-rep users that are bucking the trend and are *increasing* their contributions over time? To determine this, I performed a quasipoisson generalized linear model predicting the number of questions/month as exponentially growing or decaying over time. Using false discovery rate control with an FDR of 5%, I identified a a set of 1041 users (47.9% of all high-rep users) that have a statistically significant trend with respect to time.

Of those users with a significant trend over time, how many users increased their activity over this time period, and how many decreased it? And how fast is the change in each of those cases?

[image]

Of these 1041 users whose activity was changing over time, 84% were *decreasing* (what we could call "quitters"), and only 16% were *increasing* (what we could call "joiners"). What we see here is the percentage change predicted for each user per month (for example, the mode "quitter" shows a rate of 5% decline per month).

Now, we've identified a class of statistically significant high-rep "quitters" (874 users) and "joiners" (167 users). Do these users account for the trend we saw in our original figure? Well, let's divide the original figure up into categories:

[image]

This set of users does make up for the overall downward trend. However, it's notable that there's another trend visible among those who didn't fit this model: one that increases activity during 2012, and then decreased their use through 2013 (we could call them the "2013 quitters"). This second trend would account for the fact that the 2013 drop was much sharper than the 2012 drop, and it deserves further study in any future analysis.

#### Individual Users

What do the trends of the top users look like? (This is not to "call them out," but rather to see whether the assumptions of our model are appropriate for detecting trends):

[image]

Of the top 12 users, 1 was increasing in activity in the last two years, while 8 were decreasing (the others did not show a statistically significant trend).

In case you're wondering, here's how I fit into this trend:

[image]

I do in fact exhibit a statistically significant negative trend, but in fact I look a bit more like one of those "2013 quitters" we saw in the Other category. I'm not sure I could explain why through introspection (I'm guessing I just had less time to spend answering questions). But I would be interested in hearing from any former power users whose activity has decreased, and whether it was some perceived issues with Stack Overflow that led to this decline in activity.

Comment: I still answer questions regularly even amidst my mod duties, but even I am aware I'm not as prolific with answers now as I was in my first year/first 20k rep of activity. It's strange, because I have over 10 times as much rep as I gained in my first nigh-year of activity, but my rep gain hasn't actually accelerated let alone my level of activity.

Comment: Question: which part of the drop, if any, is coincident to the site's removal of the person's ask/accept ratio which happened in 2012?

Comment: @GarryVass: It looks like that happened in [January 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/176330), which was indeed the start of the sharp drop in answering. I can see how the connection is plausible, though of course the evidence is circumstantial

Comment: Perhaps because the high-rep users no longer have to work so hard to gain rep? The backlog of answers created provides a steady 'income' of reputation.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Indeed plausible.  Your time series annotated with significant policy changes would be invaluable.  From another angle, what about the RATE at which users are entering the high rep zone during the same period?  I suspect that has slowed dramatically also?

Comment: I'd be curious to see what my profile looks like, btw. My experience with R is exactly 0, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ask and ye shall receive: http://imgur.com/C7SwS5s. Definitely a "Joiner" (no surprise there), though it doesn't perfectly fit the exponential trend. (Indeed, if anyone is a counterexample to your last comment, it's probably you)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Do you mean quadratic trend?

Comment: @NiklasB.: No, the trend being fit is an exponential one, `exp(intercept + rate * time)` (specifically, using quasipoisson regression). This makes particular sense in terms of decay (a 5% decrease in answers per month)

Comment: Okay, I was thinking growth :) And there's a bit of a limit on how much you can write per day

Comment: If we are positing explanatory variables, I'd suggest also looking at a graph of the NASDAQ composite, which started surging at the beginning of 2013. Increase in technology sector means the top tier gets too busy to answer questions and that there are more newcomers and more questions.

Comment: @DavidRobinson That comment was really just meant to counter the assumption that all the explanatory variables are specific to Stack Overflow, e.g. policy changes. The why probably can't be determined very well from the data. A user survey is needed to address that.

Comment: @A.Webb: My apologies: I agreed entirely and was responding in kind (apparently to the point where the irony collapsed). Getting input from high-rep users whose activity was declined was indeed the reason I asked this question

Comment: @A.Webb, the NASDAQ and Obama cannot be discounted as indirect factors I suppose; but things closer to home are likely to have more a more  direct influence

Comment: So, my first thought is that "high rep users" is not a static population. Are high rep users fungible? Are the declining contributions of current high rep users offset by the contributions of newly minted 20k users? That would probably require a somewhat different data set, though.

Comment: @GarryVass I would not assume that based on _this_ data alone. I really _would_ expect the sector economy to play a rather direct role. I took the Obama comment as facetious, especially since it was lumped in with the Mayan calendar, but I suppose there could be some health care reform effects -- I would be willing to bet one depreciated dollar that at least one high rep user is a "quitter" because they felt empowered to go into business for themselves without having to rely on their corporate insurance.

Comment: -1; needs more freehand red circles on the graphs.

Comment: @A.Webb, put that as an answer and we can observe an informal benchmark on meta-sentiment

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, I'd be interested in seeing the monthly proportion of answers coming from users with 20k+ rep _at the time they answered the question_. It is unsurprising to me that a common pattern would involve a sprint of activity to high rep followed by declining answer rate. But has the proportion of all answers coming from high rep users declined? I think that requires the ability to look backwards in time in rep, and I'm not sure the data extracts allow that.

Comment: If anything, @joran, it seems to me that the overall trend is _more_ compelling, given that the number of >20k users strictly increases while the number of answers decreases. This is absolute answers, rather than proportion of all answers, so even if an individual answerer's rate drops as e crosses the 20k line, e should still be contributing to the _group's_ remaining steady or even increasing. But I agree with you that the population change seems to be an important unconsidered factor (then again, I'm definitely not a statistician).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Not quite, because this analysis uses the set of users who are *currently* 20K, including the questions he asked before he hit 20K. So if a user asked many questions then hit 20K in January 2013 and quit, he would contribute to a strong downward trend (he'd add many questions to 2012 and none to 2013).

Comment: I see, @DavidRobinson; I had understood this as "had 20k at time of posting", as Joran was talking about in the previous comment. (Do you mean "answers" in your comment and the sentence directly above the first graph, rather than "questions"?)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yes, thanks, edited in answer

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and for the analysis in the first place!

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do a similar kind of numerical analysis on the quality of the questions.  Perhaps based on upvotes per unit of time?  That might allow one to test the hypothesis that questions are getting worse.

Comment: @Edward there is the quality filter. While only SE knows the full mechanics of that, getting a 'reanalyze all the questions asked for one day each week since the start' could give some insight into that.

Comment: @Edward: One issue is that the number of upvotes is confounded with other factors- for instance, a common complaint is that SO is too ready to upvote bad questions. This is part of the reason I focused on high-rep user activity as a separate question, but [some of the answers here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow), including [this graph](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252547/712603), do address this issue.

Comment: I am sorry for possibly missing the whole point of analysing answering. IMO the problem is with the questions - more experienced users are not so keen on answering every single question they read. SO got stricter on closing poor questions and there is no point in answering 1. because it's against the SO rules 2. question gets deleted so any rep earned is subtracted...Look up how much professionals charge for consulting

Comment: "Ask and ye shall receive"... can I see my graph? How do we access these? @DavidRobinson

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, David links to his code used. If you know how to use R (particularly with RStudio), you should be able to download edit this: http://dgrtwo.github.com/pages/tumblr/are_users_quitting.Rmd. Towards the end of the file, you'll find `plot.users("712603")`. Change the user ID to yours and you're good to go.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah I feel similarly.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: you are aware that you didn't answer the question though? You just (albeit plausibly) proved the question to be true.

Comment: It really bothers me that you suppress 0 in almost all of those graphs and plot them all on different scales.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Some of the points in question already answer that. But he did provide statistical correctness to the hypothesis. It is difficult to answer without the users themselves weighing in. They should be surveyed about what the want, what happened. To me it is like economy, pumping rep(money) to system needs to be controlled (in a manner to speak). Two users may have same rep but never the same experience/grasp/knowledge ... . In this way rep looses its meaning. They no longer care about rep(gain/reward/income), which is the reason to run an economy aka the site.

Comment: Ooo, I also want to see how I fit that. I know I've had several acute incidents which have caused me to slow down, and now essentially halt, any question-answering activity.

Comment: @tcaswell The start at zero rule isn't as [universal](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/2014/04/when-to-use-the-start-at-zero-rule-.html) as people think. For the paneled plot, it is simply a judgement call on the intent of the graph: equal scales is better for making comparisons between people, separate scales are better for quickly seeing detail for each individual (which was the intent here I think). There's nothing wrong with David's choices here.

Comment: @joran If you want to suppress zero to show a small change on top of a big signal than you should plot (val - offset) and label the axis as such and make it really obvious.  I also don't really believe many of those trend lines.  The data is super spiky and they look way too biased by the end points.

Comment: @tcaswell That would be a nice way to plot it, but David's way is fine too for the purposes of this post. I don't share your mistrust of the trend lines. Only 9 were actually claimed to be significant, and just eyeballing the graphs I count 7 that seem perfectly plausible to me.

Comment: I think your graphs are misleading because it pulls data from users who have 20k rep **today**. You need to find a way to get users who had 20k rep at the time of answering, or of course you're going to see a downward trend like this. There are more 20k rep users now than 2 years ago, so older answers posted when the user was < 20k are going to show up in your graph, even though they shouldn't.

Comment: @Rachel: I certainly agree it would be good to look at the activity of users after they reached 20k (data that is unfortunately beyond my skills to extract from the Data Explorer). However, I disagree that "of course you're going to see a downward trend." The set of users that have 20k rep now is a fixed, defined class of about 2300 users. This is evidence that the contributions of those 2300 users has declined (specifically a subset of 47% of them). In what way is that tautological?

Comment: People change. Lives change. Its hard to stay part of any online community for years with the same level of involvement. In 2 years time, we'll have a new batch of 20k users, and their answers will increase the numbers displayed in the later half of your graphs simply because their questions answered now will then be considered "> 20k". Most users with 20k rep have been here a while, so its natural that older data has higher numbers.

Comment: I'm a > 20k user, and personally I just don't have as much time as I did a year or two ago to answer questions. And if you checked with me 3-4 years back, I was still a user but very inactive as I didn't have time then to participate either. If this changes in the future, chances are you'll see me answering more questions again. I like helping people, and enjoy teaching newbies. If anything, it's the rudeness and elitist attitude of some users that will drive me away, not question quality (as it already happened [on one site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/1130/rachel). :)

Comment: @Rachel I think you should provide that as an answer, as it offers a contrasting perspective (and I'd be interested in seeing your complaint on elitism in more detail)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I considered it, but there's already 25 answers posted and I didn't want to read them all to see if it was a repeat opinion of someone else :)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I ended up [posting an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253376/302677) after all... just started typing and before I knew it I had something long written so I figured I might as well post it. So there you go, another opinion :)

Comment: Is it really a good idea to sample individuals on the basis of their ***current*** reputation and infer that far backwards historically? A more useful query, were such a thing possible, would be to look at the number of answers people gave when they first attained 20K reputation versus now. For the better answerers, reputation grows solidly over time for answers they wrote a long time ago. Many users can hit the 200 rep a day cap just from random up-votes on answers written years ago. Because only *accepted* answers can break that cap, said users have to write fewer, higher quality answers.

Comment: I found a gripe with the statistics presented: The observed changes could readily be explained by the increasing popularity of SO. Consider the hypothesis, "by the time you get to read a given question, the 'correct' answer has already been given". You only look at >20k users. Perhaps <20k users have been answering fewer questions *as well*, because of an increasing users vs. questions ratio.

Comment: How hard would it be to come up with a similar graph to the first one that includes 5k - 19999 rep users? I know that I've become jaded long before I hit 7200; in fact I am certain that I got jaded shortly after I earned the right to close vote. I'm wondering how similar it would be for other users.

Comment: As time goes on it gets harder to ask good questions because most of the good ones have already been asked. Old timers had the advantage of getting here first and answering the good questions back then, which pay interest now. One answer would be to start SO over again, in terms of questions. Keep the prior round, but let new questions and answers come up that will have more modern content. I don't know if that's a good idea though,  it's just an idea.

Comment: I'm not a super power user (60k only). My reason was actually **mostly** (though not exclusively) Stack Exchange's fault: I got overly distracted by non-SO new SE sites. Another reason was "Summer of Love". I hated the idea that SE was explicitly coddling help vampires while wagging their fingers at people who try to resist them - that demotivated me from moderating OR answering to an extent.

Comment: @joel3000 if you have a good question but it's already been asked (and answered), why do you need to answer it again? What would be the purpose in forking the sites and having that same good question answered differently in different places? If a more modern answer is better than the existing answers, add another answer.

Comment: I love this answer for being the *Entertainment Tonight* of StackOverflow. I may not know what Paris Hilton is eating for dinner tonight, but I sure as hell know Jon Skeet's posting habbits for the *last two years*. Thanks, David!

Comment: Yay! Still going strong after 5+ years :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters is correct, and it's the same as in f.ex. emerging market. Get in early and the money keeps ticking in, from f.ex. already being known and already being big. The one coming in late has to work that much harder. Once you're established, there's no need for that original busy earnin' - and I don't see that as a problem. Likely the jobless knowitalls have finally landed their dream job that actually requires knowing it all, and we should all be understanding of their suffering and not accuse them of not contributing to the community as they used to.

Comment: I have one or three reputation points. I've essentially stopped even coming to the site. Haven't answered a question in almost a year, haven't commented since last August. I'm just beyond fed up with duplicated, low quality, poorly researched content and would rather rage at the askers because there is not much else to do about it (or, rather, not enough people putting out the fires). I eventually just decided it would be simpler to just leave. But I wouldn't count myself as an expert, far from it.

Comment: Great answer overall. Still -1 from me for sensational, misleading graphics that are no 0-based just to convey a more dramatic (false) impression. I hate that.

Comment: This answer is **wrong** as Shog explains [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/#comment31207_253376) as a comment to [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253376/302677) : *"Out of curiosity, I ran the numbers for folks with 20K+ **at the time each answer was created**. As you predicted, Rachel, the results were rather different - indeed, the number of answers posted by 20K users was fairly static over the years, even as the number of 20K users increased."* Your graphs take into account Reputation as of *now*, which skews the numbers by quite a bit.

Comment: @Rachel: It depends what question you are asking. I was taking a class of users (users who currently have >20K reputation) and asking whether their answering activity had decreased in the last two years. Actually I think Shog's analysis is much *more* misleading, since he's looking at the # of answers contributed by a changing population. If the number of answers posted by 20K users is static even as the population is increasing, that does mean their individual contributions are decreasing. (Unless he is saying the number of answers *per user* is static, but that's not clear from his comment)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ah I guess that's true. I was looking at this question more as *"Are we getting fewer answers from high-rep users"*, as opposed to *"Are we getting fewer answers from our existing group of high-rep users"*. I suppose if viewed in the form of the second question, your answer would be correct, however if viewed in the form of the first question, I think it would be incorrect :)

Comment: It's a shame that higher-rep users are beginning to answer questions less frequently, a part of me thinks it may partially have something to do with dumbos like me who ask too many dumb questions; for that I am sorry. Please come back.

Comment: I missed this conversation, David & @Rachel - sorry for being unclear. I was talking about total answers posted, which *has* decreased somewhat but not nearly to the degree suggested here (at least... at the time I posted that comment; things have changed a bit since). [Answers per user is another story entirely](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2uZLi.png) - let me know if you're interested in the raw data for that.

Comment: @Wooble At long last I can now add those freehand circles: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29397338/712603

Answer (score 265):

I can only speak for myself and the tags where I frequent ([sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)). I have almost 114K on SO, but my last answer was on February 6th. And it *will* be my last answer.

<sub>*Ed.: Well, I didn't **quite** hold true to that, but I went nearly 5 years without posting an answer - Feb '14 -> Nov '18. My answer rate now is far lower than it ever was, because I am much fussier - depending on the day - about the questions I bother putting any effort into.*</sub>

Quite literally, I hit a wall on how many questions were the same questions over and over again. Or just didn't have any effort put into them whatsoever.

The purpose of this site is to serve as a high quality Q & A resource. Why are these low-rep, new users having such a hard time either finding the answers to their questions before they ask them yet again or expressing them in a meaningful way? Almost everything I come across these days has either been answered 100 times, or is a "do my work for me" question. The remainder take so much teeth-pulling to get at the actual requirements (never mind reveal edge cases) that I finally made a decision to put my time, effort, and knowledge to better use.

Do I down-vote a lot of stuff still? Vote to close? Sure. When I can be bothered to sift through the unsalvageable list of junk on the front page. This problem is starting to seep into some of the other smaller sites to some degree, but I hope that flow remains very slow. Because I love this network in general, I love the concept and the implementation, I just find that the quality on SO has nose-dived like a lot of the graphs above. I mean, come on, really? How is this a valid question?

- [What specifically is SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23372800/61305) (deleted)

And this one?

- [Calculation in Temporary Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371100/calculation-in-temporary-tables)

And this one?

- [SQL server temporary table not create in transaction with Web service (EJB exposed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369650/sql-server-temporary-table-not-create-in-transaction-with-web-service-ejb-expos)

And how does this get ***4 up-votes***? (well, now 44 up-votes, I'm sure as sympathy votes to offset the 44 down-votes, which is stupid. Don't up-vote a bad question because someone down-voted it - you're destroying the value of down-votes. Surely a lot of those votes in either direction were the meta effect, but I do see this happen in other scenarios, too.)

- [Can you do a Select * FROM CASE WHEN statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369099/can-you-do-a-select-from-case-when-statement)

Just appalling. When it takes effort to find a question worth answering, I tap out. Sorry.

Comment: "Do I down-vote a lot of stuff still? Vote to close? Sure." in doing this, those who vtc/downvote sometimes become targets for passive aggressive meta posts and blogs about "love" which further depresses the desire to answer questions.

Comment: Very interesting observation. I believe, that back then (5 years or so in the past) when SO started, a lot of the *new* users (if not all of them) were already experienced developers. With the time as the site grew and became more popular, more and more *average* developers became acquainted with the SO *concept* and started to ask/answer questions in the manner that most of the people normally do - **without putting enough effort in research and thinking**. The SO case is just as every case where a lot of people are involved - the *famous* the site, the more *average* questions are asked.

Comment: Where are you going to place your efforts? I find SO has the disadvantages you mention (and I'm mostly in [python]), and I'd love somewhere else to ask and answer questions.

Comment: @Marcin well, I'm a database guy, and a moderator on [Database Administrators], so that's where much of it will go. I also have a job, a growing family, extra-curricular activities. IMHO SO needs to be better at directing users to duplicates before allowing them to ask questions - for example the first 5 questions from a new user [go through a queue before they appear on the main site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190492/would-raising-the-review-limit-help-with-the-close-votes-queue/200110#200110), or maybe even [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183618/).

Comment: I can imagine how it might feel not to see a single vote-to-close as duplicate even when FAQs are posted.  Good decision.  Others need to take inspiration.

Comment: I will miss your insightful comments and answers.  Maybe I'll @ you in a question when we need your help.

Comment: I've stated my perception of the situation here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253015/341994 It's very similar to yours. I too am finding the decline in question quality appalling, and have tried to characterize it in that answer.

Comment: I like it how all these questions have been deleted, except for the last one, which now has 8 downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, one more comment - I think the _solution_ is to give high-rep users more moderation power. I spend all my efforts stamping out the encroaching forest fire of bad questions with a thimble and I have to wait for other people to come along with their thimbles and help me. Give me a hose! **Give us the tools, and we will finish the job.**

Comment: When you say: *"the same questions over and over again"* do you mean duplicate questions that can be closed as such or just questions that are too simple (google finds answers that can *easily* adapted if you search for the question title or keywords from the question)? What is your opinion if others answer these too simple questions? Do you think it makes the web worse?

Comment: @J.F. I said and meant the same questions, not trivial questions. And yes, I've come to the conclusion that answering these makes it worse. Whether they didn't find the dupe because they didn't try, or because the search/recommend facilities failed them, we've just taught them that they'll get an answer easier/faster by just asking a question without caring how many times it's been asked (and answered!) before.

Comment: if "the same" means "duplicate"; Is the issue that it is hard to find the duplicate question or that it requires several users to vote to close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @J.F. I think there are a variety of reasons. (1) the OP doesn't search (2) the tool doesn't always suggest good duplicates (or the OP doesn't notice them, maybe their fault, maybe not in your face enough) (3) there is no real reward for close voting, and often questions sit in that queue for a long time with 2 or 3 close votes (4) sometimes the OP rejects/ignores the duplicate(s) suggested because they have a different table name or variable name or are using a different version. In other words, they're terrible/lazy about adapting an answer that doesn't *precisely* answer their question.

Comment: @J.F. And of course (5) there are people who won't vote to close because they'd rather be able to answer the question to earn more rep - more of a reward than voting to close or sitting in the review queue earning progress toward some badge. I constantly see people answering easy, pop-fly questions that I know have been answered hundreds of times. My single vote to close doesn't help this situation.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hear, hear!

Comment: Perhaps SO needs a machine-learning algorithm being fed the deleted and downvoted questions, so it can provide a pre-selected 'hitlist' for high-rep users to action. Also, there should be a 'Grim Reaper' award (with its own graphic and everything).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, maybe close votes should be weighted by rep ?

Comment: It's interesting to hear that experts feel like the quality of questions has taken a nosedive.  Here's the thing: I'm one of the noobs, and I put in several hours of effort composing a question that asked if someone could give me physical mental models of how something like a ruby method worked.  My question got closed as off topic.  That felt like a slap in the face, and froze me out as a new developer. It took me years to make my own mental models, and by that time I grew to hate the elitists on Stack overflow who answer as if you are already an experienced developer.

Comment: Lots of newbies (not meant in a derogatory sense, of course, we're all newbies at one point, to anything) have broad questions. These are perfectly good and valid questions, but they don't work with our format. They can't be easily answered in a few paragraphs, and they're not suitable for an online Q&A site. That question *does* sound off-topic to me, when it comes to what works on Stack Overflow. We're not trying to push out new developers. It would be equally off-topic if the designer of the Ruby language asked the question. Questions need to be narrow in scope, and answerable. @tara

Comment: SO probably got a reputation for "being a website where you ask and people do the work for you" among wanna-be programmers. The more lazy, incompetent and possibly poor-grammar users join SO and ask questions, the more the smart, hard-working and diligent users will stop answering or visiting SO. It's just a natural trend.

Comment: "Quite Literally"

Comment: Poor guy is going to wonder why all of a sudden he got twelve downvotes.

Comment: @mattblang Had to pick examples, sorry. No examples? I'd get "what are you talking about?" *shrug* You put a question out there, you make it subject to scrutiny, meta effect or not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh I know!  It is just funny to me.

Comment: In a similar situation myself (work in a small subset of tags, of ever declining quality), with the addition of increased work IRL - I won't say I'm out or done, but it'd be nice to find a better insulation for the [September settling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_september) in...

Comment: I would agree that the quality of questions (and the questioners) seems to have diminished significantly since I first came here several years ago.  I kind of wonder if the "jungle telegraph" out among the kiddies and the lazier end of the college crowd is saying that SO is a good place to get your homework done.  Or if Comp Sci teachers are actually recommending SO to beginning students.

Comment: I literally had my 40K+ account deleted just to make sure I was not tempted to waste anymore time on the site contributing to the low quality *"peers"* that it is creating. I recreated my account just to post a single question. There will not be any answers from me ever again and probably no attempts at flagging or moderation ever again. I had a weak moment and flagged some things recently but I have recovered my mettle and vow to never do it again. BalusC says it better than I could as quoted by Hans in his answer.

Answer (score 202):

As a very notable example,
[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882)
recently stopped posting. He's an expert in Java server frameworks, a
one-man powerhouse of answers. He has posted answers to 27% of **all**
the questions in the [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) tag, 10.6% of all the questions in the [jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsp) tag, and 28.4% of
all the questions in the [jsf-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-2) tag.

He updated his profile to explain why, and I assume he won't mind me repeating it here:

> I'm not that active here anymore as I'd like to be. I'll answer OmniFaces-related questions though and likely also a really interesting JSF-related question which is not been answered before. The remainder only if it has a bounty. Yes, for that YOU need to earn reputation first. You deserve what you give.
>
> But remember: if the question in question needs severe editing, or got a bad (suggested) edit, I am not going to fix and answer it anymore. Both Stack Exchange as company and Stack Overflow as community namely doesn't seem to bother about the quality of the posts anymore lately. I was mentally absent for a couple of months and came back in JSF tag only to find a huge mess of low quality questions with a doubled up unanswered rate. "You deserve what you give" also applies to the company and community here.

Comment: That's pretty depressing. At one point, I almost quit for the same reason of all the crap. But I got around the issue by using an auto-refresher which I leave on the side of my monitor. I glance at it every once in a while and I can scan it in a split second with negligible effort. That's what it took me to stay on the site. Perhaps it will work for others too.

Comment: It's notable that the two most common complaints about Stack Overflow are "They're too harsh on low quality questions" and "They're not harsh enough". Hopefully the tension isn't unresolvable.

Comment: It is fairly inevitable that the "too harsh" sayers will outnumber the "not enough" sayers. Contributing to SO is *very* lob-sided, only ~1% of SO users post answers. If I'm reading Bauke's profile post right, he's saying they got what they asked for.

Comment: Admiral Piett: "Bounty hunters. We don't need that scum."

Comment: @CharlesBailey I don't really think BalusC (who is one of the highest rep users here) has put up that bounty criteria for lack of internet points, or just for the heck of earning bounties. He's trying to ensure those he helps have also actually given back to the community, instead of just leeching the attention and assistance of others without any effort on their own part.

Comment: @Asad: I've no idea what you _thought_ I was saying with my joke.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Guess I read too much into it; I thought you were saying his participation had dropped off because he was focusing on "hunting bounties" to the exclusion of other questions.

Comment: I am now at this point (not comparing myself to BalusC in terms of contributions, but I only answer Qs on SO and (attempt) to moderate). I actually thought maybe there was hope, until [I just posted this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) and the answer from a mod. Apparently ... I'm wasting my time.

Comment: And there you have it, that's what killed SO.  The close-reason reform forced down our throats in the summer of 2013 removed the last means for the SO community to protect themselves against the onslaught.

Comment: @Brian, I'm not reading George's answer the same way you do. I've left a comment there for clarification, but to me his answer only says "there is no such close reason yet, propose one if you want the situation to change", not "we're happy with the current state of the system and would like it to remain the same".

Comment: As every JSF developer, when BalusC decided to "leave", I was really sad. I myself remember once he downvoted one answer of mine and left a comment like "I'll remove my downvote if you explain your answer properly". My first impulse, as a newbie, was to think "what a d***", because I had the answer but I could not explain why the solution worked. But also, he had my respect because he wasn't there just to be the "de facto" reference, but as someone trying to make things in the right way. I think not only SO lose, but the whole JSF community when he "left". But he definitively has a point.

Comment: And about his point, that SO has got what it deserves, I remember about some recent news I've read on the web about Waze and how the negotiation was based on the number of users they had. I imagine that SO dream is to be bought by some Google giant, and then we see many other SE communities, trying to reach non-tech users, and SO becoming the world-wide homework answers providers service. I think SO is sacrificing quality to get new users and I don't believe it will work. But maybe, content is not important anymore. Maybe, use base size is the social network currency now.

Comment: @HansPassant - I agree that I sorely miss the couple of close reasons (don't recall the exact wording) that I thought of as "Too stupid to live."  As it is there's no real close reason for a poor quality question (unless you use "Other" and add a snotty comment).

Comment: "Not a real question", "Not constructive" and "Too localized" were zapped.  Particularly pleas from the community to keep "Too localized" available were ignored.

Comment: @DavidRobinson The tension is resolvable, but only by becoming released from the dichotomy and finding a third alternative. Being "harsh" won't stop bad questions. Setting up a different economy, where askers need to either answer or pay $ (perhaps in proportion to the difficulty/badness of their question), will be more effective. Pure communism has its limits...

Comment: Thanks to all of you who expert in their various domains find time for people like us and answer queries although you are not getting any pay for that, I was very mad on this site because of all that downvoting issue, maybe now i understand a little bit, most people are good here.Thank You All.

Comment: BalusC has long since changed his profile description and is back answering in style. Please don’t read too much in a single high-rep user’s activity; personal life has far more influence.

Comment: Hmm, he's averaging less than 4 answers per month now.  Not his usual style.

Answer (score 136):

## What's going on?

I'm not "high-rep. user" and I'm joined not long ago. But it's not necessary to have 50k+ rep. to notice the current situation: *the system is working badly - if not to say not working*.

Why? Because, in my opinion:

- Quality of questions (and answers, sometimes) - became much worse. Look to the "canonical" questions asked in '08-'09. Yes, there are bad answers there too, but many "canonical" questions were asked there. If you'll say *"That's because canonical questions may be asked only once! And that's why in earlier years there are so many good questions!"* - I'll disagree. The thing is: IT doesn't stand in one place. New technologies, new problems, new concepts, new software e t.c. That *partly* reflects SO too - because some good (almost canonical) posts may still appear - but it's a very rare case. I won't repeat thoughts that were said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow?lq=1). It's well-known, unfortunately.
- Reputation system is "populistic". That means:

  - Good questions & answers are mostly long and requires some time to write. In case of questions it is the fact, that short question which seems to be "tricky" will get many upvotes, while really interesting question, which shows the efforts to resolve the issue, description of the problem and use-case for question, will be upvoted with score ~10 at best. Why? Because "short reading is easier". Short reading is easier => there is an upvote. Sample is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881362/why-does-true-result-in-2) question. It is: "tricky", "short" and "seems to need advanced knowledge to get the answer" (="useful"). Well, it's **not**. Actually, this is about *very basics*. It's in wiki, it's in Google, it's everywhere (if care to search). As for long question, well, I'll post [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047889/check-connection-between-two-points-on-2d-plane). No. It's not that easy to understand in one view. It's needed to read, to inspect existing solution, to realize what is question actually about. To keep in mind all the definitions, e t.c. - but .. you see the score.
  - For answers this means that short near-RTFM answers with little code will also have better chances to be upvoted. For instance, again, my [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784897/how-can-i-get-the-array-of-a-single-type-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-without/18784941#18784941) by score - isn't actually "bad" - but in comparison with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379532/determine-if-two-names-are-close-to-each-other/21382634#21382634) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341763/mysql-greater-than-condition-sometimes-returns-row-with-equal-value/23342704#23342704) ? No chances. Those three are definitely more useful (and I've spent hours on some of them). Again - you see the score.
  - Upvote just because the post has many upvotes. This is another problem. Partly it's the consequence of previous points. It is the situation when post attracts more upvotes just because of its high score even if it's incorrect. That again, means that score of such posts has nothing to do with how useful they are.
- Near impossible to do something with this. Not long ago [close-vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) queue was burned. And - that was *an admission* that we can not do anything with this wave of bad questions. We just can't react. We have 8k+ questions per day! No way we can filter them all. Thus, all this mess is on main page. I've given up to search *interesting* questions. So, when I've reached 20k, I've said to myself: *stop!* . (*by that I mean: answer only interesting questions now*).

All this non-working rep. system and problems that are on SO now - it's not too hard to understand why old users - or users who've answered arbitrary amount of questions - are disappointed. It's not an accusation against the SO team or it's community. All the things I've posted are known. My point is - that the question *"why high-rep users are answering so rare"* is just *consequence* of current SO problems.

## TL;DR

Near impossible to find interesting questions - and, if you're lucky - good chances are - your efforts won't be even noticed, your answer will just sink in this mess of crappy questions. That combination is a killer of a mood to answer for those who're not rep-hunting.

Comment: I've got `-1` in 5 seconds after I've posted (or even less?). Dear down-voter, you're an __example__ of non-working system. Or you have incredible speed of reading

Comment: And this non-working system would probably term your comment (and min too) as _non-constructive_.

Comment: @AlmaDo, Or he just meant to say, _"yo dude where is the TL;DR section?"_ ;-). (+1)

Comment: Good point. Fixed :)

Comment: I've asked one question in over 5 years of membership on SO. This is because even 5 years ago, if I looked hard enough I almost always found the answer to my problem. I've been wondering for years how anybody has the chutzpah to post questions. Almost every question has been asked! Maybe we need a question posting timeout: If you (myself included) have less than 1k rep, we have to watch a countdown for 20 minutes before our question will post. I spend at least 30 minutes searching SO before I even think: maybe this is a new question?

Comment: @Phil it's partly true. I'm asking question - but not because I can not find something or can not resolve something. But because the community will always do better that my solution. So my questions, if they are on SO, all are about "hey guys, I have this issue and this solution. Could you please suggest something better?"

Comment: @Phil How about we subtract reputation for asking questions?

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy why? Some questions are really great. And, therefore, with subtracting reputation we'll discourage enlightned users from asking questions. Those who are asking good questions are not responsible for those who are asking stupid questions

Comment: IMO a big part of the problem is those who have earned moderation rights by asking popular (but often not good) questions.  Good questions are valuable and should be rewarded in some way.  But I think that either they shouldn't count toward privileges and tag badges (keep the badges for question views and votes), or else rep from questions should be capped proportional to rep from answers.  Or combined (privileges require rep from answers to provide a certain fraction of the threshold).  The thing is that prolific question askers are able to upvote bad answers, close, etc.  Not good IMO.

Comment: That's why I think reputation milestones should not grant moderation powers. We have such things as: flags history, votes history, closing votes history e t.c. - so many _real_ things which can (and should) be used to grant moderation powers.

Comment: Just to illustrate the opposite point of view, I am an high-rep user, and I am having a blast (you won't have any problem picking up the activity graph for my account [in the answer above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252757/6309)). The questions are as interesting as ever; [most of my top-voted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=answers&sort=votes) aren't trivial, and took some time to be written.

Comment: Yes. And I didn't mean "all users". But, sadly - it's true for "most users". In any case - thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 125):

Axiom:

- **The incentive structure is the reification of the will of the organisation.**

Whatever they say they want, what they really want is what they reward.

Observation:

- On SO asking and answering duplicate questions is rewarded.
- There is no reward for marking and closing duplicates
- when duplicates *are* closed, nobody who got rewarded for answering the duplicate loses it.

Deduction:

- SO wants duplicates to be asked and answered, even though they say they don't.

Discussion/Speculation:

- Why do they want this?

Maybe they want this because they make their money from advertising. Advertising requires an audience. 99% of the audience of SO is the people who are asking stupid or duplicated questions.

Maybe they want this because they want to grow the user base, because users are considered valuable. Instagram got $37 per user by some estimates.

- Why do they say they don't?

The audience comes for help with their programming. Answers are provided by the 1% - the talent. The 1% are unhappy about having their time wasted answering stupid or duplicate questions. In order to placate the 1%, SO have to claim that they are trying to do something about it.

At some point Rep is not enough. You begin to notice that we aren't really a community. Most of us have never met anyone whose question we answered.

Joel, Jeff and the gang are making money! **There is nothing wrong with getting paid for what you do** - but we are doing a lot of the work. If half was going to charity we could think "I am helping other programmers, and generating advertising revenue which goes to cure malaria/install wells in Africa/cure leukaemia". But "I am helping other programmers, and generating advertising revenue to make Joel, Jeff and the gang rich" is not the same.

- **If it is really about "community", about helping people, share the money with the world through charity.**
- **If it's about getting rich, share it with the talent.**

Comment: I would question the *Advertising requires an audience* deduction. Most of the people I know are not registered on SO and yet browse it to get answers to their questions (which they usually find) and therefore they view advertisements without polluting the site. I am unsure whether rewarding duplicates (voluntarily or not) has the effect of increasing the number of ads seen.

Comment: @MatthieuM, that's not a deduction, just conjecture. I have no idea whether anything below "discussion" is correct - it is just guesses. As far as I know SO makes no money at all, or already gives half the money away. FWIW, I don't think it is cynical. I am sure the gang spend hours talking over "how can we maintain quality without alienating the audience". But the fact is that the goal of retaining audience engagement is simply more important than quality, or they would have chosen the latter two years ago. The goals are not compatible, much as they and we would all like them to be.

Comment: I think its often applicable for duplicates to be asked as they act as an oracle to the actual original question chain. I do agree however that most duplicates aren't marked as duplicate so I like the idea of somehow incentivising that process.

Comment: Actually, having enough rep reduces the amount of ads displayed. So the inflated reputation numbers would decrease the ad revenue. The basic analysis of the mismatch between talk and act is sound though.

Comment: I think you are getting your facts wrong. [se]'s main revenue income is from Careers., not from ads. That causes your whole argument to implode. Also, the systems are being improved. It's not a fast process, but it's a process nonetheless. You don't have the full picture, and neither do I, so let's not devolve into baseless accusations.

Comment: @SecondRikudo, not really. If they need volume of users for any reason (e.g. for Careers to be profitable), the argument is essentially the same.

Comment: @Ben: But the people you want on Careers are the experts, not the noobs. So again, your point has little merit. Careers is profitable because it links the employers with experts that seek employment. That doesn't work if you're flooded with noobs.

Comment: I wrote something similar to your first two bullet points on on an old meta post. [Jeff's comment on that post was interesting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136551/should-simple-sql-questions-be-closed-as-too-localized-exact-duplicate-or-b/136576#comment381791_136576)

Comment: There is also no penalty for incorrectly voting to close, so apparently SO doesn't mind legit questions being marked as duplicate. I realize that junk questions with many duplicates are one issue. But many only ok programmers are very trigger happy with duplicate votes, when they think they have understood the question but really haven't. This goes double if the person asking the question doesn't have high rep.

Answer (score 107):

As a medium-scale user, I'd say that I look for questions to answer about as much as I ever did, but I find questions worth answering pretty rarely. I spend much more time on janitorial work. My sense is that questions worth answering have always been in short supply.

One hypothesis: the sensible people now usually find most of their questions *already answered*. The remainder don't ask questions worth answering.

Comment: I think this is a huge factor. As SO has improved as a resource, programmers who actually bother with due-diligence have stopped posting as many questions (as they generally find their answers before needing to post)... as a result the questions that do exist are general duplicates, trivial, or lazy. This has made answering questions less rewarding.

Comment: [It finally happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31134/369).

Comment: I've posted only 2 questions on SO in 4 months, plus a bounty on another user's question. The reason is I google for answers before posting a question and almost always find them, frequently on SO.

Comment: This is an interesting hypothesis.  Can any SE person with the ability to analyse site usage provide some confirmation?  Should that be posted as a separate question?

Comment: My feeling is that this is exactly right.  Almost every question I've gone to post recently has been solved by checking the links that came up with suggestions and/or [rubber ducking](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) while writing it up.

Answer (score 78):

I'm not a high-rep user, as I never even bothered to get 10k. Why? What am I going to do with the 10k tools? I don't even know what they are, but I'm tired of my effort going unnoticed and unrewarded... and I don't see an incentive to work hard to get those tools just to become Sisyphus like all the other high rep users before me.

[Here is the only answer I provided that got more than 5 upvotes since March 1. I literally copy-pasted the JDK Javadoc. Yawn.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22416813/1768232)

[Here is an answer that took me quite a bit of time to solve, because the answer *did not exist on SO,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997736/1768232) [even though there were multiple questions on the same topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997758/1768232) I had to go decompile the JavaFX source because I couldn't find the answer anywhere on SO or the rest of the internet. Literally the only response I got was because I marked one of the questions as a duplicate and the original asker got mad at me, even though I gave him the correct answer to his question.

[Here is an answer that took me two days to figure out on my own, because the answer was not on SO, and the documentation wasn't clear.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22307855/1768232) So I was excited to be able to help someone with the same problem as me, except I only got one upvote and no checkmark.

[Here is my highest rated answer, ever.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16324963/1768232) I guess it's good that I can go to grepcode and copy paste what I find there and write it up in 10 minutes.

And finally, this is the most recent [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [answer with at least 10 upvotes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23396433/1768232). So easy to understand! And, surprising no one, the 100 reputation went to the person who answered first. Except, this question is a duplicate [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082196/string-length-vs-array-length) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720220/why-is-string-length-a-method) [over.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property)

In summary:

- People these days are only upvoting things they can understand immediately. This means if you have an obscure technology, they are probably not even going to click on the question let alone upvote it.
- There is no incentive whatsoever for searching for and finding unanswered, upvoted questions and answering them. Who knows if the asker even still comes to this site? Especially since most people asking have jobs and have to find some sort of solution fairly quickly, even if it's a terrible hack, so if you answer weeks or months later they've almost certainly moved on.
- People generally only click on questions once. Therefore, if you don't get a vote with that first click, you've missed your chance.
- Low rep, no knowledge users are rewarding duplicate answers, because the people who can vote to close are often as jaded as I am.

**Update:** [Here's another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423957/calling-a-constructor-with-a-condition) where the asker got 4 votes and Jon Skeet got 11 votes for what I knew had to be a duplicate as soon as I read it. [And sure enough, about 1 minute of searching found said duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236087/how-to-do-call-a-different-constructor-conditionally-in-java)

Comment: Except for MySQL tag I deal in some "obscure" technologies and what you are saying is so true. I think that a lot of people only register to get that one problem resolved and then move on never to use the ID again. I also noted that some people would rather accept a bad but easier to implement answer as the right choice.

Comment: Agreed. [Here is my highest-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212). Seriously? That took about 13 seconds to write, and is a duplicate many, many, many times over, including [one of my own answers that is tied for my second highest score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588423/sql-server-inner-join-when-updating/9589124#9589124). I have other, much more complex and high-effort answers, but they solve more obscure problems. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685731).

Comment: Then I have other high-effort answers with zero reward - sometimes the OP disappears, sometimes they choose an IMHO inferior answer. Sometimes they even say things like "worked like magic. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578146/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499972/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441645/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498039/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241109/) [6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740688/). I have many other 0-score answers, but those are a few that stood out to me. Also: not vote-fishing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just gave you a few upvotes. I swear I read them all though and applied the same standard I would to other upvotes :) I especially "liked" the one where the guy changed the requirements on you in the middle and you had to go back and change your answer to meet the moving target.

Comment: @durron597 that happens way more often than you might think. Anyway, I wasn't fishing for up-votes (but thanks!), I have plenty of rep, but my point is that you start to notice when the person looking for help in the first place has absolutely zero interest in showing any appreciation for your help, no matter how much or how little effort it actually takes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know you weren't fishing for rep. And, trust me, I know very well even with only 7100 rep how common the moving target is. [This might help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49787/200235) or maybe something radical like not having a reputation penalty for answers that are below a certain length.

Comment: I've remarked this annoying trend to. It's obvious that people will only upvote what they understand (after all, otherwise they cannot know whether it's worth it or not) but it means that easy questions/answers are flooded with upvotes whereas "real" questions/answers are a desert place. That and the "fastest gun in the west" syndrom are turning SO into a rapid-fire (and forget) website :x

Comment: @AaronBertrand Speaking of fishing for up-votes (which I wasn't trying to do), I'm up 90 rep since I wrote this post, all on posts that I linked in this answer. <irony>I should rant more often</irony>

Comment: @durron597 I so very much agree with you. At one time I started bounty hunting. I put lots of effort into it and got several 500 rewards. But it was such a huge fight for practically very little gain. A friend who's really good at finding the fast-shot questions collected 3-4 times more reps during the same amount of time. Finding good non-duplicates is hard, and reviewing is not rewarded at all. So, I'm just waiting for good questions to appear in [core-bluetooth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-bluetooth) and answer those if I can.

Comment: I can add another example: [Here is my highest-voted answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11969014/142637)  It's trivial, and took about 7 seconds to write.

Comment: I don't know, I don't think it's totally fair to judge the quality of an answer, or how meritorious it is of upvotes, based on how long it took you to write it. In a way, that's sort of the whole point of Stack Overflow: topic experts know the answers that others don't and can post them easily and quickly. Sure, I take the general point that "easy" Q/A tend to attract lots of upvotes, and the "long tail" of questions don't earn you much rep. I have plenty of examples in my own profile. But I think fixing on how long it took you to write it is missing the point. It obviously helped others.

Comment: [I find this answer to be full of anecdotal evidence](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/anecdotal). The basis of the argument seems to be that more time spent on writing an answer should immediately result in more votes on said answer. This is patently wrong and fails to factor in the usefulness of the answer to the people viewing it. I understand that you may spend more time digging for an obscure question, which is exactly why you're not going to get as many upvotes. The question is obscure, so the value provided to the community is minimal, hence the minimal reward.

Comment: I've deleted all my questions here about supercollider and basically won't ask anything about that or about csound here because there are no knowledgeable (enough) users around. For some low-profile stuff, the old mailing lists are still the best source. I've experimented with answering my own questions here, but there's no rep incentive to that basically. I can answer them in my own head and keep private notes with much less hassle than it takes to write an answer for public consumption.

Comment: funny now you got 27k :)

Answer (score 67):

This is going to be blunt.

I recently chose to stop contributing to a site at which I was one of the top-rep users.

There are a variety of reasons, but among those relevant here:

- I don't enjoy being exclusively a janitor due to the deluge of junk
- I don't enjoy *having* to be a janitor to participate in a site, even if this just looks like sifting through junk to answer
- I don't enjoy community outrage over downvoting and closing crappy questions.

  - The "think of the poor new user, how can you be such a jerk to them" site culture is a huge turn off for me. YMMV.
  - People love upvoting crap. This drives me nuts. Fighting an already lonely battle for site quality is hard enough without other active members working against you.

I am not going to answer your crappy question. Sorry, but I'm not going to make it my responsibility to parse your rambling wall of text or a confusing or unclear "wtf?" question. I'm gracing you with an answer to your question (or edits, comments, etc) because *I want to* - not because *you need an answer.*

Community involvement is the water, weeding, fertilizing that makes seeds grow. Those seeds are official SE policy, site mechanics, etc.

My participation in Stack Exchange is because it's fun, enjoyable, and contributes to me professionally. At some point, maintaining and curating a site became work and not fun. There are specific people/reasons for me but regardless none are likely to change anytime soon.

It's not fun watering and fertilizing weeds, so I've stopped.

---

I've started making a concentrated effort to up/downvote every question I read. All of them. On ALL StackExchange sites I visit. And you know what? I don't upvote a ton of new questions (these are primarily in the [VBA] tag on Stack Overflow at this point).

I suggest any of you who are on the fence about question quality to start doing the same. If you force yourself to think, "up or downvote?" and make a decision I think the problem with question quality will become really, really, REALLY obvious.

Comment: elusively??????

Comment: My lord, 22K on Workplace? How did you ever last that long?

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/one-of-our-top-contributors-recently-made-a-decision-to-leave-what-can-we-learn

Comment: +1 Im with you on the VBA tag. Plenty of crap, 95% questions are duplicates, too localized - never going to help anyone else cause its an exchange of code dumps etc), I have nearly stopped participating - sick of "I NEED YOUR HELP IF YOU DONT WANT TO HELP THAN F..OFF" - just like youve pointed out - *"I'm gracing you with an answer to your question (or edits, comments, etc) because I want to - not because you need an answer."* +1 for that

Comment: I presume that elusively is supposed to be exclusively? Didn't want to make the edit myself though just in case not.

Comment: I notice a lot of the high-rep users on this tag are serial commenters. The tag could be greatly improved if these few users would more frequently vote to close (low quality/off-topic), and also to mark Q's as duplicate (i.e., pointing to other accepted/canonical answers) rather than simply giving the "answer" as a comment (from which nobody gains any rep, and the tag just gets more and more of the "same" question).

Answer (score 43):

**People change. Lives change.**

It's hard to keep the same level of involvement in any online community for any extended period of time.

To answer your question accurately, you have to ask what is a high-reputation user? It's simply a person with a lot of time on their hands that can spend a lot of time answering a lot of questions.

Sure there's some outliers, people who provide stellar answers that accumulate a lot of upvotes in a short period of time, but this typically isn't enough to take a person to 20k reputation points.

So, to answer your questions from my point of view:

> Is it true that most high-reputation users have been decreasing their answering activity recently?

Probably yes. High reputation points typically means you've been on the site a lot. And most people don't stay at the *"I want to answer other people's questions online"* stage for that long in their life.

> If so, why is it occurring? (Input from high-reputation users whose activity has slowed would be very useful)

For me, it's my life has changed. I have a new job, working with a different technology, and no longer have the time I once had to answer as many questions as I once did. I suspect many other high rep users feel the same way.

> Is it a problem? (Perhaps it is simply a case of SO becoming more "democratic", with lower reputation users and "newer blood" filling the gap).

I would say that as long as a Stack Overflow still has a healthy base of users answering questions, and with answers getting voted up/down accurately, no this is not a problem. It's a natural lifecycle of a site like this.

> If so, how can it be slowed or stopped?

I don't think we should be fighting to keep people staying on the site for years at a time. Instead I think the system should encourage newcomers to pickup the slack and grow into the next set of "high reputation users". It's the only way to keep a site of this size and nature sustainable.

Comment: A note about people saying question quality is the problem... keep in mind that most users posting on meta have usually been using the site for a while, and if you're tired of answering the same question all the time, its probably time for you to move on (or ask SE to implement better filters). The entire programming community does not learn at the same level you did, and we need sites like SO to grow the next generation of programmers. Everyone was new once.

Comment: You make good points, but David's analysis in his answer spans across *all users above 20k points*. That's an awfully big spectrum and not all of them are tired veterans to whom your theory may well apply. Perhaps the analysis could be refined by controlling for "veteranship"... But either way, totally agree with your last paragraph.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, David has some great graphs and theories, however I think his data is flawed since it counts users that are over 20k rep **today**, as I pointed out [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/253376?noredirect=1#comment13334_252757) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/253376?noredirect=1#comment13339_252757). Run those same queries for the same dates in 2 years time, and I doubt you'll see the same results.

Comment: I regret I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: True in my case.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I ran the numbers for folks with 20K+ *at the time each answer was created*. As you predicted, Rachel, the results were rather different - indeed, the number of answers posted by 20K users was fairly static over the years, even as the number of 20K users increased. I talk about this briefly in [the latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/). cc @Pekka

Answer (score 41):

Only 56K user here, but I just wanted to say that I agree with what [Hans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252799/601179) and [Aaron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252770/601179) wrote.

I stopped completely from participating on Stack Overflow, and the reasons are exactly as you guys say. The main problem is that I feel like the Stack Exchange management feels comfortable with this situation.

More junk in the network -> more traffic load -> more money. Why did they delete the *What-Stack Overflow-is-not* thread? Why don't they provide tools and help making canonical answers to avoid duplicate answers? **MONEY!**

**I'm sure Stack Exchange stakeholders want to make money by improving the Internet which is great! But I feel like when money collide with that ambition, money wins.**
<sub>I might have done the same business decision, but I wouldn't be surprised that people stopped donating their time.</sub>

BTW,

I noticed that in many questions about why Stack Exchange networks is "broken", if the issue is true, and about how Stack Exchange network itself behaves, you won't get an official answer from one of Stack Exchange employees which is extremely annoying. Instead they send the community to defend their decision making...

Comment: only 56K? hah what's that like top 5% or 10%? I don't agree with the money part but +1 for mentioning the use of "public defensive strategy" used by SE

Comment: +1 I'm not sure *"SE management feels comfortable with this situation"* but I sure would like SE understanding that the ones who didn't leave yet find it harder and harder not to. We need, at the very least, more tools like the *what stackoverflow is not* thread.

Comment: I actually agree with you, and have said so before. If the *actual* goal of SO is what is stated, then the "what stackoverflow is not" thread would never have gone away. The answers were concise, not rude, explained *exactly* what the problem was for a specific Q type, and offered a way to quickly comment on a Q (while submitting a close vote) with a link to let the user know what was wrong with their question. This is why I worry all of these meta discussions are going to fall on deaf ears.

Comment: I'm sitting here *shocked* at the moment. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x ... Apparently, yes. They want crap, and from now on, we shouldn't close crap, or be concerned about crap. I guess this is no longer the site I should be contributing to, which makes me sad.

Comment: @mehow, top 0.27% :)

Comment: @BrianRoach: Please, let it go. We have read your question, we have read the answers, we formed an opinion on the matter, no need to keep pestering us with it. And for the record, I disagree; there can be *good* "How do I do X" questions, so let's not kill them all because of stereotypes.

Comment: Here is the Meta SE Deleted link for the "What Stack Overflow is Not" Question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not.

Comment: @Rahil, will you keep editing this post as gdoron's reputation increases? Because I'm not sure bumping this question for the sake of such minimal edits is a good thing.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Probably not

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I even think this edit should be reverted. The answer was posted from the view of a user with X reputation, it makes no sense to change that value.

Comment: @Stijn, true, done. The question was already bumped anyway, so it's not like we're adding much more noise.

Answer (score 36):

Probably. I know I'm answering fewer questions than ever.

Why? Because these days it feels like the purpose of SO is to exercise our programmers' OCD and categorize, delete, close, edit, rename, retag everything, rather than just providing content. Look at how many posts there are on Meta about how such and such questions should *not* be answered, how, apparently, unless they are the *right* questions, we are doing the community a disservice by answering.

SO has already become hostile to newcomers and people [*asking*](https://twitter.com/IrisClasson/status/461193053622251520) questions, and I feel like it has gotten to the point where criticizing answers for not following the right etiquette and not having the right secret handshakes, has become more important than the actual content of the answer.

This isn't a new development, and I've voiced my concern about it before.

But unless and until SO refocuses on the core idea of "get some answers for all those programming questions", even if yes, some of them are going to be duplicates, and some of them are going to be very trivial, I don't see it changing. Seasoned/high-rep users will gradually get disenfranchised and become less active.

Ultimately, I see two reasons why people stop answering questions:

1. good questions are too hard to find (typically because too much low-quality junk is cluttering up the place)
2. actually answering questions does not feel rewarding

In a nutshell, you could say that #1 is about making it easy to write answers, and #2 is about making people *want* to write answers.

Historically, SO has focused very heavily on #1, which does make a certain amount of sense. If I have to climb a mountain to even *find* a good question, then I'm probably not going to bother.

But what has been neglected, and this is what's bothering *me* is #2. You might have worked hard to make it easier to find good questions, but you have done *nothing* (and even sacrificed some of what used to be there) to motivate me to actually write an answer once a good question has been found.

When questions get closed left and right, this also eliminates the answers we wrote. I can see my time and effort disappearing down the drain because others don't like the questions that I answered.

Other answers (and I believe this may have recently been rectified?) have become community-wikied, solely because I had the audacity to *care* about them and edited and improved them after posting. Apparently, that is discouraged.

And if you just skim over Meta, by far most of the activity centers around what content should be *removed*. Which questions should be deleted, which ones should be closed, how should they be closed, what can we do to make it *easier* to close questions. How do we dissuade people from answering these questions or those? It is quite clear that Meta thinks the biggest value is in *removing* content, not adding it.

As I said above, it *does* make sense to try to prune the low-quality content, and I am not saying content should never be deleted or closed.

But there is a complete lack of awareness of the fact that *every* time you delete or close a piece of content, you are removing something that someone put time and effort into. If you close a high-quality question for being a duplicate, you're still closing something that was high quality. You are still saying "don't do this again". And when you close a question, regardless of its quality, you are also closing all the *answers*. Answers which may have been high quality, which may have taken a lot of time and effort to write. Answers which could have helped people, and which were worth rep. And to those who wrote an answer that is now no longer visible, the message is "don't bother".

It's been made quite clear over the years that SO does not value high quality answers. Answers are seen as a disposable resource, something that doesn't have to be cultivated or encouraged, because it turns up no matter what, so instead, focus has been on filtering and pruning bad questions, with no concern given to what this does to the answers that are effectively collateral damage.

In short, why *should* I write an answer? It seems that SO wants me to close questions instead.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more so it's not stuck at the bottom of the list where few people will read. I personally feel the same way.

Comment: I also agree.  My reaction to all the people being unhappy about 'bad questions' is to tell them to walk away.  If they don't want to be helpful, at least don't be actively harmful.

Comment: +100. I [answered similarly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253472/388626) not expecting anyone else to have. It looks like people are becoming a lot more vocal about how anal-retentive this place has become since I last checked last year.

Comment: I would point out that the idea of closing questions is to help you climb the mountain. I do feel sometimes that close votes are too "hard", but I do wish I did not have to sift through the junk.

Comment: How many questions do you normally have to sift through on any given day before you find one that you feel like answering?  Or do you just not get a lot of chaff in the C++ tag?

Answer (score 32):

I've been actively contributing to SO for about 5 years now. It's interesting that this post just came up, because I'd just noticed how much my participation has dropped of late.

For me, like many, I've grown a little bored of the same questions over and over again. But I think there's some nostalgia going on about how good "the good old days" were. I always remember there being a ton of the same questions. The difference is that I used to have seen the same questions for 1 year, and now I've seen the same questions for 5 years. So it feels like there are more, but it's partly because of how addition works. And of course SO is bigger now, and the number of really good questions has probably stayed about the same, but still I think there's some nostalgia going on. (I admit that SO is really many different communities, and things may be different in my tags than in yours.)

But there's another side to it. I may be alone here, but my primary reason for answering SO questions isn't to help people or to gain rep or to show off what I know. My primary reason for answering SO questions is to learn things. My favorite questions are ones that I don't know the answer to either. They force me to go research. Maybe even write some code. And when I'm done, I know something I didn't know before. I don't answer SO questions because I'm a good developer. I'm a good developer because I spent so much time answering SO questions.

After 5 years in the trenches on a small number of tags, I've kind of hit most of the intersection of "likely to be asked on SO", "I didn't know already," and "I'm interested in figuring out." Every year, the things I don't know in my field become more advanced or more specialized. That's the nature of becoming better at your craft. Sure, new things come out every year, but most questions are about the well-established pieces. And people who have very advanced, specialized questions seldom ask them on SO.

For awhile I focused on more specialized tags. Instead of looking at general iOS questions, I focused on more obscure tags related to text layout, encryption, and other specialities that interest me (including those new things that come out every year). But those questions are rare, so I participated less.

Now I've been learning new languages where I'm not an expert, and I've found I'm starting to answer a few more SO questions. They're smaller communities (scala and go) and there's a lot more opportunity to again find questions that are interesting and I don't already know the answer to already. Being less of an expert makes me more of a help. And being more of a help lets me learn faster.

This may just be a quirk of me and may not apply to other contributors, but I'm a reasonably high-rep contributor who has reduced my involvement recently, so I wanted to give my anecdote on why.

Comment: Just so you know, you aren't alone. I originally came across Stack Overflow while researching an issue I was having, but I've stayed for essentially the reasons you've detailed in your third paragraph.

Comment: lol. And I have been searching `user:97337 [security]` on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 27):

I only have 28k reputation, but if you need a report from the [java] tag:

The major reason I rarely answer questions is that I rarely find **questions worth answering**, because most questions are either:

- poorly asked (overly broad, lacking sufficient information, no attempt at isolating the relevant information)
- duplicates
- too trivial to be interesting for me

That is, the proportion of well-asked, new-to-me, and interesting-to-me questions is far lower than when I started using Stack Overflow. This decreased signal-to-noise ratio makes participation less efficient. Consequently, I spend less time here, further exacerbating the effect.

Let's look at those problems in greater detail:

**Poor Questions**

As a community, we must agree on minimal standards, and enforce them. When the community was smaller, and a greater proportion were regular users, we had a much better agreement on these standards (even though there were fewer rules). We have more casual users now, and must find a way to deal with them more efficiently. This being the subject of numerous other meta posts, I'll rest my case here.

**Duplicates**

Presently there are incentives for asking and answering questions, but none for identifying duplicates. And indeed, duplicates are asked and answered, rather than identified ...

I think duplicates should be subject to voting (awarding reputation for upvotes), and be valid accepted answers. A low-tech way to implement this is to point out a duplicate not in a comment or close vote, but an actual answer.

**Triviality**

It is to be expected that spending time on Stack Overflow caused me to learn more about coding, and that my interests have shifted to more advanced topics. It is therefore inevitable that I find newbie questions more trivial than I used to.

However, that shouldn't imply that I have to look at newbie questions, should it? Can I filter on advanced questions?

Comment: Though I really do think there's a glut of bad questions, one should keep in mind that "interestingness" is in the eye of the beholder. As one learns more about a topic, the subjects that one finds interesting change.

Comment: Oh! I wish I could filter on the "advance" level of questions too. It would be really interesting to filter out all those trivial questions that anybody can answer already and focus on questions where I stand a chance to learn something. Of course, the real challenge would then to be able to judge how advanced the question is...

Comment: ... I may have a simple proposal, based on the badges for the tags relevant to the question. A user's experience on the matter is judged depending on the presence of silver/gold badges he has for any of the tag of the question, leading to a simple scale: no-badge (+1), silver-badge (+5), gold-badge (+25). Likewise, each question can be tagged no-badge, silver-badge or gold-badge. By default a question is no-badge (so newcomers are not even exposed to the system).

Comment: ...  Users can vote for what they think is the "right" badge, however their input is weighted by their own rank. That is, a no-badge user vote is 1 point whereas a gold-badge user is 25 points. The question's current badge is the badge that has the most points at the moment. *Note: we may 1/ need a threshold for no-badge voters and 2/ need to adjust the points given from the badge; also, when tags are edited, the votes should be re-evaluated.*

Answer (score 27):

I was a very high rep user for a few years then practically stopped contributing overnight. Here's why....

I am the sort of person that is focused on becoming very good at something. I'll practice every day, read up about it, try to find new approaches, and always try to optimize my abilities. StackOverflow is just one example of this. Other examples over my life where I have had various degress of success: juggling, Scrabble, speed solving Rubix cubes, codegolfing, robozzle, etc.

I prefer to focus on one thing at a time, and do it intensely. Once I have a specific hobby that I enjoy, I'll practice it every day for weeks, months or sometimes years. But at some point I reach my peak and it becomes less interesting to do this single activity so intensely and I search for new challenges.

On StackOverflow, I initially was not that great at answering questions but I decided that it would be fun to "rep whore" (as some people here call it). To do this I needed to improve my skills.

- I read "competing" answers from other top contributors and learned why their answers were better than mine.
- I learned technologies in depth. I didn't just want to be good, I wanted to be an expert.
- I read manuals in detail when it helped me to give better answer questions.
- I learned the basics of technologies that I don't normally use, so that I could quickly answer beginner questions in a wide range of topics.
- I learned how to express myself more clearly in my answers.

The result: I became a better programmer. I also became more confident in myself. The skills I learned from answering questioning on StackOverflow certainly helped me with my job. I know that I gave my time away for free to other people and I have no regrets at all. Others also gave me their time for free, even when it was people criticizing my answers in the comments. It helped me improve.

I learned. Others learned. It's a win-win.

I also wrote tools to help me answer questions faster, in order to get more reputation faster.

An example was a partially automated tool that could parse the (often badly-drawn) ASCII tables of data that people would often post in their questions. It would generate SQL for creating those tables in a database, and inserting the data. I could then use this to test my answers. I often had to make small edits to the input data before my tool could correctly parse it, but even so, it was a huge time-saver compared to creating the database tables manually.

For commonly asked questions where the answer would take a long time to write out (for example group-wise maximum in SQL) I had a program where I could input the table names, column names, etc. and it could spit out the SQL for various different databases. Then I could just copy and paste the SQL into my answer instead of having to write it out by hand each time. Of course I could have just closed the question as duplicate and let them work out how to adapt the previous answers to their situation. But when it takes so little effort for me to help someone with a specific answer tailored to their question, and I get rewarded by some internet points, both people are happy.

I had intentions to write a more complete tool that could automate more of the work of answering questions. My dream was to have a "StackOverflow answer tool". I wanted stored "answer snippets" similar to Visual Studio code snippets. I wanted so that if I typed in some keywords, it could expand it into complete sentences (for example, typing "mutable-struct" could expand into "you shouldn't use mutable structs" with a link to a relevant article explaining why). Or perhaps I could highlight a function name and press a button, and it would automatically add a hyperlink to the relevant documentation into my answer. Basically I wanted a tool that would help me write high quality answers more quickly and with less typing. Even just saving a few seconds could be the difference between getting 20 upvotes and the accept, or no upvotes at all.

I never wrote the complete tool. I had a few programs that optimised some parts of the answering process, but it was still mostly manual work to answer questions. I automated some things, but mostly I practiced and practiced answering fast.

So why did I stop? All these tools now go to waste...

A major part of it is that I got a new hobby that I love. It helps improve my fitness, teamwork and self-confidence. I now concentrate on my new hobby. I don't have time to devote so much energy to two hobbies, so I basically stopped posting answers.

A minor part was a feeling of negativity from other users. I occasionally got complaints that by providing good answers to bad questions, I was encouraging people to post more bad questions. My answers were sometimes downvoted not because they were wrong, but because some users felt that I was helping lazy people too much.

I still use the site almost every day to find answers. I also occasionally answer a question or two, but now it's only when something catches my eye. I don't actively try to gain rep any more.

Comment: This seems like a good example of the dangers of gamification. As I understand your answer, you don't really care about the SE goal of creating a high-quality Q/A repository, you care mostly about points, and possibly about helping individual users (seemingly regardless of that being helpful to the site in general, e.g. answering questions instead of closing them as dupes). Which is entirely understandable as a way of maximizing your points, but sadly not a way to maximize the usefulness of SE.

Comment: @l4mpi Without gamification StackOverflow wouldn't be successful. Take that away and you have just another forum where most questions go unanswered and most content is low quality. Don't blame the people who are "playing the rep game". If the site owners want their users to maximize the usefuless of their site, they should award reputation for user actions that contribute to this aim. E.g. you could award reputation for correctly closing as duplicate. If I got more rep for closing as duplicate than for repeating an answer, I'd close as duplicate.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand my comment as directed against you personally or high-rep users in general; as I said it's entirely understandable from your perspective. I'm also not arguing against all gamification, but as you say it has some design flaws - one could say it's not balanced very well (which in turn leads to a site that's not optimal). Choosing ways to improve the gamification aspects is of course in the hands of SE; there have been many ideas such as giving users rep for finding dupes, but only little action.

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah... things can no doubt be improved. But SO is an order of magnitude better than every other site that existed at the time it was introduced. I can't point to any change that would make it another order of magnitude better. Small optimizations are maybe possible, but it seems to work fine as it is. You can post a question, and you get a good answer quickly. You can't really complain much about that. Askers are happy. Answerers are happy. The moderators though are hard to please. I guess the moderators have very different goals from the users, and it sometimes causes conflicts.

Comment: "You get a good answer quickly" - unless your question is complicated; then it's lost in the countless stream of questions that are effortlessly answerable. The only two "hard" questions I asked got a low amount of views and were eventually self-answered (granted, both could have been written far better and required specific expert knowledge to answer; and I didn't offer a bounty). I'm not certain that SO can be optimized to support both, but it's far from optimal that one basically needs to offer a bounty to have a chance to get an answer to things that are not answerable in 5 minutes.

Comment: @l4mpi I experimented with answering for bounties, but it was never worth it. The "time spent vs return" was lower than normal questions. The bounty questions often got a lot of attention from people trying to "steal" them. Even if you spent several hours tackling a difficult question for +100 bounty, you would not be guaranteed to get the bounty. Someone could easily come a long a few days later and basically copy your answer and just change it a little bit, and often they would get the bounty for the "best" answer even if you did all the hard work and they just made a small improvement.

Answer (score 24):

It's totally subjective, but my general view would be that the lifecycle of a Stack Exchange user is:

1. **New user:** Ask questions -> rewarded with answers+knowledge
2. **Seasoned user:** Answer questions -> rewarded with reputation (+knowledge)
3. **Established user:** Perform mod/admin/review duties/meta -> no reward other than 'helping out' + a little reputation
4. **Veteran user:** Loss of interest, disillusioned, have steady reputation points income from old answers, maybe maintain discussion in meta -> no reward for continuing active participation

Stack Exchange heavily incentivizes 1 & 2, as a means to draw more and more users in, however the incentives for actively participating when users move from 2->3->4 drop off HUGELY. Typically during this transition users have acquired a lot of knowledge, not only of particular subject areas, but also the site itself (what's been asked before, etc.) and so fight an increasing flood of content flooding in to buoy up those at 1 & 2, e.g. incoming users. They find themselves effectively performing *unpaid work*.

With that in mind, if we are loosely relating reputation to knowledge (I know, I know), it can be argued that users who possess more knowledge are less incentivized to participate; is this a good thing for a Q & A site? Arguably not, users will get their answers, but the average participant then becomes lower-mid level and may get lucky to get a very very good answer as opposed to just a working solution.

So how to go about supporting those users at 3 & 4, the heavy hitters/big contributors? I don't have any real solution, perhaps:

1. **Reward moderation tasks** such as identifying and closing duplicates, closing questions, successfully flagging, etc. - perhaps **not with reputation**, but another score which could be linked with additional moderation/caretaking duties/responsibilities.
2. **Allow users greater control over the content they see** on the site- what's worse, letting a user filter out < x reputation points questions or losing them all together? This could be unlocked at perhaps 50k, thus driving users to move from 20k-50k, and keeping them longer when they get there.

I believe the key here is giving users who have really contributed, a feeling of ongoing ownership- after all it is they who effectively created it, what is Stack Exchange without its content?

Comment: +1 for a low rep question filter. (I think the required rep should be 30K)

Comment: @podiluska - I did think about it being 30k when I put 50..looking at the %users at each bracket I think you're right, 30k is probably better

Comment: It wasn't statistical, it was self interest :)

Comment: I would just note that there's no necessary relationship between reputation on the site and expertise beyond a basic level.

Comment: @WarrenDew: I beg to differ.

Comment: @WarrenDew - there is an implied by not implicit relationship

Comment: 1 and 2 aren't phases users move between.  They're alternatives: 1(a) is a user learning programming when they discover the site, 1(b) is a user with substantial experience prior to joining.  While (we hope) learners become experienced and able to provide answers, the timescale for that process is almost totally unrelated to accumulation of reputation.

Comment: @podiluska - not perfect...but: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/191956/recent-questions-filtered-by-asker-reputation?Parameter=1000

Answer (score 22):

As for me:

I've been posting answers more as comments, and less as actual answers. Several reasons:

1. I want to help the OP, so that's why I comment.
2. I'm no longer interested enough in most questions to be bothered to write an actual *answer*. My interests in answering questions have mostly shift from "programming" to "computer science", and SO has fewer good-quality CS questions.
3. It takes less time for me personally to just point the OP in the right direction and go along with my business.

But perhaps the biggest reason for me is a complaint I have about the site:

**People on this site have extremely severe allergic reactions to succinctness**. There seems to be some prevalent mentality that a 1-line answer *cannot* be sufficiently useful to post *almost by definition*, no matter how crystal clear I try to make it, and no matter how much better it may be than other answers.
The result? I don't bother posting answers, since when I do, I often get burned at the stake (downvoted) instead of thanked (upvoted).

Fortunately, I can leave comments in lieu of answers without having to worry about their succinctness.
Unfortunately, I haven't found a similar mechanism to prevent allergic reactions to 1-line questions, so my number of questions is increasing while my number of answers is not.

P.S. the minimum number of characters required (that we can no longer bypass, IIRC) is arguably the most annoying part of the site, and it encourages this.

Comment: This is a big problem for me as well. I find succinct to-the-point answers to be the best. But it seems the mentality new favors researched show-off-what-you-know answers, perhaps of equal use to the OP, but of little additional use otherwise.

Answer (score 20):

Yes. For any individual there will be multiple reasons.

For me, I get more reward from helping the next generation of top answerers for example by commenting and seeing them improve their answer. There's no 'reputation' for this, neither is there any 'reputation' from an answerer deleting their incorrect answer having learnt from your comment - another thing that I count as a 'success'.

The reputation system discourages users with a large number of existing answers from providing more answers. I probably hit the reputation cap on more weekdays than I don't, whether or not I provide any new answers. I am "bankrolled" by old popular answers and the gamble of getting a 15 point bonus for an "accept" just isn't that exciting.

Comment: Ah! Good point about the bank rolling! Even though I only have about a third of your reputation I still get ~1000+ points per month just from old answers (and generally boring ones) so that there is no real incentive to get reputation anyway.

Comment: This is the problem for me. I only have just over 20k reputation, but in the tags I participate in it's far too easy to hit the rep cap. Once I hit the rep cap I rarely continue to post answers to the generic new questions as I feel I'm not really gaining much out of it. This doesn't stop me posting new answers on popular questions though, but I can completely imagine it to be a bit annoying to hit the rep cap before you've even checked the site for the day.

Answer (score 19):

The data we have available can show *if* this is happening, but not *why* it is happening. There are too many factors to consider:

- Factors internal to Stack Overflow -- policy changes, scale, sentiment, etc.
- Factors external to Stack Overflow -- the sector economy, hiring, self-employment, etc.

We need additional data in the form of a user survey. A discussion about whether to conduct surveys, how to conduct them, and what their content should be would be more fruitful than speculation.

Comment: +1, nicely put.  As a precursor to it, are people actually concerned about those trend lines?  I.e., if high-rep participation continues to decline, is there a Smaug waiting to devour SO and destroy the site?

Comment: Agree on the user survey. Disappointing that the annual user survey currently seems much more about collecting marketing information than genuinely requesting feedback about how we feel about the sites.

Comment: @GarryVass: The concern is a single facet of the one brought up by posts like [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question): I'm not sure I agree with the consensus in those posts, but the fact that the concerns are widely held means they might be worth taking seriously

Comment: @GarryVass That might make a good question to include in such a survey. My answer -- too early to tell. Obviously, we feel a sense of loss whenever famous (high "real" reputation) users decline. But, for the vague high "points" reputation? Meh.

Comment: User Survey Input: In the past years, I have gained in knowledge to the point of becoming *the* reference for development among my team mates. As a result, I answer more of their questions and I have less time to spend on SO. I would not be surprised if a number of other "high-rep" users were concerned by a similar phenomenon -- gathering more responsibilities/duties in their work as their experience grow. That being said, it's only one of two factors, whenever I look at a SO I have to sift through so many crappy questions/answers that it takes time to locate one question worth answering.

Answer (score 13):

Answering only anecdotally for myself, I can say that yes, I have been a answering fewer questions over time. There are a number of reasons for this:

1. On the rare occasion that there is an interesting question to answer that takes any time investment, there are several disincentives to actually answer it:

   a. On several occasions, I've taken significant time to compose an answer, only to have the question closed shortly before posting the answer. This means that there is a strong disincentive to answer any question where there is a possibility it will be closed.

   b. Older answers have a lot of inertia (more upvotes means it shows higher, which means more upvotes, so whatever gets upvotes first has a clear advantage). This means that there is a strong disincentive to take the time to give a thorough answer if there is any possibility that someone else will answer a correct if incomplete answer sooner.

   c. Answers to more difficult questions or more complete answers are not rewarded proportionally to the extra effort required.
2. Most of the questions are the same old questions that have been asked a million times, and I dare not even try to answer as they will be closed per 1a.

Comment: I wish I could upvote 1c a hundred times! Most of my rep comes sadly from very easy questions which didn't require any research from my part as I already knew the answer, and where I had the luck of being among the first to answer it. Actually, my highest voted accepted answer is to a freaking Hello World problem!

Comment: On reddit there's an option to only show the karma/upvotes for any comment after a timeout (eg. an hour after posting).  Do you think a system like that would help with 1b?

Comment: @robertc, I don't think that's necessarily the right thing, either, especially given that a highly voted answer may, indeed, be highly voted because it is really the best answer out there. Normalizing the score by time, by visibility/position in the list, and also randomly showing very new answers at the top to increase visibility of newer answers would be a better fix for #1b IMHO.

Comment: Regarding 2. => actually, that's a feature, those questions are meant to be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Oh yeah, the "I'm halfway through answering a question when I get a notification that it's been closed". I had never really considered before how much that contributes to discouraging me from writing answers but... now you mention it... I'm sure a lot of people will rush to tell me how important it is that these questions get closed, and maybe they're right. But it *also* discourages from writing answers. It gives a bad experience to people who are trying to help by sharing their programming knowledge.

Comment: I wish there was more reward for difficult answers as well. I've even had one of my answers, that showed obvious research and unearthed results that later helped answer other questions on the site, downvoted (naturally without explanation). * *sigh* * It's frustrating, but I have no idea what the solution to this is, or if anybody cares to implement a solution anyway.

Comment: I think "Older answers have a lot of inertia" is indeed a big problem. I would illustrate it for example with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program/

Comment: As for (c) "Answers to more difficult questions or more complete answers are not rewarded proportionally to the extra effort required." It depends. The bounty system fixes this to some extent. On math.SE where I asked a single (graduate-level) question, I somehow got 6 upvotes for my question, but the only and partial answer only got two votes (one from me) even though the proof it provided was detailed and not trivial, at my level of mathematical maturity anyway. Even though I'm very low rep there, I really felt like giving a bounty award to the answer and did so.

Answer (score 12):

The statistics thus far presented don't actually answer the question.  Rather, they answer this subtly different question:  "Do most high rep users answer fewer and fewer questions?"

To answer the question "Are most high reputation users answering fewer questions", you'd have to look at statistics on the users who were high rep at the point the answers were written, rather than at users who are high rep now, or were at some other fixed point in time.  You could, for example, plot the percentage of questions answered by users over a certain level of reputation, over time.

To put it another way, it's possible that all users' question answering declines with increasing rep, but that that pattern hasn't changed over time, and the same percent of questions still get answered by high rep users.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to write about it, but then thought that nobody would understand it anyway, and decided not to.

Answer (score 11):

I guess that high-reputation users are drawn to interesting questions, but interesting questions are buried under the sea of questions which can be solved by reading the first few chapters of a basic programming course.

The problem is, that interesting questions are very hard to understand by (or are uninteresting to) the vast majority of SO users, so they don't visit them and don't upvote them. As SO became more popular, the rate of beginner or student programmers became higher and higher. What question is more likely to be upvoted by a beginner programmer or by a student looking for help in a homework?

1. A highly specific and possibly very interesting niche problem which gets asked here because the QA couldn't find a satisfying answer even after an exhaustive research and turning to SO was almost a last hope?
2. A very basic question answered in any introductory programming book, but the large crowds of entry-level programmers or students see it and think "wow this is exactly the question I wanted to ask as well".

And which kind of question from the above two would make high-reputation users interested enough to try to answer it?

I have experienced it myself, and as I looked through the questions posted by me, I can see that my questions receiving the most upvotes are those which I'm the least proud of, as they are about asking for clarification or further explanation about relatively basic concepts. On the other hand, my questions about problems which I researched extensively and could only find suboptimal solutions and I asked here in the hope someone did know a better way, are stuck with below 100 views, at most one or two upvotes and no useful answers or no answers at all.

Would it be too undemocratic if **the reputation of the asker had an influence in the position of the question in the queue** (or having a different coloring)? Or any other metric, like the number of accepted answers, or the amount of reputation received only on answers? This would make questions asked by people who did gather reputation through answering more visible.
Even if we don't do this in a general way, what about an optional filter or sorting method which high-rep users could use in viewing questions asked by users who have at least some reputation in answering questions, so they don't get overwhelmed by questions like "whuts the difrenc betwen int and unsinged int plz"?

**EDIT:**

As others also pointed out, often someone asks a question, and we don't know if they even bother checking it again after some time have passed. Another problem on SO is that new  questions arrive in such a huge amount that if I post a non-beginner question, I only have a few minutes until it disappears from the first page.

What about making an incentive for high-rep users to answer relatively older unanswered questions? The problem with such questions is, that as they got so little attention, almost no one will read and upvote the answer, and it might happen that the QA is no longer on the site. So, what about adjusting the question sorting metric so that questions asked a while ago which have the QA still active on the site will get a priority over questions where the QA never did anything on the site (maybe didn't even visit it) after asking the question?

Comment: Regarding the incentive: that's what the bounty program is about. If you care enough about your question, you can put a bounty on it. It may attract unwanted attention from reputation-minded users that will try to answer with crap just to maybe eek out the bounty...

Comment: I find that "interesting questions" can be all sorts of things. Sure, fiendishly difficult and specialized questions can be interesting, but so can a complete newbie's question of how something really basic works. The simple act of explaining and helping others can be fun and rewarding and interesting.

Answer (score 11):

Obviously this doesn't go back to January 2012, but recently I have been answering few questions on SO largely due to the new cross-advertising of questions from other StackExchange sites.

It is *much easier* to find an interesting question in "Hot Network Questions" than in the most recent questions for my preferred tags.

Since I had not regularly visited any other sites before, I am answering questions on sites for which I am a low-rep user instead of the site for which I am a high-rep user. They're also for the most part further from my expertise, so I can spend longer looking at interesting questions and answers before finding one to answer myself.

Answer (score 10):

I'm Probably the most junior (rep-wise) to answer but as someone who owes so much to this site and genuinely wants to give back but whose primary skillset is PHP I can summarise why I slowed right down in answers ...

```
mysql_connect($how, $can, $you, $still, $be_using_the_mysql_extension)
```

Secondly, @durron597 nailed it for me. There is zero incentive to answer when, of the last 5 answers I have put significant time into answering, only 4 OPs have even bothered to check their question.

One possible solution to this might be to allow high-reps to evaluate and accept answers to non-accepted questions?

Lastly, and perhaps more pertinent due to my junior user status -> I clicked on this question as the exodus of high rep answers has also stopped me from **asking** new, SO appropriate questions. This is also partly due to the fact that SO is a victim of its own meaning that questions get flooded out of priority by:

> Can someone please do my homework? Ta.

So I think there is a double whammy happening and one of the risks to consider is semi-experienced juniors reluctant to ask new questions that will increase the net value of SO.

Answer (score 10):

After decades of programming (and writing books on programming), I followed the suggestion to come here. I have tried to contribute in measure to what I have asked. These are my observations from a short timer:

1. If I ask an easy question, it gets answered quickly. By this, I mean its something I know would be common but I just don't know and cannot find the answer.
2. If I ask a tough question, it will not get answered. After a few weeks, I can now predict with certainty what questions will get no answer and those that will get an instant answer based upon how hard the question is.
3. When I see interesting questions, challenging questions they have usually been placed "On Hold" by the time I get to them and I am learning the names of people who show up regularly as marking things on hold. It appears that there are those out there who respond to questions they don't understand by placing them on hold.

My conclusion is that that the incentives are directed towards softball questions that people can use to built rep up quickly.

I also point out that I find much of the same thing on the other Stack forums.
On other observation is that there are a lot of olde answers that are no longer valid. I frequently find answers to my very question for Xcode 2 and things have changed.

---

Let me amplify to address comments. A really interesting question is likely to take the form of, "What approach should I take to solve __________ problem?"  I can think of a wide range of, say, database locking and communication problems in this domain.

Such a question is also likely to have multiple possible answers; in contrast to the typical, simple C++ question that usually has one answer.

Such a question inherently has some degree of opinion, even if it is not along the lines of "What is the best application for doing ___________?"

That opens the door to "On Hold" Opinion, Vague, and so on.

Comment: My observation is slightly different.  Questions on obscure technologies tend not to be answered, presumably because there's no one here who knows the answer.  Questions that are merely difficult sometimes do get answered - and are almost always answered if accompanied with a bounty justifying the effort involved in putting together a good answer.

Comment: Meh. It's been my experience that the questions people consider "interesting" are the ones that can't properly be answered in a Q&A format. They're the things you'd talk about at a cocktail party. Sure, they might be interesting to experienced developers that think they already know everything, but they're not really workable for our format. As far as tough questions not getting answered, I agree that's a problem. But that's not a limitation of the site, that's a limitation of human knowledge. There aren't very many people *qualified* or *experienced* enough to answer the tough questions...

Comment: The whole point of Stack Overflow is that these questions are *more likely* to get an answer than they otherwise would. When I was an active user, I spent a lot of my time going through old, difficult, unanswered questions and answering them. I monitored the tags for technologies I was an expert in, and if necessary, I invested a considerable amount of time doing research and testing solutions to find the answer. I liked the challenge, and wasn't doing it for the reputation. Now, I'm like everyone else: overwhelmed by the crap and lacking in motivation.

Comment: `It appears that there are those out there who respond to questions they don't understand by placing them on hold.` I don't think that's widespread. But the rules that govern what is on topic on Stack Overflow can be complex and esoteric (which is a problem). Other than that, re reputation building and old answers - while you do have a point, show me a resource where things work consistently better. For all its flaws, the SO model is arguably still the best there is.

Comment: One of the most important considerations when placing a tough question is to use all relevant tags, so those who specialize in those tags will notice.  Second is the question title.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what qualifies as a high-reputation user, but my contributions have significantly slowed down after I hit ~10k reputation

For me a large part of it is due to the incentive structure - the gap between things gained from higher reputation is too large - forcing answering a lot of crappy questions, which one can only do for so long before getting bored with it. The other issue is that what you gain with that higher reputation doesn't have high enough marginal utility - I didn't even notice what I gained at 15k - it's some very unimportant thing that wasn't worth the 5k in effort and I only got to it because I'm still active in one of the tags.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what your threshold for high reputation is, so not sure if with 52K I'd qualify. But I can explain the reasons why I greatly reduced my activity on SO (not on some of other SE sites though).

- The most important, lack of any feedback to the answers. No upvotes, no comments, not marked as answered. It is very demotivating to spend time seemingly for nothing. I don't even know if the person who asked the question bothered to read the answer.
- Answering question just to have it closed as duplicate before you even finish writing the answer. Almost all obvious question have been asked already.
- Generally low quality of the questions asked. People just don't try to put in minimal effort.

Back in 2009 I used to answer more question in one day, then I've answered in last 12 months.

---

Interestingly enough, the rate at which I get reputation on SO has not only not slowed down, but is actually accelerating. However, for me getting rep might have been something I was looking for initially, but not something I cared about since getting about 2000.

[image]

Comment: **`It is very demotivating to spend time seemingly for nothing`** but in reality *answers, comments, accepted answers* are still **nothing**

Comment: @mehow: helping other is not nothing. Upvotes, comments and answer being accepted is a positive feedback indicating that your answer has indeed helped.

Answer (score 6):

i don't know if i can be considered high rep ( 36k now but i actually stopped at 25k more or less ).

There are mainly two reason why i stopped/slowed down.

1) i know this sounds silly but there was nothing left to unlock as privileges

2) when i started posting on SO i was working for an italian company. In Italy software developer are not well paid ( i got about 1.200€ a month ) and i couldn't stand living in an office ( i worked in nightclubs until i was 32 and started working only at 32 in the day ). So my main goal was to work remotely for a USA or Canadian company. Fact is, project you do in Italy are utter shit. Most of them are simply "do this website in 2 weeks, and do it fast" so i had nothing i was proud to show. Moreover in most companies software developer are treated like "brute force" and all my colleagues where simply not good.
Since i was doing most of the work for my company in 1 hour and actually doing nothing for the other 7 hours, and since i couldn't get a raise even if my boss recognized i was 5 or 6 times more productive than the rest of the team, i decided i would spen 1 hour working for them and 7 hour making a reputation on stackoverflow so that i could have something to show when i applied for telecommute jobs, and in the meantime i would become a much better coder.
And that's what happened, i was 3 months in the top 100 hundred of the whole site, i was number 1 on jQuery, i became a much better coder, i changed 4 job in italy ( nothing interesting obviously ), i sent hundreds of CVs and when i hit the 25k spot i was called by 3 companies. That was April 2012, i've become an happy, well paid, remote worker since then.
Working remotely meant having much more free time to spend on sports, going out, and other things you can't do in an office, it also meant i could go back to djing during the week so the time i spent on stackoverflow was drastically cut down. Moreover, working for a start-up, means that if i have 1 hour of free time, i do extra work, as i want my start up to have success.

I will be forever thankful to stackoverflow and it's not said i will not go back to it, but as other said, things in life change and so i drifted out.

That's my story, if i have to say my opinion, two years ago the discussions on meta where not that different :D

Comment: Hi Nicola, I was passing by and noticed your answer. Couldn't agree more. However back in 2009-2012, (when unfortunately I was still studying in high school) it was a lot easier to gain points, as there were less users around and much more interesting questions

Comment: @LppEdd when I started contributing, in late 2011, I had the same thought: "how easier was to gain reputation in 2009...". If you spend time practicing, I'm sure you will be able to get a good reputation, it's only a question of time :)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to see high-rep users and when the user signed up separated in such analysis.  Is there any difference between high rep users who have been here since the beginning versus high rep users who are a little newer?

Granted a lot of high rep users tend to be users who have been here a while.  But my answer is well maybe they just have moved on either personally or professionally?  The comment by @Mehrdad seems to make sense to me where it is now about Computer Science (not welcome here as much) and not coding.  And what about those people who have moved on from coding to Management and maybe don't have the same hours to devote to this site?

So at least to some small degree, I would answer life moves on.  CR7 will be your star for so many years then it is time for a new star.

Comment: The problem with CS (theory) questions and answers here is that they're sometimes wrong (both the question and the answer) because they draw little attention (for years).

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You know why? Because high reputation users keep discovering their popular answers have been on quesitons redefined as off-topic, or not well suited for the question and answer formaty, or otherwise get modded away.

Comment: Please substantiate this claim - it's just a rant right now, albeit a short one.

Comment: Ecce Homo. I am a high-reputation contributor and I have reduced my participation substantially because I'm tired of having long-standing questions with substantial answers deleted. I'd add to that I'm tired of having similar questions moved from SO to god-knows-what new stack exchange, and as far as questions go, not a little tired of trying to figure out which of 7 different stack exchanges is the right one for a question.

Comment: Preserving value isn't being considered, when moderating. Or if it's considered, it's not being valued enough.

Answer (score -3):

[Dunbar explains it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_number)

Stack Overflow has done a masterful job of stretching Dunbar's number, but Dunbar's number is not, and can never be, infinitely elastic.

Per-capita social capital always declines once population surpasses some limit.  This is what is happening here.

More reading on Dunbar's number, and why it applies to us, whether we like it or not:

- [Dunbar in Businessweek](http://www.businessweek.com/articles/2013-01-10/the-dunbar-number-from-the-guru-of-social-networks)
- [Dunbar in Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/georgeanders/2012/07/18/oxford-scholar-facebook-wont-widen-your-social-circle/)
- [Dunbar at Phys.org](http://phys.org/news183791343.html)

The good times at SO were nice while they lasted.  Regrettably, this problem probably cannot be fixed.

Comment: I am skeptical that Stack Overflow is or ever was built on "meaningful social connections", as it's not a social network. Unlike all the networks cited by the articles you point to, SO does not have features for "friends," the ability to "follow" users, or private messaging.

Comment: @DavidRobinson:  You are right, of course.  Your point is well taken.  Yet still, consider:  Private messaging or no, you and I have not met before.  After this pleasant exchange and one or two others between us, I would have learned a little of your sensibilities and temperament, and you of mine.  I would be less apt to provoke you (purposely or accidentally); and you, less likely to be provoked.  I enjoy reading answers by old acquaintances in the SO tags I follow, as maybe do you.  This is the beginning of what Dunbar meant.  Maybe Dunbar's idea thus has relevance even here.

Comment: +1 for "Regrettably, this problem probably cannot be fixed." It is too late now.

Comment: I'd say it's partially true. You're right about social capital decline. More like while it was more niche, only the most engaged and brightest people were using it. Now it has gotten popular and mainstream, even the most clueless and lazy people try to use SO.  But I don't think it related to Dunbar number. I've never really saw any social aspect to SO even 5 years ago, when it was functioning great.

Comment: Frankly it would be a lot more insightful to compare SO with Wikipedia than with social networks. Both are focused on building some kind of content base. There are some studies on the user retention problem(s) over there: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=wikipedia+user+retention. Being a non-profit (unlike SO) Wikipedia was/is more open with their database, so it was easier for the problem to be researched by outsiders, usually academics.

Answer (score -6):

I stopped asking and answering questions because the moderation here is hostile towards any question that isn't absolutely A+ flawless. Even for an otherwise very good question, any *speck* of a problem -- however reparable -- and the question goes down -- often along with the answers.

I'd rather waste time sifting through slightly dubious questions than waste time crafting a half-decent question only to have it shot down. Maybe it's convenient for people answering questions, but for people asking questions, this site is becoming an unpredictable waste of time.

You may not agree with me when I say that the moderation on this site is way too heavy-handed. Indeed, even with [very clear evidence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165281/200548) that this is at least sometimes the case, moderators are reluctant to admit to it.

But it should be difficult to deny that the moderation here is, at the very least, **way too high-brow and anal-retenetive to encourage participation**.  A common theme of the [complaints regarding SO](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow%20moderation%20-site%3Astackoverflow.com#hl=en&q=stackoverflow+moderation+-site:stackoverflow.com&start=0) (and a lot of other SE sites) is that there's zero informational content to the complaints moderators have regarding questions: you could ask a question, have it -1'd or closed, and you'd never know why. Askers just "have the door slammed shut in their face", as one person put it. Moderation here is just too flippant.

Sure, you could read the FAQ or ask on meta, but when the moderators and voters don't follow the FAQ very closely, or when moderators react to questions based on keywords rather than actual content, all we're left with is frustration.

I'm also not the only one to notice the sheer number of *wrong* moderation moves. My last two questions, which I asked last year, were both closed or flogged, despite both being [attacked for exact opposite reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165275/requesting-re-open-on-a-closed-question). In the end, after I asked about it on meta, one was well-answered, and the other was reopened. And no, it wasn't because my questions were both extreme in any way; they were both categorically opposite in nature.

Comment: The first several paragraphs are contradictory. You complain that the standards for question quality are too high, yet you say that you've stopped *answering* questions. That doesn't make much sense to me. Moreover, I'll ask you what I ask everyone who makes sweeping claims like this about the moderation on Stack Overflow: **do you have any specific examples** of "very good questions" that have just "any *speck* of a problem -- however reparable" that got closed (or otherwise "[went] down")?

Comment: `People answer with reasons why they stop answering questions, and you... refuse to believe them? ` Most highly upvoted answers here complain about bad questions, though. That's not to say you don't have a point; you do. But you *have* to acknowledge that there is another part to the puzzle, the volume and quality of the content coming in.

Comment: @CodyGray It makes perfect sense, and I explained it. There's no point answering questions when there's such a high likelihood that the question will get closed or worse. There are plenty of questions that are good enough to answer, but tarnish this apparently pristine site. It's exactly this kind of polarized classification of good and bad questions you demonstrate that we're fed up with. It's also extremely clear that you didn't read my answer at all, and again, that's something I've noticed to be true *every time* there's a discussion about moderation issues here. Hear no evil, see no evil.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Of course, but people have been complaining about poor quality questions and answers for years -- [myself included](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1109/6385). That's just a fact of life on the Internet for a site that has no barrier of entry. To think otherwise is just part of the kids-these-days phenomenon, where people tend to think newcomers are increasingly stupid. The moderation is what really changed.

Comment: @CodyGray And really, specific examples? There's one (two) [right there in my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165275/requesting-re-open-on-a-closed-question). Again, it's glaringly obvious that you have your ears covered. [Here's another](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218269) off the top of my head. If you'd ever even *read* these things, you'd see that people are sick of this site with good reason. Blogs via Google tend to have more easily visible examples because, of course, the mods here love hiding controversy. But if you're honest, you'll see plenty here too.

Comment: Community moderation has changed, and become so overzealous it sometimes hurts to watch. But so has the *number of questions,* which now has reached some 8,000 every day, and the massive number of problematic questions included in each batch, caused by the vast increase in audience for the site. Viewing one problem in isolation from the other is disingenuous.

Comment: `Even for an otherwise very good question, any speck of a problem -- ... and the question goes down ...` totally agreed, and that sucks. But what exactly do you suggest we do about that? Not vote to close? Then the problem remains unfixed, because there's more stuff coming in than eyeballs to look at it. Give custom advice instead of voting to close? Tried that, doesn't work. There's too much stuff coming in to give advice on how to fix it for each one. Have some canned comments to provide custom advice? Tried that, [caused massive problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795).

Comment: Have some better canned comments to provide custom advice? Is [expected to not work.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142710) Just ask people to comment more? Likely to be a debacle; many users aren't able to make non-abrasive comments as it stands and there is no way you can change that. Delay showing downvotes to make newbies feel less bad? Hides the message that you need to fix your content. And so on, and so on. I remember Jeff Atwood saying that he never intended the degree of strictness that the community enforces these days. How to turn around the trend in a way that works?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I ignore the capacity issue because it's been beaten to death. It's the *other side* that needs attention right now. The size of the site isn't an excuse for many of the new *kinds* of overzealous moderation we're seeing. Some mistakes in interpretation of the question content, sure, but moderators are increasingly dickish even upon review and in meta. I mean, [just look at this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253473/388626). It's bad management culture. There's no two ways around it. If it were truly just a capacity issue, the solution would be to hire more mods or queue newbies.

Comment: `It's the *other* side that needs attention right now.` you have a point there. But: re "bad management culture" - what aspect of that question are you referring to? I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with someone suggesting a close reason like that; [I've suggested it myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043). Also, to me, most of the overzealous moderation isn't actually being done by mods - it's more the closevoting public, which is often applying the law to the letter. How to change that? I'm not sure. I'm not sure whether it *can* be changed.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't care how tired you are of trivial questions, or if you disagree to the idea that sometimes it's hard to know exactly what to look for; demanding users RTFM is ridiculously unprofessional. It's flippant. Condescending. Self-congratulating. You're practically trying to fight trolls by being trolls. For years there have been several software solutions proposed on how to moderate the community moderators, but seldom tried even when mods begrudgingly agree. Why? Because fundamentally, this site is now more about taxonomic rigor (read: being anal) than about content or helping.

Comment: @Rei no one wants to introduce a close reason that literally says "RTFM." But if you believe that trivially google-able questions (where the correct result is on page 1 on Google) have a place on Stack Overflow, then we're indeed on a different page. I'm interested in interesting questions from people with a modicum of previous knowledge and initiative, and that's the standard I expect from this site.

Comment: `For years there have been several software solutions proposed on how to moderate the community moderators, but seldom tried... Why? Because fundamentally, this site is now more about taxonomic rigor (read: being anal) than about content or helping.` the community that is enforcing the taxonomic rigor isn't the entity that would actually implement those suggested changes - it's the SE team and from what I know about them, they are *very* interested in making the place work better. Either way, I'd be interested in which set of suggestions you are referring to specifically?

Comment: @Pekka웃 You can't possibly think regular users aren't offended by the proposition of an "RTFM" tag even if that's not its final name. It's the attitudes themselves we're fed up with. I don't have an opinion on whether or not trivial questions should be answered. My point is that that's irrelevant. [shog9 is among the people who have agreed to the need for audits on closes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165275/requesting-re-open-on-a-closed-question#comment482519_165281). That was a year ago. At this point I'm highly skeptical that the people running this site care. Can I be blamed?

Comment: I have no idea why  any competent programmer - or someone really on the way to becoming one - would be offended by a "general reference" close reason. Who finds joy in being an unpaid mechanical turk for others? If discouraging "how to remove div in jquery" type questions is anal retentive to you, then I'm proudly anal retentive. The overzealousness that worries *me* has more to do with good questions on the "fluffy" side, which often don't have a minute's chance on SO any more. And the slightly flawed ones that you mention, that get plenty of downvotes and snarky comments but little help.

Comment: ... but I agree that both sides of the coin, the low quality content and the overzealous moderation, need systemic solutions. I'm waiting for a couple of feature requests to be implemented, too, and I'm not sure how many of them are ever going to actually materialize.

Comment: I think you're completely mistaken about the RTFM thing - it's a completely innocent acronym with zero implied hostility when used in this context, a working title more than anything else. But I don't disagree that there tends to be a default stance that all questions are garbage unless proven otherwise, comparable perhaps to a group of jaded cops that treats everyone as a potential suspect.

Comment: I realize that can come across as incredibly arrogant to people who put a lot of energy in their questions, and that sucks ass. Adding more mods might be one way to battle that, but it's a more widespread thing - because to some degree, the hostility against questions is frustration over lots of really bad content. Not all of it, but some. Reducing the influx of that content is going to be one prerequisite to fixing the problem. Not the only one by far, but one of them.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If I'm mistaken, judging from the discussion on that thread, I don't seem to be alone or unjustified. Anyway, expanding on the jaded cops analogy, people have sympathy for cops who put their lives on the line for their work. But no one has any sympathy for a cop that's fired after being provoked into punching an agitated bum. Sure, causally speaking, taking bums off the street or somehow civilizing them would reduce the number of cops punching bums, but fundamentally the cops have to stop punching bums. It's part of their job to be civil. That's no different for moderators.

Comment: Show me an instance where a moderator was *actually* incivil to someone (like, rude) and was not reprimanded by the community or SE. Closing stuff - even downvoting stuff! - is not inherently incivil. I've seen some incidents where mods made wrongful decisions, but those that I've seen brought up on Meta were *mostly* resolved in a, to me, okay manner. I don't think mods are the problem, it's the development of the community standards that have become stricter and stricter.

Comment: `...judging from the discussion on that thread, I don't seem to be alone or unjustified.` neither am I; that doesn't mean either of us is inherently right.

Comment: @Pekka웃 If I'm not mistaken, you would agree that there are lots of questions that are good, answered, and in line with the FAQ that get closed. It's extremely hard to interpret that as anything other than hostility. Asking for examples of them *not* being reprimanded by the community no longer makes sense when they need to be reprimanded so often, and when said community in meta refuses to hear those cases. Again, just look at the [Google search from earlier](http://goo.gl/TSx3t6) and see the number of people frustrated at having the "door slammed in their face" for seemingly good questions.

Comment: Or, if you prefer to look for why people think SO sucks rather than what they think about its moderation, you can find a similar frequency of people complaining about the hostile moderation on the site by searching for ["stackoverflow sucks"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow%20moderation%20-site%3Astackoverflow.com%20-site%3Astackexchange.com). Likewise searching something more neutral like ["stackoverflow community"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=stackoverflow%20community%20-site%3Astackoverflow.com%20-site%3Astackexchange.com).

Comment: The fact that there are people who are unhappy with Stack Overflow isn't proof of anything in itself - as it can be easily countered by pointing to the 8 million questions and 42 million monthly visitors who imply that a sizeable population of visitors seems to *be* happy with it. It's an empty argument. That's not to say that many of those people don't have a point - they do. But we were in agreement on that some 20 comments earlier.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Of course. You can never make everyone happy. I was hoping it would be clear that that isn't my point. My point is that the people who *are* unhappy tend to be unhappy about the moderation and the hostility.

Comment: Yes, and I symphatize with that unhappiness and would like to see the culture change so there is less of it. But achieving that is not a trivial task, and it is *also* (although not *only*)  connected to the quality of the incoming content. I think we need to become more exclusive in some ways (like shutting out the abovementioned trivial Google questions) but more lenient again in others (intelligent programming questions that don't fit the super narrow scope SO now has). That doesn't mean excluding newbies - but you need to bring *something* to the table to ask a question here.

Comment: Either way - I saw Shog recently announcing some fundamental changes in the way questions get asked. I have no idea about an ETA, but perhaps something good will happen. We'll see.

Comment: I don't know, I guess the problem is that I fall into the category of high-reputation users who are answering fewer questions—a *lot* fewer. My participation is rare nowadays. I only drop by every once in a while when I am super bored. But my reasons are *completely* different than the ones pointed out here, and by jalf. I haven't stopped answering questions because I'm afraid that they'll get closed. Instead, I spend all of my time voting to close the god-awful crap that gets posted. That influx of crap zaps my motivation to post answers. So I find your explanation completely unconvincing.

Comment: @CodyGray You aren't everyone. Neither am I, of course, but that's why I looked up on Google, where people are talking behind the moderators' backs.

Comment: Why should I care if the people who post crap get mad when their crap gets burninated?

Comment: @CodyGray It's that very assumption that every question the moderators think is crap is indeed crap that's pissing people off. The amount of "I caaan't hearrrr youuu" on this site makes it even more hopeless than it already is. The site owners really should at least start paying attention when it starts being [compared to the Stanford Prison Experiment](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/10/best-description-of-stack-overflow.html) which is, at least in principle, noteworthy, even if for whatever absurd reason you don't think it's significant.

Comment: I also love how a community of professional *programmers* become so incapable of comprehending language that they think "people being unhappy about SO proves nothing" is a correct response to "people are unhappy about SO because <specific reasons>".

Comment: I don't know why you keep blaming "the moderators". Stack Overflow is largely community moderated. *Most* of the questions that are closed are closed by regulator community members, not moderators. It isn't that I don't think the Stanford Prison Experiment is significant, it's just that I think the comparison is patently absurd. And of course, I didn't say that some people being unhappy about SO proves nothing. I asked why we should care. The argument here is that the question quality is declining, which is causing experts to lose interest and stop answering questions. What about those users?

Comment: @Pekka Closing or deleting or massively editing stuff you wrote *without giving you any explanation* as to why ***is inherently uncivil***. It should be part of the workflow to give an explanation to the user. If the explanation is brusque that is also uncivil.

Comment: @CodyGray The concern of those users has been described a million times over on this site. It's the others that are being disproportionately ignored. I blame the moderators because their general inclination tends not to be any better than the community moderators. You're asking why you should care about crap questions, when the whole point of my frustration is that the non-crap questions are being treated exactly the same way.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka i only wish i could vote you every single minute....its time that some people take a stand....

Answer (score -11):

1. I think the StackExchange network is largely responsible for the decline of SO. People got used to asking and answering weird off-topic questions and leading philosophical discussions on SE and carried it over to SO.
2. I also feel that there is a strong focus on earning reputation as more and more employers are asking to show an "active SO profile". At the same time, the system is very far from being fair: one short answer on a good topic such as "How to undo the last Git commit" can give you **several thousand** upvotes. A lot of such short questions have already been asked and answered. Reputation, in effect, has already been distributed, and new users are at a disadvantage. Thus, they naturally came up with a solution: ask and answer more off-topic questions so everyone can get more reputation.

Comment: *"People got used to asking and answering weird off-topic questions and leading philosophical discussions on SE and carried it over to SO."* On which Stack Exchange site are these things promoted? The whole spirit of the Stack Exchange network is answerable, on-topic questions with focused, helpful answers. Same thing on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, I don't know what your experience has been, but "an active SO profile" doesn't equal "lots of reputation". It means providing lots of helpful answers. For example, I accumulate lots of reputation each day from my old answers, but I have posted very few new answers of late. Would you consider me an "active" user? I wouldn't.

Comment: @CodyGray this is promoted not by the "sites" but by brainless hot questions formula designed to work well only on large scale site like SO (maybe even only at SO) and breaking miserably at smaller / subjective-ish sites, **["diluting the brand"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224750/make-hot-questions-with-multiple-answers-age-away-faster-on-smaller-subjective)**

Answer (score -11):

Here's an example of what I described above. I saw the question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541653/what-is-funclet

When I saw it, I said to myself, "I'd really like to know that. I've seen the term bandied about, never knew what it means, but never took the time to ask."

I pop in to look at the answer and it's marked

```
  "On Hold-put on hold as unclear what you're asking "
```

The question is absolutely crystal clear. I was interested in hearing the answer. I presume others would as well. But a crew has jumped in to mark it on hold.

It looks like a bunch of folks trying to rack up points in C++ (normally full of softballs) see a question they cannot answer, so the knee jerk response is to put it on hold.

Comment: No, it's *not* crystal clear.  Read the comments; the context is highly relevant to understanding its meaning, and without said context, a definition couldn't possibly be given.  And even so, SO is not a dictionary (there are plenty of sites that *are* dictionaries, which would be an appropriate place to search for the definition of a term).  This is not a *programming* problem.

Comment: `It looks like a bunch of folks trying to rack up points in C++ (normally full of softballs) see a question they cannot answer, so the knee jerk response is to put it on hold.` Putting questions on hold does not earn you reputation.