# What close reason should I use for give me teh codez?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There's a lot of questions I find myself wanting to close which basically are:

> I'm trying to do X in code but I (fill in the blank) and so I can't, how can I do this?

Where fill in the blank is something like:

- I'm not sure where to get started
- I'm new to programming
- I haven't even tried

These questions often look ok at first glance, but ultimately are "give me teh codez" types of questions with nearly no effort. They generally are simply asking for someone to write code for them.

I'm never sure what to vote to close them as. Generally, the questions aren't unclear, and so the only close reason which seems to make sense is:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

But normally these questions do include sufficient information - they just want code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23412113/1048539) is a good example of this sort of question.

I don't generally add a custom reason since I find myself voting to close *mostly* because of this reason, and quite honestly, it'd be a pain to copy/paste something into every one.

Comment: If none of the close reasons apply to the question, it's a pretty strong indication that the question shouldn't be closed.  That the author didn't spend a lot of time trying to solve their problem isn't reason to close the question, it can potentially be a reason to downvote it.  Of course, many low effort questions, uncoincidendally, happen to have other problems with them, but in that case you're closing the question because there really isn't enough information to answer it, or it's not clear, or it's too broad, not because of a lack of effort.

Comment: There used to be good close reasons for questions like that.  Not anymore, they were removed in the summer of 2013.  Highly effective, it greatly increased the volume of such questions.  SO users just love it.  Well, [not everybody](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252799/17034).

Comment: @HansPassant No, the fact that a question didn't demonstrate effort was *never* a valid reason to close a question.  There were close reasons that were misunderstood, and thus abused to close those types of questions.  Those (entirely valid) close reasons thus needed to be removed, because they were being abused so much.

Comment: As Servy notes, these questions nearly *always* have other issues. In this case, the question is [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915215/excel-check-if-cell-value-exists-in-column-and-then-get-the-value-of-the-next), [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780192/excel-match-data-from-one-range-to-another-and-get-the-value-from-the-cell-to) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923197) [*many*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560013) times over - I stopped looking after the 4th result and just closed it.

Comment: Lack of effort has *always* been a valid close reason, because this is a site for enthusiasts and professionals, who put in effort themselves and are not interested in those who do not do likewise.

Comment: Valid downvote reason @Raedwald. Not a valid close vote reason.

Comment: @Bart Next you will be claiming that a question about cake baking should be downvoted rather than closed as off topic. SO is not, and never has been, a site for programmers. It is a site for *professional and enthusiast* programmers.

Comment: I would never claim that @Raedwald, give that that **is** off-topic. If that is what you mean by a "lack of effort", you might simply have your definitions mixed up.

Comment: @Raedwald You're welcome to pose a feature request that asks the community if "Lack of Effort" should be made a close reason -- but let's be clear, in all the time Stack Overflow has been around, *it never has been a reason to close a question*.

Answer (score 22):

If you can answer the question at the OP's level of expertise, without writing a book, then answer it.  Otherwise, close it as Too Broad.

There is no close reason for "I didn't put any effort into the question," and there never was one.  Downvote the question instead.

Comment: *"Downvote the question instead..."* assumes one has a downvote. We often run out of close votes and down votes while disposing of low quality fodder. Off-topic garbage has increased exponentially but we are using allocations/limitations from 2012.