# Provide "Not enough effort" as a new close reason

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

It's quite clear by now, I am not any longer afraid to ask for it officially; all recent highly visited and discussed posts that the community demands a new close reason.

New, because it [has never actually been a close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253137/what-close-reason-should-i-use-for-give-me-teh-codez/253138#253138) ( *not to confuse with minimal understanding and not a real question* )

If any question on SO is possibly a duplicate OR is researchable within 5 minutes spent on google OR answerable within a minute why is "not enough effort" not a close reason?

It would greatly reduce both:

- the amount of duplicate questions as people(answerers) can't be bothered to find a duplicate while there are 8K+ questions asked per day, that's 5.5 questions per minute, that's 25+ people constantly looking at the questions trying to match duplicates...it's sometimes easier to answer than to find a duplicate... but say NO to those. Close them as "not enough effort"...
- noob questions which are more likely easier to close than to answer as most of the questions lead to a *"OK, thanks for your answer but I don't understand nothing, can you explain? Yours faithfully, [help-vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)"*. Don't bother with those, close asap and tell the asker he has not put enough effort - that's a motivation! not a CTRL+C/CTRL+V...

Examples; [tons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520142/copy-paste-the-dump-from-the-mail-attachment-run-the-report) of [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519657/functions-from-object-to-a-xml-file-and-xml-to-object) - [within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23516216/function-to-start-a-user-defined-add-in) a [day frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514538/search-text-data-in-excel) in a [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514538/search-text-data-in-excel) [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507674/how-do-i-clear-a-txt-file-in-vb) [popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521495/macro-to-group-entries-based-on-postal-code) [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520852/what-loop-to-use-printing-to-pdf-and-saving)... *just sad*.

**TL;DR**

Two questions to conclude:

**Why does Stack Exchange refuse to add/implement "Not enough effort" as a close reason?**

**What are the top 5 cons to support the refusal?**

UPDATE:

Please re-read everything changing **"Not enough effort"** to **"Absolutely no effort"**

Comment: That's what downvotes are for, in my opinion. The question can be perfectly on-topic yet not show any effort -> downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So the question is do we want these questions answered.  By asserting that it shouldn't be a close reason you're saying that these questions *should* be answered, even if they are downvoted.

Comment: And I object to the *Community demands* claim here. Strongly. That's what we have feature request / discussion posts for, we *vote*, not demand.

Comment: I foresee way too much abuse of a "Not Enough Effort" close reason to make this a valid reason.  Too many people used the _minimal understanding_ close reason for this, it was heavily abused and as a result removed.

Comment: You demand "the top 5 cons" but don't give the top 5 pros? Rather one-sided, don't you think?

Comment: @Servy: I wouldn't necessarily answer such questions, but sometimes they can deserve an answer anyway. And 'not enough effort' is *very* subjective. What is easy for you or me is not easy for someone else; they can get stuck by not even knowing the terminology to look for.

Comment: @bluefeet Well, one thing to consider there is that a lot of these questions are being closed anyway, it's just that some other close reason is being abused to close these questions despite the fact that it doesn't apply.  Adding this close reason simply means that those questions will have an applicable close reason.

Comment: IMO downvotes by "good" voters have a hard time outweighing upvotes from "bad" voters (and people tending to not downvote to be nice or whatever tips this heavily in the favour of upvoters). Close votes don't have this problem.

Comment: Your post also fails to refer to [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840), which is really applicable here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, "not enough effort" is probably a bit too subjective - how about "absolutely no effort"?

Comment: @Dukeling: with no effort, it's real easy to close as 'unclear what you are asking' or 'lacking sufficient detail', as it is entirely unclear what help the user needs. Heck, I could even make a case for 'too broad'.

Comment: It sounds like you're mostly looking for the "General Reference" close reason [that was discussed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) 
([another link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)), but never actually implemented, a while back.  That was worded in a much more constructive/objective manner than this proposal, while still serving the same purpose.

Comment: @MartijnPieters why is the logic for downvotes on questions and answers different then?? If something is useless, unclear, does not show any research it should be CLOSED not voted on. Voting should be for the good things and exceptionally on answers when content is simply wrong.

Comment: Also, I agree with @Servy,SE lacks either "Absolutely no effort shown" or "not enough effort" and because of that other close reasons are being abused and the "explanation note" even after a post gets closed is usually irrelevant to the actual reason people voted to close a question..

Comment: @mehow: Voting for answers and questions *is* different. I am not sure what argument you are making there. We can already close questions that are unclear; including unclear what help is needed (if they didn't show the effort required to tell us what they are stuck on specifically).

Comment: @MartijnPieters but the arrow on a downvote says the same thing as a close reason ("or nearly") it's unclear etc. Why is there a close reason for "unclear" but not for "absolutely no effort"?

Comment: All but one of the posts you linked to are closed, what exactly is the problem here? That you want to give these users better on-hold text? Since they already didn't put in effort, I don't see the bother. And the possibilities for abuse of 'not enough effort' are even bigger than 'minimal understanding required' had, which we ditched for good reasons.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes they have, wrong reasons though. We have established a great team of few people who are active in the VBA/Excel tags and those poor bastards(read. questions) are getting served quite quickly, there are 0 posts to review in the review queue with VBA and Excel filter (even in the old queue there have been nearly none)..

Comment: @mehow: So, you have a good community around the tag (same for Python). **What is the problem then**; these posts do get cleaned up! Why *yet another close reason* where the existing tools clearly are working for you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters A question closed with the wrong reason doesn't tell anyone what the actual problem is with the post. What's the point of reasons if we use the wrong ones, we may as well have a generic "Should be closed" reason then. Not to mention that we want "official" encouragement for this, which we don't have, given Shog's answer, for example.

Comment: @Dukeling: we *have* a should be closed reason, "Other", with a free-form text field. I disagree the posts are being closed for the wrong reason, and you can always leave extra comments. And last but not least, for no-effort posts, it matters less (in my opinion) what the close reason is as the OP won't put in more effort to fix things *anyway*.

Comment: Realistically, @Dukeling, folks who've been around for a while have always known that closing is driven by need - the close reasons are for the benefit of new users (both those reading the closed questions and those just gaining close privileges). Terrible questions get closed for *some reason* even if that reason wouldn't pass a lawyer's scrutiny. We do have to be careful to not train overly rule-oriented users to close things that are actually *useful* though.

Comment: @servy - so we should stamp out close-reason abuse.  I've been flagging a lot of those where the stated reason is clearly inapplicable to the question - feel free to join in.

Comment: Subjective and really presumptuous.  How do you know how much effort someone put in?  It's really easy to guess wrong, and when you do, it can feel quite insulting.  Compare with the existing close reasons-- I don't think they have this problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree. Downvotes are hard to understand, especially as a new user. Having your question closed with a message saying why it was closed is a lot more helpful than a -6

Comment: @AnubianNoob: There are *so* many resources teaching new users how to ask questions. If downvoting is painful and confusing, perhaps that's a better impetus for them to pay more attention and learn about how to ask better questions. Question quality and on-topic-ness are two separate issues with a post, after all.

Comment: [What happened to the you're just lazy close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491/what-happened-to-the-youre-just-lazy-close-vote-reason)

Comment: I also would like to have the proposed close vote reason. It would improve quality.

Comment: Despite the moderator responses, the community seems pretty clear in its desire for this feature.

Answer (score 36):

It wouldn't *reduce* anything. It's shutting the barn door after the horses have bolted - the question has already been asked. Asking five trusted members to spend time reviewing and voting on it isn't a particularly great way of *reducing* the cost these questions impose on the site.

Worse, what if the question has already been answered? What if it's been answered *well*? Who are we really punishing now, the lazy OP (who is likely long gone and never cared in the first place), or the poor sap who actually *did* invest effort into it?

Combine these two factors, and you get an even more perverse outcome: lazy questions with good answers become *more* likely to be closed, *because folks are actually reading them!* The flood of unanswerable / duplicate / boring cruft that creates so many problems continues to be ignored, because... Well, who cares?

And that's how it should be. These questions should be ignored, abandoned, and eventually culled. Demanding that *we* invest more effort to handle questions where none was invested is a recipe for even more frustration. You can't hold back the ocean with your hands.

#### See also: [Should Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) be awarding "A"s for Effort?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: Soo... Don't cast your close votes, just cast the questions to the wind?

Comment: Downvoting takes like 2 seconds. Downvote and walk away.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: downvotes help there; the post is removed from the homepage and gets less attention. Automatically. Hey, goal achieved!

Comment: Of course, this doesn't do anything about rep-whoring answerers, which is what the community has been spending most of their focus on the last few days.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Except for all of the brand new programmers who aren't qualified to answer the high quality questions who love to upvote these "google my own title for me" questions, or all of the people who know it's a bad question, and even comment that it's a bad question, but won't downvote because, "it might hurt people's feelings" or "they should be given time to fix the post first".  The reality is that so many of these questions *don't* get downvoted (or at least they get an unfair share of upvotes along with them) and they are frequently answered (usually with poor, 1-2 line answers).

Comment: I'd love to believe that downvoting these questions solves all our quality problems, but I'm not sure I'm convinced of that.

Comment: @Servy: So the OP got what they deserved? *Over time*, if those posts don't help people, they'll get downvoted *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But they don't.  That's the problem.  People know that they're low quality.  People complain about them, **but people don't actually downvote them** (enough).  Questions like these have a reasonably high chance of getting at least some upvotes, and they have quite high odds of collecting answers (although very low odds of collecting *very good* answers).  The site has built in the tools to handle these questions *but the community is not effectively utilizing those tools*, and so these poor quality questions are causing a lot of problems.

Comment: @Servy: **None** of the posts Me how links to have a net positive score here. I see plenty of downvoting going on in the section of Stack Overflow I frequent. If people don't downvote enough, they won't vote to close enough *either*. If you feel the community is not doing a good enough job to use the tools, how are more tools (another close reason) going to help?

Comment: Broken window theory? Not closing and deleting no effort questions that may get good answers encourage no effort questions that are much, much worse and have "valid" reason to be closed, not to mention encourage more no effort questions that may get good answers, where-as the people asking them could've asked a good question in the first place, but didn't know it's expected that they do this.

Comment: @Dukeling: But these kinds of posts do get auto-deleted. They get cleaned up. I find it quite funny how everyone is complaining that we didn't have these kinds of questions in the olden days, forgetting tat we *did* get these questions *all the time* but that they have been auto-deleted since and thus are no longer visible!

Comment: @MartijnPieters [The system doesn't delete open answered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) (regardless of score). And just because we remove (fix?) a broken window eventually doesn't mean we don't have that broken window while its not removed.

Comment: @Dukeling: Sure, if there is an answer, and the answer isn't helpful, then it'll get downvoted too. If you feel it is creating a broken window, you can ever vote to delete negatively scored posts. Can you show me this happens a lot more recently; e.g. are downvoted questions receiving more answers now? Take into account that stats may be skewed by old downvoted posts without questions having been deleted already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, which is why I'm not completely convinced that this suggestion will help, even though I think it's worth consideration.  You're exactly right that we should ideally be trying to get people to use the tools that are currently available to them.  The question is how.  Adding closing has the advantage that a lot of the newer, low rep users can't reopen the questions, or answer them, whereas they *can* provide low quality answers to questions that have just been downvoted to oblivion.  So while getting people to use the tools would be best, more powerful tools might help.

Comment: @Servy: See, now we are talking. Perhaps Shog's idea to give Gold badge users more powerful close votes has merit there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, that problem has its own set of potential problems as well, but it also has a lot of good potential.

Comment: So I was thinking about the problem where people answer questions that get closed and deleted, thereby wasting their time and effort...why are the number of close votes on a question not shown publicly? It can be a visual indicator, **and warning,** that answering the question may not be worth your time, because it might get closed soon (and perhaps deleted thereafter). Or make it even more obvious, put a big box at the top of the question that says to the effect that it may be closed (like when people vote to close questions as duplicates, the canonical question is displayed at the top).

Comment: [Uh...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes) @Cupcake - btw, [have you seen this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166844/show-duplicate-suggestions-as-answers)

Comment: @Shog9 right, I mean make that information available to all users though, not just those with high enough rep to see it. If the original poster sees that he or she has close votes, they have more time to take action to maybe improve the question too. But I guess I should just start another discussion about it later `:/`

Comment: Might make more sense to put this in the hands of anyone posting *answers*, @Cupcake... "Don't let your hard work go to waste! Edit the question while you're here."

Comment: so is it better for site to allow [questions with -6 votes and 4 answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507674/how-do-i-clear-a-txt-file-in-vb)... What's the point of that? I am the only one who cast a close vote... why is that? Maybe it is a good and on topic question...  Maybe because there is currently no matching close reason such as "Absolutely no effort!" ... i mean how is the linked Q even a programmatic question.

Comment: Yeah, that question is crap.

Comment: We should be punishing "the poor sap who actually did invest effort into it" and that helps the "poor sap" not to invest in these type of questions and to be picky. The "poor sap" can always add a better question and self-answer. The system currently encourages rep-whoring and code only answers, because of the explicit lack of this close reason.

Answer (score 9):

I found this question, because I wanted to ask the same question. I actually think it should be an excellent close reason. StackOverflow is meant for professionals and enthusiasts, both of whom should show some effort when solving a problem.

Also, a question like that is very unlikely to help future visitors. If the answer is readily and abundantly available, then an extra question isn't going to add much value. Either the future OP will already find one of the existing answers, or they will not try and therefore not find this question either.

As for rep-whoring, a closed question doesn't accept new answers, and I even think that a question with a couple of close votes already is less likely to be answered, because it is less visible, and maybe there is a psychological barrier (close voting is a stronger signal than downvoting).

I think a bad question that did show research effort can be improved. Maybe the question was unclear or some relevant information was missing. This is solvable. A question without research effort is useless. Once the person asking it starts doing the research that they should have done before, they will probably find the answer as well.

So for various reasons I would like to have this close reason as a way to clean-up these questions.

But until such a close reason exists, just downvote the question, and/or check if any of the other reasons apply as well.