# Question that can be solved using basic debugging

Tags: discussion

More often than never (that would be around several times a day, and about half the questions asked under the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag), questions can be answered using *basic debugging*.

Reading the stacktrace, following the breadcrumb to the line of error, identifying the culprit, all this I feel any professional and enthusiast programmers should know or be in the process of learning.

On Android in particular, using [ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html), you only have to double-click on the first red line that contains the name of your package to see where it went wrong.

However, I am not going to write a complete debugging guide for each of those questions (not to mention that it does not actually answers the question), and I feel that Eric Lippert's *[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)* mentioned in the help is not specific enough and is too generic for most.

So basically I don't know what to do.

Comment: In this situation (very frequent under the `iOS` tag as well), I always feel the urge to reply (or comment): "Was heißt Denken?" But somehow I never do...

Comment: It's not just in the [tag:android] tag. It's in a lot of tags - I see it a lot in [tag:ruby] too and always want to comment 'did you actually READ the error!?'

Comment: Forget *reading* the error, half the time they can't be bothered to copy and paste it into a freaking search engine.  Or click on any of the various duplicate questions that *always* pop up...

Comment: Heh , under "c" tag yesterday was a problem where the guy even posted the compiler message saying "requires `;` before `if`" but didn't seem to connect that message with the required remedy.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215406/debug-me-questions-solvable-with-a-stack-trace-or-debugger

Answer (score 54, accepted):

We expect askers at Stack Overflow to have some basic troubleshooting skills, and to have used those skills to narrow down the problem to a specific part of the code.  If the OP hasn't provided that specificity (in essence, they've posted a "what's wrong with my code, it doesn't work" question), close it as **"Insufficient information to diagnose problem."**

Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.  If the OP hasn't performed some basic troubleshooting themself, and cannot tell you

- What the problem is ("it doesn't work" is not a problem statement)
- What the error message is
- Which line of code is causing the error message, and
- How the program is supposed to work

*Then you don't have enough information to solve the problem.*  If you can spot the error just by looking at the code, then you're certainly welcome to answer the question, but you can't be expected to reproduce the OP's entire environment just to debug their code for them.

**Further Reading**
[Are there legitimate “fix my code” questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788)
[Write Canonical Posts, and close commonly-Googled questions as dupes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254116/102937)

Comment: So why did we get rid of the "minimal understanding" close reason? This sounds like a perfect example.

Comment: Because it was being widely abused to mean "minimal effort," which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: In a lot of cases, there is in fact not much information. however, it also happens a lot that, once the OP has been reminded of the necessity to post more info, the stacktrace is posted. At which point it becomes obvious that the `minimal understanding` is not there. (But I agree that this close clause can be abused too easily)

Comment: "Insufficient information to diagnose problem" is a complete (and more accurate) replacement.

Comment: They are weasel-words.  Everybody *knows* what the problem is, the OP needs to learn how to use a debugger.  No additional information is required.  If you insist we need to distinguish between "minimal understanding" and "minimal effort" then we need an extra bullet in the dialog, not weasel-words.

Comment: @HansPassant: The post I linked makes that distinction crystal clear.  Question askers who can't use a debugger also generally can't describe their problem in sufficient detail for it to be reasonably answerable in a Q&A setting.

Comment: We already know what good questions look like.  At issue here is what to do with bad ones.

Comment: @HansPassant: Close them as "insufficient information."

Comment: Hmya, you already stated that opinion of course.  That's a problem with weasel-words, they provide only a very small vocabulary and you'll quickly have to switch to treating listeners as tone-deaf morons.

Comment: @Hans: Not quite sure what your objection is, unless you simply want the close reason to say "your question sucks."

Comment: Those are not weasel-words.  They are rude words, can't say them either.  Although I'd guess that's exactly what the OP muttered under his breath when he saw the question.  The means for *reasonable* communication were made unavailable, you can't simply state something as obvious as "I don't think this question belongs here, the answer is widely available".  A big reason why we get so many of them lately.  Can't get there until we stop having to resort to using weasel and rude words.

Comment: Honestly I am not quite understanding the definition of "weasel-words". Can you define "weasel-words" and provide an example of a non-"weasel-word"? ..

Comment: This clearly falls under the minimum understanding close reason. Even with the abuse is it more desirable to have the new feed polluted with low quality questions?

Comment: @HansPassant The thing is that in real life there are a lot of additional bullets that could be included in the Close dialog (and I wish they were). I've already said [elsewhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no/253015#253015) what they are. Things like "Expects us to write your code for you." "Too lazy." "What is Google? Howzabout using it?" "Too gormless. Don't just sit there: _try_ something!" "Too ignorant: not ready for Stack Overflow. Do some basic learning, then come back."

Comment: @HansPassant: If your only objection to the close system is that the close reasons are weasel words, then put your own words into a custom close reason.  Problum solved.

Comment: My objection is that the system is rigged for everybody, not just me.

Comment: I've occasionally closed questions with the exact wording expressed in this question: "This question is off-topic because it can be solved with basic debugging."  But I also get annoyed typing that all the time, and just close answers with "Insufficient information to diagnose problem." I agree with Hans' sentiment that we *really do* know what the problem is, we just don't feel like dealing with yet another first-time programmer who's too lazy to learn how to debug. [What happened to the “You're Just Lazy” close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491)

Comment: The thing is, if code for reproducing the problem is posted, of course there is enough information to diagnose the problem. It feels like removing the "minimal understanding" close reason is just forcing us to abuse the other reasons. A question that would have had 5x minimal understanding votes before, now gets 2x lacks info, 2x too broad, 1x unclear.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've updated my answer.  I hope that clarifies.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: If you know what the problem is, then just answer the OP's question.  See my answer update.

Comment: @OGHaza: See my answer update.

Comment: **Some people** will apparently **never learn** how much effort is unnecessarily wasted in the close/reopen cycle...

Comment: @ChrisStratton: If you have a **viable alternative,** I'm **all ears.**

Comment: Do nothing, or at least give the normal question/comment/answer process a couple of days before **getting in the way of it**.  Moderate and close/delete against spam, name calling, etc - not against normal healthy usage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The premise of much of the conversation here on Meta.SO over the past couple of weeks centers on how to improve question quality. At the center of that debate is the premise that low-quality askers keep asking their low quality questions because their questions get answered anyway (frequently by other low-rep users... the blind leading the blind).  The way you prevent that is by *closing questions early.*  Closing *is the grace period;* it prevents answers while giving the OP time to improve their question.

Comment: The view that closing should be used as a *temporary* tool is **utterly broken** - it's both highly inefficient and **contrary to natural interpretation**.  No matter what language you put in the close message, it's still a blunt instrument by which a few people (often with no great interest in or knowledge relative to the question) **create a roadblock** to normal healthy interaction between askers and answers.  **It impedes precisely the process which leads to quality**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Then **offer** a **viable** alternative.  **Something** other **than** doing **nothing** at **all.**

Comment: Post a comment indicating what specific action would improve the question, **then give the poster time to do that**.  Quite often, this results in a full improvement and resolution cycle in minutes to hours.  But if instead someone of the "close first" mindset happens along and disrupts the process, it can take days - or simply drive a frustrated poster away from the site forever.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568693/array-in-interrupt-service-routine) is the kind of question I'm talking about.  There's no waiting on questions like that.  They just need to be closed.  Next?  There are hundreds of questions asked like that on Stack Overflow, every day.

Comment: And which action on that question - your wielding the close hammer or my interacting with the poster by comment - do you honestly believe is more likely to be productive?  And worse, if they do respond to my comment, we'll still have to undo your heavy handedness before we can resolve it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The likelihood of that question being rehabilitated is close to zero.  That's not our fault; it is the fault of the asker.  The same problem that plagues such questions also prevents their rehabilitation: **lazyness.**

Comment: Such a viewpoint is why **you do not belong** on a site where engineers seek to **help** other engineers.  Helping means guiding people to learning and achievement, not spanking them or assuming they can never learn.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I know you're not going to understand this, but there are an infinite number of possible questions that can be asked by an infinite number of monkeys,  so we have to reserve our limited and precious **free time** for those folks who deserve it, meaning those folks who will take the time and effort to help us help them.  The only way we can do that is by reducing the noise.  See also http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @ChrisStratton: How does one find those questions in the sea of noise that is the front page of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Perhaps you should choose some tags that are personally interesting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You mean like the PHP tag?  Or the Android one?  Tags that are flooded with newbie questions from folks lacking basic knowledge?

Comment: Interesting enough for you to be willing to *engage* with a poster and provide specific assistance towards a resolution, instead of wielding the hammer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Where?? I must fix that immediately.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Anyway, if you don't believe the premise that the noise is a real problem, then you'll naturally resist any attempts by other community members to find a solution.

Comment: I actually agree with @Chris here - closing is entirely the wrong tool for the job, regardless of whether the goal is helping people improve or reducing noise: it's just too damn *labor intensive* for everyone involved. We've made it as friendly as possible, and gotten a nice little bump in improvement *from the tiny handful of folks who actually care about learning* - but statistically, you *have* to assume that if you're closing a question, it's gonna stay that way and probably get deleted.

Comment: As an aside: there are two more changes, long-discussed, that will finally be rolling out in the next few days and should pretty much wrap up [those complaints about the SO close queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue). I'll write up an epilogue, and maybe then we can finally get back to working on the problem of thousands of mediocre questions that aren't worth anyone's time *even to close*.

Comment: I disagree with the `If you can spot the error just by looking at the code, then you're certainly welcome to answer the question` in cases where the answer is so obvious that the OP should be able to see it if they knew a thing or two about the language.

Answer (score 18):

Consider taking a page from the PHP folks' book here: create a few [canonical posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) for [commonly-googled errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) and then dup-close everything that fails to read them.

Plenty of folks will still ask them anyway, but the more you reference them the easier they'll get to find for anyone who isn't perversely dedicated to *not* searching.

Comment: The Java NullPointerException question comes to mind here as well.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)?

Comment: @assylias Yeah, that post exactly.

Answer (score 16):

Leave the question open and downvote. There is no "not enough effort to solve the problem yourself" close reason and that's how the community team likes it.

[further reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253890/110707)

Comment: This is the non-weasely answer, it is accurate.  It is going to be unpopular.

Comment: Yep, "This question does not show any research effort" is what the down arrow says. Why waste community time pointing to answers via the duplicates close reason, which _rewards_ the asker by providing an answer via the link.

Comment: @A.Webb Why?  Because until they are deleted, they show up in Google searches and the link to the duplicate will help others.

Comment: +1 This answer certainly seems to be the official stance (despite Rob's opinion above differing), but I'd probably be abusing one of the other close reasons myself (exactly what removing the "minimal understanding" close reason was supposed to avoid....).

Comment: Plus, as a bonus, if we don't close them, rep whores will answer them. This helps SE's goal of building the world's biggest archive of duplicate (and often wrong) answers to the same questions over and over spread out over many different ad-revenue-generating pages, make making the site stickier because a user will have to go through many pages to solve their problem. Everyone wins!

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Follow the [further reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253890/1756702) link in this post. I agree with Shog9 there. You must also realize all negative statements are tinged with irony; we wish the problems were solvable in other ways.

Comment: It's not much of a strategy to build a bigger web site.  After years of experiencing geometric growth, SO stopped growing in the fall of last year.  You can't draw more visitors when you web pages are filled with uninteresting crap.  A quarter of a million questions per month doesn't make much of a dent when you try to get past the 40 million mark.

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed a lot of these questions under the PHP tag. I normally downvote the question and ask the people to do some basic debugging. Depending on the response I choose to remove my downvote or further vote to close the question as a *duplicate of ...* (or as a *problem that can no longer be reproduced*).