# Dealing with questions with very large code dumps

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I see a lot of questions on SO (usually from new users, but not necessarily) where they dump *all* their code into the question, I suppose, in order to tick the box "I've shown my code".  Here's [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947462/java-lang-numberformatexceptioninvalid-double-when-parsing-json-with-retrof).  Often most if not all of the code is irrelevant and it feels that the poster couldn't be bothered to try to understand where in the code the error actually happens.

On the one hand, having all the info is good, on the other hand, it easily gets too much to digest and I find myself thinking "sod it, I can't be bothered reading through thousands of lines of code". Sometimes I would add a comment indicating that there's no need to post all the code, just the relevant piece, at other times, I downvote the question and add a comment stating why. Is there a suggested/preferred/whatever way of dealing with this?

Oh, and most (if not all) of the times, the poster doesn't own the copyright to the code they are posting.  I wonder what their employer/client would say if they realised that the entire source code of their app is posted on SO :)

A similar argument goes for a a lot of data (e.g. the question linked above contains a very large json response, which among other things contains what looks like real phone numbers).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried repeatedly to figure out the best way to close these. It is tempting to close them as "off-topic" for the 3rd reason, the one that links to the ["minimal example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page in the Help Center. But that reason also says "it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem", which is clearly not true. It includes way too much information. So I just shake my head at the lousy close reasons we're now stuck with and punch the downvote button.

Comment: `no need to post all the code, just the relevant piece` "But it's all relevant. And I don't know where the problem is but it's in there <wave pointing hand> somewhere."

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah, I hear you.  Sometimes, if I feel particularly inclined, I vote to close providing a custom reason of "too much irrelevant information make it impossible to diagnose the problem"

Comment: I'd +1 a feature request for introducing an "Off-Topic: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service" reason.

Comment: I'd +1 that if you request it.

Comment: When I see lot of code copied on SO from a new user, mostly I assume, OP don't know anything about code, OP haven't tried to understand code, OP has copy pasted some code from here and there and he doesn't know what he is doing, now OP wants us to fix the problem. I have seen incidents, where some users tried to teach OP rather than just giving them code and those OPs refused or get into a fight with helpers

Comment: @DroidDev Those are a different bunch.  I myself have tried on my occasions pointing out where the problem is and how to go about fixing it - and all I was getting in return was "can you write that code?" A few times I get reply along the lines of "this is too complicated for me" - to which I _always_ reply "then you shouldn't be writing code in the first place".

Comment: Whenever I've come across a question that contains what look like real phone numbers or email addresses I've edited them out of the question and left a comment saying that they shouldn't be posted. If it was posted in a comment I put a custom flag on it saying that they've posted potentially sensitive data that shouldn't be in the public domain.

Comment: In-fact sometimes that _bunch_ also includes some heavy question-askers, which sometimes also offer bounty for writing code for them.

Comment: @DroidDev Oh yeah! and you can't vote to close a question that has bounty attached

Comment: In-fact, it has more chances of getting a very good answer because of the bounty attached. I was just browsing bounty tab and until now I am through at-least 5 such questions. __P.S.__ I am still on first page of bounty questions.

Comment: I see far too much of this in [android]. A user sees a `NullPointerException`, and decides the best course of action is to post their entire Activity class, their entire Fragment class, their layout files for each, and a random selection of other classes and layouts just to be sure that they have someone's attention for the next half hour.

Comment: There is an SO guideline that says OP's are automatically entitled to have their poorly-indented, [i][j][k] ** etc. code debugged in parallel by SO contributors without making eny effort themselves first.  I can't seem to find it now, but it must be there somewhere, since so many believe it.

Comment: @CodyGray I was going to propose that, but [meh (about what reason can sometimes work)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254094/question-that-can-be-solved-using-basic-debugging/254096#254096) and [meh (about what presumably SE's, and the community's, stance is)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253787/are-there-legitimate-fix-my-code-questions/253788#253788) (but I don't think a debugging question **with** all of that provided has much, or any, long-term value, or at least I don't remember having ever seen one).

Comment: @MartinJames With regard to no effort - something along [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort/223482#223482) [lines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort) perhaps? (or look for "minimal effort" on MSE or here - they removed that reason because it was used for this reason - I'm sure I've seen dozens of occurrences of mods pointing out that showing no effort isn't, by itself, a reason to close the question - still makes me cringe every time).

Comment: @Dukeling For your first link, Robert's answer kind of blows my mind. I mean, sure, I do exactly what he suggests sometimes, but only because there is no better option available. Closing a question with *too much* information as having "insufficient information to diagnose problem" is, however, absurd. It is also confusing and sending the wrong message to users. They think, "oh, not enough info" and post *more* code—exactly the wrong way around. As for the second link, that doesn't seem to contradict at all. There, Robert has just described what a *good* on-topic question would look like.

Comment: I'm not here to read the bible, so I usually just ignore these questions and move on.

Comment: Evidence for the prosecution [Genetic algorithm error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982868/genetic-algorithm-error) — over 900 lines of code, over 750 non-blank, non-comment lines of code.

Comment: One issue is that those who do post only the relevant portion of their code are often told in the comments repeatedly to "*post ALL of your code, please.*". Perhaps instead the response should be "*Please post the relevant sections of your code. What you've given is not enough to answer the question. No need to post all of your code though.*" Or instead, just posting a link to a good example would be helpful in those cases.

Comment: @CodyGray, on "having too much information": wrong. These questions don't have too much information. What they have is too much data. There is very little information on them. (not a Comp.Sci. person myself, but I'm pretty sure this is even technically true). Narrowing down the culprit adds critical information to the question and makes it answerable. So I'm pretty happy with the idea of closing as "not having enough information".

Comment: @Euro Okay, semantics are fun, I agree. But consider whether the type of people who *ask* these questions are likely to understand that difference. If not, what have we accomplished?

Answer (score 46):

I tend to down-vote and point the user to the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page.

I don't have a lot of patience for people who code dump; they are often lazy and can't be bothered to adjust their code to suit their audience. The idea of providing anything other than a vague description of their issue and a copy/paste out of their editor is alien to them.

Conversely, I'm really quite pleased when I see a question with a decent code example and they often get an up-vote for that reason alone.

*Don't get me started on indentation.*

Comment: _Don't get me started on indentation_, that is exactly worth italicizing.

Comment: Also, it's much more annoying if the code is poorly indented.

Comment: The problem with this view, is that at least half of the time, if someone actually knew which code was specifically relevant, they would have already solved their own problem.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Not necessarily. I see plenty of questions where the code presented is minimal and the problem is not clear to the OP. The instructions in the MCVE page are quite clear and will guide a beginner through creating an MCVE. If they solve the problem in the process, well that's a bonus.

Comment: @ChrisStratton In a way, that is exactly the point of asking someone to generate a minimal code example: The exercise of generating it often reveals the problem.  If it doesn't reveal the problem, it focuses the question.

Comment: @WayneConrad - yes, that can be true.  But someone with the knowledge of how to localize the problem generally won't need to ask a (new) question here anyway.  Most questions come from people who's difficulty is not the technology at issue in a problem, but rather not knowing how to approach it.

Answer (score 29):

I tend to comment and downvote as well. Quite often I try to explain why all the extra code isn't needed. Most notorious to me are questions about some Ajax/PHP/MySQL setup, where all the code is posted and it's not even clear whether the error is in JavaScript, the PHP source or a query being executed.

I think a developer should know where his code runs and in which context. I also think they should be able to at least narrow down the issue to the relevant area. And I believe that if they would, that most of the time they wouldn't even need to ask the question.

So usually, I comment, explaining where to look for first, so they can exclude a big area of their source code. And often I also downvote, not to be hateful, but because questions in that format are not useful, both for OP as for future visitors.

If there would be a 'Off-Topic: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service' close option, I'm afraid I would use it quite a lot, because that's usually how I feel about questions like that. But on the other hand, quite often I get the idea that questions like this are from people who just bit off more than they can chew. They are learning the syntax and in the mean time they're already building a complete application. They just get lost in the forest, so I think it's valuable to give some proper hints in the right direction. Even a remark like 'Press F12 and look for script errors' would be more useful than 'SO is not a debugging service', although it's a pity that they didn't follow a good tutorial that already taught them about debugging.

Comment: pet "favorite" `where all the code is posted` _except the bit that's actually relevant_. Like "I get this sql error" and there are no sql commands in the reems of code in the question.

Comment: That's a good point about biting off more than you can chew. I asked a question recently where I felt like that, I'd tried debugging and couldn't understand the issue any further. In the end I SO'd it but it took me about an hour to write my question + provide enough contextual information. I guess it's how much effort someone puts into that.

Comment: @AD7six Mine would be 8 classes each 100+ lines long and at the very end a quick `My error says Null something..` without even one full line from a stacktrace or legitimate error to help wade through all the dross.

Comment: Re: "Even a remark like 'Press F12 and look for script errors' would be more useful than 'SO is not a debugging service'": The reason that starts with "SO is not a debugging service" could certainly end with a link to a Help page with helpful links.

Comment: _it's a pity that they didn't follow a good tutorial that already taught them about debugging_ - I can't count the number of times when I added a comment with a link to a good tutorial and get a response along the lines of "I don't have time for this, please solve my problem"

Comment: @AleksG Fortunately I also get responses along the lines of *"Gee thanks! I've never seen these developer tools before. They are sure gonna help me a lot!"*. If someone answers like you say, I would like to have a burn and bury-button instead of a downvote button. :)

Comment: The VERY occasional 'Oh, right, thanks I'll find out how to use the debugger' replies are vastly swamped by 'if you can't be bothered to do my debugging for me, sod off'.

Answer (score 8):

I usually vote to close these questions. I use "unclear what you are asking" if the OP seems just lazy and "Too Broad" if it seems they are clueless. The latter because an explanation that *they* would understand would be too long. If I feeling cranky I've chosen "Too broad" because even one word of reply is more than the question merits.