# What was our stance about short, self-contained examples again?

Tags: discussion, minimal-reproducible-example

I'm on the fence about this one.

On the one hand, I'm all for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s. Having the OP make me scroll through pages and pages of code, most of which is completely irrelevant to the problem, is not a pleasant activity.
(Of course if the OP doesn't paste their code at all, but just provides a link to their live webpage, or to a zip file containing the source code, that's a no-brainer. Not asking about that.)
So, yes, providing an MCVE is good.

On the other hand...

1. It happens far too often that the OP *tries* to create a MCVE, but makes a tiny mistake, and then all the [FGITWs*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) flock in and post answers like "You have a `)` too many", like a dozen in the first minute after posting. And then they disappear before the OP can edit the question, not to return again.
2. It happens far too often that people spent time and effort in an answer, and then the OP comments, "yeah, nice, but that doesn't work in the *real* program, see..." and you can go back to the drawing board.
3. Or people can see it's a MCVE, and they comment "Hey, that's not your real source. Post your real code instead!" or they totally ignore it being out of context and remark things like "you don't really need this".

So, what's our standpoint, officially? Is there a canonical post, or blog, that I can refer to?

* Yes, I know technically it's FGsITW for a plural, but I can't bring myself to type that.

Edit:
Judging by the number of downvotes, people seem to think I believe MCVEs are not a good idea. That's not true! Like I said right at the beginning, I'm all for MCVEs. So I'm not proposing a move away from MCVEs.

What I want is solutions for the *problems* with MCVEs. The points mentioned above. Of course #1 can be addressed by "just test already".
#2 is the hard one: how can you make sure that, when you don't know what the solution is, when you may not even be certain what the *problem* is, that any solution posted to your simplified example will also work with your real source?
And then there's #3; this may require re-education on the answerers' part. I haven't seen any solutions for that yet.

Comment: Simply said: An MCVE is often mandatory, a huge wall of code is never acceptable, and if there are special circumstances which might rule out some obvious solutions, those have to be mentioned. Now a canonical spelling *all that* out? I guess it's dispersed over multiple posts, and I don't have them at hand.

Comment: Oh look, a downvote. Why is that? My post is not a feature request, so it's not a matter of disagreeing with the topic. So what is it? You think it's a bad, unresearched question, with an answer that should be blindingly obvious? You simply hate MCVEs?

Comment: It seems to me all these problems only occur when people start from scratch to create their MCVE. If they ripped out code to simplify it (like you normally would when debugging a problem), then we'd have exactly what we want: an example that reproduces the problem in its original context but is small enough that it is not just a wall of code.

Comment: I just typed out an answer, but it boils down to this: **it depends on the question**, so there isn't (nor should there be) and official all-encompassing rule for every case.

Comment: @CodyGray But that's exactly what people should be doing. They **should** be starting their MCVEs from scratch. On the contrary, I think people have **more** issues when they try to remove code to create their MCVEs instead of starting a new example project from scratch.

Comment: To whom you actually want to point a canonical post? To questionner or to FGITWs?

Comment: @Teemu to whomever turns out to not understand the rules. For example if we had an official page saying a stripped-down version of the original were better than an example written from scratch, direct anybody to it who has an opinion different from that.

Comment: @Teemu Example. Someone post a piece of code using foreign words for variable names. Someone else comments that they don't understand the code and the OP should translate it. As the situation is now, I don't know whether the OP or the commenter is more correct

Comment: Honestly, I think that 1) and 2) are false problems. A MCVE should be a functional code in the correct language reproducing exactly the problems people are facing. That's not a pseudo-code in a pseudo-language, and if there's an obvious syntax error, it simply shows that the OP hasn't done enough research effort. Act consequently: downvote, close, and continue on something more interesting.

Comment: An MCVE isn't pseudo-code either, so 3) wouldn't apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256728/dealing-with-questions-with-very-large-code-dumps

Comment: *and you can go back to the drawing board* - No. The OP CANNOT change their question after they've gotten answers. If they edit their post to move the goal posts, revert the edit and tell them to ask a new question. If it keeps up, flag a mod.

Comment: *they disappear before the OP can edit the question* - If the typo is what caused the problem for the OP, the question should be flagged as such. If fixing the typo doesn't solve the problem then those answers aren't useful. Down vote them.

Comment: Your point #1 is why I think SO/SE should eliminate downvotes entirely, and disallow close votes until the OP has had time to fix the problems noted in the comments.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - Closing a question is what gives the OP an opportunity to either 1) fix a salvageable question or 2) delete an unsalvageable one *before it gets answered*. The problem isn't the down or close votes, the problem is the FGiTW that answers and gets up votes which prevents the OP from deleting a question that can't be fixed.

Comment: One additional point: MVCE could be extremely beneficial for OP him/herself. More than once I solved my own problems while creating a decent MVCE.

Comment: Reminds me of a problem I had once where I provided a MCVE with some text that said "don't select the div based on its class, there is more than one in the production page and that might change in the future: I want a unique selector, but I don't know how to give it an ID because it is autogenerated (jQuery UI)."  First respondent then used class selectors.  When I informed him that he directly went against my desired goals, he said my MCVE wasn't Complete.  Took back and forth in the chat for 30min to convey the "don't use class/index selectors" goal.  2nd answer was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @PM77-1 That's called "rubber duck debugging."  I've solved so many problems that way. :D

Comment: I don't think we should dismiss #2 so quickly. I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29423991/3773066) an MCVE, the author accepted, and then learned that the solution didn't work in the live version and determined another MCVE would need to be created. On the one hand 1) this solved a problem, but 2) it didn't help the author.

Comment: @OhBeWise: Ah, but it _did_ help the OP. It didn't provide the ultimate solution, but it was a step along the way. It may not have even been a step in the correct direction, but it helped to clarify the _real_ problem.

Comment: Also, answers are to help future readers with similar questions, not just the OP. Sure, helping the OP is the immediate goal, but it's not the long-term goal.

Comment: **It happens far too often that the OP tries to create a MCVE, but makes a tiny mistake, and then all the FGITWs* flock in and post answers like "You have a ) too many"**  That means that OP didn't  actually *try* to create *an MCVE*, it means that OP tried to redact some code from a non-minimal example and broke it in the process.  That's not the really the right way to create an MVCE.  As others have noted, it should be created from scratch, introducing just enough to reproduce the problem.  (I realize that *some* problems require lots of complicated interaction to manifest, but not *most*.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes, but that's exactly my point. Creating an MCVE from scratch leads _directly_ to my issue #2: if the code in the question is not absolutely identical to the original code that has the problem, solutions for the MCVE might not be applicable to the original program. (Here, too, solutions usually help the OP, maybe with some extra tinkering, but not always!)

Comment: @MrLister it sounds like the issue you're describing is that the asker might create an MVCE for a *different problem*. While I'm not entirely unsympathetic to that case (we've all been there), Stack Overflow is a site for professional and enthusiast programmers; at least some of the responsibility for isolating the problem has to be on the asker.

Answer (score 25):

I didn't know there was [a page describing Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) until reading your post. Now I do. Thanks!

**MCVEs are (and should be) encouraged**

I think the first sentence:

> When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

says it well. There are two key parts:

- they elicit better answers, which if you're asking a question, is in your interest. (i.e. it's not uniformly mandatory but helpful, and later on in the page it's acknowledged that people often ask for this).
- They consist of "provide code people can use to reproduce the problem".

The three problems you provide aren't about MCVEs, because in all three cases, the OP isn't providing "code people can use to reproduce the problem".

**Are MCVEs realistic?**

Now, I think the argument you're making is really that for so many users, writing an example that meets that criterion is hard and either they try and fail or just fail to try.

Assuming the OP has been given a sufficiently clear definition of an MCVE, then my feeling is if they cannot produce an example that others can run, then often the question would be eligible for closing under "Real questions have answers".

And if you don't care enough to run your supposed MCVE and find it fails with syntax errors (or doesn't exhibit the problem behaviour), it's unreasonable to expect people with no access to your environment to do it for you. It wastes the time of those willing to help. Requiring an MCVE is a reasonable filter - and trying to make an MCVE may cause the OP to work out the problem. We should be encouraging people to consider MCVEs even for problems they have no intention of posting as questions.

**Is there anything we can do differently?**

Do comments link to those handy guidelines, or just say "Example, please?" "Make it shorter." "Show us the other bit of code!"? As BSMP points out in the comments, it's easy to link to those guidelines ([or indeed others](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)) by typing `[mcve]`.

The issue of hit-and-run syntax checking may have something to do with the reviewing system, which encourages "I know nothing about the subject matter but I can spot a mismatched bracket from fifty paces" type comments/edits. I can see why it feels odd, but I think it's a feature, not a bug. Even if they don't come back, the next person - who may be an expert - has one less syntax error to fix.

Comment: *While syntax in comments is restricted, it would be nice for the comments UI to come with some way of linking to help pages without copy-pasting whole urls.* This already exists. The one you want is `[mcve]`. I'd demonstrate it here but apparently it doesn't work on meta.

Comment: The full list of shorthand links for comments is here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I get from your post that your stance is _"use comments to ask the OP for more details"_. That's doesn't really stop anyone from FGITW'ing an answer based on the syntax error and the oh so common problem description _"it doesn't work"_. Such questions should be closed immediately until OP clarifies their problem.

Comment: @BSMP - thanks - didn't realise. I have incorporated this.

Comment: @CodeCaster: depends on the quality of the post. The OP of this thread seems to be suggesting that MCVEs are in practice not achievable or rarely achievable. What we do about non-minimal, incomplete, non-verifiable or unillustrated questions is probably another question, but I'd say fix errors with edits, resolve ambigutities or request more concise examples with comments and where there are outright lacunas, then put on hold until they're fixed,

Answer (score 15):

1. A MCVE should actually compile (well, up to the compiler error if that is the problem) and demonstrate the problem.  If they fail to do this, their problem is "must contain code to reproduce problem" and close until they fix it.  Part of their job is to actually compile and test the code causing the problem before they post it.
2. The risk that the MCVE doesn't match the real problem is a real one.  So people posting MCVEs should include a short description of the source problem, summarized, next to a working minimal complete verifiable example of a tiny version of it.  And yes, this can still lead to them asking a question that doesn't line up to their real problem: but a problem was solved.

They can then figure out why their MCVE didn't demonstrate their issue, and write a new question with a new MCVE that does demonstrate their issue.

3. A MCVE is not pseudo code.  It is actual code that demonstrates an actual problem.  If it is pseudo code, then yes, that is a problem.  If the problem is that it is not doing anything useful, then that should be explicitly explained (see #2 above), with the motivating problem roughly sketched.

---

MCVEs make it easier to solve a problem.  They both make it easier to understand what the problem is (because a wall of code can easily hide a dozen problems unrelated to the OPs problem), and make it easier to solve (because the answerer can pick it up and try it out somewhere).

---

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) is where MCVE was introduced.  [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258845/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta) is where it was authored.  Both should be of use if

[image]

Comment: Clear questions guarantee citizenship! Would you like to know more?

Comment: Well said. It takes practice to learn how create a good MCVE, but IMHO it's an essential part of learning how to debug. But even a bad MCVE is often better than a full program dump, or no code posted at all.

Comment: That picture [may need some explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kdrjzE1SE58)

Comment: `If they fail to do this, their problem is "caused by a typo, close".` -- Wait, what?  Absolutely not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Close reason fixed.