# Which branches of stack is good if want to check my entire code?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to check my code of more than 110 lines with node.js and Luis, my first time does stack overflow support that or I need to identify the exact issue? If not what stack branch do?

Comment: We don't do code debug-throughs. If you want that you'd need to pay someone professionally. Here, it's your job to trim down and identify the problem. Once you've given a [mcve] you're question is easier to answer.

Comment: see also: [Dealing with questions with very large code dumps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256728/839601) and [Should we have a more specific close reason for vague debugging questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/839601)

Comment: Check it against what?  Are you suggesting that OP's supply a complete virtual environment and test spec, for volunteer SO users to run for you?  I think no, never going to happen:(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have *working* code that you'd like someone to review, you can get feedback on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but make sure to read [their guidelines](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) first.

In short, I wouldn't just post 110 lines of code and ask for a review. Make sure you specifically mention what kind of guidance you're looking for (refactoring, potential pitfalls, performance issues, etc.)

Comment: The question is stating that they're looking for a solution to a problem, and do not have working code.  CR is for *working* code.

Comment: @Servy Where does it say they don't have working code?

Comment: "I want to check my code [...] I need to identify the exact issue?" Meaning they have some unidentified issue with their code.

Comment: @Servy That doesn't say "I do not have working code."

Comment: @BilltheLizard No, it says that they have an unidentified issue with their code, which means that their code isn't working.

Comment: @Servy Not necessarily, but you already know that.

Comment: Sure, the (meta) question isn't the clearest, but even so, suggesting a site that's extremely likely to be inappropriate is still harmful, as you're *very likely* sending bad questions their way that they'll just need to close.

Comment: Bill I would *strongly* recommend to explicitly state that CR.SE require working code, to avoid any shade of misreading your answer. [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/839601)

Comment: @gnat Good suggestion. I updated my answer.