# Can this question be closed as Unclear or "Why is this code not working"

Tags: discussion

I flagged [Entity is returning null when application is published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379514/entity-is-returning-null-when-application-is-published) for mod attention (since it was bountied) but my flag was declined.

You can see from the answers that it's unanswerable but a big bounty made rep chasers stab in the dark.

Comment: Well... at least the bounty didn't go to waste.

Comment: I guess that depends on who is talking. :) The asker didn't get "the" answer for 500 rep, just some debugging advice.

Comment: Which type of flag did you use?

Comment: moderator attention flag

Answer (score 4):

I was the one who declined your flag, which read:

> Bountied question that needs closing as a dupe of NullReferenceException or Unclear

First, when you say "closing as a dupe of NullReferenceException", that's not particularly helpful because you're asking me to go dig around for this "NullReferenceException" canonical question of yours. If you want us to close something as a duplicate of something else, you really should provide a link to the target to make that clear.

At the time you flagged it, there were just a few hours left on the bounty. People had left answers (one of which was very well written) as a result of that bounty being present, with the expectation it would continue to its natural end.

At that point, I'm a lot more reluctant to step in, wipe the bounty, and unilaterally close a question. There has to be a pretty compelling reason to do that, and I didn't see that there. The question was lacking in detail, yes, but I didn't see it as being so horribly off topic or complete trash that it needed to be closed immediately and the bounty be denied to those who had answered. We have a higher threshold for questions with mature bounties than ones where the bounty was just placed and no answers have yet been given.

You're free to vote how you want now, however.

Comment: If you read the "well written" answer all it contains is general debugging advice and in no way answers the question. Just because an answer is long and has some formatting on it doesn't mean it's a good answer.

Comment: Furthermore, allowing bounties to resolve on these questions tells people that they are allowed to answer poorly and that bountied questions are allowed to be poorer questions. If a question doesn't meet site standards then it should be closed, regardless of bounty status.

Comment: @Shoe - ["This answer may lead to the real answer. Thanks Shaun Luttin –  Christian Mark"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379514/entity-is-returning-null-when-application-is-published#comment47212144_29504848) . Sometimes, the best answer is teaching someone how to fish. The answer itself is well-written, and we're not worse off for them having written it. If bounties promote that kind of contribution, I have no problem with that.

Comment: Are we remembering our close reasons? _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._ SO isn't a discussion site. It's a QA site. The answer can teach how to get an answer, but *the answer must actually answer the question*

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254096/1950321