# Do users upvote out of sympathy, and how should that be addressed?

Tags: discussion, voting, low-quality-posts, upvotes

Are people sympathetically upvoting bad questions that have been downvoted?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh4ec.png]

Who in their right mind would upvote such a ridiculously awful question?

I tend to see this late at night, and suspect that it's because someone (me) from a different timezone downvoted and left the sarcastic comment. How can one hope to improve the quality of questions on Stack Overflow when people upvote crap like this?

> [image]

Other examples

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832743*

Comment: 'Close Vote' is your friend here. Vote early and vote often (to maintain site's quality) :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh That I do. I've considered programming my middle mouse button to execute a close vote macro.

Comment: Now that is a nice idea. Regarding your question, I believe you are correct but the sympathetic up-voters are less in number. I understand your frustration but you have to keep in mind that not everyone here has a "right mind" :)

Comment: That is a dreadful question. But then, just as people are free to downvote as they like (as long as they are not abusing the system with sock-puppets or serial voting), they're free to upvote as they like. Luckily the community tends to even it out.

Comment: The problem with the "close vote" solution is that I think it's pretty clear from meta that we should _not_ be closing these problems. The second example, for instance, currently has 3 close votes marked as lacking sufficient information to diagnose the problem. But that's wrong; there's plenty of info to diagnose the problem, because it's a simple problem. So, we don't vote to close, and then the questions get answered, and then it encourages more such questions. **What we need is a clear mandate from the powers that be that these questions should be closed, and quickly.**

Comment: I'm sure this has already been talked about before, in some old question that probably ended up on [meta.se], if it hasn't already been migrated back to Meta. See also [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253485/456814) and [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253547/456814).

Comment: @yshavit Agree x1000. The problem is that even *the powers that be* [can't agree on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216491). The argument is that even all of the crap awful questions (that are probably 100x duplicates) somehow *add* to the value of the site because they point to the good answers (somewhere). I disagree in that they bring the overall quality way, way down, diluting the good questions, and exhausting the experts.

Comment: Also, OMG, there's a "rant" tag?!?!?! Meta is not a place for ***rants!!!*** `:P` Only [civilized discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)! `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake Well there *was* one question tagged as such 8-)

Comment: If that 2nd question had been tagged regex it would have probably gone +5. The sad thing is, that first OP has still be rewarded with rep....

Comment: This problem must be isolated, as I can assure you that I haven't had any such [experience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254132/mad-as-hell-tag).

Comment: @dilbert I disagree.

Comment: @OGHaza One positive side is that it demonstrates that folks on SO are not discriminatory.  They upvote not only good questions but also awful ones.

Comment: @dilbert You need significantly higher rep to receive upvotes for such questions.

Comment: This strategy is known as keeping the question alive.  Reward poor questions with upvotes so that your answers can be seen by more folks and you get more upvotes in the process.

Comment: @devnull, that's true, we're friendly peaceful people. And I suspect you're right that it's the answerers upvoting.

Comment: I have literally hundreds of examples of this. There are questions that are just barely readable and show no signs of research but a blatant disregard for the culture and conventions on SO, which still get upvoted multiple times - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16915707) is one of the worse example thus far, which was at 4 upvotes _before_ OP edited in his meager try (check the edit history/timestamps and my comment on the question). I guess too many people interpreted "be nicer to noobs" as "upvote every post by a new user as long as it's not horribly offensive"...

Comment: @yshavit The first question given as example is **quite closable** as "too broad". Maybe the OP is just having an issue with one line, but maybe the OP does not even know how to configure Apache at all. The question does not say. You have a point with the 2nd one.

Comment: That's somehow related to why I have asked for [a new close reason](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253889/provide-not-enough-effort-as-a-new-close-reason)

Comment: I would agree that question is extremely poor and broad. I'm disappointed at seeing the sarcastic comment on that question though. Clearly the OP has very little knowledge of PHP and SO **purposely led him astray!**

Comment: @InternalFX "PHP expansion board" doesn't even show up on Google. I think he'll quickly find it to be sarcasm. If we can't have a little fun, I don't want to be a part of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can't _believe_ that you didn't specify that it's the **left-handed** PHP board, @JonathonReinhart; we are _supposed to be helping_ clueless people who ask strangers to take them by the hand and spoonfeed them!

Comment: @Cupcake [Yes it has been discussed on meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=sympathy++vote)

Comment: I think that people will up-vote a crappy question because they themselves have submitted an answer and want other users to look at it, perhaps up-voting the answer in the process.

Comment: I agree with InternalFX. A comment like that to someone who's starting out could be really confusing and make learning much more difficult than it needs to be. To someone who has no knowledge on a subject you'll find them taking things literally.

Comment: You mean sympathetic like this ridiculous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java

Comment: In [this case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254374/2284570), the questions get upvotes, then come the downvotes.

Comment: @InternalFX The question was utterly fatuous because it probably took more effort to join SO and type in the question than it would take to find a simple tutorial using a popular search engine, and therefore it deserved a fatuous answer. Whilst this is something that should not be done regularly (I agree that it might put off newbies), sometimes a question is daft it deserves some ridicule. The first lesson of anything is how and where to ask the right questions, and sometimes the lesson is harsh.

Comment: If there are people that build rep by answering and then up-voting a bad question, maybe answering a question should nullify your up-votes on that same question. Your answer itself already indicates your belief that the question is worthy of being answered.

Comment: Actually the second question is not as bad as the first one. The first one is from someone having no clue at all, the second one might be just a somewhat lazy beginner. The first comment is helpful and I would leave as it is. Having 5 answers is absolute overkill. Some guys have too much free time.

Comment: Is it possible that some people have multiple accounts and upvote their own questions? Is it possible that some people collude (come to a secret understanding for a harmful purpose; conspire) with one another and upvote each other's questions?

Comment: I am sympathetic to your question so +1 ;)

Comment: Sometimes I think people shout to a colleague across the room: "Hey, could you upvote my question?" I was able to largely solve the problem of junk filling up my screen by filtering a large number of popular tags. Of course, if you *want* to answer PHP questions, this provides no solution.

Comment: I give sympathy upvotes because this community is ridiculously elitist and hostile to new users.  It would be one thing if it was just the down votes, but the comments are also incredibly rude.  There have to be some people around who try to encourage new users to stay and to improve as members of the community.

Comment: @user3114046 If you want to answer PHP questions, that is punishment enough, surely!

Comment: @Jeff I admire your position, and you've been around longer than me. I did decide recently that some askers are just not worth the effort, and I just downvote and move on. If someone is genuinely trying, then I try to help them ask a better question. And I flag rude comments as not constructive or rude and offensive. This usually gets them deleted.

Comment: I don't see how this question proposes in any constructive way a solution to the problem of "sympathetic upvotes", nor does it present a good case, backed up with strong evidence, that such a thing is even a big "problem". Voting to close as primarily-opinion based (though "unclear" might have also been a suitable close reason).

Comment: @user3114046 You're right, some *aren't* worth the effort. I'm not saying every new user deserves a kinder treatment. The people who come on and just ask for a solution to a homework problem or for code to be written deserve to be down-voted and have their question closed. It's just the fact that the community treats *all* new users and *all* bad questions that way, regardless of the actual intention of the user.  I don't think veterans of this site understand that the Q&A format isn't common on the Internet or immediately understandable to a new user. Most people first think of it as a forum.

Comment: sometimes the person upvoting is a friend of the person asking.

Comment: Sometimes I throw on an upvote because I think a question is bad, but not `-3` bad. So something thats at `0` might not get upvoted. But something at `-1` or `-2` might get a `+1` to try and prevent the user from getting piled on by drive-by-downvoters. Though I'd `-1` both of those questions.

Comment: Only us geeks actually understand SO, for most of the world that upvote is simply a like button...

Comment: @johncip Which question are you referring to? The first is off-topic, and the second shows all signs of "write this code for me". It's not a "particular question" - I see this happen *routinely*.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You have no way of knowing how hard someone worked to get the answer they sought before posting. If you feel the the poster did not perform due diligence then ... ignore the question. Don't answer it. Problem solved. But by downvoting the question you lessen the chance that someone else may notice the question and choose to answer. What makes you look like a bad guy is your self-righteous comments.

Comment: I have, on a number of occasions, upvoted "newbie" questions that had a nugget of merit but were being rather unfairly downvoted for trivial errors.  If you want to call this "sympathy upvoting", so be it.  (And, given how rare it must be overall, YOY is it considered a "problem"??)

Comment: why in the world would you get mad over this? i would be mad at aggressive comments towards those kinds of questions instead. that would be something worth discussing instead. btw, i would upvote that question aswell lmao. just to piss people off who feel like this question is beneith them. i cant stand that kind of arrogance coming from SO veterans

Comment: Yeah, I upvote too.  Not newbies, necessarily, just any fair question that seems to run afoul of pettiness or pile-upons.  Believe me, it's not because I'm nice.  It's because I'm irritable.

Comment: Or maybe someone had the same question and solved his issue thanks to that

Answer (score 162):

You're assuming all people see "good" and "bad" in the same way.  If there are people who think those are good enough questions to ask, then there are people who will think those are good enough questions to up-vote.

Comment: Have an upvote; because this is how I often feel.

Comment: The type of people that upvote low-quality content are not the type that will also coherently defend their bad ideas.  I'd rather see the latter because it's has a higher entertainment value.

Comment: This is also why some bad edits get approved.

Comment: some questions can be asked "broadly" since people should be familiar with the problem that is asked. something like "how can i avoid this known bug xyz when doing xyz" with no code sample and no detailed explanation could still be considered a good question in some cases, because the bug may be known

Answer (score 65):

> Who in their right mind would up-vote such a ridiculously awful question?

- The same type of person who would **ask** such a ridiculously awful question.

  Who are these people, you may ask? Probably those with excessive laziness, lack of respect (for oneself and others) and/or total and utter obliviousness.
- Someone who favours usefulness and largely ignores quality.

  We strive to have a high-quality site. This behaviour is actively harmful and definitely part of the problem.
- A [sock puppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/sock-puppets/info).

> Sympathy upvotes?

That could also be.

Lack of seeing the bigger picture? Definitely.

---

There are plenty of possibilities to deal with this, but a necessary precondition is that the SE staff realizes that this is a problem and are more open to suggestions.

Comment: Just one thing, these lazy people are lazy because everybody starts from somewhere. Can we all not give some space to these lazy people.May be they do not still manage to have that smart culture in them yet.

Comment: @whoknows Laziness is rarely something you can just shake off. Obliviousness? Now that's a bit easier to change (but maybe not so much the "total and utter" variety). I don't know what "some space" is meant to imply, but having these terrible questions float around is actively harmful to the quality of the site. I'd happily explain my downvote if the reason for it is unclear, but most of the time (like in the above cases) I literally can't even wrap my head around how "does not show any research effort" requires any explaining, or why/whether me repeating it would have any value whatsoever.

Comment: @whoknows how does "starting from somewhere" justify laziness? These people are lazy because they are lazy. Giving them rep points will not lead them to be less lazy, but quite the opposite.

Comment: `Probably the same type of person who would ask such a ridiculously awful question.`. Not necessarily. The question can be awful, however the topic brought up can be interesting. For example I see almost 100% of questions worth upvotes, so I do. I encourage people to ask even "bad" questions. Well there are no bad questions actually.

Comment: or people creating multiple accounts just to upvote themselves... It happens on other forums, no reason to think it doesn't happen here.

Comment: @dfsq So you're saying that you're actively trying to decrease the quality of the content on this site?  That's something you should be ashamed of, not proud of.  There most certainly *are* bad questions, and we don't want them here.

Comment: @Servy I don't see it the way you put it. The reason why the quality is decreasing, is not because bad questions are upvoted/downvoted.

Comment: @dfsq That's not the only reason, but it's certainly a significant contributing factor.

Comment: @Servy Do you really think the user that posted this cares anything at all about their reputation? Look at the username and rep. **They are here for an answer, not for reputation.** If I am to believe that this is the typical example of a user who is decreasing the quality of the site, and your hypothesis is that somehow up/down votes encourages/discourages these low quality questions, then in light of the fact that the user has no rep or account I would conclude that your hypothesis is false, as far as it applies to this type of user.

Comment: @AaronLS It doesn't really matter if you care about reputation or not - if you only ask bad questions and get downvoted a lot, you'll get banned - simple at that (and getting around it isn't just as simple as creating another account, although it's certainly not impossible to do).

Comment: @AaronLS So, as Dukeling begins to discuss, it has a more indirect effect.  First off, there are *some* users that are asking questions to earn rep.  Next, there are others that, while they don't care about rep, still see a big negative number next to their question and *do* recognize that they did something wrong, and try to fix it.  Beyond that, questions with a score below 3 don't show up on the homepage, decreasing the odds of an answer, unanswered closed questions with a negative score will be automatically deleted, and can be manually deleted more quickly, and the question ban, etc.

Comment: @Dukeling It's not hard to cycle an IP when you don't care about an account or rep. You're treating a symptom instead of treating the cause. Comments encourage an improved question, and also it shows the asker that there is some interest in answering the question once they've put some decent effort into it.

Comment: @Servy " do recognize that they did something wrong, and try to fix it"  Do you teach dogs to sit by hitting them with a crowbar?  How do you think the dog will try to correct their behavior if you don't make your expectations clear?  There's lots of science to show what you are talking about is pretty ineffective.  Keep whining about decreasing site quality but ignore the solutions that history has already taught us.

Comment: @AaronLS If you manage to figure out a workaround to a question ban, you can probably manage to ask good questions as well, and you probably have enough self-respect not to try to force your way into a community that clearly doesn't want you. The cause, IMO, is too many users who just couldn't care less. In that regard, comments without downvotes does nothing. It's not too difficult for those who actually care to figure out what they did wrong.

Comment: @Dukeling They don't want into the community.  What they want is the answer. They don't care about an account, cause they didn't create one. Why would you think they are interested in participating in the community aspects of the site?  Give me one shred of evidence of that?

Comment: @Dukeling People become part of the community for two reasons: 1) To give to the community(many sub reasons, from generosity or ego) 2) Get help from the community.  This user is after #2, as long as they are an anonymous user asking bad questions, they aren't going to see the value in being a part of the community.  If 2 or 3 comments can nudge them in the right direction, then they will begin to get useful answers and will see the value of the community and begin to care about how the community reacts in terms of up/down votes.

Comment: @AaronLS You totally missed the point in my last comment. I could argue something about implicit community membership through participation, but that part really wasn't even the important part of my comment. And I was saying too many users in #2 **just don't care** (or are hopelessly too inexperienced to be asking questions here) - no amount of comments is going to lead them onto the right path. Time commenting would be better spent answering decent questions.

Comment: @Dukeling I understood your point, I just focused on invalidating the presumptions of your point. Some will care if given the opportunity. Bad questions do get turned around through some commenting. People don't come into the community understanding the culture and mechanics. They get indoctrinated into it and then value the mechanics once they see a return on their investment of effort. Certainly there are those who simply are "do my job for me"? From a single question that is a black box. They might be either do-my-job person or just a noob who doesn't know better.

Comment: @AaronLS Speaking from personal experience - 95%+ of the times I've commented and/or waited around for a change, either nothing happened (i.e. the probably don't care) or there was a bit of a back and forth after which I realized the user really shouldn't be asking questions here and no amount of explaining what's wrong with the question or answering it is going to help them a whole lot. And I really do want to help the 5%, but my sanity can't handle doing something with a 95% chance of (failure with a chance of more failure) and a 5% chance of a really, really small reward.

Comment: @AaronLS A lot of the people getting question banned are people that are too lazy to so much as do a web search for their question to get an answer, yet you think they're going to be jumping through hoops to subvert a question ban?  Sure, some occasional users do do that, but a very significant portion don't subvert the ban, for the exact same reasons that they got banned in the first place; incompetence and/or laziness.

Comment: @AaronLS So when your dog poops on the rug you give him a treat, so that he learns not to do it again?  And that works for you?  You think that positive reinforcement for negative behavior *discourages* that behavior?  It does not.  Negative reinforcement for negative behavior *does* discourage the actions in question.  When people post bad questions they almost always *do* get feedback as to what's wrong. When their questions are closed that provides very helpful guidance.  Most bad posts get some comments explaining what's wrong, yet the percent of questions that get fixed is very, very low.

Comment: You missed a group of people... the ones that don't know/understand how the site works. Many people are happy to change the way they post/vote if you just educate them.

Answer (score 18):

Perhaps the upvoters felt like rewarding the original posters for attempting to contribute, even if their contribution was poor.  The examples you cited are, admittedly, pretty bad.  But many people believe that positive feedback is more effective at encouraging good behavior than negative feedback.  After all, most of us get defensive at negative feedback, and often tend to tune out the critics.  Whether upvoting a bad question is an effective method for delivering positive feedback is another issue.

Other possible reasons: perhaps the upvoters misread the question.  (After all, the downvotes vastly outnumber the upvotes; it seems plausible that it was just a mistake.)  Perhaps the upvoter is not particularly strong on the substance of the question and therefore thought it was a good question.  Perhaps the upvoter is not familiar with (or does not agree with) the approach of most people on SO and thought a general question (in the first example; the second one was incomprehensible) was a good one.

I could probably think of a dozen more reasons similar to the ones above...people do things for lots of crazy reasons.

Comment: Providing positive feedback *for negative behavior* doesn't encourage positive behaviors.  It simply validates that the negative behavior is good, and encourages the user to repeat that negative behavior.  As for the possibility of a mistake, yes, that does happen, however this described situation is simply so common that its clear that that is not the *primary* explanation.

Comment: @Servy Some people believe that making a good-faith attempt to participate is a good behavior, even if the overall effort was poor.  The question was why people would upvote a poor question, and that is, arguably, a good reason.

Answer (score 11):

If your assumption is that sympathy upvotes of these types of questions are decreasing site quality, then that assumes that askers of these questions are encouraged/discouraged from asking such questions based on overall score. If you look at the username and rep you'll realize these types of users are **here for answers, not reputation.  Up/down votes mean nothing to them and will not change their behavior.**  The overall negative score warns other users away from wasting time on the question.  If you want to modify the users behavior, then a comment goes much further.  As another said, we tune out critics when the criticism is negative.  If you can offer a suggestion for how the question can be improved, then that will set a foundation for good behavior.   If you slap a dog because he didn't sit, he will never learn to sit cause he doesn't know what it is you want him to do. A little hand holding to guide someone into improving a question goes a long ways.  And then in the future maybe they'll have a better idea as to why they are getting downvotes and no answers.

Often times I will withhold making an attempt at an answer until the asker has provided sufficient information.  That's the carrot they want.

Comments also show the asker that there is some interest in answering the question once they've put some decent effort into it.

Comment: I hope our typical user is more intelligent than a dog, and would be able to figure out that negative means bad here (or at least mouse over the arrows to figure it out) and go looking to the help center to find out what's wrong, or possibly find their way to Meta, which hopefully leads them to somewhere like [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254263/1711796) or even to asking a question, to which the answer is hopefully more complex than "You didn't do any research effort". It's all about caring enough to do this, and if they don't, their loss. Oh, and question bans and such.

Comment: @Dukeling These expectations are part of the culture of stackoverflow. If you punish without guidance, then you don't establish an expectation of what modified behavior is expected.  "negative means bad here" What part of "he doesn't know what it is you want him to do" do you not understand? **It doesn't have anything to do with equating negative with bad**, it has everything to do with establishing expectations. Of course negative==bad, that's not the point at all :/

Comment: @Dukeling "It's all about caring enough to do this, and if they don't, their loss" If this is your attitude, then why are you so worried about site quality or a single upvote in a pile of downvotes that effects the overall score by less than 10%? I don't see any coherent logic in any of what you are saying.

Comment: I sincerely hope someone who shows even the faintest attempt would be able to guess that the help center and/or Meta would be good places to start looking to figure out why they were punished, and find them. (Not a big sports fan, but) I can't imagine a referee would explain offending behaviour to a player in a whole lot of detail particularly often - they're expected to know the rules and know when they did something wrong. Is this that different?

Comment: I also don't see any coherent logic in how you got to your last point. **I** care about site quality and having people get upvoted gives them tons of reputation compared to a downvote and makes it take longer for them to get banned if they keep up the unwanted behaviour, or makes the motivation for improving their own behaviour so much less.

Comment: "Up/down votes mean nothing to them and will not change their behavior" - generally agree, but they will be questionbanned if they are sufficiently down- and closevoted. They might not change their behaviour, but they won't be able to keep up this behaviour for a long time. Sympathy upvotes of course affect this process and will result in keeping these users around longer...

Answer (score 11):

I think the snarky and misleading comment does a lot more damage to the site than the simplistic question.  Perhaps people are only upvoting the question because they can't downvote the comment.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, "PHP expansion board" doesn't even show up on Google. I think he'll quickly find it to be sarcasm. If we can't have a little fun, I don't want to be a part of Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you start with sarcasm soon everyone will use it, I guess.

Comment: You can always flag comments for moderators to take a look at, if you think that there's something wrong with them.

Comment: Jonathan, can you imagine if someone you worked with gave you an answer that you thought might be real and you wasted an entire day before you realized that they were just being a sarcastic dick? How would you feel about working with that person? That's you, isn't it? The guy that knows a lot that no one wants to work with because he works against the common goal.

Comment: @AJB understands the spirit of StackOverflow.  ^ This comment epitomizes the attitude we need to have toward negative influences in our community.  You can fix ignorance with knowledge and guidance, but it's much harder to fix a bad attitude toward the userbase.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that you shouldn't vote based on the current vote count of a question, that is, if you see a question having -2, it shouldn't make you more likely to upvote than if it was 0.
Your vote should be cast as if you were the only one vote, it shouldn't be cast in order to "cancel out" other votes.

Comment: Another suggestion that's floating around somewhere is to charge rep for upvotes -- either _all_ upvotes, or only upvotes on negatively-scored questions.

Comment: Preventing voting based on score to ... prevent voting based on score. Hmmm... I'd rather have < 125 rep users not be allowed to vote at all if we're going in this direction ... or weighted voting based on reputation or voter's tag score in the tags on the question.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Charging rep for upvotes would be a terrible idea, though. My idea is about fighting pity-upvotes, this would obliterate all upvotes. No one will upvote if they charge rep for that.

Comment: It would make everyone think _a lot_ more carefully about their upvotes, and I don't think that would be a bad thing. I'm not completely in favor, but it's an intriguing idea.

Comment: On occasion I will upvote an **answer** (I haven't seen applicable questions) which are at -1 because the answer is a relatively good answer that was downvoted (Sometimes even if I wouldn't upvote otherwise). For some strange reason, I've noticed that downvoted answers tend to be downvoted more, even if the answer is a good answer. So by bringing the score to 0, I make it more fair for the answerer.

Answer (score 6):

I think the important question is

> Who in their right mind would **ASK** such a ridiculously awful question?

That's the point! I don't think that there is THE answer. My guess is that there is different type of stackoverflow users:

- The one that are specialist or at least good developer. Those one search a lot, google a lot and when they are blocked it is because of a quite complex problem, something interesting and that require other specialists expertise. I think this is the stackoverflow "purist" developer.
- The beginner-qualified user. Good developer that are looking for reputation point and that want to be part of the community.
- And a new type, the one that doesn't know stackoverflow philosophy and they use it as a "do my research work for me". They maybe think that stackoverflow is a kind of board, ask a question, usually stupid, and as soon as they got their answer never come back. They can't help and don't even try (maybe because they can't).

The problem is that this last type is pulling S.O. down. The feed is full of stupid, ininteressant and very basic question that can be answer by Google in two clicks. There are tons of tutorials and that is not the S.O. purpose to answer stupid basic questions when there are ten times duplicate. And the one which upvote and support it are the second type that are looking for easy reputation point. And the one looking for interesting question can't do anything cause every interesting question is answer in the minute as everybody rush at it, and other are just too basic.

But as some peoples says those people are beginners and may become experts. We all have been beginners at a time, so I am not for the extreme "get rid of them" solution. Maybe creating a  **new platform especially for beginners** where other beginners can help them could be a solution. And once they become better they switch to classic S.O.

**Beginners helping each others and professionals helping each others.**

That's my opinion, I am not an expert, but a professional that has been helped a lot by SO and want to bring something back to it.

Comment: No experts will want to participate in a new platform for beginners for the *same reasons* that experts are being pushed away now.  Beginners "helping" beginners causes the same mutual upvote *wankfest* that we're suffering from now.  It won't help anything, and the new site would be *awful*.

Comment: Honestly, the majority of experts that I've interacted with don't have a problem answering questions that are *easy* so long as they are quality questions.  It's important to have the questions that are of low quality (regardless of their difficulty) removed.  Of the remaining quality questions, there's no real reason to separate them into difficult or easy (not that you can effectively do so anyway).  Most of the top experts *love* to come across a question from an enthusiastic new user that can describe their problem well, clearly researched and tried to solve their problem, but couldn't.

Comment: @Charles "No experts will want to participate in a new platform for beginners" - everyone keeps saying, but I actually doubt it (these days, at least) - some 'experts' love reputation a bit too much - if there's a site where the questions they want to answer don't get downvoted into oblivion and closed, I'm sure they'll be happy there. Currently (pretty much) **everyone** is getting pushed away, help vampires and rep whores are pushing those of us away who want high quality, and we are pushing them away by downvoting and closing the questions they like - no-one's winning.

Comment: I see SO as a marketplace for questions and answers with a clear defined rule what is on-topic. We should be interested in bringing all the different interests together as smoothly as possible.

Comment: See [Create a New Stack Overflow Instance for Beginner Users and Content](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253646/456814).

Comment: See [Should we fork Stack Overflow for beginning programmers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381/456814)

Comment: See [Would it be a terrible idea to split SO up into a tiered platform?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252781/456814).

Answer (score 5):

I think people see downvotes on a sliding scale. SO users are happy to see truly terrible questions get 10+ downvotes. Merely mediocre questions deserve to be downvoted but not as much, hence they'll upvote if they see the amount of downvotes as "unfair".

This is actually how I used to think (as evidenced by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site) three years ago).

Answer (score 0):

Sympathetic voting is as bad as agressive downvoting, which at places looks absolutely unnecessary. Another thing you "left a **sarcastic comment**" I guess that is a problem in itself.

P.S. A question! What you "belonging to a different time zone" have anything to do with those upvotes (and I agree wrong/sympathetic upvotes)?

Comment: I don't know what it has to do with it, but it's a behavior I've seen.

Comment: And aggressiveness is another behaviour that I observed frequently.

Comment: How does one downvote aggressively?  Click the mouse extra hard?

Answer (score -5):

I didn't read all of the replies so this could have been said already.. what if there was a way to link questions together. It seems a lot of these questions have been answered before somewhere else on the site, so if you could group them all together then the answers for these simple questions would be better organized and more easily searched for, reducing the problem. maybe??

Comment: This is why we users can close questions as "duplicates" of other questions, so basically we already have this.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I mean instead of closing the question as a duplicate, link that question to the question that was duplicated.

Comment: This already happens when you close the question as a duplicate. What's the difference, other than the duplicate doesn't get closed? We close duplicates so that answers all get funneled into one question, instead of having answers spread out among many questions.

Answer (score -9):

I would not be so quick to downvote such a question and I might even upvote it and add a comment explaining that I upvoted because the OP is a newbee and is trying to learn from the experts here, but it's really not an appropriate question, and explain why:

It's obvious that the OP is a newbee and downvoting is likely to scare them off. IMO, people should be encouraged to come to the site to learn - it should not just be about big time experts "scratching each other's backs". So encouraging with upvote and providing **guidance** in a comment and/or vote to close seems appropriate to me. Nobody is going to be garnering thousands of rep points from newbee questions and "sympathy votes", and you're not losing anything with the upvote.

In general I am very reluctant to downvote questions unless they are just plain stupid and show blatant negligence or malice. A naive newbee doesn't deserve a downvote IMO. Let them feel good and ***teach them*.** Their questions will improve, and the site at large will be the better for it in the long run.

Comment: "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear" (question upvote button text) somehow doesn't match with "encouraging with upvote [...] and/or vote to close" for me.

Comment: I think the question cited by the OP is essentially "useful and clear" it's just way too broad. So I see it as a "teachable moment" - but not necessarily to downvote IMO. Perhaps I am not entirely within the guidelines here... just my own particular opinion - I'd prefer to upvote and educate than downvote or vote to close without a reason. I understand that that might not sit well with others.

Comment: By upvoting poor questions, you're only encouraging users to continue asking poor questions, instead of communicating to them that their questions can be improved. You're not helping anyone with upvotes in such cases. If you don't want to downvote, then you absolutely must not upvote either, just to make the original poster "feel good" about themselves. Upvote ***good questions***, don't upvote junk.

Answer (score -22):

It amazing me all the people on here who whine about simple questions. For goodness sake... These people are beginners trying to learn how to program. They aren't masters of Google search (yet). Call them lazy. Maybe they aren't in the same mindset as you on how to solve problems.

They are asking basic questions and think this is the place to do it. This place is a buzzkill for beginners. People sign up and get downvoted to hell on their first questions. I doubt they ever come back. I've never had trouble sifting through bad questions to find an answer. I get people want to improve quality but if the question is clear and concise, I don't get the point of downvoting it or closing it. I still run across plenty of answers that have been closed. They still show up in search engines, so you guys are accomplishing very little other than hurting the advertising profits of the company by turning away new people. The PHP question I agree, but someone asking how to parse a string... Ok, so no one ever had to look up how to do parsing the first few weeks they started programming?

Comment: "They aren't masters of Google search (yet)" - Doesn't take a lot to learn to use Google and if you haven't taken that simple step first then you probably shouldn't be trying to set up Apache. I suspect this whole thread applies more to that kind of question than the parsing one (and I agree with you on that point: We all start somewhere). But even my aged step mother, who has the IQ of a fence post, understands how to use Google to ask questions and get answers before asking other people.

Comment: If people aren't capable of doing basic research before asking their question then this *isn't* the place for them to ask.  This site expects a sufficient level of research for all questions asked.  If someone cannot, or will not, take the time to do that, then their questions *don't* belong here.  If people are being driven away due to an inability, or unwillingness, to ask questions this site considers acceptable *then that's a good thing*.  We want people who will provide *quality* contributions, not people who will proved *any* contributions.

Comment: It's ironic because I came across a horrible question right after posting this. Someone said their programmer was out sick and had a question on how to do something. lol >> Maybe new people need a little grace on how to use the site. People look at this site as a way to ask more experienced people how to do things... All the experienced users are looking at this site as a last resort when all other research fails. Personally even if someone could search 20 minutes and find an answer to a tough question on a blog somewhere, is it so bad to have an easy to find answer on SO.

Comment: I do get where you're coming from, I really do - and I try and tell people to search Google for a quicker response than waiting for downvotes to kill off their question - but sometimes the 'questions' are a waste of space. I suspect a lot of people do take the time to find out how to post a good question and in doing so essentially realise that they can answer their won question quicker and easier than posting it on SO (although we'd never get metrics on that), but those who don't probably never will as they want someone else to do the work for them, be that write code or search Google.

Comment: **The bottom line** is that the experts get really tired of seeing the same question over and over again, questions asked by people who have no business on a programming site in the first place, and many also the constant flow of questions that show little to no research effort. Whether or not you agree with this, many experts feel this way. So either we downvote these questions, or the experts try to find a place where there aren't such questions ... and leave the blind to lead the blind.

Comment: I think closing a duplicate question is really a different issue. If the question has already been asked then sure... close it. But, if it's  too "basic" in the eyes of an experienced programmer, I don't see the need to discourage the user. I've been programming 25 years and I still find myself looking up basic things on SO that I forget the syntax of, etc., and I'm honestly glad the questions are here. I wouldn't ask what I consider a basic question, but it is nice that someone else has. SO has such as great interface for finding things. Compare it to the MSDN forums for example.

Comment: Furthermore look at the huge amount of questions that have been closed that have TONS of upvotes. It just shows that the "experts" are out of tune with what the audience wants. I guess if I spent all day answering questions, I would feel different. I answer questions here and there, and obviously ask my own. Also ironic in regards to basic questions is the really difficult questions are hard to get replies to. I think people fish the easy ones for reputation, which I guess is a problem.

Comment: "People sign up and get downvoted to hell on their first questions. I doubt they ever come back." Great. Fine. I have not the slightest problem with that.

Comment: This site isn't designed or intended for beginners to get _help_, it's for "professional and enthusiast programmers" to get solutions to programming problems. [Stack Overflow is first and foremost a knowledge repository](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179009/159251)

Comment: Define professional? Define a professional level question... It is all subjective. I'm sure if you posted a CSS question, a CSS expert would say your question was a "beginner" question. Programmer typically suck at CSS. I am a UI designer and a programmer (of 25+ years), so I see plenty of them. I am also thankful for basic questions in this "professional" knowledge repository as I don't have a photographic memory.