# If your question was not well received, read this before you post your next question

Tags: support, faq, downvotes, closed-questions

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are probably reading this because the community "closed" your question and referred you to this post.  This post explains what happened to your question, and how you can fix it.

- What does "closed" mean?
- What is that negative number next to my question?
- What if too many of my questions are closed or downvoted?
- What can I do to fix my question?
- Why does all of this matter?
- I edited my question, but the "closed" mark wasn't removed! Why is that?
- My question suddenly disappeared! Was it deleted?
- How can I prevent all of this from happening again?

(answers are below...)

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Click here before you post your next question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262)`</sup></sub>

Comment: Can we get a link to this added automatically to the blue closure message box?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Post a feature request.

Answer (score 152):

### What does "closed" mean?

When your question is marked "closed", it means that community members decided to "pause" it, preventing new answers from being posted while you edit your question to improve it. Your question was most likely closed because of one of the following:

- Your question did not meet the [guidelines for good, on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- Your question was incomplete in some way; i.e. there wasn't [enough information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for others to provide a reasonable answer
- We're having trouble understanding your question
- Your question [needs more focus](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); it is too general and good answers would have to be very long to address it, or it asks multiple distinct questions at once
- Your question is [too subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); it mostly asks for opinions, such as "what do you think about..." or "what is the best..."

Closing a question is ***not* a final decision**; it can be reversed if you edit to improve your question. If you do so, it *may* be reopened (i.e. the "closed" mark removed and answers allowed again) if enough users believe you have corrected the problems and it is now answerable. See *What can I do to fix my question?* below.

### What is that negative number next to my question?

That means people are [voting your question down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).  Votes indicate the quality or usefulness of your post; downvotes indicate that your post is of low quality or isn't a good fit for the library of questions that is Stack Overflow. Read the comments (if there are any) on your question and address them by editing it.

### What if too many of my questions are downvoted or closed?

You may be warned prior to asking your next question, and may be subject to short rate limits of up to 7 days. These prompts are to ensure that you've read and understand the guidance on how to ask good questions in the help center.

If you continue to post questions that are negatively received despite receiving such warnings, you could get [altogether banned from asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997). Question bans are difficult to reverse; you want to try and avoid getting banned, if you can.

### What can I do to fix my question?

Address the problems that are [described in the "closed" banner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) that was put on your question, or in any comments other users have left.  For example, if you post a troubleshooting question, and it was closed as "*insufficient information to diagnose the problem*", then you need to [edit your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) to [add the information we need](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/102937) to help you solve it. If a user has left a comment asking a question, edit the requested information into the question.

When you or someone else edits your question, there will be an option to indicate that all issues with the question have been fully solved. This will place it into a review queue where other users will review your edited question. Reviewers can either vote to reopen it (i.e., vote to remove the "closed" mark), or indicate they think your question should remain closed. At the time each user reviews your question, they will be shown the current state of the question, so additional edits do help if they happen prior to users reviewing the question. The close banner on your question will indicate if your question is still being reviewed or if the reviewers assessed it should not be reopened.

### Why does all of this matter?

The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is not only to provide help to the person asking the question, but *mainly* to compile a library of questions and answers that are helpful to future readers. Additionally, our question-and-answer model means that we strive to reduce back-and-forth discussion as much as possible, leaving behind just the questions and answers; this makes it easier for people to find answers quicker when searching for solutions to problems similar to yours.

For this reason, we expect questions asked here to have a certain [minimum level of quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The level of expectation may be higher than those of other programming forums, but overall it helps further these goals. In particular:

- We expect you to use complete sentences and proper capitalization and punctuation.
- We expect you to describe the problem clearly and accurately, and give us the information we need to answer your question, without us having to *guess* at what parts of your problem may be.
- We expect you to do your own work.  We're here to help you, but we're not here to do your work for you, or help you find things on other sites.
- We expect you to demonstrate that you have some basic skills, so that you will understand the answer we give you.  If all you need to do is go read a book or fire up a debugger, then that's what we're going to tell you to do.

### I edited my question and indicated that the edit resolves the close reason, but the reviewers left it closed! Why is that?

If reviewers assess that your question should not be reopened, the close notice will be updated to reflect this fact and will indicate the feedback reviewers gave: either the original close reason wasn't fully resolved, or a different close reason applies to the edited question (e.g., you've edited it to add required information, but it is already answered in a duplicate question).

If this happens, you can try and make another edit to resolve the indicated close reason, and it will be reviewed on its own merits.

If you need further clarification as to the close notice or how to resolve the close reason(s), you can post a question here on this site, Meta Stack Overflow, tagged [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed). Clearly explain why you believe your edited question meets the guidelines for the site (e.g. if your question was closed for not having a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex), explain that you've edited one in). Community members will either reopen your question or answer your meta question with an explanation of why your question is still not a good fit.

### My question suddenly disappeared! Was it deleted?

If you can no longer find the question in your user profile, it was probably deleted by others.

There are three general reasons a question would be deleted:

1. Your question was deleted by the Community user, in an [automatic cleanup process called the "Roomba"](/help/auto-deleted-questions).
2. Your question was deleted by [users with high reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or a moderator.
3. Your question received enough *spam* or *rude or abusive* flags from users and was automatically deleted.

**You can still see your deleted question, however**. All of your deleted questions are listed on [the "Deleted questions" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current) linked at the bottom of the "Questions" subtab in your user profile. You may also find links to your deleted questions in the "Reputation" subtab, if you check the "Show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom.

If your question was deleted, you can request that it be undeleted by posting a request here on Meta Stack Overflow, or, if a moderator deleted it, flagging it for moderator attention. You may be able to edit it to address concerns even while it is deleted, so if it's possible, do so; this will increase the chances that your request will be granted.

The [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ on deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) has more info on what happens when your post is deleted, the criteria for deleting posts, and tips on what to do to request that your post be undeleted.

### How can I prevent all of this from happening again?

The best way to do that is to:

1. Read the [articles in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and
2. Watch others ask and answer questions for awhile, so that you understand what the community expects from question askers.

#### Good Luck!