# "I understand, but disagree" for review audits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

Recently in the reopen queue I got the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33097276/php-remove-characters-before-and-including-the-symbol):

[image]

So, this isn't an outstanding question?

But, contra the close voters (only one of whom has higher rep than I do, FWIW), while I'm not a PHP expert, I don't think it's too broad, either. "How do I strip everything up to and including the first occurrence of a certain character from a string" should be a reasonable question in any language.

I upvoted it from -2 to -1 and voted to reopen it, but I won't shed any tears if it stays closed; reasonable moderators might disagree.

But I submit it's not **obviously** terrible -- it's a lot better than most of what shows up still open in, say, the edit queue -- and the fact that it was presented as obviously bad by the audit system suggests a flaw in the audit system. It would be nice if there was some way to indicate that -- and some alternative to an "I understand" button that implies an admission of "not paying attention."

Comment: Just another case of too broad being misused. your upvote on the question should make this no longer come up as an audit.

Comment: Apart from the benefit of sorting out bad audits, this would have the positive side effect of making the user experience better, as flawed audits would be less frustrating if there is a clear way to rectify the situation.

Comment: that is why you do not make judgements on things you are not an expert in, the **skip** button is there for a reason

Comment: This wasn't "Too broad"

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Are you suggesting someone needs to be an *expert* in PHP to know if a beginner-level question is appropriate?

Comment: It's possible that 3 or even 4 of the 5 voters chose reasons other than "Too Broad". I would have chosen "primarily opinion-based", for example.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson The entire construct of the reviewing system is so you **don't** have to be an expert in the domain to close-vote. For example, I don't need to be an expert in PHP to know that a user is asking for an outside resource.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I'm not a PHP expert, but I'm giving it the benefit of the doubt and assuming that it's no stupider than any of the languages I'm more expert in.

Comment: @DavidMoles Unless you're expert in VBscript, PHP is... well, it's something else. "Stupider" might be too kind.

Comment: I have worked with `AppleScript` and `VBScript` extensively and I agree with @IanKemp, `PHP` is about as *stupider* as it gets and that is about as politically correct as I can put it as well. ;-p

Comment: to all those that can not read for intent, the **skip** button is there for a reason, when you have doubts ( knowledge/expertise/opinion ) or consider the entire tag domain a waste of your time regardless of the quality of the question. If I see any tags that are a waste of my time I just hit **skip** by reflex, [php] falls into this category with extreme prejudice! :-)

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson: there’s also a filter option. It doesn’t allow to exclude tags but you can specify which tags you *want* to see. The funny thing is, if you see questions which look wrongly tagged, not actually being within the scope of your filter, you know instantaneously that you’re seeing an audit.

Comment: @OP: my knowledge of human nature tells me that then everybody will click on “I disagree” instead of “I understand”, but since you didn’t specify any consequences for clicks on “I disagree”, that wouldn’t be harmful either…

Comment: @Holger - shhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 59):

That was a bad audit; the question shouldn't have been closed.

[Brad Larson has proposed a similar system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790) for handling these in the past; I think it's a good idea.

Comment: Just curious, what happened to Brad's suggestion?

Comment: @Keale Nothing, according to the Meta post linked in Shog's answer. (It's not uncommon for even popular feature requests to go unaddressed; the Stack Overflow development team does a lot of things)

Comment: In the form it was for that audit, the question asked "What is the best...", which is one of the examples cited for "subjective" [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question/254263#254263). Now, the question has been edited to ask "how do I", but that isn't what the OP asked. Based on what they asked, and the guidance both on Meta and the Help Center, the question _should_ have been closed (or better, edited).

Comment: If we're going to mechanically close any question that asks "what is the best" as too subjective, we should just forbid it programmatically. There are valid questions where "what is the best" actually has a consensus answer. (What is the best way to tell if a Java collection is empty? Call `isEmpty()`. Yes, you can check `size() == 0` but no experienced Java programmer would advocate that.)

Comment: @DavidMoles I fear a programmatic approach would cause too many false positives. Furthermore, "what is the best" is an *extremely* subjective question - best in **what way**? Best practice, fastest speed, lowest memory usage, makes more angels dance on the head of a pin, ...?

Comment: @IanKemp That's true for many questions but not all. For many questions involving common, simple operations, "what is the best" is really just a synonym for "what is the most common" or even "how do I". If it weren't, we wouldn't have to worry about those false positives.

Comment: @DavidMoles For common, simple operations I would expect the language's documentation and/or examples, or a simple Google search to give all the consensus needed. Perhaps the incoming Stack Overflow documentation feature might help this particular case.

Comment: @IanKemp If the documentation and/or examples invariably gave that information in a way that was easy to Google, [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring) [highly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum) [rated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operator) Stack Overflow questions would be unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidMoles I don't disagree, but the fact is that a question's rating doesn't necessarily correlate with its quality, and such questions - while useful - are not necessarily *on topic* for Stack Overflow's focus on *professional*, as opposed to beginner, programmers.

Comment: @IanKemp as a programmer with 15+ years of professional experience, I often find myself briefly working in unfamiliar programming languages. I've generally found that Googling with `site:stackoverflow.com` is much more effective in those situations than up-front time slogging through tutorials or memorizing documentation.

Comment: It's a good idea that hasn't yet been realized, @Keale. Too many good ideas, too little time.

Answer (score 13):

I think you're being generous in saying "Reasonable moderators may disagree."  Closing that question exemplifies the trigger-happy rule nittery that makes people complain about SO moderation.

The question is clear, is vanishingly unlikely to generate opinionated debate, and the poster put some effort into formatting it correctly with markdown.  It might seem like a trivial question to experienced programmers, but moderation shouldn't be an exercise in passing judgement on what confuses a beginner.

Comment: While I agree about this specific question, but the feature request would still be nice. There are bad audits, while this one might not have been one.

Comment: I'm a _lot_ more concerned with database quality than I am about some naysayers moaning about SO moderation.

Comment: They're moaning _because_ the rules hurt quality by closing many, many useful questions.