# Add dispute for audit fail

Tags: feature-request, moderation

I reviewed a triage item and apparently failed this item.  As a result, I've been banned from review tasks for 7 days!

In my defense, this solution was 38 lines of code with ZERO explanation and text.  All I tried to do was add a comment that the poster should have added a little background about what the issue was and how they fixed it so the OP could learn from his or her mistakes.

**Update in Regards to Mark As Duplicate**

Agreed, but the problem still has not been fixed and the clear sentiment on the duplicate post was that it should be.  I think this problem should continue to be re-visitied until it is fixed.

[image]

Comment: Also related: [“I understand, but disagree” for review audits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309420/i-understand-but-disagree-for-review-audits)

Comment: @hichris this is an active issue. If its closed, nothing will be done about it. Therefore, i think it should be left open.