# How do I get attention to this Stack Overflow post that has had no views or votes for two days and was put on hold?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, on-hold

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Can't add multiple items to shopping cart please suggest ways with php(No Sql)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314053/cant-add-multiple-items-to-shopping-cart-please-suggest-ways-with-phpno-sql)

Can somebody help me or vote me up because it is been 2 days and no one has looked at my post or removed it from hold no mater how many times I fix the issues?

If there are still issues with the question, could you help me understand how I could improve it to have it re-opened?

Comment: One little thing: although the empty lines may exist in your original code, it is useful to avoid them here, if they aren't necessary. As you can see, the size of the code block in your question is limited, thus these empty lines make it harder to read your code, due to the needed scrolling

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three things.

1. **Your ask is unspecific.** An eCommerce site is a ***big*** undertaking, and as such, there are a lot of moving parts.  Even doing a cart is fairly complex.
2. **It's largely unclear from the question what the actual issue is.** This lends itself to #1 in that you say these things in defense of your question/code:

   > I have tried to make cookies but it is not working at all I have also tried JavaScript but it does not work at all. There is no other way i can find can someone answer my question Can you please suggest a few ways to make my cart so that I can make it add more Items and delete items

   Towards the bottom you get at the root issue...but...that's not quite clear enough either.

   > I expected it so i could make more than than one item appear when I click the add to cart and I can remove them from the cart.

   Which brings me to...
3. **You're missing details about your error.**  Do you get some kind of error from your code when this happens?  Anything either in PHP or JavaScript?  Why do cookies factor into this?

I would encourage you to focus your question on these parts:

- What the issue is - you're trying to create a shopping cart, and you're having issues with making more than one item appear.
- What you've done in the most concise statement possible - there's a lot of code and it's unclear how cohesive it is; maybe paring that down a bit may tease out a better answer and enlighten you how to solve the issue as well.
- Remove noise and extraneous details.  This entire sentence can go away and it'll read a bit better:

  > Here is my page to see what it looks like: http://localhost/victorphp/StoneLearning/Website/index.php

  ...especially since we're not running your server locally. ;)

Comment: [Here is my fixed page and I gave it everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362491/cant-add-more-than-one-item-sessions)

Comment: @Victor:  You *probably* shouldn't add ***everything***.  Add *enough* that we can identify and see the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: fixed my paage you can check it again there is my cart my session declares and my problem is I cant add more than one item I also gave you the way I made it so that you can see why it works.

Comment: I fixed up my code so you can see what my problem is all you need to do is paste it in your code way on diffrent pages and you will see what I mean.

Comment: will you please recheck it or answer it and tell me if it is better now

Comment: fixed my page now