# Should FAQ questions use consistent terminology & formatting for canonical link/quick link?

Tags: discussion, meta

I noticed that five of the pages in [FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) have an inline code block link to itself at the bottom of the question:

- [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)
- [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)
- [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions)
- [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
- [If your question was not well received, read this before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/if-your-question-was-not-well-received-read-this-before-you-post-your-next-ques)

The link is formatted as markdown code, rather than as an actual link:

> Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Click here before you post your next question.](https://s.tk/onhold)`</sup></sub>

I'm guessing (though I haven't found documentation to confirm this guess) that this is a convenience feature for questions that frequently need to be shared, so they can be quickly copy/pasted.

The formatting and terminology used for this feature is inconsistent across these questions.  The terms used are: "Canonical link", "Markdown link sample ", "Markdown link", and "Quick link".  Most of them use `https://`, but two use [protocol-relative URLs](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) starting with `//`.

---

Current format variations:

> **Canonical link:** `[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)`

> **Canonical link:** `[Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)`

> Markdown link sample: <sub><sup>`[Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)`</sup></sub>

> <sub>Markdown link:
>
> `[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)`</sub>

> Quick link: <sub><sup>`[Click here before you post your next question.](https://s.tk/onhold)`</sup></sub>

---

Should these link samples be made consistent across FAQ questions in terms of formatting, terminology, and HTTP scheme?  If so, what term should be used, and what should the format be?

Note that one of the questions ([Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)) is locked, so I personally can't update it if we should make it consistent.

Comment: Incidentally, this demonstrates once again that the lacking support for the `<small>` HTML tag is unambiguously a bad idea: people use small text *anyway*, via obscene combinations of `<sub>` and `<sup>`. Sigh.

Comment: @KonradRudolph A counter argument could be that we want to discourage small text, making hacks like this more obvious.  That said, I don't have a strong opinion either way, or data to back up such an opinion.  Either way, I would argue that none of the quoted texts should have been small in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, being a convenience feature was the idea. It arose somewhat organically as people started to just edit the FAQs (especially since they are community-wiki, which lowers the bar for editing). As I and others have done maintenance to the existing FAQs, we've vainly tried to keep things consistent with the existing entries, but things fall through the cracks.

Rather than standardizing the format, **I think we should get rid of these altogether**. It only serves to encourage people to post these bare links to the FAQ in a comment, which isn't constructive (and often just ends up with your comment getting flagged and deleted).

The only reason you should link to these FAQs in a comment is if you are providing *specific, relevant* commentary in addition to your link. In that case, it's not at all a burden to just type out a meaningful message. There's no need for copy-pasta shortcuts.

Comment: The other side of the coin: if we did keep them, should they be applied more broadly than to just those five questions?  I'm guessing those five just happened to be a case where someone got annoyed at having to copy/paste the same link over and over.

Comment: Some of them used to have it, but then [some mod edited it out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/284236/revisions), probably out of frustration were people were just blindly copy-pasting it into comments.

Comment: I disagree with the blanket assessment that posting these links as comments isn’t constructive. Of course this is part of an ongoing trend but (unfortunately) I’m convinced it’s a march in the wrong direction, and achieves the opposite of the stated aim of making the site more welcoming. This sort of commentary is, more often than not, as specific as necessary, and it is a tremendous time saver, which reduces frustration and leads to a direct reduction of unwelcoming snark.

Comment: @Konrad A link to RTFM is not constructive. When you come across what you think is a homework question, and you dump, "How to ask and answer homework questions?" as the sole content in your comment, that's literally the definition of unwelcoming snark.

Comment: Great, now references to on-site help/meta information suddenly become unwelcoming.. what's the alternative then? Not commenting at all is less helpful, but is more welcoming, right?

Comment: Not commenting at all is what you should be doing unless you have something specific and unique to say about that post. Leaving bare links, *implying* a problem but not clearly stating it, is not useful and never has been. @Sinatr

Comment: @CodyGray “unless you have something specific and unique to say” — It *is* specific. And your “unique” requirement is arbitrary and useless. — “A link to RTFM is not constructive” — Uh, no. The *term* “RTFM” is not constructive, because it’s explicitly insulting. But an *explanatory text*, with a link to a *specific guideline* is the epitome of helpfulness. It’s neither “unwelcoming” nor “snark”, and for you to claim otherwise is frankly bizarre and concerning. I’m all for giving specific help, but the truth is that for many questions a template text *is* fully specific.

Comment: @KonradRudolph https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment (Did that help? No.)

Comment: @CodyGray … because it isn’t *specific*. I agree that *just* commenting with a link to “How to ask homework questions?” isn’t helpful. But commenting “Hi, please show the solution you’ve tried. Make sure to read the information under ‘How to ask homework questions’.” is.

Comment: Err, yes, then you're saying the same thing I am. Commentary must be added *beyond the bare link*.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, actually I made a mistake in my second-to-last comment: the problem with RTFM obviously isn’t just the insulting term but the breadth: as I’ve emphasised, a useful comment links to *specific* help (which your …/comments link didn’t, but the “homework” link *potentially does*). But unfortunately we’re still *not* saying the same thing, because I am saying that having these link shortcuts is valid and helpful, and banning them/editing them out is counter-productive, and makes achieving your (and my) stated goal harder. And many canonical link texts are *entirely sufficient comment*

Comment: On the other hand, most homework copy-paste "questions" need exactly the same comment: "Please don't copy-paste your homework question. Instead, show what you've tried and where you got stuck. See \[link\]." Why should this need to be invented anew 20 times a day? The post is not unique, why does the comment need to be unique?

Comment: A comment is not mandatory, @Cris. If you have nothing unique or novel to say, then no comment needs to be left. Just leave a close vote.

Comment: Cody, sorry, I don’t think it’s welcoming to close a question without explaining why. The standard close reasons don’t lead to explanations of how to ask about homework questions. All they see is “too broad: try to focus on one thing at a time.” If there was a clear explanation to newcomers on how to ask such questions then it wouldn’t be necessary to leave a comment.