# Why was this Python question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked a question about Python lists ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947260/python-index-method-claims-item-doesnt-exist-but-its-there)) yesterday. I tried to provide enough information, since the problem I'm facing is something I can't understand - an unexpected behavior of the .index() method, which is not behaving as I expected it to.

The question was summarily closed. As the question's activity shows, votes for closing were cast without any wait for my responses to comments.

On top of that, the reason given for closing the question was simply "not suitable for this site". What exactly about this question is not suitable?

Is something missing from the question? If that's the case, why wasn't I given time to correct it?
Is it about something that doesn't belong on Stack Overflow? Is Python not suitable for Stack Overflow?

Closing this question feels arbitrary and unwarranted.

Comment: "*votes for closing were cast without any wait for my responses to comments.*" [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263)

Comment: By the time it was closed, you had not provided a minimal reproducible example. If you take a better look at the close reason, you will see _"Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question."_ This was clearly not arbitrary nor unwarranted. After improving the question with that example, the question has already entered a re-open queue. Should the question be in condition to be answered, it will likely be reopened eventually.

Comment: Looking at the timeline more closely, I don't even find any fault with the close voters. You posted a question and was notified that it lacked details within 5 minutes. The first follow-up interaction you had was *11 hours later*. I'd understand the frustration if you acted promptly but half a day is not that. How are people to know when or even *if* you'd come back to the question? We get thousands of questions that are posted and abandoned regardless of whether they are answerable.

Comment: I see.

I posted the question and got away from it, since I assumed it would take some time for people to notice it and comment or respond. It was already late so I went to bed, hoping I'd at least find some helpful comment. Instead, I found my question was closed.

I guess this means that if I post a question I'm not allowed to sleep, then (that's sarcasm, by the way).

Comment: I think that you ruined your early  re-open chances by your [delete / undelete vote](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65947260/timeline) as that invalidated the re-open review. Now it is to be seen if your later edits trigger a fresh re-open review. Unless someone hits the re-open link on purpose.

Comment: You are allowed to sleep. Nobody says you aren't. But I'm not sure I agree with the implication that people should wait for you to do that before casting their votes.

Comment: Doesn't feel that way. Closing a question makes it almost invisible, there is NO useful feedback on *why* the question was closed, and I'm given *zero* information on how that question might be able to be re-opened. I don't expect people to wait for me, but people shouldn't expect that I'm standing beside my computer to respond to their criticism immediately.

Comment: For what it's worth, you did react to the given feedback. But like any other closed question, it has to go through the reopening process now. It does help to get the question right the first time, and it definitely helps to [keep the browser open on the question for a little while to respond to feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your edit automatically started a reopen review. You have no way to know if did not succeed, except that a positive outcome reopens your question. But you got already 2 reopen votes by the meta effect.

Comment: Wait a little bit, improve it if you can, and then ask it again. Your question in its current form was clearly acceptable, and re-posts are not forbidden for a fixed version of a deleted question. Do not re-post exactly the same content, that is not okay, but if you improve it, at least a little bit, so it will be imho okay. Note, closed + deleted + downvoted questions make you closer to an automatic question ban, so do it only if you are ready to take the risk. Probably you can avoid the q-ban if you write many answers. (No one knows, exactly how many.)

Comment: It might be helpful to provide some clarification to advice being given, you should edit the question that was closed, instead of submitting a new question.  A new question would likely be closed as a duplicate of that existing question.  Appears the question was deleted, since it was caused by a typo, which is a valid reason to delete a question. I wouldn't advise submitting that particular question again if the problem was actually caused by a typo.

Comment: Closing a question is done so that it doesn't rack up the sort of garbage answers that come from guesswork. It's a defense mechanism, not a punishment. In an active tag like Python, the bullk of the views that will be useful to you will come in the first hour-or-so and an incomplete or otherwise unanswerable question is likely to be closed within a few minutes. It's in your best interest to nail the question down with the first post.

Answer (score 18):

Just trying to summarize the series of events real quick:

1. When the question was asked, it lacked a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is standard and proper procedure to close these questions.
2. You arrived at the question hours after it was closed, and tried to fix it as per the feedback, including an example in code.
3. Then you asked this Meta question about the closed question.
4. An inspection of the question from the community reveals that there was a very specific mistake in the code: that you were expected to iterate over `p.auctions['auctions']` instead of `p.auctions`. Note that such a mistake is hard to ever be useful for future visitors, which is why there is a close reason "Could not reproduce or was caused by a typo":

> While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

You also left this comment (before the question was deleted):

> Well, if anything, being pissed off by the question being closed made me take a fresh look at the data. I found the answer. And no, it wasn't the lack of `['auctions']` (although that was an issue, too).

This unfortunately is another sign that the question was not focused to a specific problem, making it even more problematic. Perhaps a slightly more thorough debugging session would have cleared the need to ever ask the question in the first place.

---

This is an example of what can happen when bringing a question for discussion to Meta SO. It generally creates a moderation catalyst, which may go in favor of the question, but will often go against it. In this case the question was deleted, but at this stage I admit that I should have waited until the discussion here was settled before casting the last delete vote, and for that I apologize. Still, I feel that trying to undelete this one is more harmful than just retrying a new question with reiterated research, should that still be worth doing. Hopefully this at least helped you get unstuck, although it would have been better with a quality question.

See also:

- [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260263)
- [If your question was not well received, read this before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262)
- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score -14):

Your edited question is indeed a valid question, so I voted to reopen it.

Comment: That "you cannot post it there" doesn't mean you should post it here. E.g. being q-banned doesn't mean one gets to post questions in meta that belong on the main site.

Comment: @yivi I am not banned, the presence of the answer here illustrates that the closing was unnecessary.

Comment: No, it does not. That a question **can** be answered does not make it fit for the site. If you believe the question should be reopened, argue about the question merits. Your post is fine as it is otherwise. And I know you are not banned. I was explaining the point by analogy.

Comment: Nobody implied you are banned. It was an example of how being unable to post on main is **not** a reason to abuse posts on meta.

Comment: @user000001 I gave another reopen vote. We wait for the final one and you can post your answer.

Comment: @user000001 Not he. Click the question, it was deleted by others, most likely by a mod.

Comment: @user000001 Wow, it was not mod deletion, but a very quick community one. Sad. Thanks! Btw, which OS/browser is it? :-)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Firefox on ubuntu