# How could I have written this question to avoid the immediate downvote and close vote?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, quality-improvement

Within minutes of posting my question it was downvoted and a vote was cast to close the question. The downvoter has left no feedback to explain their actions so I'm asking here what I could do to improve the question.

[How can I identify which time-driven trigger has called a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69301792/how-to-identify-which-time-based-trigger-has-called-a-function)

Comment: We can't really speculate why the downvotes. I for one think your question looks okay, for instance. The downvoters would have to explain, but they are not obligated to do so mainly because doing so reveals their identity.

Comment: @x-x well, maybe instead of listing out requirements at the beginning you could just take the bottom paragraph and put it at the top making it more concise. I've done an edit to your question, if you don't like it roll back. Again, I am not an expert and your question looks fine to me, so wait for an SME.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, do you have any suggestions to improve the question itself?

Comment: @x-x: I'm no expert on the subject matter, but if I were asking the question, I'd try to include as much of my own relevant research into the topic as possible

Comment: SME here - the question does not look unfocused (i.e. asking multiple questions at once or unscoped) at all. It looks like a duplicate, though - as, if my memory serves me right, it is not the first time someone wants to know which type of trigger is firing. I don't have time right now to find a suitable target but during the end of the week

Comment: @OlegValter I can't find a duplicate question myself, but if you find it and there's an answer that would be great! Note that I don't need to know what TYPE of trigger it is -  they are all time-driven triggers - I need to know which time-driven trigger it is.

Comment: The question seems to have a lot of… fluff. It looks like much of the description, most of the code comments, and in fact most of the code are just not relevant. It doesn't help that one has to re-visit some of these elements, e.g. to find out that [some of the comments *are* directed at the SO audience](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69301792/2).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Am I not supposed to provide as much detail as possible to ensure any answers posted actually solve the problem? Which irrelevant "fluff" specifically should I remove to be more concise while ensuring the problem is correctly stated?

Comment: @x-x I'm not an SME, so please take this with a grain of salt – the "seems" and "looks" are there on purpose. Spending some more time I see how they click together; so the problem isn't relevancy, but how long it takes to get the relevancy. For example, the first ``if`` is where your actual question "is", and basically you want to know "how to separate the daily and minutely trigger *here*?". That the comment restates the purpose of the minutely trigger and its own pseudocode is just redundant, yet the UID part is highly relevant.

Comment: @x-x well, the problem of identifying type/funcname/id of a given trigged usually boils down to the problem of storing/retrieving a reference to the created trigger. Not saying it is definitely a dupe (and being a dupe would not make your question a bad one - just the one that already has an answer) just that it might be one. As for the task at hand, you might be facing an X/Y problem, but I am not sure what your real code is, so you might be out of options: how about calling the one-off trigger like `my_one_off_trigger` and always self-delete from inside it?

Comment: If that is not an option, then you are, and I concur with Dmitry here, in need of storing a map of <triggerId, type> or <triggerId, handler> (or something similar) in script properties to track which trigger is which (I would choose script properties because user properties, as you likely know, will not work across users)

Comment: With all that said, it is, indeed, baffling to see the voting on your question, at least from the POV of someone who gave 179 answers in Apps Script and has been doing it for years now. The likely explanation is the unfortunate phenomenon of the [Meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) biased negatively thanks to the comment you apparently made which 
Hovercraft mentioned above.

Comment: side note: your question has benefited/suffered from the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention. For what it is worth, I myself have neither up-voted, down-voted nor close-voted your question since I am not a big fan of this effect except in the most egregious cases of site misuse.

Comment: Related - [Why isn't feedback mandatory on downvotes and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: I’m wondering if we do people a disservice by allowing people to ask about their posts on the main site here. It is extremely rare for this to work out in the OP’s favor, no matter how sincere they are about fixing the problem(s) with their post.

Comment: @BSMP I've been strongly veering towards the position that bringing up (in the specific case of "I have a question about...") a post on meta should disallow any interactions on the post for at least 48 hours apart from comments and edits. Right now I do agree that it rarely works in a person's favor (one could argue that they usually get more rep than they lose in the process, but at what cost...)

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/if-your-question-was-not-well-received-read-this-before-you-post-your-next-ques

Answer (score 10):

Don't fret over *one* downvote.

I can't see any telltale signs of why this question isn't good, and I feel like a large consensus would rather keep it open than see it closed.

If you had an avalanche of votes, then there'd be more to concern yourself with. But with just one? I don't think it's an issue.

Comment: Now it has 6 downvotes and a net score of -3.  Do you want to revise your answer?

Comment: At the time it wasn't. I still don't see anything actually wrong with the question and so I'm as perplexed as the OP as to why it's getting voted the way it is.

Comment: Likewise, I see nothing wrong with the question and was happy to answer it.

Comment: @NateEldredge Even currently at +7/-9, it's still a win for OP. Not only did he get his answer, but his rep outcome (for whatever that is worth) is a net gain of +52 at the moment. Anyway, the results of the Meta Effect shouldn't really be considered about when to fret over downvotes either. Meta's going to Meta.

Answer (score 9):

I can't speculate over the reasons for the downvote, but the main problem with the question is it doesn't have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also it's a A-B problem. You originally ran into the issue of the runtime limit of 6 minutes (problem A). In order to solve that, you provided a theoretical solution and pseudo code, where you ran into another problem B. The question can be improved by

- Providing a minimal, complete and a verifiable case scenario.
- Showing your research: Working around the runtime limit is the [third FAQ in apps script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?tab=Frequent)

Comment: I have used this term "A-B problem" a few times in the past, but I have no clue where I got it.  It is SUPER relevant to this type of question/answer dialog.  Do you have any links to other terms or phrases used for this idea?

Comment: Ah, I found this for anybody else who had the same question, X-Y Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem