# Question Close Reasons project - Introduction and Feedback

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, announcement

A few weeks after I joined Stack Overflow, I was given a project by my manager, [Cesar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/1058732), called “Question Close Reasons.” In short, the project was to create a community-wiki post on Meta Stack Overflow that can serve as a resource to help the community know when to use each close reason when closing questions and to help users who had their questions closed understand the reason behind it.

### A new user story

To say I felt ill-equipped to tackle this project was an understatement. How could I, a new employee/user, come up with such an important and valuable resource for the community? I immediately went head-first into researching all of the definitions and guidance across Meta Stack Overflow.

I made a rough draft of the proposal, but I still felt lost. I had never had a question closed. I had never flagged, or voted to close a question. I had never reviewed questions in the queue. So how could I build this resource?

That was my answer: I couldn't – not alone, at least.

### This resource belongs to you.

**A tool is only useful if it fits the hands who are meant to wield it.**

The same had to be true for this project. I am not a typical user of Stack Overflow, so while I had data, I could not truly envision what was needed for the project. So I asked for help – and the community answered.

The project you are about to see has come from months of working side-by-side in direct collaboration with the community. Moderators and regular users gave countless hours of their time and expertise to help define and build this community-wiki post as a canonical repository – but it is still incomplete.

That’s where you all come in.

**This wiki belongs to the broader community that has not seen it – until today.**

#### [You can find the Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance community-wiki post here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/)

It’s already 80-90% done, but we need your help to make it even better. While we have worked hard on these definitions and workflows, we recognize that our understanding might not be complete, so like all content on Stack Overflow, we welcome revisions. We hope that this wiki becomes a fixture within the community, but that will only happen if it is moldable to the needs of the users. As such, we hand it and its ownership over to you. This resource will need the community to keep it relevant and up to date so that it may continue to be valuable as definitions change and workflows evolve.

Lastly, while I know it is not customary to include thanks in posts, it feels wrong to not acknowledge the vast amount of support and goodwill that I received from everyone who helped bring this project to fruition. All the success of this project lies solely in their contributions.

### What about changing existing close reasons?

The scope of *this* project is to formalize and clarify *existing* close reasons. If you have feedback or suggestions on improving or rethinking Stack Overflow community-specific close reasons, you might be interested in the follow-up discussion:

[Overhauling our community's closure reasons and guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417008)

### Any questions?

This was a new collaborative project, and I haven't gone into as much detail about the process behind it as I could have. If you have specific questions about the project or the process, please feel free to post them as an answer below, and I will be happy to answer them.

Comment: As I'm sure you realised researching this, re: *"help the community know when to use each close reason when closing questions"* -  When certain close reasons should be used (some more than others) can be rather opinionated. I'm hoping this guidance isn't intended to be prescriptive.

Comment: What is the plan with the text telling a user their question got closed? Will it still link to the help center or will it now refer to the new meta post? If it is the latter, then you really need to make sure that the question (or the answers in case of a direct link to each answer) will never be deleted, or else all prior close reason boxes will contain a dead link.

Comment: You cannot begin to comprehend how overjoyed I am to see this.  The company is *finally* taking the time to explain what these close reasons mean.  It only took so many years but...it's nice to see.

Comment: I mean... not to be blunt... but... what does this actually accomplish? we still have the same close reasons, and this is more or less just a community curated FAQ posted by an employee.

Comment: How is this going to be made visible? An FAQ on meta isn't the most visible thing in the world, and we can't feature it forever. It's not even explicitly featured now, but not really the point. Do you plan to link it somewhere more visible?

Comment: @Makoto: When was that? [In 2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: [It's been a recurring theme with all of their "campaigns" in "support" of the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386324/1079354) that the company just didn't bother to explain why close votes happen or what they mean, or own them in some way.

Comment: @KevinB:  Yes, the community would be curating the FAQ, but it's very much the company that put the FAQ out in the first place.  Now we have an authoritative thing to point to to say why someone's question was closed, and none of us get the giant target painted on our backs in doing so.

Comment: @Makoto I like your optimism that users still wouldn't try to lecture us what the close reason really means. On multiple occasions I've been told that re-asking a closed question is the correct thing to do. Because that's what the close reason says.

Comment: @KevinB one possible source of inspiration that springs to mind for this project is [this FAQ post at SE.SE meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6483/31260). I wouldn't call it a million dollar success but per my observations it is referrred quite regularly and saves people more effort than they invest in its maintenance

Comment: ...another reason for this effort may be more internal to the company: they may want to grow an expert in SO close reasons (these reasons probably matter 10x more than those at all other sites combined - and besides, one familiar with these could reuse this knowledge quite efficiently at other sites - give or take handful of site-specific "surprises"). When Bella wrote about feeling ill-equipped this immediately clicked because at one of past jobs I was assigned fairly similar project in the area I had no idea about before (that was tough but eventually it worked, to my own surprise)

Comment: That one provides an answer to a common problem though... "Why was my post closed or downvoted?". This one... not so much. We have [another resource here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/if-your-question-was-not-well-received-read-this-before-you-post-your-next-ques) for such users, where as the new FAQ just seems like what should be in the help center, as it's far more blunt/information rich, rather than speaking directly to users about how to resolve their immediate concerns.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine The Community-specific ones can be linked to in the close post notice for the asker quite easily as well as the guidance for how to use the close reason in the flag/vote to close modal - this will make those, at least, immediately accessible to askers. Right now we don't have a solution for the network-default close reasons other than encouraging close voters to link to the appropriate answer in a comment when they vote to close.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine (& others): The idea (for CMs) is not to be done here. We definitely agree that an FAQ is not the most visible thing in the world, however, it is a significant improvement. We wanted this to be a resource for reviewers, moderators, and folks who have their questions closed. Reviewers can more safely and more consistently apply these reasons, them + mods also have an authoritative thing to point to. Users who have their questions closed have a compilation of what next steps they can take, if any, to get it reopened if they so wish. (+1)

Comment: What you see today is what CMs (Bella, really) + a lot of community members, and moderators could put together. The next step for me is approaching our product team and figuring out ways to incorporate this *into* the product. I don't know what this will look like yet, that's a conversation for our Product folks, CMs, and probably even more community members. But I definitely want us to explore ways to make this more surfaceable by design. We don't know when yet, and it could be a while, but there's room to make this even more usable. Shipping now was not letting perfect be the enemy of good.

Comment: "How could I, a new employee/user, come up with such an important and valuable resource for the community?" Well... you could actually take part in the Close Vote queues for a few weeks and find out hands-on how difficult it can be to ascribe (or not) a close vote on some of these posts. Perhaps a bit of review time spent in the ReOpen queue wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Bella, I'm sorry you were given this on your plate. The objective of "create a community-wiki post on Meta Stack Overflow that can serve as a resource to help the community know when to use each close reason when closing questions and to help users who had their questions closed understand the reason behind it" is best served by modifying the close reasons themselves. I was thinking that we were going to do that backwards, explain what we mean and then craft a message that was short and to the point to replace the close reasons. This is not that. We've already tried this.

Comment: @Makoto read this to know ^ why is not what you think it will do.

Comment: @Braiam:  Gotta roll before you can rock (before you can crawl (before you can walk)).  As in, this is at least some progress.  Can't expect Rome to be built overnight on this.

Comment: @Makoto at least Rome has solid fundamentals to be built upon. Building on sand doesn't work either.

Comment: @Braiam:  Not sure why you don't think the fundamentals are solid.  The start is getting this together and allowing the community to provide clarity and feedback in one, centralized and standard location about these close reasons.  The ultimate objective would be to then enshrine it as a part of the actual close reasons and FAQ and provide the contextual information that so many people actually need.  So I don't know why you protest here; this *is* the foundation.

Comment: @Makoto the fundamentals were not solid because they were continually diluted from their weak state. Duplicates now is firmly putting the onus on the answers, rather than the question itself. Community specific reasons still don't include an option to just say "this is not programming at all" (which is what off topic literally should mean on SO). This is *not the foundation*, this is simply more force applied to inertia. If you want to correct course, this will make it harder. Tell me, if there's something wrong that is not tolerable, how is going to change? Another discussion?

Comment: Will the "opinion-based" text change for all sites? The proposed text seems ok for sites like Stack Overflow where there's often an objective solution available, but for other sites like Workplace.se and Literature.se it doesn't work as well because there may not be an objectively correct solution; however, people are still expected to justify their answers with facts, references, etc.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine the project was specifically scoped to be about Stack Overflow only, but if its scope ever gets expanded to the network sites, methinks the current wording should suffice for more subjective-oriented sites of the network as there is a distinction between "good" subjective (verifiable as you mentioned) and "bad" subjective (baseless opinions)

Comment: If this initiative does not bring back some previous close reasons it's worthless.  The one close reason that absolutely needs to be brought back is "too localized".  In other words, just debugging the OP's code.  It seems that's what SO has devolved into.

Comment: @Dexygen you might be interested in the followup [discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417008/overhauling-our-communitys-closure-reasons-and-guidance/417323#417323) then

Comment: This is a good project to have -- don't screw it up. Close reasons on SO have been a moving target for years. There have been improvements (and not so much improvements). The rational behind how and why one target should be chosen over another has been a moving target as well leaving gaps (where no close reason fits many questions needing to be closed) or overlap (where more than one may apply). The "this question belongs on another site" generally doesn't list the needed site (*Unix&Linux* being a common one). Moderators give differing basis for either moving or failing to move. Good luck!

Answer (score 59):

Is the close notification text going to remain the same? Because it is sometimes misleading. Very misleading.

Take this one:

[image: Guidance on a closed question. It reads "Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one." The last phrase "ask a new one" is a hyperlink leading to the ask question page.]

This is misleading as the *intent* seems to be "You can ask a new question *different from this one*" yet many users read it as "You can re-ask the exact same question".

This problem was even [mentioned when the new closure text was announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332500):

> I don't think it's a good option to remind users of to the option to 'post a new one' in this banner. My gut feeling says it will only lead to repeated questions, worded slightly different but not enough to make it clear.

Then later *again* [when the closure notices were rolled out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015) but was marked as "status-declined".

It has been almost three years and the close notice has not been altered. We now get an FAQ which...I have to be perfectly honest here - it does not help one bit. We have an FAQ entry for this: ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i) It already is ignored by most people because it is not discoverable. Ironically, [we now have a duplicate of that FAQ about duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417477). Yet if the problematic guidance (or lack of) on the actual close notices remains, then no amount of FAQs would really help.

Comment: This exact project is limited in scope to getting the guidance together, but I'd definitely love to see an extension to it that finally solves this misleading piece of advice

Comment: I feel like this specific example is one that we've discussed internally and decided that we do want to change but I'm not sure where we are on that specific discussion. I also know that there's some concern about the wording of the migration notice and I know that when we rewrote the close reasons for too broad and Needs details, we didn't do a great job at differentiating them. While that's out of scope for this project, it's definitely on our list of things to revisit (or it's on mine, anyway).

Comment: @Catija In the Wiki under "My question was closed as [Duplicate]. What should I do now?" there are 17 bullet points (including nested ones) but nowhere does it mention (if I'm not mistaken) the idea of asking a new question. Isn't this a clear inconsistency? At the very least the official close reason should be a summary of that longer text here, but they seem to be mutually exclusive currently.

Comment: @Trilarion intentional - this is a big mistake that we even suggest to users to ask a new question. A given question is either (A) a duplicate (and hence should not be reasked) or (B) not answered (and hence should be edited and reopened). I think we should just get rid of the mention in the notice.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine But it seems the company has decided to not getting rid of that notice, so they might see it differently. In the end it's an inconsistent guidance. One could do a bit of statistics and see how often people produce serial duplicate questions, asking the same thing over and over again. But if the company doesn't want to, it simply doesn't want to.

Comment: @Trilarion it actually seems like the company is finally open to discussion with curators about what should *really* be the guidance on closure - this FAQ was only the first step towards that, so it is possible that we finally see the close notice amended.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Good but overall it's too slow for me. I'm not that patient. I'm personally more interested in platforms like Codidact now. Just pointing out the inconsistencies here.

Comment: @Trilarion "but nowhere does it mention (if I'm not mistaken) the idea of asking a new question" that was basically our fault. We pushed, really hard, to not include re-asking anywhere on the document (maybe even subconsciously)

Comment: @Trilarion yeah, things are going quite slow - I was surprized even this project got greenlit at first. But it's a start, and it seems lke there's going to be an expansion into revisiting the close reasons themselves (at least the community-specific ones), so I'd say I am optimistic about the perspectives. As for Codidact, I checked it out a while ago, and it looks good, but I don't think I will jump ships. But I do want it to succed - I think SE network went too long without a viable competitor - it might actually liven things around here.

Comment: @Braiam now we only need to make sure it disappears from the notice too - and it seems like it's actually going to happen.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I would not hold my bread to that. We tried to remove boilerplate language from the guidance, and those were rejected by staff.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Yes, there may be more happening now, but in the end it's still too slow for me. If I'm honest I quit long time ago in the sense of investing lots of time. And putting all eggs in a single basket only isn't a good idea either.

Comment: It would be great if we can have more choices for `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` options. For example, sometimes some questions are related to maths/specific machine learning algorithms. I think Maths Stack exchange / Data Science Stack exchange could be a better destination for these questions, instead of the current stats.stackexchange.com. This is just an example and I think it would be great if we can have some kind of search box to allow us to search for suitable stack exchange sites to redirect the question to.

Comment: @ray: 100% agreed.  Either provide a more complete set of vote-to-migrate options (e.g. to sites where your SE account exists), or don't have it at all.  It feels like a leftover from very early days of SO / SE that hasn't been maintained.  It makes no sense to be able to migrate to superuser but not serverfault, askubuntu, or other .SE sites like electronics, computer science or codereview.  (Possibly not to unix.SE because of the amount of overlap, if we don't want questions bouncing around too much if both places decide the Q is a better fit on the other.)

Answer (score 27):

This is probably a good time if there ever was one to suggest replacing the very triggering term "Duplicate".  For many years, users have quibbled about whether a given question was suitably closed as a "duplicate" despite there being some snowflake nuance between the two pages.  "I said I need to know if the string length was more than 3, but that duplicate page checks if the length was more than 4!" or "I asked for a case-insensitive regex pattern, but that one is case-sensitive!"  Come on, we don't need a page for every snowflake, people.

May we please consider throwing out the term "**Duplicate**" and replace it with a short, snappy, yet accurate term like "**Resolved Elsewhere**"?

This very minor rephrasing paints a more accurate picture of:

1. why the closure points to where it points and
2. how it is possible that the "dupe target" is actually posted more recently than the closed page (otherwise an inexperienced user might say, "how can I be guilty of posting a duplicate question if I posted earlier than that one!") and
3. why questions without an upvoted or accepted answer cannot be used (unless by the same asker) to close another question.

If any accompanying text or explanation is needed with this close category, then you might explain that:

> Stack Overflow continually strives to improve the researcher experience by minimizing content redundancy and redirecting users to pages that have the best answers and fewer bad/misleading/outdated/incorrect answers.

> If your question is closed as "Resolved Elsewhere", but after trying all of the insights on the recommended page your problem persists, please edit your question to demonstrate what techniques you've tried, and include details about how those techniques failed to resolve your specific scenario.  Once edited, your updated question will be reviewed by other users and may be reopened.

Feel free to vastly modify the above quote-formatted text.  It's the vibe of the thing.

Comment: Perhaps my thoughts are too much of a departure from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417477/2943403 ?

Comment: WRT to your comment. The intention of this project was create an FAQ for how to use the _existing_ closure reasons. The reasons inform the guidance not the other way around. If the reasons change, the guidance will need updated, but the existence of guidance for the current reasons does not preclude or in any way affect changing the reasons. So it's not really a factor of how far your thoughts are from that guidance.

Comment: WRT to your post. I agree that "duplicate" is often a misunderstood term, especially for cases where different problems can be solved in the same way or have the same underlying issue. That said, I'm fairly certain the Duplicate closure reason is uniform Network-wide and changing it would affect every community not just SO. For that reason, this might be a better suited conversation for MSE.

Comment: This actually raises a valid point because if we check the historical MSO/MSE posts an exact definition of "duplicate" was never given. When some thought about giving a definition it usually boiled down to cliches like: "answer on duplicate target could easily be adapted by "professional/enthusiast programmer"" or "sufficiently similar" or something like that. So using two words "**solved** (elsewhere)" actually does a better job of defining what a duplicate should be about (although if referring to such Qs we'd have to call them something instead of "duplicate" which would be more cumbersome)

Comment: What's also amazing is how clear-cut the use of "duplicate" is in practice, without needing an exact written definition of what marks the border between being or not a duplicate. So this is kind of a conundrum, since it's easy to use but the term has never been clearly defined on the metas...

Comment: I feel that "Resolved Elsewhere" is an excellent label for relating different questions with the same resolving approach. This is _actually_ what good "signposts" should be doing.  We don't need multiples of the same question asked the same way pointing somewhere.  We need different encounters which are all resolved in the same way. These are good signposts that should be immune from deletion.  When we have two questions that ask the same question, we should keep the better/clearer question and make sure that the best advice is found at the better asked question (then trash the inferior page).

Comment: This is non-sense. We want that the first answer they read to be the one that solve the issue. Otherwise why we have requirements that the answer has to apply to the question asked. This is the worse approach to the good old [not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/792066) argument.

Comment: @bad_coder it was given, [in the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). Duplicates allow for "many subtle variations of a question", but not fundamental differences, like another language, or this is the recipe for an apple pie when you want to know the escape velocity for a rocket with a given mass.

Comment: "I said I need to know if the string length was more than 3, but that duplicate page checks if the length was more than 4!" - I felt this in my bones.

Comment: I very much like "Resolved Elsewhere". Nicely done. +1.

Comment: Changing the title to "Resolved Elsewhere" doesn't solve the problem that you seem to think it would solve. Users would still say "I need to know if the string length is greater than 3, and the other question doesn't resolve this, it only checks if the length was more than 4!"

Comment: The "technique" to resolve will be provided without explicitly guaranteeing duplicity.  It affords wider acceptance of the goal to consolidate content, and urges answerers to answer specific questions in a way that well also resolve technically proximal scenarios.  In my experience, good, narrow questions ask for a single technique or suffer from a single error.  My opinion is that multi-technique or multi-error questions Need More Focus.  Otherwise we will see questions avoiding Resolved Elsewhere closure by asking multi-faceted questions.

Comment: @Flimm Still, it seems easier to *argue* that another question "resolves" than "duplicates" the closed question. Of course people can refuse to listen to any closure reason, no matter the formulation. Often enough, I have to *agree* that a duplicate is not *exact* – which then ends up with an argument over technicalities of what "duplicate" means. At least those cases could be avoided.

Comment: This feels like an invitation for argument: https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=If%20you%20see%20a%20question%20closed%20as%20a%20duplicate%20but%20don't%20agree%20that%20it%20truly%20is%20a%20duplicate

Comment: +1. Maybe specify more clearly that the referred question might not *directly and verbatim* relate to the one being closed. I especially like the reference to "all of the insights" - it could happen that the question itself, even if posing a different problem (so, not a "classic" duplicate), solves in passing the one the OP is asking.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments, there is similarly designed and structured post at SE.SE meta: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6483/31260)

Don't know if you are aware but anyway, thing worth mentioning about their post is that after it gained wide enough acceptance of site community, moderators edited help center "on-topic" section and included links to some of its answers into help center bullets covering relevant off-topic reasons.

You can see how it worked here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic And here is related discussion at their meta: [Help Center tuning... references to meta guidance](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7237/31260).

I think if your guidance post matures enough (say, from [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) to [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)) moderators can similarly edit Stack Overflow help center and add appropriate links to its answers.

Comment: So basically, half of the work already existed. Are the general close reasons descriptions in both documents more or less exact copies or are they maybe even different and contradicting with each other?

Comment: @Trilarion the initial text we got was indeed compiled from existing docs IIRC (don't think it was from that doc), but each reason has been heavily edited since + community-specific close reasons have been written from scratch. As for contradicting - hope not, but needs further review

Comment: @Trilarion hard to tell because I wasn't deeply involved in making that faq at SE.SE meta nor am actively using it. Per my recollection there was a time when it was very actively edited and this took rather lot of time but eventually it stabilised - maybe this happened when active maintainers all felt that everything finally matched smoothly in various sources of guidance. I suppose that all (noticeable) contradictions that could be there were somehow resolved by collaborative editing - although I'm not 100% sure because I never thoroughly checked that

Answer (score 0):

## There is no way to change the documents to suggest or change one or more of the reasons.

If this post is meant for feedback, it should include any feedback, that includes new reasons or changing reasons. There's no mechanism in place to do either of those. If the reasons belong to us, there should be a way for us to change it.

Comment: That seems to be outside the scope of the linked [Question Close Reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417476/1478931) post. That post is merely meant to explain and provide guidance for the close reasons that exist on SO. If any changes are made to SO's close reasons, the linked post could be updated at that time.

Comment: @V2Blast how can you "explain" something that several people are against or don't feel that it represents the desired state. The sound bites close reasons has to emanate from some well throughout document, not backwards.

Comment: The linked Question Close Reasons post is for documenting the existing close reasons. It doesn't prevent those reasons from ever changing – but it's also not the place to propose those changes. Such a change *should* be proposed in a well-thought-out post, but it should be a separate post (rather than posted as an answer to the linked post). If the close reasons change, then the linked post would be updated accordingly (e.g. if an existing close reason is removed, the corresponding answer to the linked post would be removed; if a new close reason is added, a new answer would be posted).

Answer (score -3):

Initially looking at it, it looks very useful in its current state. But I wonder how it's going to be monitored going forward?

For example, I often use "not likely to help future readers" for questions that ask such rudimentary questions about a language such as ("How do I write an if statement in X?") that in my own opinion I don't think it is likely to help anyone else since its so trivial that any professional or enthusiast would bother to come to Stack Overflow for it.

It feels slightly counterintuitive if I were just to add my own reasoning to why a close reason is used when I could well be wrong and then this is written down as factual.

Comment: Your middle paragraph is exactly why we are trying to clarify this guidance, because that is a complete abuse of the close reason and should never be the basis for closing any question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray - That’s fair enough, so for that example, how should you treat that question? Downvote for no research and answer it anyway?

Comment: If it's been asked and answered before, close it as a duplicate. Otherwise, answer it with a high-quality canonical answer. Trivial questions are extremely valuable additions to our knowledge base. Plenty of people come here asking them, as you've surely seen for yourself.