# Should / Let's close old Recommendation questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-queues, close-reasons

> ### Stack Overflow doesn't provide product or service recommendations
>
> Requests for book recommendations, suggestions for tools, and product
> comparisons [tend to attract poor-quality answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).
>
> We cannot reliably tell you what the best book, language, platform,
> tool or library is. We *might* be able to tell you which one will meet
> *your specific needs **right now*** - but chances are that won't help anyone else a year from now.
>
> Instead, try to ask questions that prompt *instructional* answers.
> Seek *explanations*, not suggestions: be specific about *what* you
> need to accomplish, learn, or buy, but ask *how* to accomplish it,
> learn it, or select it.
>
> **See Also:** [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/),  [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/), [Let's Play the Guessing Game](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)

From Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562

So there are many old recommendation questions (not constructive) present till now. I have closed above 200 questions with custom flag by taking moderator attention. But this will take time of moderators as moderators having many others tedious moderation to do. And on SO many people having power of closing questions. So let's utilize it.

Review this questions:

1. [5000+ Recommendation unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=recommend+closed%3A0&submit=search)
2. [5000+ Book Recommendation unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=book+closed%3A0&submit=search)
3. [5000+ Best tools unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+tools+closed%3A0&submit=search)
   Many more...

Also we can check 2,745 questions of [books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books) and 397 questions of [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recommendation). And people should not entertain new questions coming with recommendations. Close them as early as soon as possible. So they will know this questions are not allowed on SO.

There can be many questions which will come under all 3 categories. Many questions can have only this words and different meaning. Then edit them. Many of us will love to have those recommendations. But be honest.

**Let's close Recommendation questions. Let's make our community cleaner.**

Comment: You might want to consider adding those to [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)...

Comment: We can check for questions tagged with books and recommendation tags. But we can't say all of this questions are not constructive. That's why we have to review those questions. And I am sure above 70% questions will get closed.

Comment: This is a great pointer to things which should be closed.  Thanks!

Comment: I like how people are upvoting this but not actually taking any action. I thought the whole point of this post was to get people to take action without having to involve moderators?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I believe that `books` is already on the cleanup list.  Regardless, both tags should be eliminated, but *only* after they've been reviewed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to be a pain in the ass to handle.  [Unless.........](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136705/show-a-mod-menu-on-questions-summaries)

Comment: @Won't: Won't that be bad because some people might give recommendation about concept, concept in specific book. And people can close those good questions without reading it. That's why I said 70% questions could get closed. And rest of questions we have to edit. i.e Review of those questions is required.

Comment: @Won't:http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136838/178505

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few quick notes:

1. Some of these are fine as-is (if you're implementing a recommendation feature, you probably do want to use that terminology), many others are simply misleading (using "recommend" as a "polite" way of asking for an answer is not uncommon, or strictly-speaking incorrect - I'm *recommending* several things in this very answer). Strongly prefer editing for clarity to closing here except in the most blatant cases.
2. Your query is returning every question where the word "book" appears anywhere in the question or any answers. This is going to have a *ridiculously high* false-positive rate if you're just looking for book recommendations. Try: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3abook%20closed%3a0 (and be aware that there are *still* quite a few perfectly good questions returned by that - folks ask questions *about* books too).
3. Again, I recommend limiting this to titles as both of these are extremely common terms: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A0+title%3Abest+tools Note that although search *says* there are 5K+ results, there are less than 150 with *both* terms in the title.

Any time you're trying to use keywords as a shortcut for something like this, you're gonna run face-first into the fact that folks are very creative in their wording. Stack Overflow has had a number of keyword-based warnings and blocks in place for quite a while now; folks just find other ways of asking the same thing. Err on the side of not catching decent questions in the crossfire if you do go through these lists.

Comment: Very good notes. It will help a lot in reviewing search results. Should community wiki questions also closed?

Comment: CW is orthogonal to this; if the question+answers are good, leave open (+edit if necessary)... If not, close.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that these questions should be closed, old or new.

Here is a [***good query***](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201658/questions-with-pending-close-votes-off-topic-reasons) that finds questions that already have 1 or more close vote for closing as tool/resource/etc. Just type in **8** in the input box that says *CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId*.