# Ask a question about the pros and cons of certain languages within a platform

Tags: discussion, subjective-questions

I would like to ask a question somewhere on SO/SE about this:

> What are the pros and cons of using **Jython vs. JavaScript** in
>   automation scripts in Maximo 7.6.1.1?

Is there anywhere on SO/SE where this kind of partially-subjective question would be appropriate?

Comment: On the network?  Not really; it's too broad, at the very least.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't ask anywhere in the Stack Exchange network for a list of pros and cons between things as that would be both too broad and opinion based. What a pros is for one can be a cons for another, depending on context, experience, etc.

What you can do is asking (but search first!) about a single practical aspect about something that you feel as a cons.

For example:

> In Maximo 7.x when I want to automate a foo I need to duplicate the bar in Jython. Here is my code
>    `<add MCVE>`
>   This leads to fubar all over the place. Is there something I overlooked or misunderstand?
>    (I'm not bound to using Jython).

What I imagine is that this question leads to answers that either solves your issue, or shows how you can achieve the same in JavaScript, and hopefully that is convincing enough to be a better alternative. Both question and answers are well scoped to be useful beyond your own context.

You can rinse and repeat for a couple of cons and so build-up your own list of pros and cons tailored to your needs. The collective knowledge base that SO wants to be has become a bit better with that content.

See also: [Should / Let's close old Recommendation questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254389/should-lets-close-old-recommendation-questions)