# Do we need better guidance for "recommendation" questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, help-center, recommendation-questions

For just shy of a year now, we've had the following close reason on Stack Overflow:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

I *really* like it. It's *insanely* useful for quickly resolving a broad class of generally-unproductive questions where *there's no clear problem to be solved* while still providing specific guidance as to when it should be used and how to ask a better question.

But occasionally, it seems to motivate [some rather unproductive behaviors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254374/close-clean-up-questions-asking-for-recommendation) itself:

> I started using the search engine and I saw very few question had false positive.
>   So, Let's use the SQL query equivalent! There are ≈ 4,000 questions to close!

As I was writing up [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254374/close-clean-up-questions-asking-for-recommendation/254395#254395) to that proposal, I realized that we don't really have a single, succinct description of what "recommendation questions" are and how to avoid them *written with Stack Overflow in mind*. That close reason links to an answer I wrote a couple years ago that... Is probably reasonable... But is also fairly specific to one person's question, and hardly quick to read.

There have been [other attempts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) at teasing out a good explanation for these, but nothing that *quite* captures the key difference between a question that begs for a list of recommendations and one that *focuses on solving a problem* (although I think [Kate Gregory's attempt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad/185482#185482) came very, very close to this).

So I guess what I'm asking is, do we need something better than a terse close reason here? A single meta [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) or [help center](/help) article? And if so, what should it contain?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're also looking for something which would avoid the "unproductive behaviors", or was that just the motivation for this discussion?

Comment: Mostly just an explanation for why I'm posting this now - there'll always be someone trying to reduce this sort of analysis to a test for a few keywords, but if I had something better to point to when saying "your test for false positives is crap" then perhaps it'd be easier to communicate the problems with them.

Comment: One somewhat common case where a recommendation question is actually viable is when you can easily rephrase it as a problem solving questions. So instead of "Is there a library for X?" you can rephrase as "I have the situation Y, how can I do Z?". Answers can still be essentially a recommendation for a library, but phrasing it differently discourages one-liners and doesn't restrict answers to recommendations. But this is still a judgement call and not an unambiguous rule.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6487/31260

Comment: The usual explanation I give folks who are stubborn about their "finder" question staying open: "We're here to provide you with our expertise; not help you find that expertise somewhere else."

Answer (score 6):

I think the [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question/254394#254394) link should be tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), but otherwise I think the solution is adequate. I was thinking about ways to explain this in a succinct way, but everything I thought of kept coming back to just saying things like "no, seriously, just read this link". If the wording of that close reason isn't enough, the person is going to need a lot more than two sentences to get it.

One other idea would be to remove the bolding on **a tool, library, or favorite offsite resource**, because **recommend or find** is really what that close reason is about. Here's how it would look

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

---

This is not exactly the question you asked, but it's related enough that I'm going to include it here: Now that [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is in public beta, I think we should attempt to drive traffic there with our close reasons. Possibly start migrating appropriate questions, but at the very least [include a link to SR, (e.g. to their "how to ask" rules) in that close reason.](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules)

Comment: Please don't include a link to SR itself but to our questions rules :) Not every "What Foo does my Bar" is applicable over there.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer edited

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced there is no clear problem solved. The current SO rules tend to encourage a very counter-productive approach to programming. Consider two approaches to starting to use floating point.

User A hears rumors that there are special difficulties and pitfalls in using floating point, and posts a request for tutorial recommendations. That question would be rejected under this rule.

User B goes head and writes floating point code anyway, and gets some weird-seeming results. User B posts a question containing a program, and asking why it got its results. User B will almost certainly get a reference to one or both of a pair of well-regarded tutorials on the subject, the information User A requested, either directly or via a duplicate question link.

Does SO really want to favor programming-by-guesswork, supplemented by questions when it goes wrong, over reading about a topic first?

Comment: What we might *want* is immaterial; the fact is, we'll *get* both questions anyway, and chances are we'll get far more of the latter since anyone willing to google "floating point tutorial" or "floating point pitfalls" will be too busy reading the wealth of information returned to bother asking. So the best we can really do is to try to have at least one good answer somewhere that folks will find or can be pointed to when the need arises.

Answer (score -1):

they should have the text box broken down to these types:
manually ask

problem
what you've tried
where you think you're going wrong
et al

This would help people ask the perfect question more often.