# Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

In response to [someone's question relating to closing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254374/close-clean-up-questions-asking-for-recommendation), [Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) posted this:

> For the most part, **it's a gigantic waste of time and effort**: most of these questions aren't causing problems. If you observe a question that is attracting spam or whose answers are all out of date or even just poorly-written, great - flag it or vote to close it. But don't dig up graves just so you can pound another stake in the rotting corpse.

(As per my understanding of his clarification in the comments, this relates to all close reasons, not just the one relating to that question)

Is this really the advice we're supposed to follow?

What's the motivation behind this?

Shouldn't we try to clean the site up?

If we should follow this, why do we even have a close vote review queue at all? Why not just get rid of and disable close votes on questions older than ... like a day?

If it's just for those gathering spam or having out of date answers - I really haven't seen *that* many of those that it would justify having a review queue.

Comment: Also, I heard we keep questions around even if they are duplicates in order to direct people to the canonical answers. Does that mean redirecting older questions to the canonical answers is bad? That somehow calls the rationale for closing as duplicate at all into question.

Comment: I can understand that people don't think it is worth the effort. But personally I really dislike the high percentage of unanswered questions caused by bad (and possibly old) questions.

Comment: If a question is never again looked at (either here or in a google result), does it matter if it is closed or not? Will anyone see a difference anywhere?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Where do you get "never again looked at" from? If it being old implies that it will pretty much never get looked at again, then what's the point of even keeping these questions? We might as well remove them with an automated script.

Comment: @Dukeling: I nowhere implied that "being old" == "never again looked at". On the contrary, those are totally orthogonal metrics. "Closing old questions" for me implies that you mean that they "just" have normal close reasons, and "just" happen to be old. So if a question would be often enough looked at, it would eventually been closed; so old questions that are not closed and should have, might just be in that state because no one looked at them. New questions just had not have enough time to be classified as "no one looks here". If we continue to not look at them, will that really matter?

Comment: @PlasmaHH A question can remain open forever if 1000 users a day look at it, assuming these are low rep users, users who don't know the guidelines, users who don't care, or users who don't bother because they believe their close vote will just expire anyway. The bottom line is - there are plenty of criteria which can lead to an old question not getting closed. I agree that questions that no-one looks at don't do much harm, but I think we should pro-actively close questions which *might* be looked at in future, and so what if we happen to close a few that won't be looked it.

Comment: @Dukeling: I totally agree with you here. I was trying to highlight the "waste of effort" part. If no one looks at them, spending effort on closing them is wasted. Spend that effort on closing questions that are actually looked at.

Comment: I'm not going to bother answering this because this will closed in a year or so

Comment: I'd love to see this question re-opened. The dupe question discusses the _difficulty_ of closing an old question, due to low traffic. This question discusses the _desirability_ of closing old questions - whether or not it is worth spending effort on. That's a huge issue, e.g. on the Beta site I moderate where we aren't huge and our site definition isn't hammered out yet.

Comment: Old questions count as page views, page views count toward ad impressions, ad impressions means your privacy being sold out and the guy buying shovelling barrels of cash into SE pockets. Stop trying to fight money. Just thought you'd appreciate the truth behind the whitewash reasoning.

Answer (score 27):

There is only point in closing questions (and to a further extent deleting questions) if they interrupt the normal flow of the site.

Is the problematic question:

- Likely to attract future problematic answers? Close.
- Attract lots of discussion? Close.
- A duplicate of a newer better and already popular question? Close.

Otherwise, like Shog said - it's a gigantic waste of time, we gain *nothing* by closing old questions that don't take attention. If they're dead questions that won't take any more of anyone's time - just leave them be.

The primary reason for question closing is to direct attention towards better questions. If a question is not problematic (and heaven forbid, it might be closed *and* useful) - leave it. We gain absolutely *nothing* from closing it except for overhead.

Comment: What about "- Adding to the signal of allowing low quality content on [so] to the internet at large, causing more low quality content? Close." ... oh, wait, that's **all** old questions that don't conform to the guidelines.

Comment: @Dukeling so what? There's no cost to adding low quality content to the site. Let me tl;dr my answer (and my position in that) - The problem with low quality content is not that it exists, it's that it steals attention from high quality content. That's the part that bothers me and that's why I close/down/delete vote. If Stack Overflow had a billion more bad questions but no person trying to answer a question, or person trying to find a solution to their problem ever laid eyes on them - I wouldn't care one bit. I care about the site being _useful_ for people who post answers/ask questions .

Comment: "It steals attention from high quality content" is **exactly** my point. More low quality content (LQC), whether it be old or new = more stolen attention from high quality content. The case for new LQC is obvious, the case for old LQC, a little less so (beyond inspiring more new LQC) - people rarely go looking through old questions for that gem that may have passed through the cracks because there's a constant stream, nay, tsunami of new questions to deal with, and the old questions are filled with LQC.

Comment: Yeah, signal to noise argument, the more you have noise the more difficult to discern the signal it is.

Comment: I'd add "* likely to serve as an example of an acceptable question". Which is why they should be closed, not left open.

Answer (score 24):

The only time when closing an old question isn't a waste of time, is when that question is completely off topic by today's standards, such as a book/tool/website recommendation.

Having such old, off topic questions makes more work for the moderators as people use them as justification for asking new completely off topic questions:

> Well, *that* question is open and has lots of votes/answers, so why did you close *my* question.

Having them closed or even locked with the "historical" reason means that they can't be used to justify new attempts to raise the same issues again and again.

In all other cases, even if it a bad question, it's probably better to just leave it alone.

Comment: So...to get specific here, what about [#1 most voted JS question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (too broad), and [#17 most voted JS question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js) (recommendation)? Do either of these fit your criteria?

Comment: @PaulDraper - these really old, high voted questions are candidates for historical locking. As I said, they shouldn't be used to justify what happens to new questions now, but closing leads to deleting and they've probably got lots of incoming links, so the only solution is to lock them.

Comment: I was just wondering since at least the second one fits in the category of "completely off topic by today's standards, such as a book/tool/website recommendation"

Answer (score 22):

It's hardly the first time I've said [something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111734/26-000-questions-have-close-votes-now-what/111738#111738)...

> Personally though, I don't think it matters. A question that struggles to get even 100 viewers period isn't exactly poisoning the air on the site - no one's looking at it!

The most problematic posts are the ones that *get in the way*: clog the recent questions lists, show up in search results but don't actually reflect what was searched for, keep getting bumped to the front page, etc. There are countless questions on SO that are borderline off-topic, but since *no one ever runs into them* they don't cause problems.

Meanwhile, there are questions being posted *right this second* that are *blatantly* inappropriate, and they're clogging the home page and pushing reasonable questions off of the recent questions lists.

That doesn't mean questions should be automatically protected from closure after they gain some age. But going *out of your way* to look for borderline questions when there are so many that aren't even close to the border... That's just a waste of time. In particular, flagging for closure when it takes *at least* three people to process that review under normal circumstances is borderline abusive, a waste of very precious community resources. That's why [as of last week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions), questions that no one sees or cares about are silently dropped from close review: we need to focus our efforts where they can actually make a difference.

When you see a problem, fix it or close it or raise a flag - but [make damn sure it's actually a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231413/should-i-close-questions-which-were-on-topic/231439#231439) and not just your own quest for [foolish consistency](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/353571-a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds-adored).

Comment: "as of last week, questions that no one sees or cares about are silently dropped from close review" I wasn't aware of this, but at least it explains the custom "please close this" flags that have resurfaced lately.

Comment: Not closing low-traffic questions may in general be a good thing; they tend to be highly specialized, which means both that those who find they may really find them useful, and also that the community in general may not understand them well enough to judge if they are on topic and answerable.  The one catch: occasionally a badly stated question ages the necessary days and gets a bounty slapped on it - at which point it is not closable, but isn't any better of a question.

Comment: This is one of the most sensible things I've read for a while here at Meta.    It's great to read something clearly defining the _purpose_ of closing questions.

Answer (score 4):

Closing *is* helpful for current questions or questions that are currently attracting attention, but otherwise closing it is needless faf.

It's a bit like suggested edits - putting the first close vote on an ignored question makes work for several other people, and it's not worth it unless the question is currently a problem. We're strict with suggested edits about discouraging minor edits, so it does make sense to avoid bringing up non-active problems when you have a bunch of active problems.

If we clear the close vote queue, it might be time to go spring cleaning the forgotten parts of the site, but not right now.

It's like clearing out the loft - tidy up the big mess throughout your hallway *first*.

It's particularly a problem if your family are trying to clear the hallway so they can come in and out and you keep bringing things in from the loft and the garage, putting them on top of other things in the hallway saying "we need to sort these out too".

Comment: I agree with what your saying, but it is a bit different then saying it's *a waste of time* to close old question.

Comment: @Jack It's a waste of the time of the people trying to get through the close vote queue backlog, when there are more pressing things to close.

Comment: What I mean is saying it's a waste of time sounds like there is no point in of itself, while what your saying is there are more important things to do right now. The difference being say someone has a gold badge in one of the tag or is a moderator in which case it won't take up anyone (aside from their own) time.

Comment: @Jack I have a gold badge in the Haskell tag - it gives me no further closing rights. Only diamond moderators can close with a single vote, and moderators are extremely busy dealing with all the exceptional stuff and quite rightly leave routine closing to the democratic process. If I am on holiday and choose to spend an evening on stack overflow, that is recreation. If I am at work tomorrow and there is a deadline, three hours on SO is a waste of time. Waste of time is not context free. If we clear out the close vote queue like the others, closing old questions will be less of a waste of time.

Comment: Actually it does give you further [closing rights](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212)

Comment: Closing old questions that no-one's reading is a waste of time like hoovering your loft is.

Comment: I'm not really arguing with your basic premise, I suppose it's mostly a choice of words.  I'm not suggesting for example that you start digging up old things to vote on, but say for example you came across an old question tagged with Haskel that you thought should be closed, if you now voted to close it under the recent changes it would be closed right away not using anybody else's time.

Comment: @Jack Wow, I did not know that. Hmmm. Wow. Instant duplicate closing. Very interesting. That makes it _less_ of a waste of time for _me_ to close old duplicates because now I'm hoovering the loft on my own rather than starting hoovering and asking four other folks to finish it off for me.