# How to answer extreme beginner questions

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

This happens many times a day , just for C and C++ which are the primary tags I follow.

Someone posts code they are having trouble with, and the problem with it is something *really basic*, that would be covered in the early pages of even the most dumbed-down book on C, or early on in any C course.

I usually answer anyway, because I like to help, and certainly this person will be helped by my answer.

However it bothers me, because this answer has zero chance of being useful to anyone else.  If another beginner has the same problem then they will not know which search terms to use to find this question, out of the hundreds of thousands of questions that exist.  In fact it'd probably be impossible to find the question even if you were looking specifically for it, just because of how basic it is. This question is just contributing to the "badness flood" that is a hot topic on meta at the moment.

Often I see others have vote-closed such questions, either with "simple typographical error", or "unclear what you're asking", or "not enough information provided".

[Example from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709822/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-fscanf/23709858). I don't mean to pick on this particular submitter - but this topic has been bugging me for a while, and after this post I got around to writing on meta.

The question is too basic to have any value (in my opinion of course), however none of the typical closure reasons are appropriate. It's clear what he's asking, enough information was provided, and it wasn't a typo; but a lack of basic understanding.

Comment: *"The question is too basic to have any value"* ... sounds like a downvote would be appropriate then, given its tooltip.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some teachers / books are really terrible - they may teach things in the wrong order or skip / rush over some things / explain some things really badly, leaving the students lacking some fundamental knowledge.

Also, if you've been programming for a while, you simply may have forgotten that you yourself actually also struggled with this exact same issue when you first started off (or something equally basic). It's likely that the further you move from beginner level, the higher you perceive beginner level to be.

We shouldn't close something answerable just because it's really basic.

Keeping that in mind...

**You don't think it's useful?**

Downvote.

**Did it take you less than a minute to find an answer online?**

Downvote. Apparently not a reason to close though, unless...

**The answer was found on another Stack Overflow post.**

Close as duplicate.

**Do you essentially need to teach the guy (or girl) half the language to be able to answer the question?**

Close as too broad.

**You wouldn't know where to start explaining because you don't know what OP knows or how they can't understand this.**

Close as unclear.

**Otherwise:**

- Create / find a canonical post to close it as a duplicate of.

  For [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23709822/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-using-fscanf-to-read-into-a-pointer), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault) seems like a decent candidate, although the answer is missing a section on how you actually fix it.
- Use the typographical error reason anyway.

  > While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

  Seems pretty applicable.

  The idea here is to get rid of questions that have absolutely no future value, not to use the 100% strictly correct close reason, although, [apparently that's not important](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254402/is-closing-old-questions-a-gigantic-waste-of-time-and-effort).

Comment: *future value* for who? We're not here to help `SO` get plenty of good questions / answers - we are here to **help** others - at least I am

Comment: @Adelin I am most definitely here to provide answers to questions that seem like they would be helpful to more than just the question asker (what's wrong with wanting to help more than one person at a time?). Questions that have no future value should be (closed and) deleted (because in that case there's no point in keeping them around, and doing so is probably actively harmful, in that it makes the posts that have future value harder to find) - although whether you decide to answer them first is entirely up to you.

Answer (score -5):

As silly as it might sound, in my thoughts, if one person has come here asking for it - then there are probably a dozen or hundred others looking for the same thing.

I would answer the question and then make sure that the actual QUESTION contains what others might look for - if they are unclear about a technical term or function - things that others might look for, add them in, so that others searching for the right thing find the answer you provided.

If the question is a basic typo ("hey, how come this doesn't compile") I often leave a comment with the solution then vote to close off-topic->Typo.

Folks are answer are here because they like helping others, but that doesn't mean we can't help and at the same time keep the site standards the way the site is meant to be. Close questions that need closing, migrate those that need migrating - but above all, help people who come seeking our help :)

Having said all that, just because I pop a downvote on a question doesn't mean I won't sometimes spend a minute or two answering it - if it can be answered in a minute or two.

Edit: One thing I missed, if the question is a duplicate, I vote to close duplicate and leave no answer, but if I can't find something qickly on SO or it doesn't appear to be a too similar, I will probably answer.

Comment: In my opinion, answering a poor-quality question only serves to further encourage users to ask more questions like that. For the majority of these users, it does not *matter* that the question has been closed (or to be PC, "put on hold"). All they want is an answer; removing the incentive will help prevent these questions from being asked.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yeah, I won't post a lengthy in-depth answer to one of these, but if it pretty straightforward to answer, then I don't mind leaving a sentance or two.

Comment: @Fluffeh: Do you also advocate downvoting low-quality answers (is such a short answer good?)? Because then you are inviting downvotes by following the guidance in this your answer here.