# Which option shall I use to close questions with answers in comments?

Tags: support, flags

We all know there are many simple questions with short answers in comments, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611573/insert-on-php-not-working) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566134/integrity-constraint-violation-1048-column-user-id-cannot-be-null-in-ios) . After asking myself how to deal with this questions I read several meta posts like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255261/how-to-answer-extreme-beginner-questions/255262#255262) or [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253045/answerers-who-only-use-comments?rq=1)

In sum they suggest to

1. After some time post the comment as an answer [and maybe get the rep for otherones "work"]
2. Post the conclusion of a solution worked out by chating in comments as an answer and mark it as community wiki
3. Close the question

The first two options are clear to me if the answer maybe useful for further people. But when it's a very simple syntax error or something like this which option I shall use to close those questions?

The options when flaging a question with "Should be close":

1. Duplicate of
2. Off-Topic
3. Unclear what asking
4. Too Broad
5. Primarily opinion based

Hmm well, the examples are not a duplicate, they are not off-topic to SO, it's not unclear what they were asking, they are detailed written so not too broad and they are not primarily opinion based.

So which option shall I use to vote this question to be closed?

Comment: *That one* question you link to is clearly *"need code to reproduce"*. The error is clear, the solution isn't due to lack of code. The other question is unfortunately linked incorrectly, but something similar would probably apply.

Comment: Fixed the other link, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"when it's a very simple syntax error or something like this which option I shall use to close those questions?"**

A syntax error is the same as a typographical error.

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

[image]

Comment: Good to know that these are handled the same. Maybe it would help to state this in the description of that option. Thank you.

Comment: @bish I think some of the confusion is that "typo" is really short for "typographical error."

Comment: "Closing" option is no longer available.. what is the current equivalent solution?

Comment: @p._phidot_ "A community-specific reason" > "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"