# Closed as off-topic 4 years later

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was going through this interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android) which I wish should be reopen.
The [closed as off-topic] is justified as it tends to attract opinionated answers and spam. So no arguing about that.
But as an question which has remain open for almost 4 years, having some interesting answers and lots of activities, doesn't that give it the privilege to be left open?
Or will it make the job of the moderators harder, if it is left open?
As technology is evolving, new interesting answers will probably be posted, of course some spams too.

Comment: Old questions don't escape new rules

Comment: Can you offer an actual argument about *why* it should be re-opened? No one [yet] is advocating its deletion, so the "interesting answers" are still there and available for viewing.

Comment: @CodyGray, I think you misunderstood me. I am not asking for it to be reopened. This post was intended to be a discussion, not a request. I found it odd that after 4 years of activity, it is closed besides being a good question. And Bart put it out well "Old questions don't escape new rules". It is the new rules thing I did not grasped!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254402/is-closing-old-questions-a-gigantic-waste-of-time-and-effort)

Comment: What is the value of this question? The first question recommend 7, the second question recommend 20 frameworks. Which one should I take for my specific problem? Wikipedia is the right place for a list and comparison of available Graphics packages for Android.

Comment: I'm not so sure it is that unclear what the OP is asking. There are old questions, which themselves aren't bad questions and that have good discussion (some good answers as well as bad answers), which may or may not really conform to SE's requirements for an on-topic question. If they've been around since before the walked the exchange, should they just be left to their own devices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, you want the quality of the site to improve over time. Likewise, its content should be consistent with its charter. So no, it may take some time for those questions to finally get caught in the sieve of moderation, but once they get there, they should be subject to the same considerations as a fresh new question without prejudice due to age.