# How can I bring attention to an outdated closed question that should be deleted?

Tags: support, questions, flags, deleted-questions, outdated-information

I came across a question that is closed and outdated:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883492/how-does-the-whatsapp-app-work

The API is now accessible making this question completely useless. When I come across a question like this, should I report it (with a flag)? If not, how do I bring up attention so that the question can be deleted?

Comment: Add a comment if there isn't one yet, (on question and possible answers), and consider downvoting for "not useful" when you get the privilige. Maybe others will chime in with better ideas...

Comment: The question itself is still too broad, even if the API is now available.

Comment: Related: [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254402/is-closing-old-questions-a-gigantic-waste-of-time-and-effort?lq=1)

Comment: I do not have the privileges yet to comment on someone else's question

Answer (score 5):

[As Will states in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267719/456814), you should ***not*** flag a closed question for moderator attention just because you think it should be deleted.

Since you don't have enough reputation to do any of the actions that Will suggested, your other options are to:

1. Bring the issue up here on Meta, which you have already done, indirectly.
2. Bring the question to the attention of users in an appropriate [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/).

With regards to chat rooms, make sure that you select a chat room that's appropriate for the expertise domain of the question (JavaScript questions in the [JavaScript room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript-perfect-client-side-security-since-1995), for example). Also be sure that you [read the rules](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/17/javascript-perfect-client-side-security-since-1995) for each chat room before joining.

**Beware**, not all chat rooms are receptive to all questions regarding the administration of questions over on Stack Overflow. If you want to try bringing up the question in a chat room, I can recommend to you the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), which is full of regulars who are generally receptive to post administration questions.

*Note*, however, that just because you bring up a question on Meta or in a chat room that you think should be deleted, that doesn't mean any of the other users will agree with you.

Answer (score 3):

Report it to who?  Mods?  No.  They are janitors and should not be asked to judge if a question is still worthwhile.

Do one or more of the following, depending on the circumstances:  downvote, vote to close, vote to delete, leave a comment.

I downvoted and voted to delete.