# Questions off-topic about VirtualMachine and command-line

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

The community is tolerant questions of this kind?

This question sounds like off-topic for me:
[Shrink a vmdk Virtualbox disk image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309819/shrink-a-vmdk-virtualbox-disk-image)

In related questions have others questions like this:

- [Why could VirtualBox not find a registered machine named Windows_7?n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565680/why-could-virtualbox-not-find-a-registered-machine-named-windows-7n?rq=1)
- [How to SSH to a VirtualBox guest externally through a host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host?rq=1) (206 up-votes)
- [How to resize a VirtualBox vmdk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659005/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vmdk-file?rq=1) (111 up-votes)

The community accept questions about `command-line`, `terminal`, `cmd` and `software`?

For me questions like these are off-topic, unless they are related to programming, examples:

- How to run *"terminal command"* in C
- How to run *"terminal command"* PHP

Assuming *"terminal command"* is a specific terminal or command software that can run on specific command line.

- How should we act when the question is not related to programming?
- Questions like are really are the StackOverflow scope?

Forgive me if I understood something wrong. It is questions like these that seem more appropriate for the superuser.

Comment: I didn't really spot a clear _"question"_ there. But anyways it's undergoing a bounty currently, and we can't close it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I used this questions as an example for being late. In the "related" there are similar questions.

Comment: @KevinBrown I think it's not off-topic, my question is about "Virtual Machine" and "Command-line" :)

Comment: The "possible duplicate" (not off-topic) has more or less the same question, and even shares a common example. The comments there are actually a pretty useful read, and I'll update my answer to address one last point.

Comment: Tolerant is the wrong word, more like worn-out.  These questions are tagged appropriately and have a good title.  Which pretty much ensures they won't get closed because not enough SO users look at them.  Google brings in the voters, later.  Notable is that you didn't downvote.  Sure, it can't work that way, can it.

Comment: @KevinBrown Forgive me please, it is clear that wrote "off-topic" by mistake :)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, but a question *tolerant* is more like *permissive* and *worn-out* is more like *frayed*? Correct me if I have misunderstood. Sorry my native language is not English. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can post questions on Stack Overflow about ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which includes Vim, Git, and *(arguably)* VirtualBox.

Yes, VirtualBox questions are probably going to be better received at [Super User under the [virtualbox] tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox), because they are about software. But that doesn't necessarily make them off-topic here at Stack Overflow, where we also have [virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox). Though after looking at that tag, I'd say we have a "broken windows" issue and might need a cleanup.

The question you specifically referenced ([Shrink a vmdk Virtualbox disk image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28309819/359284)) has an active bounty, so it's not possible to close it at the moment. This can only be done by a mod, or we can wait for six hours when the bounty ends.

The other examples you referenced are quite old. As the qualifications for determining if a question is on-topic or not have changed, it's possible that these were on-topic at one time or another, and have since gone out of style. Some people consider closing old questions to be a waste of effort, which is a possible reason for those questions sticking around.

- [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402/359284)
- [Should I flag old questions that ought to be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250060/359284)

Comment: It can be closed by a mod I believe (who can refund the bounty), see [Very broad question but with a bounty, what to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252193)

Comment: The question I posted is just one example. The point I'm getting at is that several questions about "command line" and "virtual machines" are often closed, but there are many others that are open and to receive answers.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento if `cmd` or `command line` questions are about scripting then they are on topic (scripting is programming).

Comment: @DavidPostill I know that, I just put referring to issues that often speak of using the command line only and that has nothing related to "batch" or something similar. :)