# How should I deal with a very old no longer on topic question that some one just answered?

Tags: support, review-queues, scope, old-questions

I was going through the review queue and immediately came across an odd situation.  A poster posted an answer to a question that doesn't seem to fit *current* guidelines for questions in Stack Overflow.  As I understand tool recommendation/finding questions of any description are not allowed here (and hence the existence of Software Recommendation SE site).

[image: screenshot of posts 3297319 and 44522074]

Should I be flagging this question? If so, with what flag? What should I do about the answer to this question I was meant to review?  The answer itself is not any worse than the others listed, but it answers a question that would otherwise not be allowed on the site.

Note the question is so old apparently it can't be migrated (where it would actually fit better in SR).  What am I supposed to do in this situation?

Comment: Link is down. Probably question deleted?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth they deleted it earlier today. I had the link open and all the questions and the answer were deleted, didn't catch who deleted it though

Comment: My comment was actually meant as suggestion to update your post 

Comment: @LinusGeffarth No.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Deal with it and its answers as you would any other active question; age doesn't matter.

In that case, flag for closure (off-topic, Request for off-site resource). Once you reach 3k rep you will be able to cast close votes directly (I cast one).

Flag as VLQ or NAA all answers that apply. In that case most answers are fairly low quality (here's a tool < link > the end) so complete deletion of the question is appropriate (and probably underway).

Answer (score 21):

There's another discussion that I point people to: [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402/1043380).

Short version:

> If they're dead questions that won't take any more of anyone's time - just leave them be.

However, if the question gains new attention with new answers or edits, then that advice doesn't apply. I'd vote to close when something like this comes up.

Comment: I think important point of the linked question - *don't dig* for old questions. If you stumble upon one - it is fair to act on question the same as if it is new one.

Comment: The sentiment is fair. But it's worth keeping in mind that dead questions that produce useless false positives in search results _do_ waste people's time. I agree with @Alexei that one shouldn't waste time looking for old questions, and that certainly it's always worth evaluating and voting on questions that you happen across through normal use of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the question and close vote/flag for closure as off-topic -> tool recommendation.

As for the answer, it is a link-only answer so you can delete-vote it for that reason. Or if you don't have enough rep to cast delete votes, flag as very low quality.