# Can we have a "recommendation and off-site resource" filter for the Close Review Queue?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close, filtering

I can only afford to spare 10 minutes a day at most to the task of reviewing questions in the Close Review Queue, but since it's an *extremely time-consuming* process, I've recently just given up completely on closing questions through the queue. Which is sort of a waste, because I have **40 close votes** a day to use in the queue that, for the most part, never get used.

### Recommendation and off-site resource questions are easy to close

I've noticed that questions that fit this close reason,

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

take very little effort to review, so I used to filter the close review queue using the [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=offtopic) filter.

The problem with that filter, however, is that it also contains questions that are possibly off-topic for 4 other reasons:

[image: Screenshot]

Because of that, I end up clicking "Skip" on a lot of questions that don't ask for recommendations or off-site resources, and thus even when using the off-topic filter, **having to slog through all of these other questions still ends up being a significant drag on my time**, and demotivates me to go look through the Close Review Queue.

### A new filter?

Would it be possible to have a new filter for *just* recommendation and off-site resource questions? I imagine that this filter would pick out questions that people have either flagged or voted to close as a recommendation question.

If such a filter were implemented that allowed me to *only* review these type of questions in the Close Review Queue, I would probably be motivated to actually use most, if not all, of my 40 close-votes a day (for the review queue), instead of just letting them all go to waste.

### Additional enhancements to closing workflow

As an additional enhancement to streamline this workflow, if I'm going to be looking to filter on questions that should be closed as recommendation and off-site resources questions, it would be nice if the Close button only needed to be clicked once to vote to close, if the system already knows that I'm filtering on a specific close reason:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Otherwise, the current workflow requires ***4 darn clicks*** to close a recommendation question. 4! **4 clicks to close a recommendation question is 3 clicks too many!**

However, just because I'm looking at a question that someone else flagged or voted to close as a recommendation question, that doesn't necessarily mean that the question should be actually be closed for *that* particular reason. Maybe it's really just unclear or too broad, or whatever. So we still need the old popup dialog too. So I guess perhaps one thing we could do is to have two close buttons, one for the instant-close for the reason that you're filtering on, and the other close button maintains the current popup behavior:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: The same but with all OT close reasons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191540/close-vote-review-additionally-filter-off-topic-close-reasons

Comment: This definitely has potential. I don't think it's fair that robo-reviewers have the pleasure of 1 click reviews, whereas regular reviewers have to do so many more clicks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes these questions deserving of higher priority than the rest of the off-topic questions? If we're gonna build a queue / UI for one particular off-topic reason, it'd better be a real *urgent threat* to the site...

And I'm not really convinced that "recommendation questions" fit the bill there. Yeah, there are some pretty nasty ones, but a lot of them can be fairly useful - heck, [there are folks trying to make a go of a whole site dedicated to the topic](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Indeed, [a well-asked recommendation question can nearly always be fixed via editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254374/close-or-edit-questions-asking-for-recommendations/254395#254395) if caught in time - which doesn't exactly justify making *not* editing any easier.

But even if most of these were unsalvageable trash, they make up a fairly small minority of what gets asked and what attracts votes. Here are some numbers for the current backlog of OT-voted questions in the close queue:

- **2045** Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
- **776**  This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.
- **735**  Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).
- **393**  This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.
- **541**  Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
- **341**  Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254394/) and what has been done so far to solve it.
- **313**  Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)
- **308**  Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).
- **183**  This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
- **129**  This question does not appear to be about $Topic within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].
- **81**   Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
- **37**   Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Now, if you have any bright ideas for making unclear debugging help questions easier to review...

Comment: Guess you don't have a drill-down on debug under `filter-closereason=offtopic` then?

Comment: No, but [such a stone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191540/close-vote-review-additionally-filter-off-topic-close-reasons) would kill both of these birds...

Comment: So what if it's a minority? And why do we need to promote editing so much? Most posts in the CV queue *are* unsalvageable trash.

Comment: Regarding the questions being in the minority, @bjb568, this is basic cost-benefit analysis. You don't optimize performance in a system by improving the efficiency of something that's not the immediate bottleneck, because that's just a whole lot of wasted effort, for little to no gain. I don't have an answer for you for editing right now though.

Comment: You can get around the problem of it being a minority by making all other off-topic reasons targetable.