# Allow users to change their decisions in the review queues in case of misclicked Approve, or confirm approvals

Tags: feature-request

I spend a lot of time in the review queues these days, but unfortunately I can only do it on one of my computers, as the other has a fairly twitchy mouse. Every once in a while I attempt it on the worse computer, but the occasional misclick always reminds me why it's a bad idea.

Today, I failed a hilariously obvious review audit on the Suggested Edits queue due to that twitch. I moved quite quickly to hit Reject, since it was a clear audit, but speed and precision don't always mix. It's a sign to me that I need to stop ever trying to review on that mouse, but I really would like to be able to help out when I don't have access to my better computer.

The ability to switch an approval directly after would be nice; obviously, once it's approved, it'd be too late, but as long as it's still in the queue, it seems feasible to let me edit my decision.

Another potential (worse, in my opinion) solution would be having a confirmation. If I misclick on Reject, it's not a problem, since I can just cancel out of it; it's not a one click process. Making Approve a two-click process would solve this, but it seems like a bad idea to me. It makes all reviewers go through more effort, as opposed to only adding effort in the case where a mistake happens.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm... Mice are cheap.

Comment: Fair enough, although I wonder how often there's user error in the same vein.

Comment: Now that I think about it, an approval/reject confirmation message box might actually slow down the robo-reviewers a bit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey IMO, there's a 3 seconds wait before the buttons becomes actives... are they not?

Comment: @Braiam: It's not opinion; that's how it works.

Comment: Hm… Approve should have a pop-up box. There was a proposal of a slider of *how* helpful the edit is, so that can be there. And make the wait 5 seconds for approve. And get rid of the "that's just a test" clickerage.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so, that should prevent this cases, no?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No! Punishing law abiding users b.c of law breaking users is not good user experience! We need to make less clicks for law abiding users instead of more! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267691/can-we-have-a-recommendation-and-off-site-resource-filter-for-the-close-review#comment72284_267691

Comment: @Mike Precup: User error is sort of possible. I just posted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340228/is-it-possible-to-redo-an-edit-review?noredirect=1#comment424781_340228 and was directed here. Two years sans activity on this, however, is troubling.

Comment: @CodyGray Why don't you finally implement this? Anyway, I don't really care about the ban; just trying to help, if you think I do more harm than good, better make a perma-ban of it.