# Should I flag questions that need editing, but I don't know how to edit?

Tags: discussion, flags, edits, low-quality-posts

In certain cases there are posts with major grammatical errors which I am unsure of how to fix, or which are link-only-answers.  I know that these should be corrected, and for most I can edit myself, but some are beyond my abilities.

In some cases I flag these as very low quality, but not all of them are ***very*** low quality; they just are ***somewhat*** low quality.

The second thing I tried was flagging it with a custom other flag, but that was rejected with this message: `declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention`.

Right now I think the best action is to just ignore these questions, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing.

Comment: How about commenting to the person who answered asking them to expand on the link?  Other flags should only be used if it's something the community can't handle.  In this case, there are many things **you can do** without getting a moderator involved.

Comment: The exception to @bluefeet's comment is that you can always flag a link-only answer for tactical nuclear unicorn embrace, if it's *truly* worthless when stripped of markup, per [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/254929).

Comment: With things like this, you always have chat available, as well. If there is a room you are active in and you know they don't mind, you could ask someone there if they would fix it up.

Comment: If it's grammar, ping me. I *enjoy* fixing bad grammar. I'm weird.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close or edit questions asking for recommendations](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254374/close-or-edit-questions-asking-for-recommendations)

Comment: @user2284570 (and others): I don't really think this is a duplicate, although it is possibly related.  I can't find any text in that that answers this question at all.

Comment: Given your rep and the limited access to review queues that it implies, you may well be unaware that - ***unlike*** closure flags, dupe flags, low quality flags, and edit suggestions - custom flags can only be handled by the diamond moderators, of whom there are [only 17](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). This is why other methods of resolving problems are preferred, and why custom flags that require any kind of specific technical expertise to resolve should pretty much never be raised - usually none of the 17 mods is going to have the precise knowledge needed to take action.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do **not** *have* to flag posts. Flagging should only be used for *exceptional* cases that cannot be handled by the usual means. SO already provides plenty of ways in which the community can handle most situations. In this particular case:

- Editing: answer is somewhat bad and you know how to fix it? Just edit and maybe add a comment to teach the answerer
- Voting: answer is somewhat bad? downvote it and comment why you think it's suboptimal/partially incorrect etc and check if the answerer improves it
- Commenting: just tell the answerer what you feel is wrong. If someone reads that and know how to fix it they can do the work for you
- Chat: check the relevant room and ask if someone else knows how to fix the answer.

If it's something so small that doesn't fit any of these actions it means you are just nitpicking and the answer is already okay.

Comment: This doesn't address the situation the OP is asking about, namely that they can recognize that the answer needs editing but they're not capable of editing it personally.

Comment: @Servy I believe it does. If you know that you have to edit because the answer is in some way bad then downvote + comment what you think should be changed. If the edits required are less serious just go for the next option of simply explaining to the answerer what would improve the answer. Finally, if you aren't able to do even this you fall for the next option: go to chat and ask the help of someone else. The whole point of my answer is that the situation described does *not* require a flag, but you should use those 4 suggestions in order.

Comment: @Servy Also, the OP just changed the title to the form "Should I flag ...? if so how?" so an answer of "no" followed by alternative suggestions seems in the appropriate format. If you disagree regarding whether he should flag you should have explained why in your comment.