# Want to alert people in Chat about a poor answer, but site is blocked

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Reading [this answer on how to handle answers with issues beyond one's ability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272689/1270789), I see:

> Chat: check the relevant room and ask if someone else knows how to fix the answer

My comment has been ignored, so I would like to visit chat, but the corporate firewall blocks it, and the Android app doesn't support it; what should I do in the general case where I might not have easy access to a non-firewalled machine? My home PC is an ancient netbook, so that's quite a poor substitute.

The specific issue was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39714661/1270789), specifically:

> The way to zero the entire array at runtime is with `arr = {0}`

As I [pointed out in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714646/bug-in-c-code-setting-one-variable-to-zero-causes-unrelated-variable-to-becom/39714661?noredirect=1#comment66727459_39714661), my test code fails and I believe that I am correct, but I don't quite have the confidence to delete the problematic statement.

Comment: Open the chat on your mobile browser, outside of the app?

Comment: Find an employer that trust their employees?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Good plan! But which of the 2700 pages of rooms should I choose? I can't believe there's no search button.