# Is it off topic if a question is both seeking for function/algorithm solutions and finding tools?

Tags: discussion, scope

As we know, tool recommendations is off topic here, but what if OP asks for both coding solutions/algorithm and finding tools (either one to solve the problem)?

Examples:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378764)

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228391)

Is it still considered as off topic? Or we can just remove the sentences about fing tools?

And, if a question is about finding tools to solve a problem, but the problem can actually be solved by algorithm/internal library, is it still considered as off topic?

Comment: That question should be closed because neither *asking for a library* nor *asking for an algorithm / piece of code* (which comes under category - *too broad*)  are acceptable.

Comment: "Looking for an algorithm for X" can sometimes be edited into a reasonably-scoped "How do I do X?" question. (Though many are still too broad.)  I'm not sure if adding "you don't have to write the code for me" helps; sometimes that will make the question very nonspecific, other times something like "you need to use a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)" is entirely satisfactory, and the asker can follow up with another question if they need specific help implementing it.

Comment: This also sometimes depends on the answers -- if there's a good "You don't need a library for this, you can do _foo_" answer, you should try to edit the question to save it.  If all the answers are just links to libraries, it's less important.  (Particularly relevant in the reopen queue.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - I am not sure if that is a good idea. We don't want people answering *You don't need a library for this, you can do foo, oh wait or bar.. Um nope, you could do boo which works faster tha foo but is slower than coo-o-o" answer* . We want people asking *Trying to do foo in bar gives shoo error* or something.

Comment: @TheLostMind The first is a bad answer, not because of the question but because it waffles; an answer that _clearly_ presents the tradeoff between two alternative solutions sounds like a good answer to me (though you could argue it should be split into two answers for separate voting).  I'm slightly disappointed by your second example; Stack Overflow is not (yet) purely a debugging service.  But we are drifting from the topic of this question, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a question that asks many things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)

Comment: Your examples are 3 years old and shouldn't be used as a guide as to what is currently considered on or off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user posts a multi-part question, go with the lowest common denominator.

If four parts are on-topic and interesting, but a fifth part is off-topic because, say, it asks for a library/tool, down/close vote and move on.

If users insist on asking a multi-part question, then they get multiple chances of down/close votes.

It's only fair....

Comment: I disagree with this answer. We shouldn't turn away a good question because of one part asking for a tool. [Editing is the preferred solution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254395/2581872) -- quick and easy, and it takes only 1 person!