# Drive-By Upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting

How in the world does a question like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894387/php-constantly-updating-script, get an upvote? Does Stack Overflow suffer from as many drive-by upvotes as it does drive-by downvotes? How can we prevent that behavior? Are upvoters also looking for answers to these same questions?

I have noticed this behavior a lot on the PHP tag. Anecdotally, I have also noticed a much lower bar for question quality on that tag and typically burn through my close votes pretty rapidly there.

*At the time that I wrote this query the post in question consisted of the first two paragraphs. The OP has added some code and additional explanation since then. [Link to that revision.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23894387/1)*

Comment: Because PHP.  You really needed further explanation?

Comment: Thanks for making me actually laugh out loud @RobertHarvey!

Comment: This happens on all kinds of questions. In the .NET tag every question about audio, video, speech and image processing will be upvoted, regardless of the quality of the question. I guess it's people thinking "Ooh nice, I don't understand that".

Comment: This is way, way, way more of a problem than downvotes.  It's both way more prevalent, way more destructive, and much less likely to be noticed (and therefore addressed).  It just doesn't make (most) people angry, so they don't come here and complain about undeserved upvotes (much), unlike the pretty much daily posts complaining about undeserved downvotes.

Comment: Random upvotes happen everywhere, same as random downvotes. Sometimes, I think cosmic radiation triggers the flipping of a bit somewhere. I don't know that there's a general trend of this kind of voting.

Comment: Related: [Do users upvote out of sympathy, and how should that be addressed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254129/456814).

Comment: That post recommends to "vote early and vote often" where downvotes and closes are concerned to combat the issue. My problem is that I run out of these much too quickly.

Comment: I always upvote any questions I come across that don't seem stupid or very terribly worded. Also try to upvote newcomers' question regardless of quality.

Comment: Oh, you mean the one where I got [`4 upvotes`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894387/php-constantly-updating-script#comment36788559_23894387) by sheer memory instead of relying on Google?! that one? *Ah, knew it.* Well, believe this or not, a few weeks ago someone actually told me that they'd had never of Google. I almost fell out of my chair. Good thing it's a good one, cuz I'd be writing this from a hospital bed!

Comment: *"Also try to upvote newcomers' question regardless of quality"* ... i wish i could downvote comments.

Comment: I was trying to find the numbers in the Data Explorer, perhaps someone is willing to [review and/or improve the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197389/drive-by-upvotes)? I haven't got too much experience with Data Explorer, so I'm unsure if my query is flawed. (If it isn't it confirms your suspicion I think.)

Comment: I'll look at it more closely @Jeroen when I have a little more time.

Comment: @KevinB: I think he is joking. *Just in the way I always upvote questions of newbies with lots of downvotes. I think every question should have one upvote.*

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, you do realize you are just enabling them to write terrible questions. Why not help them improve their question quality, then upvote when it actually deserves it?

Comment: Seriously, can anyone explain what is wrong with this specific question that it deserves that many downvotes? I mean, original version was bad, I agree, but now it's fine.

Comment: @dfsq It's just that, the original revision deserved them.

Comment: After the edit of the questioner 1 hour ago it is now a sufficiently good question. It shows this guy can deliver if asked for it. Should be at least at zero now.

Comment: How ironic, after some drive-by upvotes it also got hit by drive-by downvotes.

Comment: If you want an explanation, look no further than the Electorate badge.  Granted, it's more balanced now than it was when question downvotes gave a penalty to the downvoter.  But still, this misguided badge encourages mass voting on questions for motives other than the only motive that should count: to increase visibility of a good question.

Comment: How would it get back to zero @Trilarion - the voters aren't notified if the question has been edited to make it better.

Comment: Oh nice! I don't understand this question. +1.

Comment: Congrats. The question now has 18 upvotes!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I don't have time to fix other people's questions. But I don't want the new users to be driven away from SO just because their first question was bad and they got tons of downvotes.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That isn't clear from your earlier comment....

Comment: @JayBlanchard I doubt that even if they would be notified of edits they would care to spend the time to change votes. Anyway the question is currently at +1 which I would say is a reasonable result. The meta question here was the necessary correction for the problem even with the drive-by downvotes. It also shows that waiting some hours before judging a question especially for beginners also has merits.

Comment: Just logged back in this morning to find that it was at 0. I find that to be a satisfactory result of having posted this meta even if the meta question caused a fairly large swing. Now that the poster has shown what he has attempted it is a much better question and if I have time I will write out an answer demonstrating the use of AJAX, setInterval(), etc.

Comment: I think it is still a very broad question, and by now the OP already earned almost 100 rep by asking it.

Comment: @kapa: It's 24 upvotes as of now.

Comment: i am here to upvote question that get downvoted because downvoters are not fair

Comment: they downvote like they eat chips

Comment: @dondom: Most of the times, that's because those questions deserve downvotes. If you don't want to get downvoted, write a good question with proper formatting and all that. Period.

Comment: Yes @kapa, it is still a very broad question but it is way better than what it started as.

Comment: Even as broad as it is, with as many views as it has gotten and wild swings in UV's / DV's there are still not enough votes to close the topic. I find that to be very interesting. Why would that be? Or should that be a new post? :-)

Comment: @dondom I suggest you read more about how the site works. If you misunderstand what a downvote is for, you might think that downvotes are bad, or meant to hurt someone's pretty little feelings.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm also interested. Even if the question is better than it was, it should still be closed.

Comment: When I visited it had exactly 29 upvotes and 29 downvotes. Brilliant.

Comment: The fact that it was linked in a meta question probably swayed those numbers quite a bit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Why do some people upvote bad questions?

Some people upvote without considering the quality or usefulness of the post, and is very common in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag (which contains a lot of people who are newbies and have no idea what they're doing).

Who are all these people, you ask? Well, there can be many explanations, but these are the ones I think to be most plausible:

- **Another beginner/newbie** - Another user who read the question and felt "Oh, this looks interesting." may upvote it. They don't care about the question's quality at all. They don't even take anything else into consideration while voting on a post. They don't care if the question is poorly asked, badly researched, or poorly worded — if they somehow find the question interesting, they might upvote it.
- **A high-rep user who sympathizes the OP** - These people, when they see a question at -1, will have a natural tendency to upvote it to make the vote count neutral. I've often seen comments like "+1 to counter" and similar on very poorly asked questions. Not all high-rep users do this, but *some* do. And they're destroying the quality of the site by encouraging the asker to post similar questions in the future.
- **A sockpuppet** - It would seem unlikely that a person would create a sockpuppet just to upvote their question. But you can't even imagine what ends people go to find a way to have their question answered. Some of them may even have a sockpuppet factory which they use for gaining the "initial traction" (i.e. to make the question look like a good one).

### How can we prevent this behavior?

**You can't.** All of the above groups are not helping the site. If anything, they're harming the site by encouraging stupid questions. Unfortunately, people are free to vote as they see fit, so long as they're not involved in a voting fraud.

The only thing we can do to help this situation is to close such questions quickly. Not all such questions need to be closed — some of them can be salvaged with a good edit. As Jeff notes in [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), we need to *optimize for pearls*, while giving bad questions the treatment they deserve.

Comment: "a lot of people who are newbies and have no idea what they're doing"... u think ur special? wait. NO.

Comment: People going for the [Electorate badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) area also partly to blame here.

Comment: @dondom: I never said I'm special. You should take a look at [tag:php] to see what I'm talking about. These upvotes actually cause a great deal of harm. First of all, you're encouraging someone who is making terrible contributions to the site. Second, upvotes affect a lot of calculations such as reputation of the asker, and the question-ban algorithm. If a poor question gets a few pity upvotes, it will encourage the user and will eventually result in many more similar questions.

Comment: Your answer is well formatted but the content is lacking. There are many reasons why things are upvoted and downvoted. These categories are too broad. Remember the reason for the voting system is that the criteria is subjective. What you consider to be a **stupid question** may be completely reasonable to me. I might see what the OP is getting at, but you might think its not enough info to diagnose. Your answer reads like a partisan politician complaining that you want more people to vote as long as they are voting for you.

Comment: @nsfyn55 You seem to be missing the point of my answer, and the question that was asked. The question was "why are these poor questions getting uovotes?". My answer is addresses the most probable scenarios. There can't be a definitive list of all possible downvote reasons - voting is anonymous and people are free to vote as they see fit.

Comment: Meh I still find your categories to be lacking. The only one I consider of merit is "Another Beginner" these being folks that do not yet understand the voting system or its purpose. The other two I can't say I have ever seen. Sockpuppeting seems like way more trouble than its worth.

Comment: There's an inherent problem with this question: it assumes some objective or universal definition of "bad".  If you can understand everyone's definition of good or bad, you may find an answer to your question.   Some focus on content, others focus on format or grammar... others?  Etc...

Answer (score 14):

Even though the asker is going waaay down the wrong path, it is otherwise a good question:

- It does not suffer the [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).
- The user has *actually tried something* and has code in the question.
- Aside from some punctuation, it is otherwise well-written.

It's getting downvotes because he doesn't know what he's doing (and seems to have the standard problem of separating PHP and Javascript), but I really don't think it deserves quite that many.

Honestly?  I upvoted it, too.  The question "shows research effort; it is useful and clear", albeit a bit too broad to correct all his misconceptions, as Brad Koch said in a comment on it.

Comment: The original question was just the first two paragraphs. It has been edited to include code and additional information since I posted my original query.

Comment: Original question: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23894387/1

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's still getting downvotes, hence my answer.  Besides, the first bullet point (probably the most important one for a question like this) still applied.

Comment: @NickQ. See prior comment

Comment: But was the question, as originally posted, worth an upvote @Izkata?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I would not have upvoted or downvoted the original

Comment: Many probably wouldn't have, but it was upvoted nearly immediately - before the DV landslide began.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't know php, so might I ask what about the edit made the difference between a bad question and a good one?  Did you learn something that you would have needed to know in order to answer it?

Comment: "How could I achieve [stated goal] with PHP?" is a valid question in my opinion because it has a definite answer: AJAX.  It's very likely that someone might Google that question and find the answer useful.  (Agree the question in its original form was not deserving of an upvote).

Comment: @SamIam the edits made a difference two ways. a.) it showed that the OP had actually made an effort to try to do what he was asking and 2.) provided people who will create answers some insight into his thought process as far as what he was trying to achieve.

Comment: @JayBlanchard point a.) is fairly unimportant.  Focusing too much on if the OP proved their worthiness is a faults of the meta community at SO.  When I'm browsing google to find answers to my question, I don't care at all whether or not the OP made an effort.  The only thing I need from the question is the ability to match it to my own.  And the same goes for when I'm answering a question.  I don't need the op to add a bunch of extra text to read through to prove that they're worthy.  All I need and want is the necessary context to be able to answer the question.  Everything else is noise.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Point 2.) is important, and that's what I was asking for.  Did you actually get any extra useful insight from the edit?

Comment: @SamIam I did get useful insight from the edit. On point a.) I *thought* this was important given all the discourse about question quality lately. In addition that is one of the core tenets of SO, is it not?

Comment: @gnack AJAX is not the definite answer. There are other ways. This (creating a chat) is a way too broad topic for SO. One could write a book about it.

Answer (score -1):

### Some people upvote "wicked" answers

#### And I guess because they think it is cool

How do I know?  This comment:

> Ya, this doesn't really fix the issue the questioner (and I) is trying
> to solve, but I upvoted just because THAT'S WICKED! Thanks,
> @MrSampson. :) –  Name Omitted (3,946) Mar 7 '13 at 17:27

on this fascinating incorrect answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10961978/103081

I'm guessing he learned something "cool", perhaps it was that `\!` invokes a bash shell from the mysql client, and although that had nothing to do with finding out why chdir wouldn't work from there it was good enough for him to +1....

The wrong answer, same number of votes as mine (until I downvoted, by 1), posted 9 months late back in 2012 as a first post by someone who has no other SO contributions, and admitted as wrong by the poster, was apparently never downvoted until I ran across it tonight from a upvote ping to my answer.

I suppose I am part to blame for not noticing or it until now, but I am disappointed that admitted wrong answers could get 4 upvotes and no downvotes at all on a question with 6000+ views.

The best thing I can say about the wrong answer, is that he admits about a day later that it is incorrect.  By then he has received a minor 3 char code edit and a congrats on a good first answer by an experienced user.

Asking others to help downvote something like this seems socially awkward.

**EDIT:** I've been reminded in comments that flagging something like this would likely be rejected as invalid.  And, it takes time to evaluate, the answer isn't obviously crap until reviewed and it helps to have a little subject matter expertise. So I posted here.  Incidentally, I'm also aware that my answer here could potentially be deleted as an "I'm having that problem too" kind of pseudo-answer.

So to contribute, comparing with @Amal's answer above, the behavior seems different.

Sockpuppet?  Well, the answer poster left and never came back. He admitted the answer was wrong, if you were creating a illicit rep-mined account for someone you wouldn't do that.

Compassion voting?  On a wrong answer?  That doesn't make sense either.  In my opinion, the standard for questions seems to be questions are allowed to be wrong and misguided if they are reasonably complete, show some effort, and answerable.  Not answers.

Another beginner?  No. Experienced users upvoted an answer that the poster himself said was incorrect.

Thinking as graciously as I can, there is this slim argument that a shell escape could be more useful than a single system command to someone who didn't want to exit the mysql client but needed to do work elsewhere.  But then, `^Z` would be just as cool, and neither answer the question.

Comment: You mention "flagging" twice in your answer here. In the case you point out, any flag you'd raise on the answer would be declined. None of the non-custom flags apply, and a custom flag would be declined on the basis that the fact that an answer is wrong is not sufficient for moderator action.

Comment: Yes, now that you mention it, that has been my experience flagging things occasionally for being egregiously wrong.  And, besides, there is even an argument that a shell escape could be useful to someone who temporarily needs to work in a different directory and can't do that with single shell commands.

Answer (score -10):

I do it if its reasonably asked.

Some people are not only newbies in the actual subject but total newbies in etiquette of what is seen as an accceptable effort in trying to help yourself.

With a negative vote, they wont get answers and the question is shunned.

I remember the very first days when I asked for technical help (sometime in 2000). Back when the best technical support came from forums(boards). And my ignorant self went an posted what was a very shallow, unresearched question on a hard core Linux dev forum. I was shredded to pieces, resurrected, my raw wounded-self sprinkled with pepper and chillies, shredded again... and so on.

It was a hard lesson, but the kind moderator welcomed me to the board(old-school community etiquette) and gave me a quick but very good lesson on how to approach technical boards/forums without sounding like some leeching dumb fart, even if I was one at that point. He directed me to the general/newbie section where you introduced yourself and everyone had a beer-shaking-"cheers!!" shouting mood. I read other newbie questions and learnt from that as a result.

So in Stackoverflow, many get so wrought up in being those faceless, technical exchanges and forget that there are real people who are ABSOLUTELY NEW, who stumble across or have heard good things about Stackoverflow.

I know quality is important, but also remembering that there will always be TOTAL NEWBIES at both etiquette and subject matter is just as important as points and quality.

We're all newbies at something.

But there are some who are newbies at just asking

TL,DR... I know

Comment: Upvoting bad questions doesn't teach anyone anything, and is harmful to the site. Downvoting should tell them they're doing something wrong (which they can further investigate - clicking "help" at the top of the screen is probably a fairly logical start, and should get one pretty far in learning what's appropriate). By all means kindly explain the problem in the comments, but don't upvote the questions.

Comment: Commenting also helps in encouraging the person to correct their question before eagerly downvoting out of irritation. After commenting, and after a response from the OP without a correction, a downvote is deserved. Thats just what I would do

Comment: Commenting and downvoting are not mutually exclusive.  You downvote to tell the entire world that the post is not a good post.  You comment to help the post author to fix it.  Doing one doesn't prevent you from doing the other.  Both are entirely appropriate things to do.  And you say that the downvotes discourage them from getting answers.  **That's a good thing**.  We *don't* want people answering bad questions.  We want the question author to fix it into a good question before having it answered.

Comment: Doing them in sequence if a comment is ignored is what my point was. Not supporting bad questions, merely explaining empathy that drives "driveby upvotes".There are as many drive by downvotes as there are upvotes. Downvotes without explanation/comment are those that I think attract the random "counter"