# Should I consider existing votes when deciding to vote a question or answer up or down

Tags: discussion, voting

I suspect the short answer to my question is "No". However if I come across an answer (or a question) that is okay but not great and it has been downvoted for no good reason (that I can see), I am strongly tempted to upvote the answer even though I wouldn't vote either way if it wasn't already downvoted.

It can happen the other way around (but not as often). I see an answer (or question) that is not very good but has a lot of upvotes, and I'm tempted to downvote even though I wouldn't normally vote either way.

Should I resist these temptations, or is it reasonable to take existing votes into account when deciding whether to vote?

Comment: Just imagine the poor programmer who comes upon the deeply flawed or otherwise actively harmful answer that you upvoted because you just assumed that the person that was trying to indicate the problems with an answer couldn't possibly have had a valid reason.

Comment: Equally frustrating are the "People on Stack Overflow are so mean, here's a +1!" comments.  People are downvoting *for a reason*.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254129/do-users-upvote-out-of-sympathy-and-how-should-that-be-addressed

Comment: It's .. complicated. When I read a question with lots of downvotes and lots of comments suggesting to improve the question, *and* the question has been edited into shape and is at that point reasonable (i.e., on itself it would not be downvoted), I may +1 it. The existing downvotes are at such a point effectively obsolete, but the downvoters may never return to reverse them.

Comment: @Jongware Or maybe the downvoters *have* seen the new version but do not find the edits to be sufficient to have fixed the flaws that they saw in the question in the first place.

Comment: As I said, it's complicated. I try to restrain myself and not downvote [because my train was late today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Comment: _"In order to form an immaculate member of a flock of sheep one must, above all, be a sheep."_ (Said to come from A.Einstein).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should vote based on wether you think the answer is useful or not. I know it's tempting to try and "balance the scales" but I usually resist the temptation. There are times when I'll read a post and *not vote at all* if I think it already has enough upvotes (or downvotes), but I try not to cast votes in the opposite direction just to make a vote count look a little bit closer to what I think it should be.

Answer (score 11):

Previous votes shouldn't impact your decision to vote, although to be honest they definitely have a psychological effect on users.

If the votes of a particular post are surprising, then perhaps it is a good indication that some research into that topic would be beneficial.

I would advise against voting on posts solely based on their vote counts because voting should be entirely based on content.