# Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

### That close reason

Yes, I believe it was condescending and somewhat rude. However there is a mass of questions that fall under a crystal clear criteria:

- They're poorly written.
- They have formatting issues.
- They don't show any research attempts.
- They don't show any attempt at solving the problem.
- They *might* be salvageable through extensive editing.

Just as importantly:

- They're *crystal clear*. There is nothing ambiguous about them.
- They're not too broad, there is a clear, although often very (too) specific solution to them.
- They're not an exact duplicate, although combining two or three other questions could easily lead to their solution.
- They're not opinion based. They represent a specific problem.
- They're not a library request, though sometimes they're a library request in disguise.
- They're about programming.
- They're not about a typo.

Here are some example titles, these are all *real questions* but I did not want to link to them explicitly to not affect their course. I'm pretty confident we've all seen them:

- jQuery parallexUiSlider plugin problem, can't find the bug.
- Why if statement failing in Python?
- Regular expression for telephone not working.
- JS function in jquery bug.
- Button click not working.
- pop is not working properly.
- Java program in course not working.
- This list goes on, but you get the idea.

All these have uninformative titles, formatting problems, about 30 lines of code with no context in the question. They're all likely to never help anyone in the future, but all have crystal clear solutions experts in their respective tags would know.

**In a lot of these (and countless more) the OP has no idea what they're doing, they've found code on the internet, mixed it around and got *something***. They don't understand why that *something* doesn't work.

Usually, in these questions, the original poster is rather *clueless*, helping them on the question is only spoon feeding them, and there is little to no chance the question will help anyone in the future.

### None of the current close reasons fit these particular questions

So here's my suggestion: Let's have a close vote reason that makes closing these questions easier. I think it can help reduce the signal to noise ratio and make closing these questions easier.

However, like I started, I believe "Lacks Minimal Understanding" is a rather harsh title. Too specific fits a lot of these, but I don't think it nails it.

So:

### Please suggest a close reason that fits these questions.

- It should not sound rude like "lacks minimal understanding". It should guide OP.
- It should be clear, that the question is closed because it is poorly written, has formatting issues and is too specific.
- Most of these questions are "debug my code", or "why does this very specific code not work" questions with no future potential, however they're rarely typos.
- These are not just "lacks research" questions. That's just one aspect of them. The other aspects are equally important.

I'd like to think we can come up with something better than "Lacks Minimal Understanding" that still conveys why these questions are problematic so that we can better close them.

<sup>bullet lists, bullet lists everywhere.</sup>

Comment: 1) I am not sure what you mean by poorly written. There is already an "unclear" reason. 2) formatting issue is not a reason to close a valid question. 3) Any attempt of research is subjective, I would say. 4) The same goes to problem solving, so for 3)-4), what is the exact reason which is not subjective? 5) The last bullet point is not a reason itself. So far, I do not see any reason for the change. I have personally lacked a "homework" reason, but usually, the "other" category suits for me.

Comment: @FinalContest I completely agree, which is why I specified that what they have in common is a combination of formatting issues, lack of demonstrated research, poor writing _and_ lots of specifity.

Comment: Is it just me or are you describing Too Localized?

Comment: Perhaps, too localized covers a lot of those issues (but not all of them). Personally I would not object to having "Too Localized" back.

Comment: Following our chat conversation with Benjamin, I would suggest to extend the "lacks information" close reason with information about what the OP has tried, and not just about "diagnosing the problem", or well, if the current text is supposed to mean that, how about clarifying it?

Comment: **sometimes** LMU just fits. Q: *What line of code does it crash on?*  A: *When I click the Search button.*  I am not sure you can keep the low quality posts out and still not hurt a few feelings.

Comment: add something to it like *appears to lack...* and it becomes less condescending

Comment: I would love this idea as long as it isn't used as a catch-all "you are stupid" close reason, even if it is reworded.

Comment: It is going to be a very hard sell.  The last podcast made it pretty evident that revising the close reason menu is not on the agenda.  Jay Hanlon isn't going to let it happen.  The "too broad" reason always fits.  In an ideal world, such a question would attract entirely too many answers.  In the non-ideal real world, you'd have to write the effin' manual to get the user up to speed.

Comment: On some other site the correct response would be "NYPA"...

Comment: Some would argue that we should be nice to our new users.  For example, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976289/what-is-wrong-with-this-code).

Comment: This would not be implemented, period.  Who would want even the silliest of questions to be shot down?  Traffic is king.

Comment: Can you explain 1) how a question can be poorly-written, poorly-formatted and yet manage to be *crystal-clear* at the same time and 2) why such a question warrants closing and not just editing and/or downvoting (since if a question is crystal-clear it wouldn't make sense to close it as, you know, unclear)?

Comment: Also, all the examples you've listed are examples of "X not working" - the appropriate close reason to use for those questions would be "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" - which sends a much clearer (and more fitting IMO) message than "lack of minimal understanding".

Comment: @BoltClock No, often there is enough information ("you missed an `;`", "you forgot to include `<string>`", "you are accessing an array out of bounds", "you are trying to access non-public data via a public interface" etc. On the other hand, "lacks minimal understanding" isn't a great alternative. I would favour re-phrasing and/or extending the "typo error" close reason to something closer in spirit to the old "too localised" one, i.e. something that emphasizes the uselessness of the question and its possible answer to other users of the site.

Comment: @BoltClock I have intentionally not included examples here because that would cause a flurry of up/down votes to them. The [chat discussion](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2081607#2081607) we've had about it yesterday has some good examples imo. Since you hail from CSS, imagine a 40 LoC of HTML, 40 LoC of CSS question asking how to make a square corner look circular and transition it from the right (both these things have duplicates individually, it is clear).

Comment: Instead of LMU, how about LMAO?

Comment: This question is putting the cart before the horse. Why discuss the exact wording of the close reason without bothering to establish that there needs to be one at all? Why, as Bolt says, can't these questions just be edited or downvoted?

Comment: Won't such a close reason be abused again? I'm only for it if there is consensus what minimal understanding is. That means a detailed and practical description what is minimal understanding and what is not.

Comment: [Not this again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: I call them 'how do i brain surgery with potato?' posts.

Comment: I'd even be interested in knowing **exactly** why a small degree of rudeness is a particularly bad thing. I've encountered, and successfully gotten over, rudeness before. Being an adult helps with that.

Comment: @BenAaronson more like I'm trying to find out if it's _possible_ to come with a better close reason for those questions before I _ask_ for it. I don't want to ask for another close reason before we can establish we need one, and can come up with a good one. This is why it's tagged with discussion and not feature request.

Comment: Not sure why we want to beat around the bush.  The OP would be the first to admit that they lack minimal understanding.  If politeness is important, then send them a notification or display a message only they can see and tell them their question wasn't up to standards.

Comment: I'd say, that we simply need a reason, which **gently and politely** says: "We are here to help you solve your problem; we will not freely write or debug code for you. Please don't abuse our generosity". Let's be honest - this is precisely how Stackoverflow works. *This* is the precise reason question doesn't belong here. Leaving the question open often leads to someone point-hungry debugging it and pointing out the problem. And in result we teach people, that they *will* find such help here. This is why such questions should be closed instead of only downvoted.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well okay, that makes more sense, though it's not what the question's title indicates.

Comment: They have this listed under the off-topic reason on SF "Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding** of the problem being solved. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See How can I ask better questions on Server Fault? for further guidance."  I don't understand why SO cannot have a similar reason.

Comment: @just.another.programmer Now they'll remove it from SF!

Comment: @podiluska I thought about that before pointing it out here.  To be honest, I only know about it b/c I had a question closed for that reason first.  I was annoyed at the time that I had to do a *lot* more research to solve the problem, but they were right.  I was not qualified to do the work and I needed more education before the answer would really be useful.

Comment: +1 _"the OP has no idea what they're doing, they've found code on the internet, mixed it around and got something."_ ... and then asked us "fix it for me".

Comment: You're missing a major requirement: it should be unambiguous so that closers use it consistently. Many of the answers here fail to meet that criteria.

Comment: +1 I want to be a part of a site for *professional* software developers. SO would be a much nicer place (at least for me) if there were only real programmers writing questions and answers. crappy questions should be automatically migrated to "yahoo answers" ;)

Comment: I'm touched by your optimism, @Michael... But from what I've seen, all too many *professional* software developers are asking really, really terrible questions. If *only* doing something for a living was a guarantee of competence...

Comment: @Shog9 - I think you don't understand the distinction between *professional* and simply employed.

Comment: @HotLicks more likes - all these 'professionals' don't.

Comment: That's because it can't be quantified, @hot; it's subjective. You feel like writing up The SO Guide to Professionalism? Be my guest...

Comment: @Shog9 Here is my shot at it. 1) Learn to program 2) Become Jon Skeet 3) ??? 4) Profit

Comment: @Sparky: ... if I had a nickel every time that happened... (a.k.a. I have found this code *(copy and paste job)*, it works for this input but I wish it to work on another input.  How do I fix?).  Bloody annoying it is.  +1 for this post too.

Comment: how about "**[Unclear What Help You Need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215806/165773 "as suggested here")** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your code needs to be corrected or explained. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: I'd just like to add my two cents in since it doesn't seem like anyone has mentioned this yet... If we are "just debugging code" I think code review stack exchange site might help: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I find this very closely related to [`Provide “Not enough effort” as a new close reason`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253889/provide-not-enough-effort-as-a-new-close-reason)

Comment: @mehow related - yes, but I'd like to emphasize that that's exactly the sort of close reason I'd like to avoid because of the abuse potential it brings.

Comment: How about "Google it."  And whenever a question is so tagged, a lmgtfy link appears.

Comment: Similar to @BrodoFraggins "Google it", I see "debug my code" questions as a teaching moment, and often comment with a recommendation for a next step for the user to take to debug their own code.

Comment: @bspymaster Code Review is specifically for code that _does_ work, but needs improvement.

Comment: @BrodoFraggins Yeah, no. lmgtfy links do nothing but make the poster feel better about insulting the person given the link. They're completely unproductive, and have no place in SO. If you don't want to answer, don't. If you want to tell them they need to do some more research themselves, then do that. If you want to refer them to a learning resource, do so, but lmgtfy links are nothing but snarky insults.

Comment: I strongly disagree that snarky insults are unproductive.  If anyone is deeply hurt by being gently mocked for being too lazy to Google something, they need a thicker skin.

Comment: I am a 68-year-old somewhat-skilled but successful programmer of six decades in at least five major languages. I have been frustrated at almost every new turn by the weirdness that is Java (the only OO language I've tried), only to finally figure it out, only to realize at the next only-slightly-different situation that I haven't internalized whatever I thought I'd figured out and I'm back to square one. This isn't Turbo Pascal, not even C++. One has only so much nervous energy. When it's spent, a call goes out to SO and the LAST thing one needs is four downvotes and multiple snarkinesses.

Comment: "Pebkac or eifoc related" would be a good close-vote reason

Comment: "real programmers" as in, people with prog-related work ? That'd be a terrible lockout.

Comment: @Plutonix back in my day they just slapped you with an 'RTFM' if you were lucky. Now it seems like all I hear is 'encourage a learning environment' and 'develop a nice community' and 'stop strangling interns'.

Comment: @AD7six I can't mark things as [tag:status-completed] so :P

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956182/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error-wrong-eclipse-maybe-or-wrong-package) is the kind of question that needs this close reason.

Comment: Can we lock the up/downvotes, I think this number should be kept.

Comment: [PHP - How to add a specific character at the end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380200/php-how-to-add-a-specific-character-at-the-end-of-a-string)

Comment: Just to play the devil's advocate for a minute, couldn't you argue that the fact that the OP lacks even a minimal understanding of the topic would mean that we'd have to explain way too much to them in order to give a proper answer (and that the question is, therefore, too broad)? (Incidentally, I totally agree with bringing this close reason back).

Comment: @DSlomer64 I was going to add something similar. When you suddenly change platforms you will run into beginner's problems, regardless of how professional you are. Currently in a workplace where nobody speaks Java so unfortunately SO becomes the place for the daft questions. After two weeks of banging your head against what appears to be a basic problem, a snarky response is really the last thing anyone needs.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Let me know if I'm misjudging the type of questions you're talking about here (although I think the below reason would still be useful even if I am)...

It seems like we're largely talking about **"fix my code" questions**.

What about:

> Questions asking why code isn't working should show an attempt to reduce the code to [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearly describe the actual and desired behaviour (including any error messages and indicating the corresponding lines, if applicable), describe the troubleshooting steps taken thus far (including attempts at debugging the code) and be written in a way that makes the question useful to future visitors.

... or something like that.

---

Questions that should be closed and I imagine might fall under "lacks minimal understanding" but aren't "fix my code" questions, I typically vote to close as too broad / unclear - because, without some idea of what the user knows, we have no idea where to start explaining.

Comment: I like this. I think this is what the "off topic -> insufficient information to diagnose the problem" close reason should say. Then it would apply not only to questions with insufficient information, but *also* questions that dump tons of code with no evident attempt to debug it. You can't with good conscience close those as lacking sufficient information, but they certainly need to be closed.

Comment: If we can ever convince the community team that this is a good idea, they will probably complain that it's slightly too long. People won't read all of it. But I guess we can cross the bridge of shortening it when we come to it.

Comment: @CodyGray "this question contains too much or too little information to diagnose the problem"?

Comment: A major problem. People posting the low grade, fix-my-big-ugly-ball-of-mud-code-for-free questions often can't, or won't, search or abstract from prior examples.  Let's face it, if the OP is having trouble with `fooBar(xyzzy,b[28])` and there is a previous answer about `fooBar(baz,True)` or maybe the OP has a for loop, and the canonical example is using while, **they'd rather have their question answered than be asked to read, think, take time, and maybe still get it wrong**. If it is a commercial user, the personalized attention equates to actual dollars in their pocket while we work for free

Comment: @immibis I'm assuming that was tongue-in-cheek. :-) But it is worth emphasizing anyway that your proposed phrasing suffers from the same problem as the current phrasing. Rather than coming right out and stating *what* the problem is, it dances around the problem. Hans Passant has referred to this as a "weasel words" problem; I think that's accurate. We need to lead with the most important problem with the question: there is no minimal example given that demonstrates the issue. Not only is that *clearer*, it is also *actionable*. It gives us a prayer the asker might be able to fix the problem.

Comment: How would you deal with this Q... http://stackoverflow.com/q/23994754/156755 ?

Comment: @Basic Too broad. Possibly too many parts, probably too many ways to do different parts, definitely too much explanation required given that we don't know what OP knows.

Comment: @Dukeling The problem is, we do know what the OP knows... Too little to be able to Google an example or understand rudimentary code (let alone what debugging is!). I try to bear in mind the [Four stages of competence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence) and be aware of areas where I'm in stage #4, but sometimes I think the answer really should be "Read a website (or book) to learn the most basic elements of the technology you're using". I don't mean the minimum to code well, just the minimum to be able to read simple code, declare a variable, call a method, etc...

Comment: @Basic If we need to explain all the basic elements of the technology, that's definitely too broad. If we don't know whether we should, that's unclear (as the question is stated, OP might know how to do each part and is just struggling to put it together, or they know so little that they wouldn't be able to tell PHP code from assembler). I'm not saying these reasons are ideal (they possibly leave OP confused), but since SE doesn't want us to close questions just because they lack research effort, they're probably not going to give us a better reason for these types of questions.

Comment: @Cody, custom close reasons have a character limit of 400 characters. The example reason here is 484, so it needs to be chopped down a bit. How about: *"This question appears to be off-topic because **it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.** Describe your problem in more detail (desired behavior, actual behavior, error messages, troubleshooting/debugging attempts) and/or include [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself."*

Comment: @jmac Are you sure? The text box allows for 500. If the limit is indeed 400, I'd rather try to shorten mine than just making a minor change to the reason we're not really happy with, e.g.: `Questions asking why code isn't working should show an attempt to reduce the code to [the shortest program that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), clearly describe the actual and desired behaviour (including any error messages, if applicable), describe the troubleshooting steps taken thus far (including attempts at debugging the code) and be useful to future visitors.`

Comment: @Dukeling, at least on [workplace.se] I only have 400 characters to use. Maybe SO is special? The current suggested copy to me is pretty unclear since it mentions a bunch of things: (1) *attempt* to provide an mcve, (2) describe actual, desired behavior and troubleshooting attempts, (3) be useful to future visitors. (1) and (2) are good, but the copy isn't, (3) is problematic since it requires us to be oracles.

Comment: @jmac Well, you should *attempt* to make it useful (you could have a very useful question hidden there somewhere, but it's no use if you fill the code with inapplicable things), but I guess that part is covered under #1, at least to some extent (not sure what you mean by "the copy isn't").

Comment: Sorry @Duke, [copy means content wording](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=define+copy) in publishing. I'm saying the concept is good, the way it's written could use some improvement (it isn't very direct). We should be clear about what we want (a way to understand the problem) and ask people to include things like errors, mcve's, desired behavior, etc. as means to that end. That's why I like the current reason -- it is clear that we don't have enough info. What could be improved is pointing out what types of info may be helpful. A list of requirements not so much.

Comment: @jmac But I see "lacks sufficient information" as factually inaccurate - we shouldn't have to, and I very rarely do, but I'm often perfectly capable of copying the code in the question into an IDE (and writing the surrounding code, in some cases) and testing it to see the error, or reading the code in-depth to find the problem, so there is, strictly speaking, sufficient information. I see some merit in pointing out why the problem is a problem, but I see more merit in giving detailed advice regarding how to fix it (a rules-are-rules-deal-with-it mindset, providing more details in the [help]).

Comment: look at my questions on akka for instance. I dont have a flaming clue what im doing, yet have seriously put effort into trying. Looking back at them they are nonsense garble - but only because i dont understand the docs and have noone in the know to guide me.

Comment: Discussing this proposal here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions

Comment: [`the personalized attention equates to actual dollars in their pocket while we work for free`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back#comment33173_257887) Nailed it.

Comment: @Qix yeah very very close to 100%. But now, after years, we still fall into such situations. Regardless if commercial or not, many posted questions are being correctly named and described but in the end they comes from the lack of understanding of the tools being in use. I believe the commercial user actually spends some time on research and investigating the issue, if he doesn't than just assume he gets less in his pocket. Regardless it all, I think all the questions showing major lack of understanding should be closed and later completely deleted.

Answer (score 407):

*Not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask*

This is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is not a how-to-program site, nor is it a debug-code-for-free site. A professional or enthusiast programmer would have enough background knowledge, interest in the craft of programming, and respect for other programmers to perform reasonable steps to narrow the focus of the question, perform some debugging and to clearly state the core problem they face. Until those are done, the question and its answers are unlikely to be useful to anyone other than the asker of the question.

Comment: +1  I use the phrase "professional and enthusiast" a lot in some of my comments (and in an answer to [Should “Professionals and enthusiasts” be qualified in the help center?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202476/225437)).  There's a whole realm of unexperienced programmers around, and some of them are professional or enthusiastic.  Ignorance alone isn't a problem. Too many, though, are not at all enthusiastic about programming.  Enthusiastic programmers, even if they have no clue what's going on, would *think* that they do, or hope that they do.  Some questions have mistakes due to ignorant

Comment: enthusiasm, but that's easily corrected.  The problem questions we get are often times due to ignorant apathy.  If not "lacks minimal understanding", I'd settle (perhaps even prefer) "shows no sign of professionalism or enthusiasm".

Comment: **+100** *Not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask* could be a *top-level close category* with an appropriate menu of close reasons and commentary breaking out the examples you mention, gimme-the-codez, and others.

Comment: No, please don't. We have plenty of "beginner" questions that are extremely useful to beginners. Some experienced programmers will likely use this reason left and right to close questions they think are too basic.

Comment: +1 But I'm pretty sure paid (technically "professional") programmers have asked plenty of bad questions -- even turning SO into their unpaid subcontractor.

Comment: Yes, please do! Beginners to programming can phrase a question in a professional manner, and show the appropriate research for their level. That a question is "basic" is irrelevant, it's down to how well the question has been asked, and that can be made clear in the description beside the close reason, possibly along with a one-line reminder of the essence of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @Dukeling: Are you arguing to nuke the part about "background knowledge" but keep the rest?

Comment: How professional is "professional"? How enthusiastic is "enthusiast"? The wording you've suggested encompasses any question that meets OP's criteria, but that's because it broadly describes any question that should be closed for any reason, plus many more that shouldn't be closed at all. It would be used in the same way as too localised or not a real question, which is to say as a general purpose "i can't articulate what's wrong" close reason. Incidentally, this is why those two reasons were taken away in the first place.

Comment: The argument about the subjectivity of this close reason is not valid.  The argument is that it is a "blow off" of the OP.  However the OP has wasted our time.  A "blow off" response seems entirely appropriate.  I don't know about the rest of you professional enthusiasts, but I certainly did not sign up to *FREELY DISTRIBUTE THE KNOWLEDGE THAT HAS TAKEN ME DECADES to learn* to a bunch of people that can't even be bothered to *TRY* to help themselves.  To people that don't write a complete thought - not because they can't, but because they are lazy and really just don't care.

Comment: @Dan-o This reason implies a lot more than just trying and it almost certainly **is** subjective and **will** be misused (**enough** background knowledge, interest and **reasonable** steps are all subjective) ... and, just by the way, lack of research (by itself) isn't a reason to close the question, and it never will be judging by SE responses on the matter (despite me wanting it so) (although it does apply here to a fair extent).

Comment: @Joshua Taylor: "shows no sign of professionalism or enthusiasm" could likewise be used to close joke questions 8)

Comment: It might be a good idea, if the admins allow it, to:
a. close (or delete) the question but retain the URL
b. link the question (or redirect the URL) to a more generalized version of the same question.
I'm a professional, but when learning a new language, I've come across (and found useful) a lot of newbie/homework questions posted here - often, that level of detail (obvious to professionals) is useful when you're starting out. 
A more general topic redirect, with an aggregation of questions asked would be really useful.

Comment: And how much knowledge is "enough background knowledge"? As it is it's quite vague. Also this proposal mixes several other closing reasons in and should be clarified. "Narrow focus" is already contained in "too broad".

Comment: @Dan-o I disagree. While there's the odd l33t-haxxor-wannabe mashing code from websites, many posters seem to post the code because they geniunely lack basic understanding. And this site is about using collective understanding to further our own. It just happens that SO is, by default, not set up to nicely filter out/aggregate examples or questions on basic concepts. So, blowing someone off because they wasted my time is an excuse for "I don't wanna help" - which is your own choice.

Comment: An answer that goes straight for the first words in the first item in the site's Help Center is about as clear as it gets. My kind of answer; hard to side-step.

Comment: The lack of research, laziness and help-vampirism are quite objective. This reason is completely subjective - because both *enthusiasm* and *professionalism*.

Comment: @BartoszKP They simply can be sub-reasons like "Off topic, because..."

Comment: The group "professional or enthusiast" group and the "new to coding" groups are **not** orthogonal. You want to close *bad* questions, not *newbie* questions.

Comment: I really don't like the term "enthusiast programmer", it could be anything and anyone. You can be very enthusiastic with little-to-no actual knowledge of the topic. In fact, this is true for a lot of the hobbyists.

Comment: @Lundin Correct, this is not about limiting questions to *experienced* programmers.  It's about limiting questions to *enthusiastic* programmers who are willing and able to put the time and energy needed to solve their problems in a professional manor, as opposed to someone who has no real interest in programming and is just casually looking into the subject.

Comment: This is way too general. You could use this reason for any closed question. Of course it covers all the examples, because it covers everything. You have to think about all the *other* things this will cover that aren't closed now, or are closed for more specific reasons.

Comment: And thus Marvin the Paranoid android has just enough enthusiasm to go on living, but not so much as the doors (smug as we know they are). I guess I'm saying this smacks of *genuine people personality*.

Comment: Way too elitist, it makes the person(s) who closed the question look like snobs. I feel this close reason will fit way too many questions, it seems a bit open-ended.

Comment: I was about to dismiss this whole discussion, until [this happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037806/how-to-implement-n-choose-r#comment37057557_24037806).

Comment: @anthony-arnold You directed the answerer to unrelated question that didn't help. Luchian also agreed with OP that your comment was unrelated. What is your point?

Comment: @AaronLS It was a terrible question. The title was "Implementing N choose R" which is the binomial coefficient. But the real question was "I have no idea what I'm doing and I'll get snippy with anyone that doesn't give my teh codez."

Comment: @anthony-arnold English is probably not his first language. He should have chose a title that reflected the real issue was a runtime error. However, it seems English is probably not your first language either, cause he **clearly states** "but I got Run-Time Error".  Anyone with basic reading comprehension would realize he's not asking for a how-to on binomial coefficient, but for help with his runtime error. If you had actually read the body of the OP post, you might have come up with a constructive comment like "What is the error?" instead of detracting from the issue, which is very annoying!

Comment: People whos question falls under this category are usually of the kind that give 1% when asked for 100%. They will whine about not immediately getting their answer, no matter how nice we try, because *it is already the not answering their question that makes them upset* so no matter how nice or rude we will be, it won't make much of a difference. So lets ask them for 500% to get at least 5% out of them. This will make them either upset and leave (which is good because otherwise they would give more bad content) or make them actually try and achieve 5% which is good too.

Comment: I think this is so patronising it's worse than the reason that it would be replacing. I would much prefer something constructive that guides the user towards improving the question.

Comment: @SamAxe no OP could ever be rightly accused of wasting your time.  *you're* wasting your own time by patrolling the site looking for bad questions.  you feel like because the OP has "wronged you," you have a right to retaliate.  nothing could be farther from the truth.

Comment: I appreciate the intent of this, but I'm in the disagree camp.  These concepts of a correct "professional" user - or any other type - are way too hard to define consistently - around the world, all the time.  I think it raises a great direction for deciding how to work on this issue .......  define people or define questions or ??

Comment: Years are passing and we still face this issue. Even if question is nicely described, many times it falls into not understanding of the language, tools or the environment they use. I saw the questions like "my code doesnt compile" or "got XX exception" a hundreds of times which stayed on site as proper questions (not being closed or etc.) where there is tones of other similar questions with good or accepted answers.

Answer (score 108):

#### It's about the *Content*

When I read the [About Page](https://stackoverflow.com/about), three things stand out to me:

1. We're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.
2. Questions that need improvement may be **closed** until someone fixes them.
3. Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!

The focus is on the content, and the content improves through community effort in improving it, and teaching people the ropes so they can contribute too.

That is why this reason [was removed in the first place](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/), it didn't help accomplish those goals that we put front and center:

> It pains me when I hear people say that our sites are unfriendly, or that we chase new users away. But it’s a hard problem, because **our highest priority has always been the quality of content on our sites.**  And it still is. We *can’t* lower our standards. We won’t.
>
> But we have been working hard to make our sites more welcoming, reminding users that [feedback can be clear and nice](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), and helping new users [learn the ropes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/about-page-2-0-the-quickstartening/) before they get frustrated.  **And, as of today, we’ve completely overhauled closing.**

#### How Will This Help Content?

So let's say we do implement this as a close reason again in some form and that everyone who has close vote privileges use the close reason in the exact same objective way -- what are we accomplishing? Will providing this message to users give them something actionable to improve the quality of content?

> [*Not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257874/1933347)

[image: You Must Be At Least This Tall to Ride]

So that's it. I'm just not pro/enthusiastic enough to post my question on Stack Overflow. This is a deficiency in me as a human being, and there is simply no way to fix that. Not trying to pick on Raedwald here (he did answer the question as-asked), but this isn't going to accomplish the goals in the about page. Denying content for reasons that cannot be corrected may prevent bad content, but it certainly won't help introduce good content, it won't improve existing content, and it won't teach users how to distinguish between the two.

The message is being used to punish. And that's not very nice. Nor is it very useful in achieving our goals. And that's why it was removed.

#### [How I learned to stop worrying and love the downvote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)

Instead of a special punitive close reason, just downvote it. The helpful hover over the question downvote button says, *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. That's a single click. It is what downvotes were designed for. It will hide the question out of sight and out of mind. And that's good. If the user cares they will try to figure out how to improve it. They will try to figure out the problem themselves and edit their question, or put more thought in to their next one. *And that's good for site quality and achieving our goals*.

Having a separate close reason solely for you to punish users who don't meet your quality criteria may be [cathartic](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=define+cathartic), but it isn't very practical. Most of us started off with some questionable quality questions. While I'm sure Benjamin is a stellar coder, there is little doubt that his [third question could very well have been closed with this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264734/java-serialization-behavior). Fortunately for all of us having this discussion, it was just downvoted, and we have a tremendous contributor with us because he took that reception as a reason to learn, improve, and contribute more quality content, not walk away angry at the SO community.

Question quality is an issue. That's what was discussed on [the last podcast at length](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/podcast-59-hes-one-of-those-science-ists/), but the solution isn't to ostracize and punish askers of a single poor question (which is what this close reason would do), it's to improve the system to minimize their impact (especially the frustration they cause), without being mean or assuming they are the problem rather than their content.

Comment: +1 for this. The question here should be how can we encourage people to downvote crap questions rather than simply leaving it, or answering them (*shudder*). I do however, disagree with your statement that the proposed close reaon would deny content which *can't* be corrected, and your assumptions based on that. This close reason would be a big hint to the OP to go and do some research, and *do some work themselves*. If they solve the problem, then great; *otherwise*, ***return*** to Stack Overflow and ask a *new* (better!) question **based** on the research/ attempts they've since made.

Comment: ... this *will* help introduce good content, and it *will* teach users how to distinguish between the two. ***However*** people downvoting achieves *exactly* the same goal; and downvoting is the tool that should be used here (as, per the hover title, is what it was designed for), and ***not*** VtCing

Comment: @Matt, the point is that a close reason that is dismissive of the *user* rather than the *content* sends a strong message to the user that their content, no matter how hard they try, is not appropriate because of *who they are* rather than what they write. And that's not good. Almost all of us have bad questions, but most of us learn. And what would have happened if one of our first interactions was someone telling us that we don't belong, that we aren't developer-esque enough to talk here? That is going to deny otherwise good users who can create good content.

Comment: I agree with you there, but that's just the wording in the close reason. However you want to word it, we don't want them to post questions which don't show any research effort into the problem at hand. Suggestions such as http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257887/444991 target the content posted rather than the user. I ***strongly*** dislike the close-reason proposed in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257874/444991

Comment: The big problem with down-voting is that once down-voted a question rarely recovers, even if the writer improves it to the point where as a new question it would have received several up-votes. This is also true of questions placed on hold/closed. If a question receives a poor reception it's often much more efficacious for the writer quickly to delete it and later post a new, better, question, than it is to try to salvage the original one. So the real issue is how to encourage writers to delete their own bad questions and start again?

Comment: @Matt, maybe you're right. When I read the OP, I read (despite all the lukewarm protestations to the contrary) *"I really hate it when people ask questions I don't think are up to SO standards, and really wish we had a reason that let me just close the damned things by pointing out (in a nice way) that the asker doesn't have a clue"*, and I don' think that is doable because the intent isn't along with the general goals of SO. Again, could be wrong.

Comment: @Ian, editing a heavily downvoted post will bump it up to the front page (currently, who knows after the last podcast), and if it gets 2 upvotes for every 5 downvotes will recover any lost rep even if it stays in the negative. I'm sure you can make a data.se query that looks for posts downvoted more than X times, then edited, that recover the rep. If the author deletes and reposts a better question, that works too. If they continue to post poor questions they get a question ban. And all without having to deal with a single menu. Why exactly do we want to close?

Comment: If you've had a question put on hold you're probably more interested in getting it reopened than in the rep damage of the down-votes. The problem I was referring to is that the barrier to getting a question reopened is rather high compared to if the question had been written well in the first place; it relies on high-reputation users noticing the improvements and bothering to take action, which I know does not always happen. Sorry if that's off-topic here. Maybe the guidance should be to delete rather than edit your own bad questions.

Comment: @IanGoldby: It's interesting what you say about a down-voted question not recovering. *Even* if you do end up with positive net repuation like jmac says, seeing the negative score next to your post is pretty demoralizing, and I'd still feel like I *failed* even if I gained reputation overall. One solution would be to reset votes to 0 when a question gets reopened (and to hide votes when it gets closed?). It sort of begs the question... why don't we just delete posts immediately (possibily excluding duplicates), rather than marking them as closed. They're a wasteground.

Comment: @Ian, I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that questions should be closed without downvotes to prevent deletion? Because to me it seems these types of questions are closed *and* downvoted. And if they are closed, then they require not only upvotes, but also 5 reopen votes before getting answered, and that makes it *more* likely that someone will just delete the sucker and recreate as it takes more effort. But I could be wrong. Care to make a data.se query to check what % of questions are edited after 5 downvotes + close vs. just 5 downvotes?

Comment: ... if we "close" a question, remove it from the site (except for the OP). Show them a message saying their post was removed because of the reason it was *closed* for. Maybe the users next post after one that got closed should be routed to a queue [like proposed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256804/444991) to give them feedback before letting them back into the wild. This stops the crap content [lingering around on the website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256742/gamification-rules-have-to-be-changed-aiming-quality-not-quantity/256773#256773).

Comment: @Matt, I see where your heart is on this one, but this doesn't seem like it has a good chance of scaling. For people who want to improve, they shouldn't need their hand held to figure out how to do that (in other words, they don't need additional special warnings, or a special queue to review their next submission). And if they don't want to improve, then we end up investing a lot of effort in to someone who may not actually care to put any in of their own. Downvotes are wonderful because they solve the problem easily -- no fuss, no muss.

Comment: jmac: I'm not bothered about them having their hand held or not. What I *am* bothered about is their crap posts lingering on the site and drowing the *good* content. Their previous post being closed (deleted?) is a good signal that their next post will also be crap; the review queue would be an opportunity to *prevent* their next post getting onto the website in the first place. For all I care, it could function *exactly* like the current close vote queue (even with the same close options).

Comment: ... if the community vote for the post "to be closed", we show a warning to the user saying their post was *still not good enough*, and the process starts again. If the community vote that the post is OK, let it onto the site. The problem with just using downvotes, is that a) [people don't use it enough](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/257979?noredirect=1#comment33639_257979), and b) it doesn't prevent the content from being posted in the first place.

Comment: Allow me to put forth a radical suggestion -- rather than providing people who are uncomfortable downvoting with a separate tool that doesn't fix the problem (a close reason that was eliminated for good cause), we just tell folks that they should be downvoting? So crazy, it just might work. What do you think @Matt? If there is a benefit in reinventing the wheel, I'd love to know what it is

Comment: So far it's been my impression that deleting your own question and posting a new one is frowned upon and that you should instead edit the original question. Anyway, yeah this is a bit tangental to the original discussion.

Comment: @jmac: Heh, but *how* do you propose reminding them to downvote? Isn't that easier said than done :). Note that reminding people to downvote still doesn't prevent the content from getting on the website in the first place, but it's a start.

Comment: I suggest that every time someone brings up this same issue, the community points out that downvoting is the appropriate thing to do @Matt. Kind of like what I did here, as did [Shog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258062/1933347). I see the issue as many people feeling that they need a *stronger* tool than downvote to extra punish people.

Comment: "This isn't a question a ___ would ask" **is about the question**, not the asker. Too many beginning users here take any criticism or rejection personally, and lash out.  Some of this is surely from youngsters who really haven't had much experience socially dealing with the rejection of their technical questions or ideas and the need to edit and resubmit them as part of a quality-oriented adversarial process.

Comment: @Paul, I invite you think a bit more deeply about what you just said. *"This isn't a question that \_\_\_\_\_ would ask"* is defining the question by who asks it. My question is defined by the fact that I am the one asking it, assuming, of course, that anyone who wasn't me (who was a proper \_\_\_\_\_) wouldn't make such a boneheaded mistake. How exactly am I supposed to correct a question whose sole fault is the person asking it? Regardless of whether I am young or whether I am a programmer, I would hope that doesn't preclude me from asking good questions, but you would seem to disagree.

Comment: @jmac Perhaps "This isn't a good question for Stack Overflow"  would be better, then. Then the user isn't being accused of anything.

Comment: @Paul, I really put some effort in to laying out all the resources that point to the SO concept, and why this line of thinking was eliminated in the past. Ambiguous unactionable close reasons, especially subjective ones, don't help achieve SO goals. I said something similar [5 months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/209637), in a much nicer way, but as you can see from Shog's response, that isn't the direction they want to go in.

Comment: @jmac I enjoyed the pictures, think they should be refined and actually used for help.  Yet, even the rephrased closed/minimal understanding "You need to help yourself first by reading a book or talking to a friend" "blames" the poster instead of the question.  I'll try to keep an open mind.

Comment: @Paul, exactly, even my attempt at being friendly when pointing out that sometimes someone has to help themselves wasn't good because it was blaming the user rather than the content. And that's why this reason doesn't exist (and shouldn't exist). You may also be interested in [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow/256084#256084). I get where you're at, and your heart is probably in the right place, but we have to think of the bigger picture always.

Comment: The problme with downvoting isn't just demoralization. If a question has been improved to the point that it's actually good, but it stays downvoted, how are people who are looking for an answer to the same question going to find it? I know I don't bother looking at negative voted questions when I need  to read answers (rather than give them. I do try to help anyone with a downvoted question, if I can think of how to do so).

Comment: How about something like "This question demonstrates a lack of fundamental concepts neccessary for properly formulating it and understanding a good answer fitting our format." That makes explicit what the problem is. Of course, we could also close with the fairly bland "too broad" and leave them guessing, in order to avoid anything which can be seen as "too plain-spoken" or "direct".

Answer (score 57):

I don't know if this helps you here on Stack Overflow, because I'm not heavily involved in the Stack Overflow close-voting community (I don't have the reputation points yet, though I do flag for closure in extreme cases). But on *[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)*, one of our custom off-topic reasons is this:

> This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to **add the research** you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or **provide more context**. See: [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

The meta post it links to ([Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)) is also a good read on this topic. This reason basically says ***show us a little effort, and give us a little more information. A copy-pasted paragraph/code dump that says "What does this mean/how do I fix it" is not what we're looking for.***

These seem to be similar messages we're trying to send, so this might help you out a bit in wording the close reason you want to create.

Comment: Playing Devil's Advocate: this sounds like *"Unclear what you're asking"* -- how do you guys distinguish between the two? If the question is clear, why are more details necessary? If the question isn't, then isn't that the issue (not the lack of research)?

Comment: @jmac "What does 'enlightened' mean?" is clear, but doesn't show any effort of research. "I found this definition for 'enlightened' online: [definition, example sentences]. However I still don't understand, because [explanation of what you tried to figure out and why you're still confused]. Why is 'enlightened' used in this context, and what does it mean?" Shows effort and helps us answer better; there are so many answers to "what does X mean". When we know *why* someone's confused, we know where to start in the answer.

Comment: *"What does 'enlightened' mean?"* is unclear what you're asking in my book. If the issue is a lack of detail, then either vote to close and/or downvote and/or comment asking for clarification. In the meantime, if asking for dictionary definitions is a common problem, I suggest taking a look at your help center to make sure that you clearly state that doing such is a no-no, and how to improve a post other than just asking the definition. Effort should not be a criteria, nor should amount of detail -- questions that follow the guidelines and are clear should be okay.

Answer (score 47):

All your points seem to be well covered with **"Lacks minimal effort"** phrase. After all, it's what we are all talking about implicitly - why not make it explicit. Also, it doesn't sound so rude as it does not suggest that OP is stupid ("understanding") - it's just saying they could do better.

Comment: +1 - Yes, I really dont understand the splitting hairs over all the other, far less clear close reasons. "Lacks minimal effort" seems succinct enough.

Comment: ... does not display a degree of effort and understanding consistent with the standards of this site.

Answer (score 41):

> None of the current close reasons fit these particular questions

Sure they do.

Look... I get that folks liked that particular close reason. So did I. But it was widely misunderstood and misused, by the folks using it, by the folks asking questions, and especially by the folks *reading* questions. What's the point of bothering with a description if it is effectively meaningless?

[So we replaced it with reasons aimed directly at specific problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow). I'm not going to address all of your many bullets, since frankly you're all over the map. I'm not even going to address your examples, since *you didn't link to them*. Instead, I'll note that *all* of the titles you quote hint at one common problem:

> This close reason *should* cover the bulk of what was being legitimately closed for "minimal understanding". Questions where...
>
> - ...No specific problem is identified
> - **...A specific scenario or set of requirements are described, but the asker fails to identify what he wants as a result of this.**
> - ...The wording or formatting is so poor as to make reading the question exceptionally difficult.

Questions of the form, "there is a problem of some sort in my code somewhere, please fix it" are *not* clear questions. Yes, any reasonably-competent programmer familiar with the topic can [daniel their way to a solution](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel%202), but *your* ability to synthesize a problem statement where none is provided is no more an indication of clarity than is *your* ability to mentally insert missing letters into "[Aoccdrnig to rscheearch at Cmabrigde uinervtisy](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/aoccdrnig-to-rscheearch)".

### There are three types of questions:

1. Those that **clearly state a specific problem** and provide sufficient information for knowledgeable answerers to identify a solution.
2. Those that fail to state a specific problem, but provide sufficient contextual information for knowlegeable answerers to **guess** at both a problem and a solution.
3. Those that fail to identify either a problem, a context, or a desired outcome.

**Only #1 is *not* "unclear"!** #2 *could* be edited by any sufficiently-skilled person to *make it* clear. #3 requires input from either the author or [a psychic](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22psychic%22+blogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Foldnewthing%2F) to become clear. Therefore...

***Barring the intervention of an editor*, #2 and #3 should be closed as "unclear what you're asking."**

### But I saw a reasonably-scoped question with a clear problem statement and sufficient context and I didn't like it for some reason!

Well, then down-vote it and get on with your life. Realistically, we're not even able to close all of the blatantly-unclear questions that are asked each day, so begging for another close reason to use on borderline questions isn't going to help - instead, you're just throwing away a vote you could've put to better use elsewhere. Close votes are not a super downvote - alone, they're actually *less* effective than a downvote would be, so if you're voting to close and *not* down-voting, you're throwing away the chance to have a direct, immediate effect on a question for the chance that 4 other people will agree with your hair-splitting.

I can't tell you to ignore problems you consider important, but **I *strongly* recommend you focus on the most severe problems before worrying about edge-cases.** There is no shortage of very bad, very unclear questions asked every single day - if we *ever* get to the point where that's not the case, then... These borderline cases will be *a good problem to have.*

Comment: BTW - I didn't link to them because that creates skew.

Comment: I like this way of looking at it; but the current verbiage of "unclear what you're asking" doesn't cover it hugely. If we had one like: "we're currently unable to synthesise your question into one based on general principles" it'd cover what you describe better for most people reading the reason.

Comment: It's those #2 cases which cause a lot of problems though - a few people not very experienced with a given topic falsely declare that it can only be answered with a guess, which means that before someone with actual, relevant knowledge and experience can answer it, they have to get the erroneous closure reversed.  Ultimately, "closing" is a counterproductive status, as all it really does is prevent answers.  If there must be a binding-on-all "disapproval" status, it would be far better if it were one which merely neutralized the possibility of earning any positive reputation from the question.

Comment: What doesn't "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need." cover, @Ben? I have little hope of anyone who can't follow that guidance being able to get anything from "unable to synthesize..."

Comment: Yeah, that's another reason I prefer "unclear" to "minimal understanding", @Chris - it's possible for folks to be *clearly wrong* in their assessment of a question.

Comment: My wording isn't any better I know! But, people assume that reason means add missing code or more "stuff". Not, "make you question more generic", but then again maybe I've misread the emphasis of your answer.

Comment: As Ben said (and as Benjamin said in the question), the problem with "unclear what you're asking" here is that it's perfectly clear what the OP is asking; he's asking us to fix his code and do the debugging for him. The part *As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking* just doesn't fit here. Perhaps changing that sentence to something like *Without more specific details, it's hard to diagnose your problem* would help.

Comment: That's not a *question* though, @Matt - that's a work order. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - which is linked to from Unclear...

Comment: "Not generic enough" isn't usually the problem here, @Ben. There's a world of difference between a *specific problem* and a vague problem with specific code.

Comment: Ok, I read this - "Get on with your life" is probably the easiest reply to make from your end and one of the least effective ones imo. Closing questions that fall under this category (long, specific clear and often "debug my code") is an effective way to minimize the time people waste on them that could otherwise be spent on much more needing questions. By not closing them I am legitimizing them which in turn causes more such questions to come which deteriorates the quality of questions on the site. This makes it harder for me to find questions to answer and get answers for my questions.

Comment: So how much work are you willing to devote to such a question, @benjamin? Remember, it takes anywhere from 5 close votes to 5 + 3 delete votes before that question actually *disappears* - meanwhile, that downvote starts penalizing it *immediately*.

Comment: @Shog9 [Why not both?](http://i.imgur.com/QWAllWq.jpg?1). Optimally, I'd rather devote exactly _zero_ attention to such a question but for the very least, I'd rather have other people devote as little attention as possible to it too. I'm the last guy to advocate closing for the sake of closing - I really only care about the attention it takes from other questions whose authors put more effort into. Perhaps close votes should penalize the visibility of new questions as well?

Comment: @Ben, I get that people don't like these sorts of questions, but is there a reason that we need two different types of weapons (downvotes *and* close votes), as well as a system change (to further mask their visibility) just to deal with them? Other than the fact that people seem to hate them, what is the benefit of eliminating these questions with extreme prejudice?

Comment: Go ahead and do both then, @benjamin - as long as you remember to downvote, at least *something* is gonna happen. Close vote when it'll do good, refrain when it wont - **just don't forget to downvote low-quality questions!**

Comment: Of course, I'm not asking for an _alternative_ for down votes. I'm asking for a complementing close reason. I completely understand the _reasoning_ of "Who cares if it's closed or not? If it's answerable, and someone will eventually answer it - let them be our guests, otherwise, closing it won't make a difference anyway" - the point that bothers me is the fact they take attention from other questions, which closing helps with.

Comment: @jmac You know what? I'm not sure I know. I upvoted your answer. Telling people that down voting is the solution for visibility and further encouraging it and penalizing down voted questions might actually be a more effective strategy than working on close reasons, as long as it's crystal clear that that's the direction the community is taking.

Comment: @Shog9 "*we're not even able to close all of the blatantly-unclear questions that are asked each day, so begging for another close reason to use on borderline questions isn't going to help*" => That is a weak argument - the existence of amazingly bad questions shouldn't prevent bad questions from being closed too. Either you want to improve content, in which case "every little helps", or you don't...

Comment: Except... Every little bit *doesn't* help, @assylias. Not when it comes to close votes. Some little bits help, some just spread already scarce resources a little bit thinner. So at some point, you gotta ask yourself: is this question *hurting the site*, in a way that justifies the resources needed to close it, review it, perhaps delete it... Or is its most likely future one of obscurity, destined to neither help nor hurt anything. Because if you don't ask yourself this question - if you treat voting and closing as two degrees of the same - then *at best* you're just wasting time; at worst...

Comment: get rid of all close reasons.

Comment: I do not see where your description solves "here is my entire 1000 line code base, and it errors when I do X.  Why?  Fix please.", which is a horrible question for stack overflow: it isn't searchable for future problem seekers, and it clutters up the front page.  Such a question should be closed and deleted.  Yet there is sufficient information (more than sufficient), and the question is clear (why does it crash, how do I stop it from crashing).  By the above logic, one should down vote and move on, not close and delete.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think you might be over-estimating exactly how much traffic comes from meta to those questions. In any event, the skew would be from the most experienced users, and those who care the most about site quality. It is essentially free advertising to perhaps finding a solution for those people - not linking them does a disservice. They're already on the internet - I wouldn't worry about them getting too much attention...

Comment: There are two problems with those, @Yakk. The simple one is that they should nearly always be closed as duplicates of a less convoluted "How do I fix ErrorY when doing X?" question. The harder one is that they're simply too long; I kinda think we should be blocking these outright in most cases. Consider kicking off a separate discussion for this... *With actual examples!*

Comment: What missing letters?

Answer (score 26):

"I don't understand how code works" should be outside the scope of Stack Overflow. We're here to solve *specific, answerable* problems. While the questions you've posted above are **answerable**, they're not **specific**. There are plenty of great places to learn how code works, how to build a web page and how to interact with a compiler. Stack Overflow is ***not*** a school and should not be treated as such.

Lack of minimal understanding is a perfectly valid close reason and should be brought back.  LoMU closers should also comment with links to tutorials and the documentation, so that OP can be brought up to minimal understanding.

To be more specific, LoMU should be "If I answered this question (and included a basic explanation of the code therein), OP would *still* not understand why it works". There is a bit of subjectivity here - but that's OK. Humans work like that, even if compilers don't.

Good examples of this principle include jQuery questions where OP has dropped a plugin in and doesn't understand why the problem doesn't magically solve itself. Their problem *isn't* the datepicker, it's a fundamental misunderstanding of how front-end development works.

Comment: Disagree that the close-voter should comment with links to tutorials — that's a lot of repetitive grunt work. Perhaps links to tutorials should be added to the tag wikis? & A link to that page provided in the close message?

Comment: If question doesn't make sense because the OP doesn't understand the basic constructs of the language at all, I'd like to see it closed. "Off topic" or "too broad" might mean something internally, but the OP will be confused. It's not off topic. It's about C#. It's not broad. I want to know how to write a function that creates an instance of a class and returns it. It's going to give the impression that we didn't actually think about why we were closing it.

Answer (score 26):

How about **"Unlikely to help anyone else with a coding problem."**

For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612636/331508).  The asker nominally provides everything needed to solve his problem and it does not match any of the standard close reasons.

Yet the problem is so unique to that asker (who has since scarpered) that this question will never help another user with a programming problem.

(Note that the question has been cluttering up search results for 4 years but has zero votes, low views (640 at the moment), [no *Helpful* votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73917/anonymous-feedback-for-a-specific-question-and-its-answers?PostId=2612636), and no comments of interest.)

Comment: I use "typo" in the broad sense of "problem specific to the asker"

Comment: @JanDvorak, Does that work?  In low traffic tags? It's hard to get all but the most obviously bad Q's closed in my tags (Except for dupes, now that we have gold-badge powers). ... Also It feels kinda hinky to me if the problem really isn't a typo but several poor practices.

Comment: This is pretty much a rewording of "too localized".

Comment: I feel like a lot of Sass questions fall into this category.  A good chunk of questions there are "How do I convert this LESS code to Sass (or vice versa)" or "How can I refactor this CSS (or Sass) to be more DRY/efficient/etc."  In many of these instances RTFM would have been my preferred closing method, especially since both LESS and Sass have very short docs, 1 and 3 pages respectively.

Comment: Suffers from [the same problem as Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168775/is-the-too-localized-description-inconsistent-with-the-communitys-de-facto-st/168778#168778) - evaluating what will/won't help others is an exercise in predicting the future. Much prefer specific reasons: "won't help others **because it is too unclear for them to find**" or "won't help others **because it was a trivial typing error / omission**" etc.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree that more specific reasons are better, but all close reasons have some degree of predicting what other people will find useful in the future. Who's to say that a typo won't result in a highly upvoted [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator).

Comment: Past experience with them, @mike. That question is popular because it's weird - there are a few others like it, and all of them have been controversial. Run of the mill "my cat leapt upon my keyboard and now my program has bugs" questions are rarely so clear-cut. Of course, you're correct: *all* close reasons rely on the judgement of actual humans... All the more reason to make sure those humans are at least somewhat on the same page when using them.

Answer (score 18):

I have seen "Too Broad" and "Simple Typographical Error" used to address these. I think that those two close reasons are great, and suit a situation that is very often repeated on SO. However, the two reasons leave a gap; as you say, sometimes the question is not too broad, and is not a simple typographical error.

It is still meets some of the criteria for closing mentioned in the text of those two close reasons: unlikely to help future visitors, and a minimal reproducible example would illustrate the problem. In other words, the only real problem is the lack of debugging efforts.

It would be nice to link to some kind of language-agnostic debugging guide. I shouldn't think we would link to such a document on a third-party site. A page similar to help/mcve, but focused on 1) checking official documentation, and 2) enabling any debugging/error information that might be available. In lieu of that, I've linked to help/mcve here:

> #### closed as general debugging by xxx,xxx,xxx June 02 at x:xx
>
> The problem in this question can be solved by general debugging or by 
>   observing basic code practices recorded in public documentation, and is 
>   [unlikely to help future readers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This can often be avoided by identifying 
>   and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: +1 I think this captures the essence of the problem described in the question very well - let's hope it makes its way to the top despite being 120 points behind because of late appearance!

Comment: Link: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - which is also at the bottom of the "How to ask" page.

Comment: @KevinB "the majority" -- yes, the majority of questions posted on StackOverflow *today* are general debugging, low-quality questions that lots of people are trying to find lots of creative ways to slow down. Another way of saying this: most of the questions (the majority?) posted on StackOverflow should be closed.

Comment: That's where i disagree. If they fall under one of the existing close reasons, yes, they need to be closed. However, there are many that don't fall under said reasons **that just need to be downvoted**. Sending these questions into the close review area isn't going to stop the behavior due to the fact that the questions that this reason would close typically get answered pretty quickly.

Comment: I dislike these noobish questions just as much as the next serious developer, but i don't see any reason for them not to exist if they aren't duplicates, are clear, and are not too opinionated. Downvote the question if you don't think enough research/debugging was done.

Comment: @KevinB There seems to be an existential divide -- it isn't just you and I that disagree on this, our entire user base falls into one of two camps. Some see the founding purpose of the site as something that needs to be preserved. To that end, we don't want to be a "welcoming community", we don't want to be a community at all. We want to be a resource. If you subscribe to that idea (and I do), then our system can be seen as a mechanism to enforce an editorial standard. Meaning, we don't want **all** questions, we want **useful** questions. Downvoting isn't sufficient, they shouldn't exist.

Comment: Discussing this proposal here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258685/should-we-have-a-more-specific-close-reason-for-vague-debugging-questions

Answer (score 15):

In a sense, it's a variant of "too broad", and we can piggyback on the explanation stated there.

**An answer to this question would amount to a tutorial.** A good question is focused and can be answered by one or at most a few paragraphs which build upon a basic understanding of the technologies used. In this case no compact answer is possible, because any answer would have to include an explanation of many basic ideas. It may be better to read a book or tutorial on the subject first.

Comment: I like this. It directly addresses the **fundamental lack of understanding** the user DOES suffer from, while stating the crux of the problem for SO: "We can't do this for you".

Comment: I'm liking it. It's an answer that convinced me that we should. ^^

Comment: The irony is that the tag-wikis often has a lot of reference material and tutorial -- however it is not-obvious for first time users how to access this -- I would suggest that the tag-wikis was made more prominent to first time users.

Comment: This is brilliant.  It's the only proposal I've seen that is concise, spot-on and completely respectful.

Answer (score 13):

I completely understand 100% why this might *seem* like a good label to explain why a question was closed ***after*** the fact,

***but…***

The problem with listing this as an explicit close reason is you are over-training the community to *look* for this as a reason to close without describing what the actual problem is. You might as well label it "not a good question." **That's just not terribly helpful… or prescriptive.**

To the end user and anyone else looking on, this doesn't describe why the question was closed at all. Here is how this admittedly rude conversation looks to just about everyone else:

> **User Seeking Help:** *Can you explain how {x} works?*
>
> **Community:** *"We are closing this because you don't understand the subject."*
>
> **User:** *"That's why I am asking the question, duh."*

The new close reasons were designed specifically to steer away from that type of unproductive and unhelpful dialog.

Comment: Giving someone an answer to their question that they have no hope of understanding is certainly *nicer* to the person that asked the question.  It doesn't seem nearly as rude as telling them they wouldn't understand the answer, but both are equally unhelpful, as in both cases the user still doesn't understand the answer to their problem.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In fact I agree with it so much that I even opened a question about it in Meta Stack Overflow, in fact - this _is_ that question. I do not think "Lacks minimal understanding" is a good close reason, I think it's rude and condescending - in fact, that's the first sentence in my answer. I'm asking about _an alternative_ on how to deal with these questions, a different close reason for a specific subset of "lacks minimal understanding" - how would I deal with it? I really only care about these questions taking attention from other ones.

Comment: -1. The problem is not explaining how `{x}` works. The problem is explaining how `{x}` works to someone who skipped the explanations of `{a}` to `{w}` and now expects a stand-alone answer to explain `{x}` without relying on prior knowledge. And of course, someone else in turn will ask about `{y}` and the whole circus has to start from `{a}` again.

Comment: @MSalters Agreed.  Don't forget people who want answers customized to the corner they've painted themselves into. OP: How do I do X in Javascript?  A: Use $('#Id').justDoIt(). OP: -1 That's not Javascript, that's jQuery.  A: jQuery is written in Javascript. OP: Sure, but I don't want to load all of jQuery just for this one thing. I really need the JS. A: Well, jQuery is open source, you could look up the code for .justDoIt() and copy the parts you need if you understand it.  OP:  That might be true, but it doesn't help.  I don't have time.  *But they have time to ask us...*

Answer (score 8):

Lack of Minimal Understanding isn't a good phrasing.

We want people to fix their on-hold questions (however unlikely), Lack of Minimal Understanding doesn't really mean anything, it's lawyer talk.

I'd much rather we'd be straight with users and tell them that their question was put on hold due to RTFM. Since that probably won't happen, there's a reason the minimal understanding reason was removed, because it was horribly abused.

Comment: or due to LMGTFY...

Comment: Perhaps "lacks *demonstration of* minimal understanding?

Comment: I agree with the opening sentence.  Really, lack of minimal understanding would require deletion, not closing.  Is the OP going to come back a couple days later and now have sufficient understanding?  Not likely.  It would take a longer period of time to get that understanding and by then the OP probably isn't interested in that question any longer.  That is the fundamental different between the current close reasons: the others can all be fixed with a little bit of effort, this one maybe not so.

Comment: Lacks Minimal Google That For You ... :)

Answer (score 7):

After visiting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765663/how-to-deal-with-php-variables-in-javascript) I must say that "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason is needed. In this case it's even worse. This question attracts many answers and all of them can be condensed to "It's impossible". Moreover, the OP "knows better" — just read the comments to the answers.

It doesn't fall under

> Questions asking why code isn't working should show an attempt to reduce the code to the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem, clearly describe the actual and desired behaviour (including any error messages and indicating the corresponding lines, if applicable), describe the troubleshooting steps taken thus far (including attempts at debugging the code) and be written in a way that makes the question useful to future visitors.

because you can easily find the reason for the problem.

This is just an example of question which produces bunch of answer but is neither constructive nor at all helpful. But still it doesn't fall into existing close reasons.

I vote to bring "Lacks Minimal Understanding" back.

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon a question today that really qualifies to "lacks minimal understanding".

[image]

No other close vote really fits here. It's the complete python code (except that print should have lowercase p) needed for the question. I guess you could shoehorn it into "details or clarity" but IMO it's a pretty clear question. You could also (as we did in this case) find a duplicate that answers it. But it's not really reasonable that we should have to find dups to be able to close questions like this.

EDIT:

Another better example:

[image]

The question is very clear, and the answer is a simple "yes".

Comment: I don't see a problem with needs details or clarity: _"The question **needs details** on why you don't understand, namely what you were expecting to happen instead."_

Comment: @E_net4theclosevoter I guess that may be true depending on who you ask, but I think that's missing the elephant in the room. IMO, there is NOTHING in terms of clarity and other stuff that would justify this question. It's simply too basic.

Comment: But how about this? The OP could be thinking that arrays are 1-indexed and that the program should just fail or return a None-like value. In the best case, the question would be expanded to uncover a specific misunderstanding.

Comment: @E_net4theclosevoter Well, it's not technically impossible that that was the intent. I guess you have higher hope for humans than I do. ;)

Comment: Humans are complicated, but we can try and give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @E_net4theclosevoter Sure. But I still think that "lacks minimal understanding" should be a valid close vote.

Comment: "*No other close vote really fits here*" That doesn't seem true; it looks like it was accurately closed as a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: @TylerH: that only proves all basic questions have already been asked. Was actually looking for a similar example, such as "how do I add two numbers in Python".

Comment: @usr2564301 It proves no such thing; it only proves this specific question has already been asked. If a suitable duplicate did not exist, this would be a fine question for Stack Overflow; *it* could become the canonical explainer on wrong-based counting in Python.

Comment: @E_net4isdownhausted I found a better example

Comment: Arguably, the _root problem_ of the OP is not understandable. It still needs and/or clarity on why they think one would be unable to use more than one data type in a struct. I mean, if they wrote just that in code, what's the problem? Answering "yes" might actually trigger a follow-up question, and therefore is a dangerous one to answer in such a state.

Comment: @E_net4isdownhausted Could be the case. I guess I would also want the close reason "This question is just plain crap" :D

Comment: Considering that some people already take our existing close reasons by heart, one shudders to think of what their reaction would be over that one.

Comment: @E_net4isdownhausted Sure. Of course I did not intend that it should be phrased like that. Sometimes I think there's "too much kindness". Don't misunderstand me, but it feels like that the philosophy is that we should never ever throw away a question that has even the smallest chance of being suitable, given that others take their time to explain to OP what is already written in the help pages.

Answer (score 6):

I completely agree. For example, take a look at [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021202/python-compare-a-string-with-a-text-file/24021243#24021243).

---

I am pretty sure the OP has no idea of how to go about doing this, but for the sake of not getting flagged as *This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.*, he just added a random example because there was no flag that covered this type of question at the moment.

Comment: @pnuts... sorry, it was to the question, which got edited.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to catch a lot of flak for this, but I don't believe that this warrants a close reason on its own.

Here are a few reasons why I feel this way.

##Conveys a negative message

Putting a question *on hold* is meant to [allow the OP to work out deficiencies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) in their questions, with the message being, "If you can edit the question to better fit [the] model, we can get you the help you need."

Putting a question on hold because it lacks sufficient information to answer the question is concise and respectful.  So they didn't include the stack trace that they said they were suffering from.  The close reason (along with a half a dozen comments) will tell them such.

Putting a question on hold because it was unclear as to what they were asking is concise and respectful.  Their question contained a lot of technobabble that wasn't really related to their problem, so the hope/prayer is that the question will be edited into an answerable state.

Putting a question on hold because the person doesn't have a "minimal understanding" of a problem feels like a slap to the face.  The primary reason that they're *asking* anything in the first place is that they don't have an understanding of something.

Now, I'd argue that someone who asked why `String word = "word"; System.out.println(word == "word");` returned false simply [didn't do the research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1079354), or if they're getting some kind of obscure stack trace that comes up within the first five search results simply didn't bother to look it up.  The former really should be closed as a duplicate, and the latter should simply be downvoted, which sends a clear-enough signal that the question is **not useful to the community**.

Questions that warranted that closure reason in the past were usually downvoted to oblivion anyway.  Sending the double-whammy seems...overkill here.

##Open to abuse

I'll admit that the accuracy of question closure ain't much to be proud of, and it wasn't really much of anything to celebrate when this close reason *did* exist.  But, with the list of titles you're providing here, I'll show you why "Lacks Minimal Understanding" isn't correct to apply here.

- jQuery parallexUiSlider plugin problem, can't find the bug.

  - If the specific part of the problem isn't well isolated; that is, if a whole bunch of code is posted and nothing else, it should be closed as **lacks sufficient detail**.
  - If the question is an abstract description of the problem, it *might* warrant closing as **unclear what you're asking**.
- Why if statement failing in Python?

  - Probably some rookie misunderstanding the falsy nature of booleans in Python.  It happens.  I wouldn't bother closing it; rather, look for a duplicate.
- Regular expression for telephone not working.

  - If there's no regex or no test data, **lacks sufficient detail**.
- JS function in jquery bug.

  - If there's too much code such that the problem isn't isolated, again, **unclear what you're asking**.  Question needs to be narrowed.
- Button click not working.
- pop is not working properly.
- Java program in course not working.

  - These all merit the same response for me; if there's insufficient detail, it should be closed as such.  If there's too much code such that the scope is too broad, it should be closed as such.

##Kind of feels like a "quick fix" which doesn't fix anything

A lot of the questions that I see that would fall under your criteria for closure under this are often misunderstood XY problems, or poorly-phrased questions.  The knee-jerk reaction to a question like these is to close them, but they probably really need to be edited into shape, or get better clarification from the OP instead.  Closing them without really looking at why this question was *asked* in the first place doesn't prevent people from asking bad questions; it only preserves their ignorance.

---

So...pretty much what I said above places me in the firm "no" category on this suggestion.

Comment: *"Conveys a negative message"* **Yeah, that's the idea.** The rest of your objections are possibly valid, though.

Comment: So sick of people complaining about the posts at SO. We need a thread complaining about the threads complaining about the decline in the quality of threads. Get over it people: it's not 2009, and the site was probably never as good as you think it was, you are just confabulating nostalgia. Perhaps make another site for people who already know everything and the questions can be immediately published in Nature and get you that great job you are hankering for.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I don't disagree that this is the intent.  However, I disagree with the intent.  Downvoting prevents the question from more experts seeing it and being dissatisfied with the contents (as well as it appearing on the main screen).  Closing it indicates that either the question was a duplicate, is off topic, or is deficient in some manner.  Those questions that are simply deficient and have a snowball's chance of being salvaged **should be**; those that aren't should be downvoted into oblivion.  In my mind, downvoting sends the clearer message.

Comment: Honestly, I'm confused by your comment. I read it a couple of times, and I still don't know what you mean. What I do know is this: I am all for closing *and* downvoting bad questions. I don't think either one is sufficient.

Comment: @Cody Why do you think it is not sufficient?

Comment: @Trilarion [Why downvoting on questions that are sure to get close or flagged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229418) covers at least *some* of the versions; there are others, I'm too lazy to list them all out at the moment.

Comment: @Makoto `if there's insufficient detail, it should be closed as such` - there isn't insufficient detail. The whole source code is - technically - all you need to diagnose the problem. Also, the question is not *too broad*. It's usually extremely specific and I guess that's what OP is trying to tell us. You may use one of these reasons, but they simply don't match the actual problem.

Comment: @neuronet I have a better idea: how about visitors to our community function within that community, or THEY can make their own site. You don't come to an established community and demand they accept your idea of what the community should be like. This site was made for a reason, with a purpose in mind, and there is absolutely no reason we should abandon those principles for the sake of appeasing people who can't be asked to participate. We don't *need* them, they need us. So your attitude is completely backward.

Comment: @Chris as long as the whining about the good old days stays in meta, it's fine. The old timers can get their catharsis and slap each other on the back and talk about how things used to be, while SO keeps its focus on programming. Isn't that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @neuronet easy to walk in as a relative newcomer and be irreverent and snarky, I'm sure. The "old timers", however, have a lot more of their time invested. What you dismissively refer to as whining, reasonable adults call discussion, and if it weren't for such discussions this place would not exist for you to leave your affected blase troll comments. It isn't about "good old days", it is about maintaining the standards that differentiate this place from other widely available resources on the internet. This place has a purpose, and hosting garbage threads noising up Google results isn't it

Comment: @Chris I pretty much agree, I just think it's a Quixotic quest, given what SO has become. Unless measures are taken that are WAY more drastic than adding another reason to close a thread.

Comment: @CodyGray:  What I mean by my comment:   the intent is to be negative, whereas I don't feel that question closure is intended to be.  That's where I'm drawing my disagreement from primarily.  It feels like you're trying to tell the user that they're wrong and bad and should feel bad for not having "minimal understanding".  Other closure reasons have a similar, yet less harsh overall tone to them.

Comment: @neuronet I haven't seen anyone arguing seriously for the "good old days", so the attack you're constructing is a straw man. We are arguing against the current state of the site, and the trajectory it is on. We want to *improve* things *for the better*, not return to some former state.

Comment: I suppose I see that, @Makoto. I think, though, that this closure reason is special. It probably is "meaner" or "more harsh" than some of the other reasons, but it should only be used in cases where that harshness is deserved. Surely you have to admit there are such cases.

Comment: If a whole bunch of code is posted, that isn't really "lacks sufficient detail"; the problem is, there is altogether *too much* detail. The question is swamped by irrelevant details.

Answer (score 2):

Developing on my comments moments ago, I think we cannot have it as a close reason again (as much as it pains me to admit it).  I see two scenarios, the first of which is the only viable one currently

1. Downvote it.  The OP does not have any idea what they are talking about.  That is why it is -10.
2. Delete it.  We don't do that here although this might be the logical conclusion to the problem.  I say delete not close because as I was pointing out before the OP likely does not have the capability in the near future to improve the question.  Too Broad?  Can be improved!  Duplicate?  Can be improved if you can prove your question is slightly different!  Unclear?  Can be improved!

Comment: The problem with downvotes is PRECISELY that they are not a descriptive enough feedback channel, nowhere near as descriptive as closure reasons. Perhaps that's the problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Maybe the downvote default text needs to be more visible to the person that was downvoted. When i downvote, it's because the question is unclear or not useful. If the user doesn't understand that, they probably can't be helped anyway. Move on to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a perfectly valid reason in *hindsight* for the ones *closing* the question, "Lacks Minimal Understanding" is not specific enough as *feedback* for the asker (as mentioned by @Robert Cartaino) and therefore not likely to *prevent* further such questions from being asked.

The second problem is that questions voted for closure would take a certain amount of time before they are reviewed by a moderator. *Downvotes and comments can reach a question a lot faster than an actual closure could, and **may provide an opportunity to flag bad questions***, that hasn't been used yet.

### Suggested Alternative: Make downvotes more informative

Regardless of what the intentions behind designing the downvote and flag/close systems were, people who post poorly-informed questions also **do not see downvotes as an incentive** to improve the questions (see the pattern, they are not extracting useful information from visible symptoms).

If downvotes do not appear good enough to stop the onslaught of poorly informed questions (and if a new close reason appears to be required), then perhaps the solution is to MAKE THE DOWNVOTES JUST AS INFORMATIVE AS FLAG/CLOSE REASONS.

> **Throw up a small list of reasons the user MAY select when downvoting**
>   **the question:** 
> 1. Does not provide sufficient detail to recreate
>   the problem 
> 2. Does not narrow down the scope of the
>   question/problem 
> 3. Can be solved by use of a compiler/debugger
>   
> 4. RTFM

**People are far more likely to click a checkbox** when downvoting than spending time to write a detailed comment. Keeping this *optional* makes sure the general pace of interaction with the site is not affected.

> If a question gets a minimum number of downvotes, show a big banner above the question:
>
> "This question has been downvoted by the community due to being
>   xxxxx",

where "xxxx" is the most popular reason for the downvotes. The banner marks just as big a warning sign as a "closed question" banner usually is, that these kinds of questions need to be improved before being acceptable on SO.

Additionally, **a tooltip for the downvote button** could show *all* the reasons selected so far by users (not just the top reason) for downvoting this question. This would be especially useful for questions with that don't have enough downvotes to trigger a "Downvoted by community" banner. It would provide **quick, low-moderation-effort** **constructive criticism** for users who want to improve their questions, without embarassing them with a big banner.

#### Afterthought: Implication for "flagging" workflow

To be perfectly honest, I haven't used the "flag" function thus far, and always associated that with "spam"/inflammatory posts rather than ones with a quality issue. **My primary tool for calling out** a question or answer's quality **is by using the downvote**, and sometimes, when there is hope for improvement, a comment.

I suspect a lot of other users - especially low-medium activity users like myself who haven't necessarily read all the rules, came here on a "drive-by shooting" and stuck as they found the community to be more and more useful - also see the flag button the same way and continue to use the downvote exclusively for question-quality issues.

And some of that confusion, as much as it does owe to not all users RTFM, also stems from the fact that **there IS an overlap in the function of the downvote and flag buttons around the issue of quality**, and perhaps it's time to remove that.

Two steps in this direction would be:

I. Remove "this question does not meet the site's standards" from the reasons list provided for "flagging" a question. This would mark a clear separation between the INTENT of flagging a question versus down-voting it.

II. Let downvoted questions populate a separate queue for **closure** by moderators, being separate from questions *flagged* for being spam/promotional or posts for being inflammatory. All this might make prioritization of attention a little simpler.

Disclaimers: 

- I do not know what workflow the moderators see, so my recommendation on separating flagging/downvotes is based on my browsing a few other questions/wiki related to this, and guesswork. Also I understand this would imply truly major changes, and I may not understand the implications of it. This is why it is mentioned as an **afterthought**.

- My primary suggestion of making downvotes more informative, **still stands.**

Comment: I'm suggesting this as a functional ALTERNATIVE to bringing back the "Lacks minimal understanding" close reason. My point is that the need for LMU cannot be addressed by close reasons, but by the method I've suggested. So I don't see the discussion addressing this fact if it is posted in a separate thread.

Comment: Down-voting, closing, flagging are different things. Closing/flagging is for post that need to be removed for some reason or the other. Down-voting is marking a post as bad and/or incorrect, but not necessarily off-topic for the site. But of course, down-voting and closing/flagging can be combined.

Comment: Yes but my point is that bad questions ARE down-voted too, might as well use that as a tool to fight them, with meaningful, timely information, instead of relying just on closure which definitely takes more time and effort than downvotes do. Also, downvotes provide an opportunity for the asker to improve the question. Right now improvement depends on somebody posting a helpful comment as to WHAT needs to be improved. Why not use downvotes (used/abused more widely than comments) to provide that information instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems clear that, for whatever reason, probably to do with the "Summer of Love", "Lacks Minimal Understanding" is unlikely to make a return.

My proposed solution is this:

Stop worrying about the close reason, and use **Too broad** as an abbreviation for "The subject in question is too broad for your minimal level of understanding".

Comment: Too broad means it covers too much, not 'it covers something you don't understand'.

Comment: @justcool393 I **know** what it currently means. I'm suggesting that it is used to mean something additional

Answer (score -2):

**Questions should be answered or closed based on their content, not the OP's ability to interpret the answer.**

I do not feel we need a close reason for these questions.

- They are on topic and answerable.
- If you don't like them, don't answer them.
- If you feel they are not useful, downvote them.
- If you feel the OP didn't do enough research, downvote them.
- If you feel it is too broad, vote to close it as too broad.
- If it is missing important information that would be needed to answer it, close it as such.

We don't need another close reason for this. Adding another close reason won't stop users from answering them before they are closed (if they even ever reach closed status) which means there is little to no penalty to the OP since they received the answer they were looking for. Downvotes are far more effective than close votes because they immediately impact the question, can lead to a question ban, and with changes mentioned in the recent podcast downvotes will impact whether or not the questions appear on the front page making them that much more effective than close votes.

Working as intended, no change needed.

---

Now if only we could figure out how to give downvotes equal weight to upvotes so that a user doesn't gain reputation when a question has been upvoted and downvoted one-two times each.

Comment: If you want a close reason for these questions, find a close reason that closes it due to it's content.

Answer (score -2):

I actually like one of the old close reasons from Mathematics SE:

> **This question is missing context or other details:** Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

(The text has since been changed, which I don't agree with).

This fits with the new Code of Conduct in that it's not condescending at all. It also gives the OP specific guidance and a specific rationale for why they should edit.

Comment: And this isn't covered by "Too Broad" or the "Why isn't my code working" close reasons because...?

Comment: @Makoto "Gimme teh codez" questions

Comment: ...which are too broad, are they not?  What prose exists in the universe to convince someone who only wants "teh codez" to not think like that?!

Comment: @Makoto Not all questions that show zero research effort are too broad, nor are all of them debugging questions. This close reason is a lot less condescending than, for example, "you could Google this in 5 seconds," "this question shows no understanding of the problem domain," or "you clearly put forth no effort whatsoever to solve this."

Comment: A "gimme teh codez" question is *also* a question with zero [research] effort, but a zero [research] effort question isn't just a "gimme teh codez" question.  I understand where that's coming from but my response is explicitly scoped to the aforementioned "gimme teh codez"-style questions.

Comment: @Makoto That's true. I realized after my original comment that I really should have included zero research effort questions in general (not just "gimme teh codez" questions, which are a proper subset of zero research effort questions in general).

Answer (score -3):

Okay, I'm going to make my comment into an answer here:

**For quite a few of these questions, it seems like you're describing *too localized*.**

Really. For quite a few of these, they're not typos, and they don't fit any other close reason. However, **no one is going to ever need to look at these.** Why? They mainly haven't debugged their code, or they haven't done something, and it's a *simple* error.

Now, the problem with these close reasons is that they [get horribly abused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185102/responding-to-your-too-localized-concerns) by [people who don't understand them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow).

The main problem with the lacks minimal understanding one was that people took it to mean *effort* was required in a question. With too localized, it was just confusing and weird.

Therefore, I propose a different variation on Too Localized. Less confusing, but getting the point across.

> This question appears to be off-topic because **it is unlikely to help future visitors.**

... and then something else after that. I'm not a wordsmith, but I think that helps because it works for those questions where no one will ever visit it again after it's answered.

Comment: I think "unlikely to help future visitors" is a very dangerous path to go down for what it's worth.

Comment: There might be other visitors in the future with exactly the same beginner questions (although they probably wouldn't find them).

Comment: Variants of "too localized" have the problem that questions in niche topics sometimes seem to be unfairly closed. Just because a question is of no interest to 99% of the community doesn't mean that the question isn't vitally important to a 1% minority who happen to work in an exotic language or ancient legacy framework.

Comment: It's not enough to say "unlikely to help future readers" - you have to at least have some idea of *why* it won't help them, or you end up with what DNA describes. We [tried to figure out a general-purpose way of expressing that idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132319/consider-changing-the-wording-of-the-too-localized-close-reason) for a long time before removing TL, without much to show for it. \

Comment: There are good questions that are just simply about niche tags and there is no one at the present time who knows the answer.  Is this too localized because the material, although possibly well presented, is too obscure?  Such questions are likely to have low views and stay at 0, neither upvoted or downvoted.  However they could be fit into the above proposal

Comment: @demongolem That's... not what I was saying. I'm not sure how to word it in a way that people won't misinterpret it (that was the problem with TL), but mainly what I'm trying to get across is it's for these questions that no one will ever look at again. Not because their in a low traffic tag, but because the *solution* was *only related to their **specific** problem, and no one will ever come across that problem again*. Mainly problems due to not debugging, etc.

Comment: @Shog9 That's what I realized when crafting this answer. I tried to come up with a good close reason for it... but I just couldn't. I'm not sure why, but I can't explain why it's not useful to other people working with the same language...

Answer (score -17):

As mentioned, several of the mentioned questions are covered. But there *are* questions which actually show that the person asking this question actually *does* lack minimal understanding *and* the respect to the people which are supposed to answer it. While I do understand that it is necessary to be polite as a community, the more SO gets popular it is equally important to not have it polluted by those "please-do-my-work-for-me-as-I-do-not-care-about-understanding-it" questions - and to make it chrystal clear that these kind of questions are not tolerated if not conforming the community rules. So my suggestion would be:

> #### Question violates community guidelines in its current form.
>
> Please be so kind to ask it [in a smart way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html),
> which will greatly improve your chance of getting an equally smart answer.

The funny thing is that [ESR actually added a section on SO](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#stackoverflow) just over a week ago.

Comment: This reason would literally apply to any reason to close / downvote the question. It doesn't really explain what's wrong with the question at all - it's about as good as replacing all close reasons with "There's something wrong with your question. See [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)".

Comment: Well, I don't think so, as it is a rebuke subtle enough not to raise any bad feelings but clear enough that there was simply not enough effort put into the question, exceeding what is tolerable. But it was just a suggestion and let's agree to disagree ;)

Comment: @Markus, people come to have questions answered. Many of those people have good intentions but don't know the guidelines. Getting this message means they not only won't have answers, but even if they *wanted* to put effort in to improving their answer they aren't any better off than before their question got closed because this doesn't give them any information on what's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: @jmac, thats why I added the link...

Comment: Yes, but people unlikely to have searched for solutions to their problem are just as unlikely to go to another link and read the rules. Even if they do not care, stating the problem with a reasonable amount of specificity ON THE PAGE (instead of linking out) can at least inform future users (at one glance) as to what they need to do to get any similar questions answered.

Answer (score -23):

I think a lot you need to take a step back and realize ... "You simply don't have to answer the question".

So a question may not be worded to your high standards ... just ignore it. It might help to realize the world does not revolve around you. There might be people who have questions that you think are stupid or "lame" ... so what? At one point in your career you may have actually asked what others considered a stupid question.

Stack Overflow seems to be increasingly filled with those who feel the "knowledge peasants" need to be "put down". Try some humility and in those times that others ask questions that you feel are beneath you or perhaps not up to the standards you would hold for yourself ... just don't answer. It really is that simple.

Only a child would respond with the "Search Google next time". You know, it might just actually be that someone did search Google and didn't understand the results as you did. I know it may be a big shock, but how you understand things may not be how others understand them.

Comment: Ignoring the problem doesn't make it go away, it always manage to catch you up and bite your behinds when you aren't paying attention.

Comment: SO was created on the premise of having a high standard of quality for questions.  If you aren't willing to post questions up to the site's high standards then you can feel free to *not ask questions here*.  Demanding that other users not uphold the high standards of quality that is *the foundational basis* of the site just for your benefit is rather arrogant.

Comment: It's not "your" problem. You can just not answer it.

Comment: So, because *you* want, we have to make the site worse for everyone else? Nope.

Comment: @webworm Making the site a worse place *is* our problem, and just "not answering it" doesn't solve that problem.

Comment: "You know, it might just actually be that someone did search Google and didn't understand the results as you did" It's _really easy_ to make this clear when you post a question -- and it generally makes a really good SO question to ask about things you genuinely tried but failed to understand. But you have to actually do it first. Another form of childish behavior is "Of course I did my homework!" "Great, can you demonstrate the answer to problem 5?" "Uh, well, the dog ate it."

Comment: So now people need to prove to you that they researched this before they dare ask a question? My goodness your arrogance is astounding!

Comment: @webworm How is it arrogant to expect people to demonstrate their research when asking their question?  On the other hand, expecting others to answer your poorly researched question, and refusing to follow the rules of the site that you're asking to provide quality answers to your question, for free,  is astoundingly arrogant.

Comment: @Servy - That is the point ... no one is "expecting" anything but you. If you don't think the question is worth your precious time then don't answer it. But don't shut the question down because there may be others whose ego can fit through the door and might actually want to help someone else. What proof do you require of a question in order for it to pass your ban filter? Must someone turn over their search history so you can verify that they have performed due diligence before the question can pass by your haughty gaze?

Comment: @webworm But you're *are* expecting things.  You're expecting the site to not enforce it's rules, you're expecting the site to act against its values, and you're expecting bad questions to be welcome here, even though the sites rules specifically state that they're not.  You *don't* have a reasonable expectation of being able to ask any question that you want and have it stay on the site for anyone to answer.  The site was *specifically* created to *not* be that, because that system doesn't work.  The site was created to have a high standard of quality that questions must meet to remain here.

Comment: If you are unwilling or unable, to meet that standard of quality, there are lots of other sites out there that have no such standard.  In fact, virtually every other Q/A site out there has no such standard of quality; people come to SO specifically because it *does* have such standards.

Comment: Keep telling yourself that next time you are looking for some help and can't figure out the answer .. oh wait .. that never happens to you does it.

Comment: How does this answer the question that you posted this "answer"/rant on? Please read the answers on [Why are Stack Overflow users more passionate about Stack Overflow than helping people?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315018/1324033)  Particularly Pekka and Yakk's answers.

Comment: You need only not answer the questions that do not meet your "standards". Why not leave them there for others to answer? If they are not deemed well written then they will not be up-voted and therefore will not rise to the top. Shutting the questions down, leaving no chance of an answer, helps nobody.