# What happens "behind the scenes" when a post is tagged with [feature-request]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

So, what actually happens when a post is tagged with [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?

I mean, do the elf Mods talk to the head of Santa Exchange about the new request, and if he thinks it's a good idea someone internally gets put to work and the post gets tagged with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

<sup>(@Mods No offense intended; just some light hearted humour.)</sup>

Comment: The Stack Exchange devs have a tool that lists `feature-request`-tagged posts across the network, I believe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So who decides whether the request should be implemented or not?

Comment: @Sam The Stack Exchange team.

Comment: @hichris123 So I guess that means *all* members? Or just the managers/team leaders?

Comment: +1 for a Meta post that's not complaining about something!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Moderators are not directly involved at all with whether or not a feature request is acted upon, although if we support something strongly, we can nudge them more to try and get it implemented (no guarantees). If a feature request is outright silly and we know, for sure, it would never be implemented, we will decline them as a way of indicating to the Stack Exchange team that they don't actually need to look at this one, but past that, it's entirely the Stack Exchange team that decides what gets implemented.

The Stack Exchange team itself tends to avoid participating in feature request discussions until it's been discussed more by the community. They look for a clear-cut problem that's being solved and reasons why this feature is a solution to that problem. They'd generally be discussed internally at a staff meeting in order to determine the merits as far as statistics and other things that normal users wouldn't quite be able to pinpoint. If they feel it warrants a response, they'll give one.

The team is not always working on every feature request. Generally, if it hasn't been declined it's still being considered, but that *does not mean* it's being worked on. They prioritize feature development based on urgency and necessity, only working on a handful at a time, some of which probably weren't even requested on a Meta site anywhere.

So nothing really "happens" - they keep an eye on them across all the Meta sites, and have a general idea of what features the community desires. More importantly, they have an idea of what problems the community is having. And there you have your key, **the problems**. Proposed solutions are great and all, but identifying the actual problem behind something allows the team to implement solutions that target that specific problem, rather than solutions that just kind of cover it up.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Does an accepted answer influence/affect a feature request at all? [Here's a long standing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/add-increase-decrease-tab-indent-buttons-to-the-editor-toolbar) which hasn't been accepted/declined but has an accepted answer.

Comment: @AD7six It can cause some confusion as to whether the request has been handled or not. You'd generally accept an answer to a feature request because a) it's been implemented and someone posted the implementation details or b) someone identified that the feature is not needed after all, explaining why. We actively encourage users **not** to accept answers on feature requests that haven't been acknowledged for this very reason.

Comment: In other words: the community is fully at the mercy of the company operating SE. Don't get me wrong, I have nothing against it. But it should also be stated as clearly as possible.

Comment: @Trilarion But the company operating SE has an intrinsic need to appease the community.  It's not a one-way street; without users SE is dead in the water.

Comment: @Dropped Yes, that is true. Nevertheless the goals are only common to some extent. If the community wants something really badly there is nothing it can actively do to make it happen short of moving out. It's an asymmetric relationship and we should not conceal it. One of the more extreme examples [Can we please have the “Lacks Minimal Understanding” close reason back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back) = Overwhelming support, a technical triviality and it won't happen.

Comment: @Trilarion True, but I don't think it's as malicious as you have framed it.  I think they probably take the position, better to move less and have it be the right move, than to move more often and disrupt the balance they already have in place.  You're right though, the community can only operate inside the constraints the developers give us.

Comment: This describes fundamental software design and project management principles. Identify the **problems** of users and find a solution that solves them. Listen to user feedback because the user is trying to communicate a problem they have (and often doing a poor job of it). Flushing out and understanding the problem is your first priority; then you can think about solutions, both proposed and ones your users never thought of. Every user here should be doing all they can to emulate the StackExchange team. =) This should be a canonical answer on some software design question.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be nice if SO, or SE if it's applicable across sites, had a public [Trello](https://trello.com/) board (or something similar) with details of their roadmap or at least a list of public feature requests from meta sites broken down in to categories like:

- Proposed (question asked)
- In Discussion
- Rejected
- Approved
- Implementing
- Complete

I know there is the regular podcast, but this would be near real time, so if you make a suggestion it shows up as soon as it's picked up and you could track it's progress on there rather than make a suggestion and leave a question open for months waiting for something to happen... or not happen as the case may be.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109712/is-the-stack-exchange-team-using-trello) (be it a couple of years old) seems to suggest that they don't use Trello, but they could!!!

Comment: There are [nearly 13,000 open feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-bydesign+-status-declined+-status-norepro+-status-planned+-status-review+-status-reproduced+-status-deferred). That's a lot. What would be the benefit of putting these 13k (plus all site-specific meta feature-requests) on a Trello board?

Comment: @jmac wow, that many! It would be a very busy board indeed :-) I think the search link you posted above kind of covers what i'm looking for without being on trellis. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot. It can help to look at the highly voted ones (just add `score:100` on the end of that search), or to look at the oldest ones (add `created:2000-01-01..2011-01-01` for instance). And if you find some duplicates, or completed ones, you can take care of 'em. And don't forget to [Vote Early and Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)!