# More AI when questions asked and answers answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers, asking-questions

After writing an answer to [Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258251/lets-improve-the-how-to-ask-pages/258333#258333) and thinking about [Shog9s](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) comment on [Does the broken window theory apply to closing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions/258348#258348)

> [..] is the root of the issue here; any solution that doesn't stand
>   between an asker and his answer is destined to fail.

I thought this sums it all up quite well, and that we should start experimenting with this assumption.

The idea is that the majority of bad questions comes from the fact that asking bad questions is *effortless*. Nothing prevents you from ignoring all of the advices people give in comments, via down and close votes, nothing forces you to read any of the howto documentation. Sure there is some stuff around when you write questions, but its easy to ignore that too. My hope here is that from those people there is a big enough amount that doesn't do this out of malicious intent, but due to pure, well, lets say "noobishness" or whatever you want to call it like. They never learned to read documentation properly, or do research properly, or to debug properly. They are used to just ask somewhere and get an answer and not bother whats around them.

*Maybe we can get them on the track of our community by screaming loud into their face what they are doing wrong*.

We all love good old clippy, don't we? </sarcasm> (I wonder how many downvotes this image will get me)

[image]

The basic idea behind this isn't that bad: The context is detected, intention inferred, and acted upon. Now of course we don't need clippy or a question writing assistant, I just wanted to add an image to the question. Ok, seriously, we might want to do something similar: Extract information out of the post, infer something about it, and then act accordingly. In this case:

*Add barriers to actually posting a question (or an answer)*

The main idea here is at the point where the users clicks on the post button, the analysis is done, and some popup may appear telling something, and giving the option to get back and edit, or abandon completely.
Some of those following might be restricted by low reputation (either as a whole or by tag) or a users posting history. Actual limits should be proposed after some analysis of reputation levels of people prone to such posts.

Parts of this can be found in [Should we peer review questions before publishing them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them) too so for details maybe there is inspiration too. I will try to be as complete as I can/want, even if it overlaps with that question.

The order of the following points has no meaning at all, and the formulation is just to transport the message and not meant as the real text that should appear.

#### Analysis for source code domination

Using similar techniques as bayer spam filters (or maybe others) it should be possible to detect if the majority of lines is code, or if there is a block of code. Further analysis could then lead to possible popups like (for questions):

- It looks like you are having a block of code there that is not formatted as such. Did you know [insert short introduction into markup for code blocks]. *Do you want to go back and improve the format of your post*
- It looks like your question contains [insert quantification such as "mostly" or "over 90%"] code, are you sure that you described your problem correctly? [insert short info about how much code isnt per se bad, but might be an indication of not describing the problem good enough. Add link and info to sscce.org]

for answers (especially when introduced via "try this"):

- It looks like this answer is mostly code. You might want to explain why this answers the question, and how it might improve on the questions original code.

#### Analysis for urls

This is mostly for detection of link only answers, but maybe someone has an idea for questions too. Detection would be for domination of the text by a link.

We have a standard text in the review queue for link only answer comments. Use that for a popup and ask *Do you want to describe the contents of the link a bit more* or similar.

#### Thank you and I have this problem too answers

The mods probably have better tools to figure out good patterns, but I think a lot of those questions are easily detectable by just scannig for "having problem too" words occuring near to each other. The text should say something like

*You are posting an answer. Starting an answer with "I have this problem too" or similar is a strong indicator that you do not have an answer. If this is an actual answer and you just wanted to say that you had that problem to, try starting it with "I solved the problem in the following way":*

Options should be/indicate

- This is a real answer, post as is
- Let me go back and edit, this is a real answer but the suggested formulation is good
- Oh, you are right, don't post this at all
- I have a question and this is really a slightly different one, please put this into an "ask question" form and let me start there

For "thank you" answers, it should probably only tell a bit (just like the review queue standard comment) about not to post thank you comments, and that you say thank you by upvoting/accepting.

#### Detecting duplicates

Ok, this is probably really hard. Although we have already the "Similar Questions" sidebar (and whoever knows how that works, it doesn't seem to take tags into account) having an algorithm that finds really good similarities won't be easy, but that isn't really necessary and already triggering by not "perfect" duplicates is good enough.

The text should ask if the question it mentions, links to, and maybe shows (as an excerpt?) is maybe a duplicate. The poster then can chose various options:

- Don't post the question. Get me to the question instead where I can upvote/comment.
- Post the question anyways, but let me explain why it is not a duplicate (offer a small input box for the explanation, add to the question text a link to the possible duplicate along with the explanation.
- Post it, the algorithm fubard, it is not a duplicate at all.

#### Similar answers

This might be a pure (edit-distance)/(word count) metric that would be there mostly for exact same code answers or plain plagiarism. It might also look for if posts contain the same links or similar keywords. It would say something like

*The answer is similar to another answer [include answer or excerpt], are you sure it will add value/quality to this site? You might want to improve on it and elaborate a bit.* Options would be:

- Let me go back and edit
- Post it anyways, I need the rep

#### Late answers

The same algorithm used to put things into the review queue might want to warn the user. It might also add something like the metric (with a different broader barrier) for similar answers to its trigger level. Additionally it wants to take into account the amount of already given answers. It might say something like:

*The question you are about to answer has X answers already and exists for N months. Are you sure that you are adding value/content/quality that is not already in any of the other answers?*

#### Possible Comments

Analysis of existing delete votes for answers that should have been comments might give away better patterns, but it seems that they are at most two sentences, with at least one of them ending with a question mark. For those the text reads like:

*You seem to be asking for clarification rather than posting an actual answer.*

Depending on the ability of the user to comment it would then show

*If this is the case, please add a comment to the question instead*

for the case the user can not comment, maybe an explanation why its bad and would be deleted anyways.

Options then would be:
* yes please make this a comment
* dont post it
* post it anyways, its a real answer

#### Short questions and answers

Here the text might be something like
* Your question/answer is relatively short. While it might well be possible that it {answers the question,is a good question} you might want to step back, read it, and look if it needs to be elaborated.*

Options would then lead back to edit again or post anyways.

### For all of them

Have the dialogues vary a bit in their actual question to ask and the position and meaning of the buttons. Have "yes" sometimes mean "post anyways" and sometimes mean "let me go back and edit". This way we force people to actually read a bit of the dialogue text. We might want to have various formulations for the same thing, and keep statistics of which leads to the most percentage of abandoned posts. E.g. keep the wording that lets people abandon posting "thank you" answers for 87% of the detected, but ditch the wording that only lets them abandon wording in 44% of all cases.

Important here is that to not break too much, to always have a "do it anyways" option. This will prevent the possibility that the detection has a false positive and prevents some legit content to be posted. Clicking on an additional button shouldn't be too much of a deal for people that errenously were caught by that algorithm.

All of these analysis might be useful for automatically putting things into review queues too, and the other way round, maybe some of those that put things into review queues might be useful for such dialogues.

PS: It might be that some of those are already there, if so please point them out. I am rarely posting questions, and probably/hopefully even more rarely some that would fall into any of these, so I might never have noticed.

PPS: Of course you can make your own suggestions. After all, [these ideas will be read by SE employees and they decide what they want to implement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258365/what-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-a-post-is-tagged-with-feature-request).

Comment: And as a last resort, "We noticed you pressed the "Continue" button 5 times in a row inside 3 seconds. You probably did not read the advice. Click **here** to go back to Step 1".

Comment: Mr. Clippy doesn't like being borrowed from [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips)

Comment: Nah, we need the clippycorn ! http://i.stack.imgur.com/RlcQV.png

Comment: https://www.smore.com/clippy-js

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if the broken window theory applies (it probably does), but if I may summarize your position in a sentence, "There are all sorts of opt-in resources available to help people ask less inappropriate questions, but I think only those matter that stand between the user and making the post." I see 10 upvotes next to '''And as a last resort, "We noticed you pressed the "Continue" button 5 times in a row inside 3 seconds. You probably did not read the advice. Click here to go back to Step 1".''' It wasn't written by you, but it fits your advice and your irritation perfectly.

The closest analogy I have read to your question is an *A List Apart* article summarized in its title, **[Never use a warning when you mean, "Undo"](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning)**. Now there are important differences, but the research and findings apply as well as if the article had almost been writing a response to your question. It begins:

> Have you ever had that sinking feeling when you realize—just a split second too late—that you shouldn’t have clicked “Okay” in the “Are you sure you want to quit?” dialog?
>
> Yes? Well, you’re in good company—everybody has had a similar experience, so there’s no need to feel ashamed about it. It’s not your fault: it’s your software’s fault.
>
> Why? Because software should “know” that we form habits. Software should know that after clicking “Okay” countless times in response to the question, we’ll probably click “Okay” this time too, even if we don’t mean to. Software should know that we won’t have a chance to think before accidentally throwing our work away.
>
> Why should it know these things? Because software designers should know that we form habits, whether we want to or not.
>
> Habit formation is actually good thing: it saves us the trouble of having to think when confronted with interface banalities and it lessens the probability that our train of thought will get derailed. In the case of the “Are you sure you want to quit?” dialog, our hands have memorized close-and-click as a single continuous gesture. That’s good, because most of the time we don’t want to think about the question—we just do the right thing. Unfortunately, our habits sometimes make us do the wrong thing: we don’t even have time to realize our mistake until after we’ve made it.
>
> So, as designers we are led to a general interface principle: If an interface is to be humane, it must respect habituation.

My point in bringing in this up is that any and all measures such as you describe are subject to habituation. Including, perhaps, pressing "Continue" x times within y seconds; people will habituate and count up enough time in their watch to pass the check for "enough seconds between first and last Continue" buttons being clicked.

There are two obvious takeaways:

1. As is discussed in the article, we should not apply more force to defeat habituation. ("Hall of Shame" type solution: require users to type a different letter of the keyboard to go on to the next step. This does not work like wishful thinking would have it; it just results in habituation with added annoyance and anger.)
2. What would work in reducing the problem, without shutting people out immediately or completely, is a system of anti-privileges from anti-badges. This could include throttling posting privileges in some degree. Or, os the server side, page load time could progressively be slowed: people who habituate and ignore (like the rest of us) may think twice if page loads get slower and slower for each bad post.

I'm not completely sure what is appropriate here, but I'd be crossing my fingers a little to claim complete agreement with the OP, even though the OP has a gripe that's on lots of people's chests. In the non-hostile context of [Never say a warning when you mean, "Undo"](http://alistapart.com/article/neveruseawarning), structuring software to gracefully allow recovery when you do something wrong and realize what you did was wrong; warnings are simply no adequate substitute to the harder job of facilitating graceful recovery.

The immediate application is that the only response I see that not be partly neutralized by habituation is force that throttles or stops the user from certain conduct. Now the Clippy response is appropriate here; so might be other changes like making it much more obvious how to mark a pasted input as code (question: can SO's software distinguish pasting a block of code from pasting text from a natural language), but the basic approaches sounds carefully thought out, probably undersells the OP's irritation considerably, and in my opinion will only work if they are non-optional, perhaps due to anti-privileges.

Would it be productive to make an anti-privilege, anti-badge system?

Comment: Your post ends with a question mark. Did you mean to ask a question? +1, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the question. It was an answer that turned into a question: optional deterrents are just that, optional; leading to a followup that should perhaps be stated as a separate question: what non-optional anti-privileges might stop people from keeping on doing the wrong thing?

Comment: I got an idea while reading, maybe a dialog box saying "You are almost finished to post your question, click okey to delete it all and start again" would be helpful ;)