# Newbie "forgiveness"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users

(To put it in the form of a question)

Doesn't SO need some sort of "newbie forgiveness"?  I see many cases where a newbie asks a very poorly constructed question and instantly gets downvoted and closed.  Not that this shouldn't occur, but it means that any points the newbie had are stripped away, no doubt creating a lot of ill will.

Yes, a substantial fraction (maybe the majority) of newbies are ultimately not sufficiently competent to stay here, but we're no doubt scaring away a fair number that will eventually develop into excellent programmers.

Could there be some scheme whereby downvotes and other negative points somehow don't count, and newbies are given extra points for any upvote and for being responsive to comments?

(Perhaps there is already something along these lines, but I don't know of it.)

Comment: Hmm.. How about something in extra bold that reads: _We actively solicit poor content from newbies_.

Comment: BTW, repwhores (read _enthusiasts_) always upvote such terrible questions when answering those.

Comment: Haha!  You'd probably go on to call a newbie rapist a _therapist_.

Comment: (There are some who already agree with what you propose.  I see one upvote here.)

Comment: This is already in place; your rep can't get below 1.

Comment: I hope that the downvotes on this post _don't create a lot of ill will_.

Comment: while I do think rebounding from certain offenses for new users is too harsh, very, very bad posts is not one of them.  They are presented with several pages of stuff when they sign up, then again when posting their first question.  When the result is "give me some code to...", then they deserve everything heaped upon them.  If they cant be bothered to read and/or comply with the rules for the community they are about to engage (potentially over and over), then we should not be bothered to show them tender mercy.

Comment: @Plutonix - I'm not saying that they don't very often deserve "constructive" criticism, but it's simply that they also need to be given some points for "effort" (even when that "effort" is less than stellar).  It's like a teacher that constantly criticizes a poor student -- the student is not likely to improve, and will come to quickly hate that classroom.

Comment: (FWIW, I fully expected this to be viciously downvoted, though I had hopes that might not be the case -- that some folks would actually consider the merits of what I'm saying.)

Comment: They ***already*** get forgiveness. No matter how egregious their start, their rep cannot drop below 1 and as soon as they start contributing good content the "vote the post not  the person" ethic kicks in.

Comment: _"but it's simply that they also need to be given some points for "effort"_ this sounds much like the giving of "participation" trophies in sports.

Comment: Disagree.  If they already demonstrated complete disregard for the rules and standards with a vague, no code, do-this-for-me, its urgent type post, something more than "constructive criticism" is in order.  Personally, I want a **You need more college** close reason.

Comment: For the most part, they're not "disregarding" the rules, they're just hopelessly overwhelmed and confused by them.

Comment: @HotLicks "hopelessly overwhelmed", I'd say it's more like they can't be bothered to RTFM. I'm sure they are a *few* people that fit into that category, but the vast majority I'd say are just too lazy.

Comment: (And I fully agree that many are over their heads and need to be told so.  For instance, anyone working in Objective-C needs to have a decent foundation in C and general programming principles.  But someone who comes in and asks a simple Java question, on the other hand, can be given a little more credit for simply trying and a little less harsh treatment for "stupidity".)

Comment: @Sam - So where is TFM, so I can read it?

Comment: @HotLicks If you can't be bothered to look for TFM, then [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). If you can, then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @HotLicks _"I had hopes that might not be the case -- that some folks would actually consider the merits of what I'm saying."_ The problem with hoping that is all the meta discussions going on anymore about treating the new users nicer. No one treated me "nicer" when I got here- I came in and asked a question and got an answer. The rules aren't overwhelming- Do your research, show some effort in that research, ask a clear question with a specific problem. That's not overwhelming- The only ones it should overwhelm are non-native English speakers.

Comment: Disregard vs overwhelmed may be tag dependent.  Yesterday morning there were 4 "format a date" questions; 2 NullReference questions, and 3 Convert this C# code to VB waiting.  The SE find-a-dupe thing isnt the greatest (google is much better), but they are told and encouraged to look for a dupe, they didnt and so **should** be slapped with a dead trout.  When they whine that they do not understand MSDN, they do not need more encouragement and hand holding.

Comment: @Sam - That's kind of a laugh.  A few bullet points.  Nothing really about how to ask a good question (eg, nothing about a minimal code example, with declarations, data, and complete error messages).  Many folks would read through those bullets and think they're asking a valid question -- like many things, you learn mainly through mistakes.

Comment: I tend to agree with you on a lot of this. It's incredibly frustrating for new users to be unable to gain rep because they're new and can't answer many "advanced" questions. So they answer bad questions, which leads to more bad questions being asked, and even then they're unlikely to get points cause there's plenty of high-rep speed-answerers who answer bad questions for internet points. And if they can't get points, they can't use a lot of features of the site (commenting) so that also contributes to them leaving bad answers because they can't ask for clarification on questions.

Comment: I think it would be good to make it a bit easier to gain rep in the beginning, maybe take away the "boosters" after a user gains enough rep to use all the basic functionality of the site.

Comment: Yes, in particular the prohibition against comments seems counter-productive.  Maybe only allow a comment every ten minutes, or limit the number in 24 hours.

Comment: Or we could just depend on comment flags... not sure if this happens already or not, but if someone kept leaving useless comments or somehow abusing the privilege, they could be banned after so many comment flags. I don't really anticipate allowing users to comment causing a ton of issues.

Comment: I gotta be honest, @HotLicks -- and no disrespect intended -- I'm surprised to see you proposing something like this. You're the most acerbic commenter on poorly-constructed questions that I know of.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - In part my concern is that the real losers will tend too hang around and make pests of themselves, whereas the relatively bright but inexperienced will be scared away.  (Or maybe I just want more newbies to beat up on.)

Comment: I'm with you on that one, @HotLicks, and it's something that Tim Post (SE manager in charge of stuff like this) is worried about too, and working on. You should see his recent posts on [Meta.SE] and chime in if you've got ideas.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I looked (briefly) and couldn't find any of Tim Post's posts on the topic.

Comment: There's these two, @HotLicks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230857/no-one-likes-quitting-cold-turkey/230899#230899, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234609/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-limiting-recidivists-to-post-one-question-per-wee/234610#234610, as well as the one I linked you below, and maybe there's some I'm thinking of that are actually on Meta.SO. I may also be reading your post in a broader context, and thinking of things as related that you don't.

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question, found this one first, and am glad I didn't ask it. I think that users with a reputation less than 100 should get no less than -5 votes on a question, and no less than -2 votes on an answer.

Comment: @... If rep cannot go below 1 then what's the point to down-vote?

Answer (score 15):

The thing is, most people who are brand-new to programming as a practice should probably not be asking questions on Stack Overflow. The kind of tutorial or mentoring help that they need just doesn't fit in to this format. It generates long comment threads and answers that are very, very specific to their exact code, because aside from the actual task-oriented problem they're having, almost without fail there's minor syntatical or practical errors that need to be cleaned up or explained. [Why is can i not use a conditional property where a string should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791240/why-is-can-i-not-use-a-conditional-property-where-a-string-should-be) is a recent stellar example of this phenomenon.

In many cases, they won't understand how to apply the proffered solutions (or existing solutions, when other questions with the same problem are pointed out). Two good examples of this:

- [Asker does not understand that e can take the computation code out of the method and reuse it elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771145/how-to-check-if-uitextfield-text-is-an-email).
- [Asker insists in a comment that the method, which was eventually accepted "requires a pre-made statement" -- not understanding that a *literal* string is not required, in other words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029165/how-do-i-replace-words-in-a-text-view-to-change-into-other-words-in-another-text?rq=1#comment37042035_24029369).

Again, this leads to messy back-and-forths, and leaves a document that is quite unlikely to  help, and maybe likely to confuse, the next person who comes across it. We're looking for the opposite: the clearest possible expression of a problem and its solution.

This is why we used to have the ["lacks minimal understanding"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back) close reason. Questions like these don't generate material that makes this site better.

The thing is, "newbies" aren't being judged directly for their experience level*; they're judged because the stuff they're producing isn't adding positively to the knowledge archive here. For those who can ask a reasonably direct, clear question, and can understand the answer: they're welcome whatever their experience level. But for the rest, **we don't really need "forgiveness" for them**; we need to respectfully tell them that this place is not going to help them **at the moment**, and to come back once they've done some reading and mastered some basics.

---

*By and large, in aggregate, as a rule, on average, etc. -- I'm sure there are some jerks on the site who like to "newb-hunt".

Comment: So, how do you "respectfully" tell them to go away?

Comment: I think the best way -- although I have no way to measure my success rate, really -- is to leave a comment pointing the way to more appropriate resources. You've probably seen my pasted "If you're new to programming, asking questions on SO is not the place you need to be..." comment here and there. rmaddy, also, seems to have a couple of similar links.

Comment: So, should there be a "NewbieStackOverflow"?

Comment: @HotLicks Generally what I've found most effective is to simply explain what is expected of them.  This means that they are faced with the decision between trying to meet these expectations that they can probably figure out that they aren't able to meet, or to wait until they're more capable and able to meet those criteria.  People can generally figure out on their own that they just might be in too deep without you actually needing to say, "GTFO" (politely or not).

Comment: @HotLicks Not really, no.  It's been proposed hundreds of times, and you can see many detailed explanations of the problems it creates.  As Josh mentioned, the questions simply aren't of value to the community, and they are *extremely* draining on the community to actually answer effectively.  The questions take a ton and giving almost nothing back.  It just doesn't scale and isn't well suited to the design of the site.  Period.  Moving them all to one separate place solves none of those problems.

Comment: Probably no, @HotLicks -- I think the platform, which is designed and tuned towards generating reusable nuggets of information, would not support it very well.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - The "reusable nuggets" thing rarely seems to be a criterion in up/down voting.  Some of the best broads dissertations on topics are the result of newbie questions.  Yes, some get voted up, but most get voted down.  The value of the question is not in the question -- if the OP knew the answer presumably he wouldn't ask.  The value of the question is in the breadth and quality of the answers.

Comment: @HotLicks That's at least true in large part, yes.  When referring to the quality of a question much of what that means is the liklihood that that question will attract quality answers.  When a question is really unclear it's very unlikely to attract quality answers.  When a question isn't appropriately scoped, or isn't on topic, or is just calling for opinions, etc. these are all types of questions that, over the site's history, have been shown to attract low quality answers, not high quality answers.

Answer (score 7):

Think of the newblets on this site as feral kittens that occasionally come to your premise. You want to adopt them and let them inside but at first they need to be house trained, because if you don't you would end up with shit all over your place. Not all kittens are okay with that, some run away. But there are food/answers they desperately need, so if they really would like to hang around, they will respect your rules ... after all you are the one feeding them.

Comment: You sound like my father.

Answer (score 2):

> Could there be some scheme whereby downvotes and other negative points somehow don't count

There already exists a mechanism for this: **post deletion**. Any reputation loss from downvotes will be reversed when a post is deleted (unless the post is older than 60 days?), though the downvotes will still count towards the post's net score, even on deleted posts.

Comment: Rep changes from deleted posts are only not reversed if the post is sufficiently old *and has a score greater than 3*.  Also, questions with multiple answers or an answer with a positive score can't be deleted.

Comment: @Servy can't be deleted by the OP at least. High-rep users can still vote to delete, of course.

Comment: Deleting a downvoted post actually hurts the user, in many cases.  I forget the exact scenario, but they're in a situation where they go into a penalty box and can't get out.

Comment: Yes, there is a post ban, @HotLicks; the rules for them [are being adjusted to try to better separate those who are genuinely confused from those who just don't care](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits).

Comment: ...and the deleted penalty box is one I think is too harsh.  I think even old deleted junk should age as some other things do on the assumption that the user learns over time.  If in reality, they do not and continue to post garbage, then the ban sets back in.  Too many first time posts cannot be salvaged and even if they could, if they have -3 or more votes, few are likely to revisit it to give an answer (assuming the user could/would wait for this process to play out).