# Can a very specialized question (regarding validity of code), be closed as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The title sounds a bit weird, I know. I came over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947179/base-class-is-undefined-error-c2504) asking about a primary trivially solvable error.

But the code shown obviously has more issues, and also serious design flaws, that will pop up after this trivial stuff is fixed.

Though this question is very specialized about the particular problems with the code (without stated by the OP explicitly), is it OK to vote for closing it as "too broad"?

<sub>**Note:** I don't care much about the accepted answer, since it's way off complete to explain all of the problems arising with the posted sample.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It's not too broad.

It is perfectly fine, even desired that an answer focuses explicitly on what the question is about.

And this question isn't about *"fix all my bugs"*.  It's about *"What is this error? and how do I fix it?"*

The accepted answer does exactly what an answer should do.  It informs the OP and future visitors what causes a *"Base class is undefined error"* and it explains how to solve the error.

The fact that it doesn't have extra information to distract you makes it do it's job even better.

the **Too Broad** close reason is defined by how difficult it would be to give a sufficient answer to the question.  Since there clearly exists a sufficient answer in the form of *explaining and fixing the error*, then the question is not too broad.

Comment: I'm not really bothering about the answer, it's perfectly OK. My concerns are about the question and the given sample code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the fact that you can give a sufficient, concise answer like the one was given means that the question isn't too broad

Comment: OK, I see and can agree so far. But I've often seen such ending up in a lengthy comment thread, where the OP asks for further fixes along the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are circumstances in which a reasonably specific question can be closed as *too broad*. The key is what does it **mean**  to provide an answer. An acceptability good answer must be understandable to the poster of the question.

If the text of the question suggests the asker has little or no understanding of the concepts necessary to  understand an accurate answer, a proper answer would have to try to explain all those concepts, which would make the answer too long. I've seen questions posted by novices where a good answer would have to explain what an *object* and a *class* was. We used to have a special close reason for these, *lacks minimal understanding*, which was (we are told) abused to brush off questions from novices that were otherwise good questions.

Although I am not saying that is the case for the question you link to.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back?rq=1