# What to do with question about nonexistent problem?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across the [question about time values differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544329/different-time-in-mongolab). But the problem OP describes doesn't really exist (these time values are the same, only expressed in different time zones). How to handle such kind of questions? Should I marked them as off-topic?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved." The OP doesn't see it is *not* a problem because of not having the required minimal understanding. (Related: [Can we please have the “Lacks Minimal Understanding” close reason back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back).) For now, I suggest "unclear what you are asking" (because the *reasoning* it is a problem is unclear).

Comment: +1 for "unclear" (hey, there's another use for these comments, Shog!) as right now there's no specific, clear question to be answered. Maybe the user does want to know how to convert the date back to the old timezone, or how to not convert it to UTC in the first place, or has any other specific issue - but currently there's just a misunderstanding and no on-topic question.