# Flagging questions

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Not that long ago, I remember there being an option to choose a flagging reason that was somewhere along the lines of "You need to have done research or know at least something about what you're asking." It was under, I think, the "It should be closed for another reason..." line of flags. I recently had a flagged declined for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840139/finding-the-sum-of-numbers-within-a-listbox-and-displaying-to-textbox). I had chosen the "Other" option, and left the notation that there was "Very little, if any, effort into the question." To me, it seemed as if he were writing the question, and didn't really care about giving any info, or even if he'd gotten an answer. So should I have flagged the question? If so, what option should I have chosen? None of the ones I had seen were, in my opinion, a solid choice for the flag. However, it was still a bad question, and needed attention brought to it.

Comment: The "other" reason goes to a diamond moderator, so no that wasn't the way I think. Usually I flag the "poorly researched" question with either "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking", depending on the case. If none apply... downvote

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back

Comment: @Patrice:  Please don't use flags for that.  Just downvote it.  The system has measures in place to remove the really bad stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The close reason that you are referring to that no longer exists was:

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

This is *not* saying that the question lacks sufficient effort from the author.  It's not saying that the question lacks research.  Rather what it's saying is that the answer to the question would be beyond the author's comprehension, so even if we took the time to answer it, they wouldn't understand that answer because it's asking about concepts that require a certain amount of background knowledge.  Explain enough of the background knowledge for the answer to be understood would end up making the question "too broad".

It was there to avoid problems like what is described in [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215722/186381)

Sadly, people didn't actually use that close reason for those types of questions.  They mistakenly assumed that the close reason was there for what you described, lack of effort, unresearched, etc.  They were closing questions with this reason purely for reasons that aren't described here.  It ended up being removed as a close reason because it was being abused so much.

If you feel that a question isn't well researched, or doesn't demonstrate at sufficient amount of effort in being formed, you should be downvoting it, not voting to close.  If, as a result of that lack of effort the question ends up meeting an actual close criteria (i.e. unclear) then close it for that reason, not because of the amount of effort shown.

Comment: You're right, Servy. I think this was just my wanting to be more important than I really and to feel like I actually had more of a hand in things than I did.

Comment: Excellent answer. Does "closing bad questions" come up very often in meta stackoverflow?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you flagged it as "Other" requesting a moderator to step in where the community cannot.  This is incorrect, you should use the standard closing votes/flags to close a question.  By using the canonical reasons, the question will go into the Close Review queue and other users in the community will take care of it.

Moderators should only be involved in things that the community can't handle - closing question is not one of them.

Your flag was rightfully declined by a moderator.

Comment: With that being said, what would be the best flag to raise for questions like this?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks It depends on the question. The one you flagged could have been closed as "unclear" or even "too broad". If a question doesn't fit in one of the canonical close reasons, then maybe it shouldn't be closed - downvote, comment, or move along. The mods have more important things to worry about, than closing questions.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks "Unclear what you're asking" or "Too broad" would be fine for something like that. Or off-topic "Should provide clear problem statement...blah blah"