# How to flag an obvious question?

Tags: discussion

Today I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833974/whats-the-usage-of-return-keyword about how does a return statement is working.

I don't know how to flag it. It's not Too broad, no really off-topic too because it's in my mind about Java. What do you think ? Should it only be downvoted ?

Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: That particular question mentioned is simply _"too broad"_, that's what I would use as close reason. I'm not aware if this is appearing as a flagging reason too.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think its too broad at all. I could write a one paragraph answer to that question *easily*. Its a perfectly answerable, terribly researched, question. It could easily be a duplicate of course.

Comment: Look at the currently most upvoted question in the Python tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At most, downvote it. We've never closed questions because they are simple or "obvious".

A downvote could easily be deserved for "lack of research/effort" on that question in particular.

jmac has an excellent in-depth explanation of this here: [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back/257979#257979)

Comment: A downvote would also be an indicator for a potential close voter reviewing that question.

Answer (score 6):

Obvious questions can be flagged as **dupe**, if you can find something that fits.

Sometimes they can be flagged as **too broad**, if explaining would take unbounded time.

Most of the time, though, **downvote** or **nothing**. "You sure don't know much"* is exactly the opposite of a close reason.

<sub>**Not that I'm saying that's your mindset. Contents may be exaggerated. Consult your doctor before reading.*</sub>