# Help me help Stack Overflow: what should a new user do when answering duplicate questions?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-answers, moderation, post-ban

I've found what appear to be
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46870965)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47020914)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53058559)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091670)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53098150)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099538)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677)
[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261574)
[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457205)
[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557902)
[11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435916)
[12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546694)
[13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54616940)
duplicate reports of a bug in our product. They have a variety of helpful and harmful answers.

I joined the site in order to engage on this topic, so I don't have enough reputation to mark them as duplicates, nor flag them as potential duplicates, nor even add comments to that effect. It seemed my only option was to post new answers.

I drafted an answer that should be helpful to anyone encountering this problem and began posting it to each duplicate question. (The 3-minute wait between answers was a big inconvenience here.) Then, with no warning and no recourse, I got the message: “We are no longer accepting answers from this account.” Also I found the answers I'd already taken all this time to post had been removed by [ChrisF](/users/59303/chrisf).

I'm about ready to give up trying to help here—any advice?

Comment: One thing I would suggest you to always do is to NOT go against the rules because you don't have enough reputation. If the questions are duplicate, but you can't flag as a dupe, don't just answer. The reality is that, even if you had the best intentions, what you did looks a LOT like what people who spam do

Comment: Thanks, @Patrice—that advice does sound a lot like “give up trying to help here”, sadly.

Comment: If that's how you want to see it, then see it this way, we can't change that. It's more "we're upholding our quality standard"... I am just telling you the proper way to help here. You didn't have the privilege to take the right action. You ended up taking the wrong one (even if you had the right intentions).

Comment: Also, I'm not aware of what rules I went against. As I wrote above, I made a good-faith effort to provide the most useful answer I know of yet. Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Dana - I understand where you were coming from, but to answer "what rules you went against"... You aren't supposed to copy paste content in multiple places; especially not by fighting the throttle, on day 1. Copy pasting an answer to multiple questions generally just results in one of the answers being removed, however, because of the other two issues, you ran into an anti spam prevention mechanism. So, that was what happened. At least your intentions were good, and I see your ban was lifted, so overall it turned out okay.

Comment: On the bright side, it looks like your answer has gotten upvoted enough to net you more than 50 reputation points, which gets you the privilege to comment everywhere and to flag posts and to upvote the better or more helpful questions and answers, so now your hands aren't so tied. Thank you again for bringing this to Meta so that things could get worked out, as by necessity, the site isn't built to allow brand new accounts to do what needed to be done, and by involving the people here, we got an overall good outcome.

Comment: _Why is that wrong_ this is straight from the [help on answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers): Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are: ... exact duplicates of other answers

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Please, don't give up trying to help or become a part of this community. I'm sure you feel intimidated or helpless as it may seem quite unwelcoming or all of your efforts have gone in vain. But, I can see this post alone has made a significant impact! I know I've received a ton of help from this site and am really grateful for it. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the responses and encouragement. @Tas, I notice the page you linked to is a little incoherent. “Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question […] includes […] exact duplicates of other answers”? Clearly, being a duplicate of another answer does *not* mean it doesn't fundamentally answer the question.

Comment: I agree @DanaDahlstrom, I think it probably should be reworded to explicitly say "it's never okay to copy the entirety of another answer" or something of the sorts, and instead teach new users what to do (ofc in this case, not much cause they can't vote or flag). As others say though, it's always a little sad when a new user is trying to do their best and well by the community, but then gets punished. I hope it's clear from all the support here that everyone appreciates the attempt and hopes you'll stick around!

Comment: Agree that page could probably use some cleanup. Feel free to suggest improvements: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Please%20separate%20descriptions%20of%20actions%20that%20constitute%20non-answers%20from%20those%20that%20detail%20other%20disallowed%20behaviors&tags=feature-request%20answers%20help-center

Answer (score 59):

First, thanks for stopping by! It's always great to see folks going out into the world to support their products. Extra thanks for coming *here*, to meta, to give folks a heads-up on what you're doing - otherwise we have to guess, and that tends to go badly.

Second, please read this: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) - it's a basic set of guidelines for handling product support here. Some of 'em won't apply to you, some of 'em might be useful, but hopefully *all* of them will give you a high-level idea of how we both benefit from and struggle with this sort of thing here.

### What to do next?

Let's start with [your first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091670/why-does-android-studio-3-2-1-fail-to-interpret-file-content-correctly-not-even/54044993#54044993): this references an answer on another question, which is helpful but kind of a long way to go. So I'll start by merging those two questions.

Then I'll close as many of the other questions you've identified as duplicates of the one you answered (which should now contain both answers, along with the top-voted answer by Asim - thus making it a pretty good "canonical" reference for the problem).

Then I'll see what I can do to get you unbanned.

### And in the future?

Ideally, just answer one question and flag the rest, either as duplicates or "in need of moderator attention" if you need to request that two or more questions be merged. Not only is this less work, it also ensures there aren't 9 different places to update if a different workaround emerges (or the bug gets fixed).

Comment: This is overall a good answer, but saying "ideally, just answer one question and flag the rest" sort of misses the fact that the OP specifically called out that as a newly registered user, they didn't have the reputation required to flag questions. I feel like OP has a really valid complaint about the fact that when your starting reputation means you can't flag, comment, or participate in Meta, your hands are really tied in terms of being able to participate in following the "rules of the road". The existence of really well prepared 1-rep users may sadly be an edge case, but it's a real one.

Comment: The questions weren't all posted overnight, @sam - it might take a bit of time to earn 15 rep necessary, but it's hardly an insurmountable barrier.

Comment: That's totally fair. I just think that this is a good example of a bit of a contradiction in onboarding, where while one one hand, the period when a user first joins is arguably most important time to help them learn the site's best practices, but on the other hand it's also a time where almost all of the tools required to be a good community member are unavailable to them. It just makes me a bit more sympathetic to how less savvy newcomers so frequently end up doing things that may defy common sense for more experienced users.

Answer (score 29):

First off, thank you for trying to help.

We understand that new users experience a fair bit of friction when trying to use Stack Overflow. That's because [our model is so much different](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) than the other sites people are familiar with. In particular, we have exceptionally high quality standards, we actively curate content (think Wikipedia, versus web forum), and we maintain a sharp delineation between questions and answers.

We've found, though, that maintaining these quality standards is what keeps experts around for the long haul (long after they would have abandoned other sites), and that, in turn, is what keeps everyone else coming back here for answers. In all, we believe it's worth it.

In your case, where you went wrong was not in answering a question, but rather in posting identical answers to a massive number of different questions. The rate-limiting you experienced should have been a clue. But okay, you didn't know. That's why we have moderators who work to clean up the site, in collaboration with regular community members.

In this case, a moderator got a flag about the duplicate answers. He did what we always do: deleted them and left a comment providing guidance. This is what he said:

> Please don't post duplicate answers or ones that just link to another answer on Stack Overflow. If the questions are the same answer one and flag the rest as duplicates.

So…please do that.

If two questions have identical answers, then there are *extremely* high odds that they are duplicates. It helps no one to have the answers spread out across multiple places. To deal with this, we have a system for dealing with duplicate questions, essentially directing everyone seeking an answer to a single, canonical question with the best answers. You post *one* answer there, on what you think is the best question, and then you flag the rest of them as duplicates. Moderators or community members can then mark those questions as duplicates. That's how you can best help us.

Of course, I kind of glossed over one teensy-weensy fact. And we moderators do tend to gloss over this very fact when we leave comments like Chris did, mostly because we forget. That fact is that brand-new users do not yet have sufficient reputation to flag posts. [Raising a flag requires a minimum reputation of 15](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (it [used to require 50](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334115/without-close-flag-privileges-how-do-i-bring-a-low-quality-question-to-the-comm), which was even worse). There are, of course, good reasons for this, namely that brand-new users aren't typically familiar enough with our content rules that they should be raising flags on other users' posts.

Your situation does seem like a bit of an edge case. You apparently have enough domain knowledge to know that those questions were duplicates, but you hadn't yet convinced Stack Overflow's reputation system that you could be trusted to make this call, so you couldn't raise a flag. Sorry. That sucks, and it's kind of broken. At the same time, allowing anyone to raise flags would probably raise the rate of false positives to such an extent that it would not be worth it.

The system is honestly designed with the assumption that 15 reputation points is an *extremely* low bar. The <strike>solution</strike> workaround here is to answer one or two other questions, earn the 20 reputation you need to get flagging privileges from two upvotes, and then raise duplicate flags.

Asking a question on Meta (as you've done here) is another possible workaround, but again, [participating in Meta requires 5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta), so you'd need to contribute something of value first, whether a question *or* an answer worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Thank you, earnestly, for the thoughtful and detailed reply. Still, *SIGH*. :-)

Comment: As an aside, Cody, I went through and did flag all of these, since the questions truly are dupes. Also left a comment on the main dupe target linking to the issue tracker where the work to fix that bug is being put. Hopefully that'll help others in that same boat :)

Comment: The user *did* have enough reputation to flag when I dealt with the duplicate answers, but clearly that came from one (or more) of the deleted answers so they lost that privilege.

Comment: @ChrisF, as I guess you can surmise, I didn't have enough reputation to flag when I resorted to posting duplicate answers.

Answer (score -8):

You probably want to choose **one** of the questions as the "canonical" question, answer it, and then close the rest as duplicates.

You could consider visiting the [Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room. This room is dedicated to special-case close votes: stuff like tags without a large audience, etc.

If you post in that chat room explaining exactly what you just explained, the users with higher rep can help you close the questions.

Comment: You need more rep to chat (20) than you do to flag (15), so this doesn't solve the chicken-and-egg problem, unfortunately.