# Closing Questions when the question only exists due to the OP not reading the manual

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

> Closing Questions when the question only exists due to the OP not reading the manual

Example: [PHP strcmp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51068899/php-strcmp-not-working)

Someone has posted a question on Stack Overflow stating that "strcmp is not working". The issue outlined is exactly as it should be and [the manual clearly states this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

However I can't find a suitable closure option for questions that arise due to the Asker simply not reading the manual of the language in question.

### Just a crap question?

The question is not poorly written, *per se*, and shows code samples, formatting and enough details for members to gather an *exact* understanding of the issue, but the issue comes about due entirely to the Asker not having read the Official documentation for the language and instead made assumptions about expected behaviour.

The question quoted above is entirely down to the OP expecting a `boolean` value and instead being given an `int`eger return value they are then trying to compare.

I see this fairly often and feel the question referenced above is symptomatic of the issue. I feel that [RTFM](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM) should be a closure option.

### Duplication?

No -- I did in the past reference the Stack Overflow Documentation for these questions but even then this was not a closure option. 
There are numerous reasons as to why these questions are not duplicates; because any programmer worth their salt will not ask the question and will simply realise the issue (and solution) by reading the manual.

### Nearest Closure choice

Current (in my view) nearest equivalent:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

### A (rough) suggestion for a new additional off-topic closure notice:

> **Off-topic because...**
>   This question can be easily resolved by reading the manual for this programming language.
>   This question appears to be a simple misunderstanding of the way this language operates. If the language manual and educational tools do not help to resolve this question please re-write the question to reflect this.

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257874/3536236) more clearly defines part of the issue; Stack Overflow is not *intended* for beginners but is used by **alot** of beginners...

Comment: Lack of effort is generally a downvote reason, not a close reason.  Users either learn quickly to do things like read the manual, or they lose their ability to ask more questions.

Comment: I believe that, were one such inclined, this would be a situation to explain to the op that the behaviour they are getting is really expected.

Comment: @fbueckert I query that it's a lack of direct effort, it's simply that they need to be told to Read The Fn Manual. Often with the questions they generally follow the "How to Ask a Good Question" process but for reasons beyond my comprehension they've not actually viewed the manual.

Comment: If they haven't read the manual, then they have not done enough research, you might argue. That's still only a downvote reason, but lack of research and lack of effort can very easily be one and the same. In these cases... I think they are.

Comment: I'd say the question shows a lack of effort.  Asker ran into an issue, tested a couple other cases, and rather than search for an explanation, instantly asked here instead.  We can't make users read.  We *can* take away their asking privileges if they abuse it enough.

Comment: @fbueckert "or they lose their ability to ask more questions" You'd like to think that, and it certainly happens in some cases, but between problems with the algorithm itself, and how easy it is to subvert it, this is an extremely poor solution to the problem, at least as the *only* solution to the problem.

Comment: @Servy I agree; there are often bad questions that I think are extremely poor and not worth keeping.  But since they are apparently on-topic, I take solace in my ability to downvote, and, hopefully, contribute to their future inability to pollute the site further.  I wish we had more ability to denote our disapproval of borderline questions, but I don't know of any solution we as users can enact.

Comment: @fbueckert There really isn't any other options.  That's precisely the problem.  It's an action that is widely stated as bad, in the help center, the site's mission, the FAQ, all over the place, but there is no (useful) recourse to deal with the problematic behavior.  It's behavior stated as being inappropriate, but with no (or at least wildly inadequate) actual enforcement options.

Comment: @Servy Well, considering that we apparently not being welcoming enough, I doubt any request to enforce that aspect is going to fall on deaf ears.  So if you want to propose something, I'll support it wholeheartedly.  In the meantime, I'll take solace in downvoting soon and easily.

Comment: @fbueckert SO has made it very clear, on the numerous occasions in which this (or similar enough proposals) have been suggested that they will never implement anything like this.  Given their behavior, I don't doubt those statements.  There was once a time where SO as an organization considered poorly researched questions to be a problem to try to solve.  That time has long since passed.  Now they're more concerned with preventing users from telling anyone whenever a poorly researched question is asked, because that makes people asking them feel bad.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I misspoke.  I meant that I expect such requests to fall on deaf ears.  Just one more nail in the coffin for those trying to enforce quality.

Comment: I close them as 'Unclear' [why the easily-available documentation is not sufficient to cover your problem] and [what logic you used to conclude that a well-tested and often-used library call is failing, rather than your use of it].

Comment: I mean, such questions are of next-to-no help to future SO users/visitors.  I can't see any reason to keep them open until it's explicitly stated that SO has to become a documentation lookup service:(

Answer (score 2):

*Lack of effort is not a closure reason.*

Period. I doubt it will be. There *was* a "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason, but it was heavily abused. This close reason would be, too.

Is the only problem with the question that they didn't read the manual? Downvote, go on! Lack of research and lack of effort are reasons to downvote, right enough.

Can you point them to the documentation and explain their answer in your own words? Heck, post an answer! It could easily be that they *can't* check the documentation for whatever various reason. You don't know, even if they really *should* outline that so they don't get responses saying to check the manual.

Reading the manual is not a requirement to post a question here. It is a requirement to write a *high quality* question, but if it was required for an *on topic* question... Well, we'd have a close reason for it already.

Comment: A long time ago, people abused the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason as a way to enforce this.

Comment: I wasn't about when we had that reason, so I could not for the life of me remember how it was abused, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> However I can't find a suitable closure option for questions that arise due to the Asker simply not reading the manual of the language in question.

If you can't find a suitable close reason, then it doesn't merit closure.

If you feel that the question is poor, then you can downvote it.  If you feel like it's one of those eyeroll painfully-obvious-but-no-one-on-Stack-has-asked-it-before questions, then you can let it survive as a potential canonical dupe target.