# We need a better solution than "unclear what you're asking"

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396742/need-some-algorithms-to-slove-this-issue) was "put on hold as unclear what you're asking"
with the usual boilerplate text:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help
>   clarifying this question. If this question can be reworded to fit the
>   rules in the help center, please edit the question.

This response is completely unhelpful in my opinion. The question is in fact quite clear and has enough details to highlight exactly what the OP needs. As it's currently written, it's *easy* to tell exactly what the OP is asking.

If I were the OP, I would have learned nothing about the original problem, and nothing about how to use this site well. (Yes, the OP *might* follow the "How to Ask" link, but it's more likely that they would assume they'd entered a Kafkaesque dystopia where questions are dismissed by a bureaucracy of insiders for arbitrary reasons which need not be explained.)

No criticism is intended of those who closed the question, but I have to ask, was the problem really that the question was unclear? Or was it that the OP was asking for help with homework, and/or that they hadn't apparently put in any effort?

And if those *are* the reasons, why aren't we more clearly communicating that?

Comment: To be fair, that should probably have been closed as Too Broad.  But considering the asker has made zero attempt to actually solve his problem, what's unclear is his solution.  He needs to provide that.

Comment: @fbueckert Good point. Shouldn't we have a means of _telling_ users that?

Comment: That's literally what the reason does.  We have to keep it generic so that it can be applied to more than just a single class of questions.

Comment: We used to have better and clearer close reasons. [They were removed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/) in favor of the current ones. TPTB subsequently [gave us specific guidance to use “unclear”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258062/2562182) where we used to use, for example,” “lacks minimal understanding”. I think that was a bit of a deliberate dodge, but it is what it is now. “Gimmethecodez” == “unclear what you’re asking”. But ultimately, it doesn’t matter, the user would never have gotten to use SO as a free code outsourcing service, close message aside.

Comment: I have to agree with @DanBron.

Comment: @DanBron, that looks like an answer to me

Comment: Opinions seem to be mixed. Some clearly feel that the question really did need editing for clarity, or that it needed to contain an explicitly worded question. Others, and probably the majority, are stating more or less explicitly that the question would have been disappeared anyway, so it doesn't matter what message or mechanism was chosen. Personally I think that downvoting might have been a better way.

Comment: It was downvoted, as it should.  Closure is specifically for questions we don't want answers to.  That's why they get closed.  I don't think that question was at all salvageable.

Comment: But it's completely unclear what they tried, what the result was, and why it didn't work to solve their problem.

Comment: @gnat You're really the _queen_ of finding possible duplicates all of my honors!

Comment: I do think there's still an issue—that there isn't always an obvious and clear answer provided to people whose questions we do not want to answer—but I suppose that there is no need for another discussion of the same topics that are covered elsewhere. So I'm okay with marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: @TimRandall _"Kafkaesque dystopia"_ That's a really creative view of matters here, LOL!

Comment: But downvoting this sends the message 'this is an acceptable question, just fix its quality'. Which is not the case here. Such a 'write my code for me' is off topic for Stack. Closing sends that message. Downvoting doesn't

Answer (score 16):

> The question is in fact quite clear and has enough details to highlight exactly what the OP needs. As it's currently written, it's easy to tell exactly what the OP is asking.

I find the accuracy of your statement dubious. In order to figure out what the question was asking for, I had to:

1. Completely ignore any text not in a code block. All of the written text is some combination of pointless noise, written in ALL CAPS, or confusing and misleading.
2. Relate the second code block to the "variables" in the first.
3. Realize that the OP is asking for a way to take the "variables" in the first, and figure out which ones sum together into 77.

I fail to see how one can consider this "easy to tell exactly what the OP is asking". Oh yes, you *can* do it. But I shouldn't have to do problem solving just to figure out what the OP is asking for.

Comment: This was a good criticism

Answer (score 9):

OK, lets have a look at that question:

> > I NEED SOME ALGO TO SLOVE THIS ISSUE I HAVE 12 VARIABLE FROM A TO L
> >
> > ```
> > [A=20] [B=18] [C=17] [D=16] [E=14] [F=13] [G=12] [H=11] [I=9] [J=9] [K=8] [L=7]   i want to find 6 variable equal 77 and other 6
> > ```
> >
> > variable equal 77 like this exepmle
> >
> > side1 >>A+E+F+J+G+I = side2 >>B+C+D+H+K+L=77
> >
> > ```
> > A+E+F+H+G+L = B+C+D+J+K+I=77    without repeat any variable in the other side
> > ```

First of all there's no question asked at all *"I NEED SOME ALGO ..."*
certainly doesn't count as a question.
Neither does *"i want to find 6 variable equal 77 and other 6"* so.

Thus closure as *unclear* (what the question actually is) looks fine for me.

A better close reason would have been *too broad* probably, but it doesn't matter much, since the OP didn't show any efforts what they tried themselves for solving the problem in the language ([c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)) they want to have a (ready made) solution.
That's not much better than asking *"Gimme teh codez plz!"*.

Not to mention that the yelling in their 1st paragraph is probably received unfriendly and overly demanding.

IMO, it's fine to see a VLQ question like that go away **as quickly as possible**, and closure for whatever reason is just fine.

Comment: So, is your answer that it isn't clear that they are asking for an algorithm?

Comment: @TimRandall There's no question at all :P

Comment: It’s maybe clear what they eventually want to happen, it’s not clear what they’re _asking_ in order to get there @TimRandall

Comment: @TimRandall Many questions have a much larger goal than what the person is asking. "I need some algorithm to solve x, I have tried y, but I am getting error z with that. Why does doing y cause z?" If a person with this issue just stops after saying the first part, and hasn't said what part they're struggling with, it's unclear what they are asking. Of course, if they are asking for the whole algorithm, then it's probably too broad anyways, so it gets closed either way.

Comment: *"it's fine to see a VLQ question like that go away as quickly as possible, and closure for whatever reason is just fine"*. Yikes. Closure for whatever **valid** reason is just fine, I hope ;)