# Display pending close-vote reasons to questioners even before closure

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, user-interface

I've tried searching for a duplicate since it seems likely that it is but have failed to track it down after reading 4 pages of question titles.

Can the system display the pending close-vote reasons to the questioner? Some of them are completely satisfactory as they stand and do not need a further comment to explain. Copying the content from the close-rationale page, but sending it only to the questioner, seems like something that the system could do to make it easier to handle these.

I was asking that the close-vote reason be automatically displayed, not that the reason be available with a click (which I knew was an option). At least on this close vote to this question on Meta, I needed to do a specific act to see the reason.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990635/error-while-loading-the-data-into-impala-table-using-implyr) is an example where I thought that the display of the close-vote reason was sufficient. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991300/mediate-command-in-loop-r-package-mediation) is a question with a close vote (not mine) for the same reason that could have benefited by a banner with that language. Admittedly, this might be improved by installation of the pending Question Wizard.

Turns out that the text I liked was submitted as an "answer" 4 years ago to: [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back?rq=1)

Comment: I believe they can see it..... at 150 rep (I think). I am 100% positive they CAN see it... just not 100% positive on the rep needed.

Comment: @Patrice: Can you vote to close this Q so I can experience it?

Comment: sure. I just cast a "POB" flag on this. You should see it under your question. "Close(1)". Then if you click on it, it should show you my vote casted already

Comment: @Patrice I think it's 250 rep...

Comment: Can you maybe be a little more detailed with your request? Would everyone see the whole text of the close reason? Where would it be? Would it only be the OP? In a message? In a box on the page?

Comment: Note that if a duplicate vote if cast on the Q, the OP does get a banner visible only to them pointing that out and an option to edit the question or accept the question as a duplicate (and effectively self-close). The other close reasons require refreshing the page and clicking "close" to check the counts... Did you have something in mind for the later something like the former?

Comment: @JonClements: I think I answered that with my edit. I'm hoping for a "head up" banner of some sort. I believe the is an expectation that a questioner will be monitoring the question. I'm better than average on explaining my closevote reasoning, and I know that the stock answer may not be enough but I also think that especially the offtopic-for-lack-of-[MCVE] reason has a pretty well written stock basis.

Comment: @42- what if there's more than one category of close vote?

Comment: I'd be happy with displaying all reasons or the first one or the last one, but think the big hurdle would be getting buy-in for any display.

Comment: Could not agree more. It seems with the current system, that everybody **but** the OP can see pending close vote reasons. If there **is** a way for the OP to see them, it is too obscure.

Comment: @JonClements IIRC, the banner asking if the dupe solves the problem also requires a refresh from the OP to see it.