# Close as dupe when there is no effort shown?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613700/how-can-i-save-boolean-in-shared-preferences) and I was about to lay down the gold dupehammer. However, [some lizard man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) closed it as ""Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")..." which I agree with but it is also a dupe.

Part of the reason Bill got to it before me was because I was trying to decide if it was worth searching for a target dupe (which wouldn't take long) since the OP didn't put forth any effort **at all**.

The question is, should we bother with finding the dupe for the user when they haven't even given it a try (the code or obviously searching). What good/bad would be done here.

### The good might be...

there is one more easily searchable question for people having an issue getting it to work. This "question" could then point them to an actual question with a good answer.

### The bad...

This would be encouraging a lack of effort in code and research.

Maybe the best thing to do for this question is to vote to delete it. But should we even bother with closing as a dupe in these cases when there can be several close reasons?

**Final thought**

The problem with someone like me closing as off-topic for that very valid reason is that it gives others the opportunity to leave "answers" to a non-question since my hammer doesn't reach that far. By closing as a dupe, I can stop any "answers" from coming in to this "question". If only my hammer had more power ;)

Comment: I hadn't considered your "final thought", for non-hammer wielding folk I'd have said just go for the easy close option, but if I was you I'd be slamming the dupe hammer to stop the answers.

Comment: The bad part, encouraging a bad behavior, is precisely what we shouldn't do.

Comment: Why not put as much effort into finding a dupe as they did into asking their question?

Comment: @tmyklebu that was my initial thought. However, since the site isn't just about helping the person asking the question, if we are too hasty about this then it may hurt the community and future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: @codeMagic: If the question's bunk, though, it's going to disappear soon and your effort is going to waste.

Comment: I just asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263021/how-about-being-able-to-mark-a-question-as-a-duplicate-of-more-than-one-question) to this today for the very same reason.

Comment: See this [closing as dupe has nothing to do with quality of answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263022/177800).

Comment: @JarrodRoberson but in this case, it *is* a dupe it just so happens that the question is so bad that it can also be closed for other reasons. But your argument is why I wish the gold hammer hand authority over other close reasons. But, I will be grateful for what I have and wait patiently :)

Comment: If you can close as a duplicate in one vote it's better than waiting for 4 other people to vote...

Comment: Snarky answer:  close as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132359/how-can-google-be-so-fast

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think it's best to close questions as duplicates whenever you can. I would have done that myself if I'd seen a high-quality question in the Related sidebar of the example question. Since the question itself was low-quality, I opted to just shut it down instead. A comment had already linked to the documentation, so the OP should be able to find a solution. The question will undoubtedly end up deleted soon regardless.

I think all of the good points that you mentioned in favor of closing as a duplicate outweigh the bad, but I just want to address this point directly:

> This would be encouraging a lack of effort in code and research.

Helping people find questions by closing as a duplicate does do that in a small way, but it also helps other people who *are* searching via Google to find solutions to their problems. If we link to canonical resources enough times, more people will be able to find them.

Comment: But, but... Jeff said that a bazillion of duplicates doesn't actually help :(.

Comment: @Braiam We can still delete the ones we find to be unhelpful. If a question uses *exactly* the same keywords as another, i.e., it should have turned up the original question in a search, we can just delete it.

Comment: This is a non-solution to a real problem.

Comment: @djechlin Offer an alternative solution.

Comment: Don't have one, it's a big problem. I downvoted this answer because it makes glib of the problem at hand. For comparison it's encouraged to downvote erroneous answers on SO even if you don't have a solution yourself.

Comment: @djechlin I'm not being glib in my answer. I don't care about downvotes, but if you're going to claim that this is a "non-solution" then you should be able to back that up with *something*. Just because you don't like a solution, doesn't mean it's not one. The question got closed, and it's now deleted.

Comment: "Helping people find questions by closing as a duplicate does do that in a small way, but it also helps other people who are searching via Google to find solutions to their problems. If we link to canonical resources enough times, more people will be able to find them." Also: most people who ask low-effort questions that are also common duplicates, are in a "fat tail" of users who will probably never ask another question (at least, not within a time span that they could reasonably retain the how-to-ask information).

Answer (score 9):

Just close as dupe, and downvote. If I understand the recent changes to the SO roomba, downvoted dupes will get deleted automatically, so it won't matter that it's also a bad question.

I don't think you should be concerned with the speed of closure you achieve via dupe vs. off topic; close for the appropriate reason.  If other people waste time answering a bad question, that's not your problem.  If SE wanted you to be able to quick-close as off topic, they'd have given you that power.

Comment: "downvoted dupes will get deleted automatically...", I hadn't realized that but it's good to know. I certainly close for the appropriate reason instead of quickly closing. The difference here is that there are multiple valid close reasons. "other people waste time answering a bad question, that's not your problem", not directly my problem but it effects the community negatively which is my concern with closing faster.

Comment: It doesn't really, though; if other people think it's a good question and want to answer it, it doesn't do much harm, and maybe you're wrong.  You're substituting your judgement for theirs, in assuming it must be a bad question and no other person might think otherwise.

Comment: In this case, I don't think there is any room for judgment. It is a bad "question" by SO standards not just mine. It encourages poor behavior, questions, and answers on the site

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no roomba changes that do that part. Downvoted, unanswered, dups have *always* been deleted by the 30 day script (it doesn't care if its a dup or not.. or even if its closed - just unanswered and negative score). Other roomba scripts tend to avoid dups (the 9 day script) or questions with comments (the 365 day script) - and those can cause some confusion about what the roomba does and does not delete. The suggestions about roomba chances are to be *more* aggressive about dups with answers, but to the best of my knowledge, this hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @MichaelT Ah, I misunderstood the post about that; I thought that was changes that were being implemented, not just suggestions.

Comment: If you *do* want to poke at those questions that are on the edge, [duplicate:yes answers:0 score:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+answers%3A0+score%3A0) shows the ones that can be deleted with a single down vote (the 365 script can't delete them because they have more than 1 comment).

Answer (score 6):

Fairly often, I am looking for a solution to some obscure problem, and I find two questions: A was posted first, and B was marked as a duplicate, but the answers on A are useless and the real solution is posted as an answer to question B. A question might be a duplicate, but that doesn't make it useless.

A question might be a duplicate, but that doesn't make it useless if it prompts good answers. the corollary to this of course, is that sometimes the answer I want is on question A but B is the first one I find, in which case it is very useful to have that "is duplicate" link. Ideally, there would be the duplicate link on B, and also a link in a commend on A going back to it.

Comment: In my experience that is more an exception to the rule though; 99/100 times I have to click through two-three layers of duplicate declarations before I get to the 'source' question where all the good answers are; in fact sometimes I make do with an answer in a dupe thread and later discover there was a much more complete one to be found through the duplicate of link. In that respect, I'd say there are too many duplicates left alive.

Comment: Actually, you are describing one of the reasons for marking duplicates, even though it did not work perfectly here: Get all the valuable information for one question concentrated in one spot linked to by all alternative formulations of the question instead of scattered all over SO, so it will be complete, up-to-date and thoroughly peer-reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

> Final thought
>
> The problem with someone like me closing as off-topic for that very
>   valid reason is that it gives others the opportunity to leave
>   "answers" to a non-question since my hammer doesn't reach that far. By
>   closing as a dupe, I can stop any "answers" from coming in to this
>   "question". If only my hammer had more power ;)

I think it's more appropriate that you propose something to fix the system, so that you can stop answers coming into the said low quality post. And discuss whether and when you should be given that option.

Closing something that you are not sure of being a duplicate as duplicate is simply wrong. It confuses new users, and is just doing wrong to them.

---

EDIT:

I heard that there was a close reason for lack of effort. Some even attributed the increasing down-vote rates to the removal of that close reason recently. There was another post [Provide "Not enough effort" as a new close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253889/provide-not-enough-effort-as-a-new-close-reason?rq=1). Either approach is better than "Close as dupe when there is no effort shown" or "to close questions as duplicates whenever you can" in bill's answer. It may be a compromise. But just looks wrong.

Comment: I would love to propose something to keep that from happening if I had a suggestion. ATM, my only suggestion is for the gold badge to cover more than just dupes. However, that has been proposed and isn't happening right now. I never suggested closing something for a reason I was unsure of. There certainly are dupes of that question. That was never the issue.