# How about being able to mark a question as a duplicate of more than one question

Tags: feature-request

#### Dead Horse

the *problem* with all the drive by / vampire questions has been beaten into the ground, but there is one trend I have noticed.

Since most of these questions are from first time users, which are overwhelming newbies to programming to begin with, the questions they ask when they do show a minimum of effort and some code are usually wrong in multiple ways that have been covered ad nauseum individually.

Mostly these are typos, or missing imports or "string" == "string" instead of "string".equals("string") type problems, and there are usually 3+ of these stupid mistakes in every one of these questions.

Right now you have a decision, mark a question as a duplicate based on the question to close it, which is usually **not** the actual problem or solution and then comment with a links to the actual solutions.

#### A better solution:

We should be able to select multiple *duplicates* to these questions, and close on all of them.

I close questions all the time as dupes with a question that only answers one of the many problems and others come behind and reopen them again.

I don't think we are making the site better by answering how to compare strings and other 101 type questions over and over, especially when the entire question is riddled with many of these same classifications of mistakes.

That is the **definition** of **too localized** and useless to the community at large.

Answer (score 4):

How about simply closing as "Unclear" or "Too Broad?"

> I close questions all the time as dupes with a question that only answers one of the many problems and others come behind and reopen them again.

They probably should not be doing that, unless the original question is not the same as the new one.

Questions are closed as duplicates because *the same question was already asked,* not because an answer to the duplicate question can be found there. Naturally, it's nice if there's a comprehensive answer on the original question that solves the problem, but that's not a requirement for closing as dupe.

If folks are reopening questions because the original question contains an incomplete answer, they're doing it wrong.  Questions should be closed as dupes because *the question was already asked.*

To be clear, *answers have nothing to do with closing as dupe,* other than we require the original to be answered in some way.  If you're looking at the content of the answers to determine whether or not to close as dupe, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: that needs 4 other people to make happen, and usually never does, close duplicate only takes one qualified person right now

Comment: on that note if closing as a dupe is *punitive* then that is just the way it is, if one of the half dozen dupes doesn't have a good answer, then too bad, this one won't do anything to help the situation.

Comment: Folks should not be using the mighty Mjölnir unless the question really is a dupe.  Abusing the hammer is the easiest way to get it taken away.

Answer (score -1):

The real question is: Is it making the site any worse?

By now, there are so many questions that you gotta use the search function to find what you are looking for. In what way do bad questions hamper the use of the site other than making people mad because their answer doesn't get accepted in the myriad of copy-pasted answers from the other pages with the same answer?

Does it really harm anything? Maybe with framework updates there will be a more effective, faster way to answer that same question eventually. Blocking or marking duplicates also stops people from entering an optimal answer if a better one exists which only serves to make the site stale. We need the repetitiveness to stay current.

Comment: it makes the site harder to use, because there is usually one or two questions that have an answer and sometimes hundreds of others that are dupes with no answers that aren't marked as dupes and you have to cull through them, **so why search for an answer when you can just ask blindly with no effort**

Comment: Never encountered what you are describing, perhaps I just got lucky. Example?

Comment: pretty much 95% of all the questions tagged `java` on a single day are these newbie multidupes.

Comment: Because of my hate for Java, I never went in there, but now I understand your concerns. However, for most of the other tags, it is not nearly as big an issue. In search, there are also advanced keywords though to help with the issue.

Comment: these people don't even search to begin with much less *advanced* search

Comment: Then the issue is, if you fix them, do you penalize someone else? In php tag for example, answers that were good 2-3 years ago are bad now and duplicates are a must to keep it fresh. The issue is even more present with JQuery.