# Should I hammer a question by using multiple different canonicals?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

(or, Should I kill one bird with two stones?)

Sometimes I come across questions like [How to compare an objects' private string member in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64791612), where the OP has multiple unrelated bugs in their code. There are a number of options when it comes to dealing with such posts. What I would like to do is close it as a duplicate of multiple canonical targets, one for each of the bugs, as done in this case.

One reason for wanting to do so is that the combined targets help the OP solve their problem. Of course, this can also be resolved by just adding both targets in a comment, so this is not a compelling reason. The major advantage is that as a gold tag-badge holder it allows me to single handedly close the question, removing the need for 2 other users to do so, while allowing me to use a valid closure reason that also helps the OP.

---

There are a number of other options:

1. **I can vote to close it as Too Broad.**

This is not ideal, since the question is not actually too broad in my opinion. Also, this still requires multiple other users to take actions. This concern applies to any potential close reason other than closing as a duplicate.

2. **I can close it as a duplicate of one of the targets, and edit the question to remove the other bug.**

This can be difficult to do in general, since the edits might require a lot of effort. Also, choosing which bug to edit out is non-obvious, although in this particular case given the title of the question, the division by zero is somewhat of a red herring, and would make a reasonable candidate. Most importantly, such an edit might change the intent of the OP's question, and I don't want to do that.

3. **Ask the OP to edit the question, and make 2 separate questions each with one bug.**

This is impractical, since the OP is unlikely to know how to go about breaking their question up like this. Presumably, this is part of the reason they asked the question in the first place. Also, it seems unfair to ask the OP to go to the effort of editing one question, and then posting another, simply so that both questions can promptly be closed as duplicates.

4. **Write an answer**

I'm not a fan of this personally, even though I do like earning reputation by answering questions. I don't feel that an answer to such a question would truly add value. I'm asserting this despite the fact that I'm still learning what is valuable to StackOverflow, as frequenters on Meta may be aware ;) Also, I think this encourages the wrong kinds of answers. We are not necessarily trying to spoon feed custom solutions to every question. Rather, we are trying to provide answers that are also useful to future visitors, while also helping the OP solve their problem. And this might also require a little effort on their part. A similar reasoning applies here, and the OP might need to read two targets to solve their problem. This is reasonable since they have two problems they need to solve.

5. **Do nothing.**

While the easiest option, the end result is most likely going to be that someone else answers the question. This of course has all the same problems as mentioned in the previous item.

---

I would like to point out that I wasn't aware that this was an option until very recently, when I [asked](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50906901#50906901) about it in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) (SO Close Vote Reviewers). I received confirmation from a user whose opinions I hold in high regard that this is indeed a reasonable thing to do. Many of the views that I have listed above are influenced heavily by discussions with this user.

On the other hand, I made an informal [request](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50970547#50970547) in SOCVR for a similar combination duplicate closure, and was met with vehement opposition from another user whose opinions I also hold in high regard.

If you follow the transcript, you can see that both these users have discussed this to some extent, along with several other members of SOCVR and myself, but no particular consensus has been arrived at. There are mixed feelings about this approach, with members falling on both sides of the argument. There are also varying views expressed by members that I have not mentioned in detail in the above list. I have tried to distill the conversations to cover the basic points as I see them, and to open up the discussion to the wider community.

So what do y'all think? Should I, and obviously other gold tag-badge holders close questions containing multiple independent bugs, with separate duplicate targets for each of the bugs?

---

Questions of a similar nature have been asked before e.g. [How about being able to mark a question as a duplicate of more than one question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263021). But in all cases that I could find, those questions and all answers to them predate the ability to do what I want, viz [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824). So I don't think this exact question has been asked before.

Since the post that I'm using as the example here is deleted, here is the full text of the question:

---

---

```
for (k = 0; k < 1; k++) 
   {
    retprice[k] = g1[k].getPrice();
    
    if (g1[k].getType() == "Action" || "action") 
    {
        retprice[k] -= ((10 / 100) * retprice[k]);
        cout << endl<<retprice[k];
        
    }
```

i have also a setter and getter like :

```
void videoGame::setPrice() {
double userPrice;
cin >> userPrice;
price = userPrice;
}

double videoGame::getPrice() {
return (price);
}
```

but when the user enters 100, it doesn't output 90, it outputs 100.

---

---

This was closed as a duplicate of two canonical targets.

- [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827)
- [Can you use 2 or more OR conditions in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781447)

Comment: While you say you'd like feedback, all your options have your own arguments against them, except for closing with duplicate targets (plural). So it seems that the post is looking for confirmation, more than feedback. I mean, it's not exactly objective.

Comment: @Scratte I'm not sure I follow. I've listed the objections that I have against the other options, and I haven't left out any objections to the option I like, that I'm aware of. The feedback that I expect is arguments for the other options, or arguments against the option I like. Or confirmation, if people agree.

Comment: I do 0 (as I have gold C#) also there is argument that such multi-duplicate closure can break auto-navigation to "correct" duplicate, but 4 seem to be mod-fave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889718/right-now-i-and-j-will-both-be-on-the-different-line-when-i-execute-it-how-can/64889861#64889861

Comment: You can also just downvote and move on.

Comment: I'd simply answer "yes" to the question but it'd probably be downvoted.  Closing to at least one canonical with comments pointing to any others seems obvious.

Comment: I don't see how spending the effort to identify, and link, multiple bugfixes is going to help future SO users, except maybe to demonstrate how little effort needs to be put in to learning/debugging/logging before dumping code onto other users, marks, drone-debuggers, whatever it might be thought we are:(

Comment: The question in question is deleted by now, a screenshot here might be useful. From the description I would say that the code example might not have been minimal. If you reduce the code to only show the problem you think you have you usually end up with a single problem or at least a single major problem.

Comment: @Trilarion [Here you go](https://cln.sh/c1nOmP).

Comment: I think there's a need to Answer some of these posts. Programming evolves. We can't just close everything as a duplicate to "How does reading a value work?", "How does changing a value work?" and "How does storing a value work?" and call that a good closure.

Comment: Meh..I looked at the question - close it somehow.  Whilst I agree that anyone can make a simple mistake like integer division, it's a massive debug fail to not spot it quickly.  Any professional/enthusiast dev would have split up the code, added temp vars, compiled with no optimization and debug, then cursed and fixed it when 10/100 came up as zero:(

Comment: I mean, what are we, biological remote-debuggers?  Why can so many users just fail heavily at trivial debug?

Comment: @MartinJames I've seen people ask questions like "I keep getting a syntax error. How do I fix it" and it's just mismatched brackets or similar. It's not even a debugging question, it's outsourcing the writing of correct code to SO. For some users, it seems to be a dump code -> get fixed code.

Comment: This question seems to have multiple issues. It's not clear why 90 is the expected output, the code example could probably be minimized further to give output 90 and there is in general not very much context. It's just a "debug this piece of code for me" question. For the problem here it might not be a good example. For duplicate closing (if no other closing reason applies), I would just pick the most important error here and close as duplicate of that.

Comment: @Trilarion they will try to fix their code according to the dupe and successful or not, they will post another question with different, non-working code for the next iteration of drone debug:(

Comment: My guess is that the question poster did not even author the posted code.  They just want it all fixed by others, (those who can actually 'program computers'), so that they can get paid:(

Comment: Close as no [mre]. Minimal implies working code extended minimally by bad code. Explanation needs to say what they expect & why. Handles all under-debugged questions & debugging a non-debugged question just promotes poor questions & ignorance of debugging. I realize that takes longer to close though. So an alternative is, any problem you see. If they dispute the closure they have to say why. That requires a MRE.

Comment: Just answering the title: yes. This is one of the reasons Shog explicitly listed for why that feature was added in the first place (a two-part question easily answerable by two existing canonical duplicates).

Comment: @TylerH Shog isn't' infallible you know? In fact, Shog has retracted of many ideas, the most recent: triage queue.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, he has retracted a couple ideas out of the thousand(s) he has contributed to how the site should run. This isn't really the same scenario though; he is simply explaining the reasoning behind why a feature was added. That's objective, like an author's explanation of why a feature exists or doesn't in a language/library.

Answer (score 34):

We (caring content curators) must not throw our hands up and move on when something is "too messy" to handle by simple methods.  So definitely don't "Do nothing".

Asking the OP to split the problems into separate questions may in some cases be too herculean a task for some OP's -- so this isn't something that you can rely upon consistently.

1. If you have a hammer, then **Hammer the question closed, then add the necessary extra duplicates to the list.**
2. If you don't have a hammer or don't have the ability to add to the duplicate list, **Vote to close with any one of the appropriate duplicates, then comment the remaining duplicates.** Other users with dupe list altering powers can transfer your comments if there is something to gain from doing so.

This is a win for all parties.

1. The OP receives an informative resolution.
2. Stack Overflow does not unnecessarily suffer from redundant content.
3. Past volunteers who answered the older question(s) may potentially earn upvotes from the renewed attention.
4. Current volunteers do not waste their time answering a question that may be trashed in the near future due to the page's redundancy.

By answering the question, it is more likely that the system will deem the question to be "well-received". We don't want askers circumventing our dupe closure justifications by packing multiple isolated problems/questions into one question.  Yes, Too Broad / Needs More Focus might be a legitimate close reason in certain cases, but this closure is one of the least helpful ways that we can respond to OP.

Also, by my personal up/down voting criteria, asking a Needs More Focus question does not guarantee that the question is downvote-worthy.

My overarching goal is to resolve new questions by honoring pre-existing content first, then only answering if Stack Overflow doesn't have a suitable answer in its stockpile.

Comment: "*Yes, Too Broad / Needs More Focus might be a legitimate close reason in certain cases, but this closure is one of the least helpful ways that we can respond to OP.*" Very good point, and very much worth keeping in mind.

Comment: "add the necessary extra duplicates to the list" is [the worst idea you could have](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402468/off-my-chest-the-ability-to-edit-the-dupe-list-is-a-godsend-whereas-adding-mul). Close with a **single** target related to the question stated **in the title**. Think of the people coming from the google search.

Comment: The title may also ask multiple questions--making a single dupe inappropriate.  If you have a good set of principles that you would like to put forward, please do so with a new answer.  Answers can be upvoted and downvoted.  Comments can only be upvoted, so you will have no way of knowing how many people disagree with you and you will have a false sense of support for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

One concern I have with the 'combination duplicate' approach is the "or more" part of your question title. At what point should the Gold Hammer no longer be used? Three different duplicates? Or four? Surely, at some point, this *must* be considered either "too broad" or else worthy of a (short) answer, which could itemize the individual points, briefly explain them, and add links to the relevant duplicates in each case.

As was discussed in the SOCVR conversation you link to, the decision between answering and closing should depend on the quality of the question. It may be the case that the OP didn't realize that there are multiple issues (it happens: one line of code can have more than one error, as I'm sure we all know); in such a case, I think answering is appropriate.

However, if the asker *quite obviously* realizes they are asking about multiple issues, then closing would be the correct action IMHO. In this case, a comment clarifying that each point is a duplicate in itself would be appropriate, in order to save the poster the 'stress' of writing two (or more) new questions, only to have them quickly closed.

Comment: "At what point should the Gold Hammer no longer be used?" That's why before adding the multiple duplicate targets I preferred to expand the hammer to more close reasons instead, [as the original feature request was worded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/213575).

Comment: @Braiam But the argument still applies, even without the Gold Hammer: The question is about whether or not to close as a duplicate. Perhaps I concentrated too much on the hammering aspect.

Comment: You can only use the multiple target if you are a gold badger, and the only reason why that feature was tied to it was because you can unilaterally close it. Those are inextricably intertwined and can't be separated. If you have the privilege to change/add the targets, you should also have the privilege to close it.

Comment: The title originally only said 2, not "or more" ;) but you're right, I'm asking about that as well. My take on it is that the *number* of targets is not the metric to use. Rather, it's whether each of the targets can be used *independently* to solve the bugs one by one. If the OP's errors are intertwined, then I don't think this approach is appropriate. And my question is actually only about hammers. I think judgement calls like this generally *require* an SME to decide whether the errors are independent. I don't think other users should be making these sorts of calls.

Comment: For what it's worth, In my experience code with more than 2 bugs is almost always not fixable by fixing the bugs independently, in which case there are no suitable canonicals anyway, and the question may be Too Broad, or answerable. And the *number* is relevant at some point; if a question just lists half a dozen errors that *are* solvable independently, then Too Broad *is* an appropriate reason, and I don’t particularly mind VTC’ing it as such, even though it will require 2 other users to VTC as well.

Answer (score 4):

Hammer it with a **single** target related to the question *stated in the title*. Add other helpful links in the comments section.

I suppose that a question "How to compare an objects' private string member in C++?" has a certain answer, or at least an explanation why it's a wrong question to ask. Go for it, mark it a duplicate for such an answer/explanation. Anything written in the question body is a different story. Completely different.

I find it somewhat inexplicable that although using of Google search is universally encouraged, the experience for people using Google search at the same time is consistently and systematically ruined on Stack Overflow, in favor of satisfying too localized piecemeal needs of the opening poster.

I [wrote about this problem recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402468/off-my-chest-the-ability-to-edit-the-dupe-list-is-a-godsend-whereas-adding-mul) but, as usual, failed to explain it properly. But I'll try it again.

For some reason, when question is considered, only the opening poster is taken into account, but hundreds of possible other visitors are always ignored. Not once I've seen a popular question with the answer that explains in a great detail a *completely unrelated problem*. The same applies to closures. The question gets closed with a link that would help the OP who phrased their question incorrectly, but would be completely misleading for someone whose problem is actually described in the title.

*I find it hard to wrap my head about the fact that everyone is taking Stack Overflow as sort of a private chat with the OP, not the publicly open site that's intended, in theory, to provide the information for the large audience.*

Remember, Google judges a question by the title. Hence, either edit the title (which is often a mission impossible, as a honest edit would be "this is an off topic question" for which you'll just be given a thick ear by the mods) or at least make your answer/dupe target *relevant to the question phrased* so the other visitor with a similar problem could find a reliable information.

As of the particular OP, there is a comments section. Feel free to fill the OP with any useful information you find suitable, *just in the comments.*

Comment: This, so much this!  Goes to the heart of the (at least original) purpose of SO, ie to primary benefit future readers

Comment: If the OP phrase their title incorrectly so that it's actually not related their problem (and wouldn't be solved by the canonical answer), then by all means go edit the title. It should not be off-topic if there's a canonical for it. However, I think this meta thread is actually about too-broad questions with multiple problems, and I don't think there's anything wrong with putting all solutions in the duplicate list. Sure, the one that corresponds to the titular question should go first.

Comment: @Bergi just curious what's wrong about adding other links in the comments?

Comment: More effort (to get the link texts right), less visibility, and no clear preference for a single question to use as the duplicate if it's really a broad question with equally relevant problems. Of course, if the question and its title are properly focused on a particular problem and there just are some additional minor mistakes in the code, I'd use a single canonical and mention the small problems in a comment as well, possibly with extra explanation. In short, I try to be more helpful on well-written questions, while I just hammer badly researched ones that will eventually get deleted anyway.

Comment: I see. So the same notion, the OP is the King. An eternal contrariety that isn't likely going to be ever resolved.

Comment: The problem is that in most cases, "the question in the title" is still fundamentally multi-part. Typically it can be thus *even without using "and" etc.* Tasks that are easy to describe can nonetheless straightforwardly break down into following or composing a series of steps, each of which is a fundamental technique, in exactly one way.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel make it a single-part then, problem solved.

Comment: Well, no; my argument is that there is not always an obvious way to do that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel then Stack Overflow is not interested in this kind of question at all.

Answer (score 1):

> This is not ideal, since the question is not actually too broad in my opinion

But that's one of the things that too broad is [by definition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291819/213575), whenever the asker intended to do that or not. If you can extract two separate questions without adding details to the question asked then it's too broad.

Duplicate here makes absolutely no sense. Because! which target should the future reader look for? Canonical questions exist as a one stop shop for that particular issue or question, if I have to go back and forward between questions... what difference there is between Q&A and the old forums? Instead of all the information spread between different posts, it's between different questions that the reader has to navigate them all to solve their issue. [That](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA088.jpg) is not a useful signpost by any metric.

The best behavior is to make sure askers understand that they must focus on one issue at a time and use their own squeaky rubber duck instead of trying to use ours.

Comment: This argument obviously can be constructed for using unclear too: it's unclear which issue you are trying to fix.

Comment: I'm not following your argument on why "duplicate here makes absolutely no sense". Looking through two *clear* targets for the issue still seems like much, much less work than sifting through even just one forum thread, least of all several. Perhaps their rubber duck even learns to squeak along the way...

Comment: The thing is that every single Question can ultimately be linked to how does reading a value, changing the value, and storing a value work, because that's really all that programming is about.

Comment: @Scratte Too generic duplicate targets are a different problem (if they are one).

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, but I'm worried that's where we could be headed if this Question is used as an argument for multiple duplicate closures. As in "All you have to do is mix and match the Answers from the list of these posts: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Think from the point of view of a reader that lands on the question: which of the two linked question should it follow?

Comment: @Braiam Well, all the links for which the tiny box says 'This question already has answers here:'. I am really not seeing the problem with visiting two links.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's what made forums of old so terrible. If you can't see a problem with that, then no argument would convince you otherwise. I personally, if I want to "buy a orange" I expect that the question I land tells me how, not a laundry list from "buy land" until "pick oranges".

Comment: @Braiam But this is not about people asking to "buy an orange". This is about people asking to "buy an orange and an apple". This seems like a long, long slippery slope to *"buy land" until "pick orange"*, and certainly more helpful than "your request to buy an orange and an apple lacks focus".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi But questions really should deal only with a single problem. If lacks focus is not well worded we can still link to helpful questions. I don't see a need for ever linking to more than a single duplicate question. If nobody asked about buying oranges before and buying oranges is a useful programming task, then that's a fine question. In a more abstract sense the question is maybe how large the distance between a question and it's duplicate target should maximally be. See the potential problem with too generic duplicate targets.

Comment: @Trilarion It seems we are talking about different topics. As far as I can tell, the question is about (unknowingly) asking *two* distinct things at once, for which thus two distinct duplicates apply. Whether *one* thing is worth asking, and whether dup'ing it as that *other* thing is appropriate, seems like a different question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "whenever the asker intended to do that or not" is too broad.

Comment: @Braiam So it is "the question is too broad, full stop" then? That I could get behind much better than "Duplicate here makes absolutely no sense.".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi peeking order: unclear, off topic, unclear, opinion based, too broad, answer/duplicate. :)

Comment: Not all questions are valuable.  A debugging question with multiple separate bugs rarely has future value, so just close it as a duplicate of all that apply.  Your argument seems to be based on the fact that this doesn't help future readers, but so what?  Are you arguing that we shouldn't help the asker of such a question at all, e.g. by closing as too broad, or as just the duplicate that best matches the title?  Ok maybe so, but I don't think the signpost argument is convincing.  Some duplicates are just bad or mediocre.

Comment: Linking the right duplicates will save other readers time if they would have commented or whatever to point out the other bugs, if the dup-hammer wielder left them unmentioned.

Comment: @PeterCordes if it's not valuable, why close it as duplicate instead of putting it in the path to deletion? The path to deletion is closing as non-duplicate as my answer argues. Also, you seem to believe that it's a useful signpost, which is it? It's valuable as signpost or not?

Comment: Does a downvoted duplicate not eventually get deleted?  I hadn't realized the long-term downside to closing as duplicate, especially without downvotes.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, but how many of them already have posted an answer which makes them ineligible? Also is the difference between 9 days and 30 days.

Comment: Then closing ASAP is worth it, *if* there aren't any answers yet.  Duphammer is a good way to make that happen.

Comment: @PeterCordes Using dupehammer to close a bad question quickly is abuse of that privilege. It's also harmful to people who might have one of the problems listed in that question, but the dupe it's linked to isn't about that problem. It doesn't matter how much the question deserves to die in a fire - if it's not a duplicate of a single other question, *you should not be dupehammering it closed*. It's called dupehammer, not arbitrary-close-hammer, for a reason.

Comment: @IanKemp: Obviously you have to find a duplicate that applies, not just any arbitrary question!  IMO a really low quality question lowers the standards *some* for how exactly it has to match, but if a reasonable person can understand the answer(s) to the problem(s) from the duplicate(s), and it's not just buried somewhere in the middle of a huge answer, that's sufficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes But the point is that there is **no single duplicate** that matches the question. Because the question **needs more focus**.

Comment: @IanKemp: The ability to edit in multiple duplicates makes it possible to close-as-duplicate even when we need a couple duplicates, especially when the 2 problems are orthogonal / separable, and just happen to occur together.  I see the argument you're making, and yes it's a judgement call when the questions are so basic that an interaction of problems doesn't deserve its own answer.  But if you agree the question should be closed, I'm fine with closing as duplicate even if you're not.  It doesn't sound like I'm going to convince you otherwise, but so be it.